# All Your Base Are Belong To Us (Restricted)

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity, restricted-source

Input must not be required, and output must read "`All your base are belong to us`".

Restrictions

- No external resources.

  Plus a minimum of two of the following:
- You cannot use "a", "b", "t", "u", or "y" in any case in your code (bonus -10 to your golf score if you can do this)
- You cannot use "l", "o", "s", "e", or "r" in any case in your code (bonus -20 to your golf score if you can do this)
- You cannot use "n", "g", "0", "1", or "2" in any case in your code (bonus -30 to your golf score if you can do this)

So for example, if you manage to get the code done with 40 characters and use rules 1 and 2, your golf score is 40 - 10 - 20 = 10 chars.

Smallest code golf score wins... Good luck!

Comment: So much as declaring a `string` breaks all three restrictions, and `char`, `var` and `Write` break two of them each.  This is going to be tough to get valid answers, bar maybe Barinfuck.

Comment: Very difficult in python. `print` breaks all three. Maybe with some creative `eval`, but then you have to meet 1 and 3.

Comment: Ok, I'm convinced a Python entry is impossible.

Comment: "no input **required**". Doesn't that mean that I could, for example, do something like `print(input())` (python)? The user would be required to input the correct string, but that isn't forbidden.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a Python entry is possible with `exec` and clever use of hex escapes.

Comment: As far as I can figure out an entry in C would only be able to output with `putc` since it only violates one of the rules, all other output functions I can imagine right now violate two of the rules. But. `putc` will have to have `stderr` or `stdout` as the second argument violating two rules anyway. Correct me if I missed some way to output or acquire stdout (write, printf, putchar, send (if it worked at all which it probably doesn't), fdopen).

Comment: @user2357112 hard to avoid 0, 1, and 2 with hex escapes, and `exec` contains the `e` already.

Comment: @Art I don't have a computer nearby atm, but I believe stdin/out/err have values 0, 1, 2 respectively, so you can simply hardcode them.

Comment: @Art C is out anyway since you need `main`.

Comment: @quasimodo Doh. Of course, that's even more obvious. No point to research esoteric I/O functions when the entry point itself is impossible to write.

Comment: Looks like `POGAACK` is out of the question...

Comment: @gerrit: You can get them into a hex escape with backticks around arithmetic. It just requires another layer of `exec`.

Comment: @user2357112 backticks are an unconditional SyntaxError in Python3.  They're deprecated (but valid) in Python2.

Comment: I think any input used should be subject to the same rules, and count as characters in the score.  It doesn't look like some answers are doing that.

Comment: @Quincunx I wouldn't accept such a solution, as the _code_ is not guaranteed to output a correct solution. Also, `stdin` is arguably an "external source".

Comment: @PranavHosangadi There is a deleted answer to this question with a score of -6 which is essentially the same as that. It's been done before a number of times in various questions and is explicitly disallowed in the [tag:code-golf] tag.

Comment: According to code-golf standard rules answers in latin1/unicode/name you charmap is rated in bytes after conversion to utf-8. Are we to count like that or have you chosen a different score method? Current leader would then be at 0 instead of -40.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Technically anyone can "create" a custom language that takes a single command, arbitrarily called `z` or something, and the result is the desired output... We don't do that sort of thing here...

Comment: If I can't use `l`, `o`, `s`, `e`, and `r`, can i use `w`, `i`, `n`, `n`, `e`, and `r`? ;)

Comment: @Makonede, you could, but you wouldn't be able to apply the -20 and -30 bonuses... ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 15 - 60 = -45

```
šz█P'zUS½█│β3‘⁾
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUwMTYxeiV1MjU4OFAlMjd6VVMlQkQldTI1ODgldTI1MDIldTAzQjIzJXUyMDE4JXUyMDdF)

`šz█P'zUS½█│β3‘` is a compressed string of `all your base are belong to us`, but because that exact string compressed contained `0`, it's split into 3 parts: `all your base are`,  , `belong to us` (which cost one byte but gave a -30 byte bonus). The first and last strings are compressed with SOGLs English dictionary, and implicitly joined with spaces. The remaining `⁾` is a simple sentence case built-in.
Note that SOGL postdates this challenge, but that's allowed now.

Comment: I just have to ask... How??? Are we dealing with some clever compression technique here? I know nothing about SOGL...

Answer (score 46):

## GolfScript, -22 (38 characters, -60 bonus)

```
"„¯¯c¼²¸µc¥¤¶¨c¤µ¨c¥¨¯²±ªc·²c¸¶"{67-}%
```

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: ooooooo, shifty

Comment: @RyanCarlson Magic.

Comment: `"..."` defines a string and the block `{}%` performs a mapping operation over all characters. Inside the block the ascii value is available on the stack and `67-` subtracts 67 from each ascii value.

Comment: Isn't superscript 2 just a different case of 2? In which case, you haven't met rule 3 and your bonus is only -30.

Comment: @FizzBuzz Numbers don't have case.

Comment: OK, case is probably the wrong word to use, but you know what I mean. I'm pretty sure superscript 2 is still a 2, so Rule 3 hasn't been met.

Comment: @FizzBuzz I know what you're trying to say, but I think what matters is that 2 and ² are different glyphs with distinct codepoints. You can make the argument that, in a denotational sense, they are the same symbol, but I think that's a far more abstract interpretation than the question merits.

Comment: @FizzBuzz Strike that—I just noticed that someone is being stomped in the comments for Kendall Frey's answer for suggesting that character refers to glyphs/codepoint. Apparently it means whatever interpretation is most convenient for any given answer.

Comment: @FizzBuzz superscript 2 doesn't behave like 2 in maths. It is shorthand for the power of two. Much the same way as I would consider `&` valid in a question which doesn't allow `and` as far as a computer is concerned these are two different entities. In this case though I think the community has to decide as this is total opinion.

Comment: Font doesn't `$%@#`ing matter.  Does the source contain the byte?  No?  `!` off.

Comment: @FizzBuzz, I'm siding with @Howard and @JordanGray `²` is deemed as a separate character to `2`. They have different Unicode signatures, in the same sense that `A` is not the same as `Å` or `Ã`

Answer (score 36):

## [Sclipting](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Sclipting), −40

```
뀖롬긇땯덗긠눦굳뉒걡댦넠눦녬닶멧긇끯긇녳
```

- = 20 characters − 60 bonus
- Only works if the input is empty, which I take to be the case; if not, add `丟` in front, changing the score to −39.
- If I can assume the input to be what I want (as [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19222/668) apparently does), then the empty program is a solution and my score is −60.

Comment: Well, `"input is not required"` as I said, so I'd throw the 丟 in front and alter the score to -39, but great effort! Especially considering you invented the language, dude!

Comment: As a Korean seeing Korean syllables in code is amazing.

Answer (score 31):

### Brainfuck, 267 - 60 = 207

```
++++++++[>++++++++<-]>+.<+++++++[>++++++<-]>+..>>++++++[<+++++>-]<++.<+++++++++
++++.----------.++++++.---.>.<<++++[>----<-]>.-.<+++[>++++++<-]>.--------------
.>.<----.<++++[>++++<-]>+.-------------.>.<---.+++.+++++++.+++.-.-------.>.<+++
++++++++++.-----.>.<++++++.--.
```

Comment: Can that be reduced any further, I wonder? :)

Comment: [fbonetti](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19415/4934) did better in his Brainfuck answer.

Comment: And [FIQ](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19683/980) did even better 4 days later

Answer (score 29):

### JavaScript - 140 bytes - 60 bonus = 80 points

```
(x="Ǎľľ y̌ǒǔř b̌ǎšě ǎřě b̌ěľǒňǧ ťǒ ǔš")[x[3*9]+x[34]+"p"+x[4]+x[5*5]+"c"+x[34]]("̌","",x[6*7])
```

Run in Firefox.

I know what you're thinking. No, those aren't the characters that are listed in the question. Those are characters with a caron, or háček (picked randomly from a list of diacritics). Even though they're combining marks, they aren't two separate characters.

Comment: Node.js REPL: `String.fromCharCode(65,108,108,32,121,111,117,114,32,98,97,115,101,32,97,114,101,32,98,101,108,111,110,103,32,116,111,32,117,115);`

Answer (score 28):

### APL (43 - 30 - 20 = -7)

```
⎕AV['⊥┤┤ ø┼&┐ `∣┘û ∣┐û `û┤┼─ù ´┼ &┘'⍳⍨⌽⎕AV]
```

This satisfies rules 2 and 3.

Comment: This is going to be hard to beat!

Comment: does this return the result or print it?

Comment: @AaronDavies: both, the result is automatically printed

Comment: @marinus I tried this in http://TryAPL.com and got an `INVALID TOKEN` error.... perhaps from the initial and tailing character before AV... Is there any other place I can test this...?

Comment: @WallyWest: use Dyalog APL (http://www.dyalog.com). Get the unregistered version, it's free. TryAPL is so limited it's nearly useless.

Answer (score 22):

## HTML/CSS 70

```
<p style="transform:rotate(.5turn)">sn oʇ ƃuoləq əɹɐ əsɐq ɹnoʎ llɐ</p>
```

http://jsbin.com/EjekuvuF/1/

I thought I was being clever with the upside down type but then realized I couldn't meet any of the ancillary rules with the actual HTML/CSS. Oh well.

UPDATE:

User Flame suggested a more cross-browser compliant solution:

```
<p style="transform:rotate(180deg)">sn oʇ ƃuoləq əɹɐ əsɐq ɹnoʎ llɐ</p>
```

http://jsbin.com/EjekuvuF/6

Comment: I guess you can use XML character references to salvage the situation.

Comment: I like the idea behind the solution though.

Comment: I'll give props to it too... thought for some reason `transform:rotate(.5turn)` resolves to a Syntax error... I like the imagination put into this...

Comment: @WallyWest I didn't test in all browsers. I bet that might be browser-specific rather than the official W3C syntax. (Does work in Chrome, though)

Comment: You should use ∀ instead of ɐ :)

Answer (score 12):

### MATLAB, All bonuses: Score of -20 (40-60)

```
['' '¤ÏÏèÜÒØÕèÅÄÖÈèÄÕÈèÅÈÏÒÑÊè×ÒèØÖ'-99]
```

#### EDIT:

Note that I am not sure of what the system requirements are to run this, tested on windows. For those struggeling to copy, a similar code can be generated like so:

```
char('All your base are belong to us' + 99)
```

---

If it would have been allowed to ask anything as input, a solution with less characters (but also missing the bonus) would of course be possible.

```
input('')
```

Comment: Please explain how you plan to output *anything* using only `input`. The second answer is (afaik) just not true.

Comment: @Jhawins: MATLAB outputs the result of each expression that doesn't end in a semicolon.  The `input('')` call doesn't end in a semicolon, hence it will generate output.

Comment: If that's correct, then my JS answer is "`prompt()`"

Comment: And shell would be `dd`, but perhaps that counts as an external resource.  So would user input, of course.

Comment: I tried running this and got the following:

_A`,`,`E`9`/`5`2`E`"`!`3`%`E`!`2`%`E`"`%`,`/`.`'`E`4`/`E`5`3

I can understand the first answer, but the second answer requires input, which I said was not "required"

Comment: byte count is off. Even though solution is in iso-8859-1 (I guess) teh byte count is after utf-8 conversion. Around 70 without bonuses perhaps?

Comment: I don't see why the byte count is relevant, a simple count leads me to this amount of characters as is mentioned in the scoring. It seems that some people have trouble copying the code into matlab, a similar code can easily be generated with: `char('All your base are belong to us' + 99)`

Comment: being pedantic for a moment: Wanted output contains a trailing space. Yours does not.

Answer (score 10):

## k (-7 = 53 - 60)

`` (#`)"c"$(465%3)-6h$"Z//{\",&){9:(6{:)6{96/,-4{',{&("; ``

doesn't include trailing newline, can be added at cost of one additional char:

`` (-#`)"c"$(465%3)-6h$"Z//{\",&){9:(6{:)6{96/,-4{',{&("; ``

annoyingly, the only offsets that work for this trick are 154 and 155

edit:

if it's sufficient to display the string (rather than printing it), as i suspect the APL solution does (it doesn't work in http://tryapl.com/, so i can't test it properly), it's

```
  "c"$(465%3)-6h$"Z//{\",&){9:(6{:)6{96/,-4{',{&("
"All your base are belong to us"
```

which is -12 = 48 - 60. can i get a ruling on whether this is sufficient?

Comment: I never asked for a trailing newline... :)

Answer (score 10):

### Python REPL, <s>122</s> <s>116</s> 98 characters - 30 bonus = <s>92</s> <s>86</s> 68 points

```
>>> '\x41\x6c\x6c \x79\x6f\x75\x72 \x62\x61\x73\x65 \x61\x72\x65 \x62\x65\x6c\x6fng \x74\x6f \x75\x73'

'All your base are belong to us'
```

I could get rid of the zeroes in Python 3.3 by replacing '`\40`' with `\N{SP}`, but alas, the `N` is not permitted.

**Edit**: Inspired by [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19171/all-your-base-are-belong-to-us-restricted/19412#19412), I've shortened it further by replacing `\x40` by .  Moreover, since I already use the `1`, replacing `\156` by `n` and `\x67` by `g` shortens it by another 6 characters while incurring no extra penalty.

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to get rid of all the repeated `\x` with a list comprehension, but that would probably necessitate `eval` and/or list/generator comprehensions with the keyword `for`, and/or `join`...

Comment: I wonder if this is this a valid entry, because it only works the interactive shell. If you put this in a `.py` file and execute it, there is no output.

Comment: @DanielHepper I'm new to code golf and this site.  Are there any rules regarding this?

Comment: my understanding was that it has to be an executable program, but I might be mistaken

Comment: It depends... I believe there is no general rule. Some questions allow interactive mode, others don't.

Comment: I've [posted the question on meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/902/4897).

Comment: This works in R too

Comment: I wrote a function which doesn't write anything to the console, but it can have input and output.

Comment: I beat this for Python, with a score of 74! :D http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19171/all-your-base-are-belong-to-us-restricted/19412#19412

Comment: @AaronHall And after my edit, I brought mine down to 68!

Comment: Very Smart move! Of course: ``len("'All your base are belong to us'")``
``32``

Comment: Not obfuscating `loser` instead of `ng` should be 11 literal chars instead of only to and should save 27 bytes and 10 bonus. Oh ... the ASCII codes contain 1 and 2. Pity.

Answer (score 10):

#### dc, <s>97 - 60 = 37</s> <s>91 - 60 = 31</s> <s>88 - 60 = 28</s> 81 - 60 = 21

```
3C87596P4d^8/P7958389P7479394P6386533P7C89P749698CP644848CP459 8^699 7^3849736388974773333 86-++P
```

Improved version (the main idea here is to vary the input base, to increase the chances of finding a useful big number with no problematic digits):

```
IDi67793554D647F84C836645D6569F69Pi6385C77P9i35PDdi6^I9^+6D59CD83D664D34+P8CPFi98CCF5PCi97P
```

In base 7, the whole thing can become a single number! Lower bases are naturally less compact, but the lack of fix-up operations here makes up for it.

```
7i4398873968644388737548444897643735447698675366869556798538985674336396359936458859886P
```

My first solution used base 10. My second used a mix of base 9, 10, 12, 13, and 15. This one is in base 7. I truly feel like all the base *are* belong to me.

**Last one, seriously:** Base 13 does a great job on the first segment, then base 7 for the rest.

```
Di67793554D647F84C836645D6569F69P7i798789699638355733695878558396339387963789536P
```

Comment: So in other words, all your base 7 are belong to you, @Wumpus?

Answer (score 9):

## Brainfuck, <s>205</s> 203 - 60 = <s>145</s> 143 bytes

```
++++[->++++<]>[->++++>++>+++++++>++++++>++++++++<<<<<]>+.>>----..<.>>>-------.<<+++.>>----.---.<<<.>>++.-.>+.<++++.<<.>>----.>-.<++++.<<.>>---.+++.<---.>>---.-.<<-----.<.>>>++++++.-----.<<<.>>>++++++.--.
```

Readable version:

```
++++[->++++<]>[->++++>++>+++++++>++++++>++++++++<<<<<]
64 32 112 96 128

>+.>>----..<.                     All                 65 108 108  32
>>>-------.<<+++.>>----.---.<<<.  your           121 111 117 114  32
>>++.-.>+.<++++.<<.               base            98  97 115 101  32
>>----.>-.<++++.<<.               are                 97 114 101  32
>>---.+++.<---.>>---.-.<<-----.<. belong  98 101 108 111 110 103  32
>>>++++++.-----.<<<.              to                     116 111  32
>>>++++++.--.                     us                     117 115
```

Comment: [Good effort!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/700/)

Comment: I kinda half-expected a Brainfuck solution eventually... Nice work!

Answer (score 7):

## Befunge 98 : 122 - 60 = 62

```
5f8+*:53-+:' \6-:5+' 91+:*3+::7+\8+:3-:7-:3-:' \3+::3-4+',' -+\4-:' \:4+\6+c+:f3+-:4+3-' '&3*:3+:6-:f+5-:' \d-:' '!+ff+k,@
```

Computes the ascii values, then prints them. I still need to try out other methods of forming the numbers to see if there are shorter ways.

Comment: I was wondering when you were gonna put your 2 bytes in... Nice work!

Answer (score 7):

## Python, 195-40 = 155

```
x,w,y,z,v=4*8,55,56,57,58;exec(("%c"*38)%(y+y,z+z,49+y,w+w,v+v,39-7,34,65,54+54,54+54,x,v+63,48+63,48+69,z+z,x,98,97,59+y,45+y,x,97,z+z,45+y,x,98,45+y,54+54,w+y,w+w,45+v,x,v+v,w+y,x,v+59,z+v,34))
```

Answer (score 6):

### Ruby, 121 - 50 = 71

A bit brute force, but most of the cute methods are ruled out:

```ruby
$><<[65,c=36*3,c,d=8*4,363/3,f=c+3,c+9,c+6,d,x=98,97,j=c+7,k=3+x,d,97,c+6,k,d,x,k,c,f,j-5,5+x,d,c+8,f,d,c+9,j].pack('C*')
```

Breaks rule #1 because of the A in `pack`, the other two should be OK.

Comment: I can save 6 chars if we're just returning the result rather than printing it, I wasn't clear on that after looking at the other answers.

Comment: Extremely long, but no more “a”: http://pastebin.com/wnsvcAMh

Comment: @manatwork I love it!  Somehow I never thought of that, even though I'm using `<<` in my answer.

Comment: So you either use the 154 character solution @manatwork has used and claim the 60 point discount which gives you 94, or stick with the non-Rule 1 version and go with the 71... I know which I'd use :)

Answer (score 6):

### {ba,z}sh, <s>67 - 40  72 - 60</s> 61 - 40 = 21

```sh
$'\x74r' K-~\#-\; _@-~\^-j<<<'Mxx ){%~ 3m#q m~q 3qx{z8 ${ %#'
```

Darn it, turns out I had a `r` in there that I hadn't noticed, so the 20 bonus doesn't apply!

Comment: In the zsh and bash versions I have handy, `$'\x74\x72'` can be used directly as a command name, saving you 8 characters for the `$(m4<<<)`. Doesn't it work that way for you?

Comment: And after looking at it again... using `\x72` as a replacement for `r` gets you the 20 point bonus at the cost of losing the 30 point bonus (for the `2`)

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley oh, you're right on both accounts. I didn't think of the `2` used there, let me see if I can find a way to get rid of it and avoid losing any bonuses.

Comment: Holy sh#t, that was ingenious! This looks like a Reverse ROT12 ASCII cypher... (am I right?) nicely done!

Comment: Nice answer.  But does `tr` count as an external resource?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I don't think so; it's a standard utility spec'd by POSIX.  See [tr(1)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/utilities/tr.html)

Comment: @FireFly - If you want to drop the `r` in `tr`, you can borrow from my answer http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19421/11259 `z=({m..v});$'\x74'${z[5]} K-~\#-\; _@-~\^-j<<<'Mxx ){%~ 3m#q m~q 3qx{z8 ${ %#'`.  78 chars - 60 = 18.

Comment: Does this print the trailing space?

Comment: @Titus it prints 31 characters with a trailing newline included (so, it prints "All your base are belong to us\n" to stdout). No trailing space characters on the line. I think that should be correct?

Comment: Sorry there´s a gap between the wanted output and the closing quote; I misread that as a space. I don´t think that you need the newline.

Answer (score 6):

## C, 75 bytes - 60 = 15

*Thanks to @gastropner for getting the score down from 50 to 33 and from 19 to 15!*

```
*q,i;f(p){(*(q=p)="\v&&j3%?8j(+9/j+8/j(/&%$-j>%j?9J"[i++]^74)?i=!f(++p):i;}
```

Takes the address of a char array as input and writes the string to the array.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYjRCoIwFEDf/QqTlDvXkDRoNtbe@wUzGIPZRsps1ov4662w83TOUaRTKoR83BmmwaEZchi5Qzy5vrPMVqmgFnBdWEwLC0WWbok9p1bUl6QxGLe34wEJwzcaMHboZNgSzDDFvTQDoGiO4h/qLp@xb/Ylbdk6NHj0N/ea/BpL@Cj9kJ0PpK/KLw)

**Call with:**

```
int main()
{
    char s[128];
    f(s);
    puts(s);
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Old version (90 bytes - 40 = 50):**

```
*q,i,j;f(p){for(i=3-3;j="Epp$}s v$fewi$evi$fipsrk$xs$ w"[i++];*q=j!=35-3?j-4:353/3)q=p++;}
```

Comment: Riffing on this, using the powers of XOR and recursion, you can reach 93 - 60 = 33 bytes: `*q,i,j;x(p){if(j="\v&&j3%?8j(+9/j+8/j(/&%$-j>%j?9"[i++])*(q=p)=j^74,x(++p);}f(p){i=3-3;x(p);}`

Comment: @gastropner Thanks!

Comment: Could go with `i=i<30` for another 2 bytes off.

Comment: @gastropner Can't use `0`.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course!

Comment: 75 - 60 = 15 bytes. Still looks to be reusable: `*q,i;f(p){(*(q=p)="\v&&j3%?8j(+9/j+8/j(/&%$-j>%j?9J"[i++]^74)?i=!f(++p):i;}`

Comment: Don't you have to add 3 bytes for the compiler flag?

Comment: @O.O.Balance The flag is only needed with a 64-bit version of the compiler. With a 32-bit compiler it works without the flag.

Answer (score 5):

## Brainfuck, (227 - 60 = 167)

```
+++++ +++++[>+++>++++++>+++++++++>++++++++++<<<<-]>>+++++.>>++++++++..<<<++.>>>+++++++++++++.----------.++++++.---.<<<.>>++++++++.-.>+.<++++.<<.>>----.>-.<++++.<<.>>---.+++.>------.+++.-.<++.<<.>>>++++++.-----.<<<.>>>++++++.--.
```

Comment: I dont think the space at the start, `+++++ +++++` is needed? It could be 226 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## Postscript, 364 - 40 = 324

I couldn't do it without `loser`, of course. :)

```
/${cvx exec}def
/+{<3C7E4F6F597E3E>$ $}def
/*{<~P&(~>$}def
/-{( )<3C7E4F754E7E3E>$ $ 3 4<~P#;~>$ 4 3<~P)#3FP'-~>$}def
/_{36(      )<~OoP~><3C7E4F754E7E3E>$ $ 4 3<~P,S~>$ 48<~P'?~>$
${96 3<~P#;~>$ + -}<~P">~>$}def
/.{_ 96 3<~P#;~>$ -}def
65 - 777 .
895 353 + _ 774 333 + .
74933 333 + 7 * 3 + 333 + .
9593 4353 + .
689653949 335 + .
735 333 + .
775 333 + _ 5 5 + -
```

This starts with encoding the text as base-36 strings:

```
%-=Encoding strings as base-36 numbers=-
%All your base are belong to us
% handle uppercase A separately
%36#ll = %777
%36#your = %1618515
%36#yo = 36#ur = 36#base = 36#are = 36#belong = 36#to = 36#us =
%1248 1107 527198 13946 689654284 1068 1108
```

And then removing the 1s and 0s and 2s arithmetically. The strings can then be regenerated with `36 <string-buf> cvrs`, but this yields upper-case letters, so we then need to iterate through and add 0x20 to make them lowercase.

The operators `cvx exec` allow us to execute string fragments of binary-encoded operator tokens in various encodings. Simplest is to encode an operator in hex `<92??>` but there's a 2 in there! So the "first-level" encoding is ascii85. Then any strings that still contained forbidden characters went through extra levels of hex -> ascii85 -> hex -> ascii85.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript

### <s>(306 characters - 60 bonus = 246)</s> <s>(206 characters - 50 bonus = 156)</s>

### (123 chars = 173 chars - 50 bonus)

Kind of nooby, probably could get more off... Let me know if I've stuffed something up, this alerts "All your base are belong to us". This is also ASCII-only.

```
(c=(''+!'')[4-3],x=([][3]+c)[6])[a='c\x6F'+x+'\x73t'+c+'uct\x6F'+c][a]('a\x6C\x65'+c+'t("A\x6C\x6C y\x6Fu'+c+' ba\x73\x65 a'+c+'\x65 b\x65\x6C\x6F'+x+'\x67 t\x6F u\x73")')()
```

If you count the console itself as output, this would also count (57 with bonus):

```
'A\x6C\x6C y\x6Fu'+(c=(''+!'')[4-3])+' ba\x73\x65 a'+c+'\x65 b\x65\x6C\x6F'+([][3]+c)[6]+'\x67 t\x6F u\x73'
```

Comment: Great approach, though a few letter subsitutions could have also allowed you the Rule-1 bonus as well... Good work.

Comment: @WallyWest: Thanks! The problem in JavaScript is that it's rather hard to get an "A" without breaking the other rules or using up way too many characters -- it would take up more than 10 characters alone.

Comment: True, you have to outweight the additional letters against the bonuses... Nice work though!

Comment: `x=(c.t+c)[6]` is a bit shorter

Comment: also, `eval` might be easier to hack

Comment: and to get `a`, you can use `NaN`.   For `A`, you can use `([].constructor).toString()[9]`

Comment: ...which is `letter_a=(+{}+c)[1]` and `letter_A=([][a]+c)[9]`

Comment: Please could someone explain how that actually alerts anything?

Answer (score 3):

### Brainfuck, 306 - 60 = 246

```
----[---->+<]>++.[--->+<]>+..[++>---<]>--.--[->++++<]>+.----------.++++++.---.[-->+++++<]>+++.[--->+<]>++.-.--[--->+<]>--.++++[->+++<]>.--[--->+<]>-.[--->+<]>+.--[--->+<]>---.-------------.--[--->+<]>-.[--->+<]>++.+++.+++++++.+++.-.-------.-[--->+<]>--.---[->++++<]>.-----.[--->+<]>-----.---[->++++<]>+.--.
```

Comment: Surely this could be reduced somehow?

Comment: @WallyWest I don't have the time to reduce a program like this by 5% for no reason :P feel free to post improvements, though!

Comment: No obligation needed here :)

Comment: @WallyWest You're right about shortening it though. It could use some major improvements.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP (35 - 60 = -25 bytes)

[`HOW LOW CAN YOU GET ?`](http://donhodges.com/how_high_can_you_get.htm)<sup>[1][2]</sup>

```
$ xxd yourbase.php 
0000000: 3c3f 3d7e be93 93df 8690 8a8d df9d 9e8c  <?=~............
0000010: 9adf 9e8d 9adf 9d9a 9390 9198 df8b 90df  ................
0000020: 8a8c 3b                                  ..;
```

---

<sup>[1] This program can be decoded using `xxd -r`.</sup>
<sup>[2] Yeah, heavy solution reuse here. I think it's... third problem I solved this way. Perhaps I should move to something else, but it's not that this is not great for problems that forbid you from using most characters.</sup>

Comment: I don't get it, what are you trying to do here?

Comment: @WallyWest He bit-inverted the string; resulting in 31 extended ASCII chars, which PHP tries to interprete as a constant name and because it finds no such constant interpretes as a string. This string gets negated back with `~`.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash, 52 - 10 - 30 = 12

The following is to be executed in a (still pretty common) ISO-8859-1 environment:

```sh
$'\x74r' À-þ  @-~<<<'Áìì ùïõò âáóå áòå âåìïîç ôï õó'
```

This calls `tr`, which translates the characters in a suitable way. I had to either use the `r` and violate rule 2, or use a digit in the escape and violate rule 3. Since 3 gives more bonus, I chose the former.

Comment: Yes he did :) You cannot use "a", "b", "t", "u", or "y" *in any case* Also you need minimum two of the conditions

Comment: @cowls: Seems I completely missed that point, thanks for making it clear. Rewrote my answer to comply with that.

Comment: @MvG great re-work... Well done!

Comment: Does `tr` constitute an external resource?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma: More like a standard library, I'd say, although this is sure subject to interpretation. But [it's specified in the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html), so I guess any POSIX system has to have it, so it's part of the system.

Comment: Interesting - I get varying results.  100% correct on OSX.  All-caps on some old redhat with tr (coreutils) 5.2.1.  This on Ubuntu 12.04 with tr (GNU coreutils) 8.13: `~B~m~m ~z~p~v~s ~c~b~t~f ~b~s~f ~c~f~m~p~o~h ~u~p ~v~t`, i.e. the character values are 1 higher than they should be.

Comment: @MvG - BTW If you want to drop the `r` in `tr` and get the extra -20 bonus, you can borrow from my answer http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19421/11259 `z=({m..v});$'\x74'${z[5]} À-þ  @-~<<<'Áìì ùïõò âáóå áòå âåìïîç ôï õó'`.  63 chars - 60 bonus = 3 (on OSX at least ;-))

Comment: OK, I guess I need to set the ISO-8859-1 environment in Linux somehow - any ideas?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma: What I did was `LC_ALL=de_DE xterm`, relying on the fact that plain old xterm likely doesn't support unicode in any case, and the `LC_ALL` override should tell it not to use Unicode even if it were supported. `locale -a` will list installed locales, and with a bit of luck there are some using ISO-8859-1 among these.

Comment: @MvG - yep, `sudo locale-gen de_DE` then `LC_ALL=de_DE xterm` did the trick for me

Answer (score 3):

## Pure Bash (no external resources), 141 chars - 50 bonus = 91

```
Z=({k..v})
f=$'\x65'
h=$'\x6c'
i=$'\x6f'
j=${Z[7]}
k=$'\x73'
m=$'\x75'
$f$'\x63'h$i A$h$h y$i$m$j ba$k$f a$j$f b$f$h$i${Z[3]}$'\x67' t$i u$k
```

Intentionally dropping the 10-point bonus to get a better overall score.

This works on any `bash` version 3.00.15 or later that I have tried.

#### How does it work

There's no rocket science here - just `bash` expansions of one form or another:

- Simple hex expansion to obtain required character.  This works for characters whose hex representation doesn't contain `[012]`.  e.g. `$'\x65'` gives us `e`
- For other characters, we generate a bash array of sequential characters using brace expansion into an array initialization (`Z=({k..v})`).  The start of the brace expansion is chosen carefully so that the indexes of the characters we require don't contain `[012]`.  e.g.
  `${Z[7]}` gives us `r`.
- `bash` is flexible enough to allow its commands to be constructed from the contents of multiple strings.  So `$f$'\x63'h$i` expands to `echo`.
- For characters that are required only once, the expansion is inserted inline to the echo command string.
- For characters that are required twice or more it is more efficient to expand them to variables, then reference the variables.

---

Previous answer with full bonus, but worse overall score:

#### Pure Bash (no external resources), 193 chars - 60 bonus = 133

I know this won't win, but I wanted to prove to myself this is possible in `bash`, while satisfying all requirements:

```
Z=({3..8} {C..z})
c=${Z[36]}
d=${Z[37]}
f=$'\x65'
h=$'\x6c'
i=$'\x6f'
j=${Z[53]}
k=$'\x73'
m=$'\x75'
$f$'\x63'h$i ${c^}$h$h $'\x79'$i$m$j $d$c$k$f $c$j$f $d$f$h$i${Z[49]}$'\x67' $'\x74'$i $m$k
```

This does require a fairly recent version of `bash` for the `${c^}` parameter expansion.  4.2.25 is fine, but 3.2.48 is a no-go.

Comment: I take my hat off to you... I just executed this... nice work... Very nice work.

Comment: @WallyWest - I just edited in a shorter version.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 23 - 60 = -37

```
“%⁼“¡¢8ṣƤ¹;“pȷȦÆ⁾“¡PȤṫ»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYY7qo8Y9QOrQwkOLLB7uXHxsyaGd1kB@wYntJ5YdbnvUuA8sGXBiycOdqw/t/v8fAA)

This is just the compressed representation of `["All", " your base are", " belong to", " us"]` (Jelly has a compressed string format). The string's split into multiple pieces in order to ensure that none of the banned characters appear within the compressed representation; they're all implicitly concatenated at the end of the program.

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, 186 - 10 - 30 = 146

I had to get a little creative ;)

```
 <?=chr(65).'ll '.chr(88+33).'o'.chr(39*3).'r '.chr(98).chr(97).'s'.chr(68+33).' '.chr(97).chr(38*3).chr(68+33).' '.chr(98).'elo'.chr(77+33).chr(69+34).' '.chr(83+33).'o '.chr(39*3).'s'?>
```

Comment: you could still golf it a little and mantain the answer idea: echo doesn't require parentheses(1), you can use `<?=` instead of echo(4), you can save the repeated letters in variables ('l', ' '). use `54*2` instead of `54+54`

Comment: Fixed. I could only do multiplying on certain ones. I can't do ``54*2`` because that it has a ``2`` in it, so I could only do it with ones that had 3 or higher has a factor. If I use a decimal, then there's no less characters.

Comment: [a few golfing tips](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/77b02684a1c69f4b9151c16bc10280de6f3ca44a) taking 50 bytes off. Most of it (23+9 bytes): You can replace the remaining `chr(68+33)` and `chr(38*3)` with literal `e` and `r`.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 67 bytes -60 bonus = 7

```php
<?=d__cJZFFcQWFVcWFVcQV_ZZQcCZcFF^"%33C3534C3653C643C333546C75C35";
```

bitwise XOR on the ASCII characters

I brute forced a pair of characters not in the forbidden characters for each character in output.
No word character pair for `A` and I don´t like extended ASCII, so I live with one string in quotes.

Comment: Now, @Titus, how exactly does this work? I can only guess that somehow you're using some clever replace function... I've never seen this kind of witchcraft with PHP before... All I know is that it works!

Comment: @WallyWest I´ll explain inline.

Comment: The ^ symbol! Of course! I had read about PHP's XOR ability a while back but had completely forgotten about it... Nice one!

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `ṡ`, 20 bytes, score -40

```
‛λʀ«×∇⟇Ȧß¥fė₀⌊↓qεǏq⟑
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=%E1%B9%A1&code=%E2%80%9B%CE%BB%CA%80%C2%AB%C3%97%E2%88%87%E2%9F%87%C8%A6%C3%9F%C2%A5f%C4%97%E2%82%80%E2%8C%8A%E2%86%93q%CE%B5%C7%8Fq%E2%9F%91&inputs=&header=&footer=)

-4 bytes / -4 score thanks to Aaron Miller.

Comment: You’ve used an `S` in your code, the -20 bonus is invalid…

Comment: @EliseoD'Annunzio It specified lowercase s - 's', not capital.

Comment: Actually what I wrote in my initial brief was 'You cannot use "l", "o", "s", "e", or "r" in any case in your code (bonus -20 to your golf score if you can do this)'

Emphasis on "ANY case" as in upper or lower case...

Comment: @EliseoD'Annunzio Oh, reverting to the 23-byter. Give me a moment.

Comment: [20 bytes, -40 score](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=ṡ&code=%E2%80%9B%CE%BB%CA%80%C2%AB%C3%97%E2%88%87%E2%9F%87%C8%A6%C3%9F%C2%A5f%C4%97%E2%82%80%E2%8C%8A%E2%86%93q%CE%B5%C7%8Fq%E2%9F%91&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

### [BF-RLE](http://esolangs.org/wiki/BF-RLE), 146 - 30 = 116

```
+5[>+5<-]>+.<+4[>+3<-]>+..>>+3[<+2>-]<++.<+A.-7.+3.-0.>.<<+1[>-1<-]>.-.<+0[>+3<-]>.-B.>.<-1.<+1[>+1<-]>+.-A.>.<-0.+0.+4.+0.-.-4.>.<+A.-2.>.<+3.--.
```

Comment: This can be shortened significantly

Answer (score 1):

**Python, 181 - 40 = 141**

[I'm using version 2.7.2 YMMV - the builtin, `file` is gone in python 3.X]

```
f=file.__doc__;c=5-3;l=f[c];s=' ';e=f[3];h=f[6+7];i=f[c*87];j=3**3;f[j*c*5]+l+l+s+f[-57]+h+f[j-7]+f[j-3]+s+f[j-8]+f[6]+i+e+s+f[6]+f[j-3]+e+s+f[j-8]+e+l+h+f[5]+f[j]+s+f[45]+h+s+f[j-7]+i
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python (104 - 30 = 74)

```
>>> '\x41\x6c\x6c \x79\x6f\x75\x72 \x62\x61\x73\x65 \x61\x72\x65 \x62\x65\x6c\x6f\156\x67 \x74\x6f \x75\x73'
'All your base are belong to us'
```

And score:

```
>>> len(r"'\x41\x6c\x6c \x79\x6f\x75\x72 \x62\x61\x73\x65 \x61\x72\x65 \x62\x65\x6c\x6f\156\x67 \x74\x6f \x75\x73'")-30
74
```

Comment: Nicely done, but you really didn't need to do the same for determining the score... ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Mumps, 150 - <strike>60 = 90.</strike> 40 = 110

```
S J=" ",Z=36*3,C=37*3,D=38*3,Q=39*3,I=35*3-4 W *65,*Z,*Z,J,*484/4,*C,*Q,*D,J,*98,*97,*C+4,*I,J,*97,*D,*I,J,*98,*I,*Z,*C,*D-4,*Z-5,J,*C+5,*C,J,*Q,*C+4
```

I'm not sure if it could have been done shorter (overall) by not getting one of the code bonuses - my goal was a bit less on shortness and a bit more on the -60... I liked the challenge of not using any of the restricted characters.

And... I goofed it up - missed the beginning 'S' command. :-/

Anyway, here's a "no rules" version - expanding the variables.

```
W *65,*36*3,*36*3," ",*484/4,*37*3,*39*3,*38*3," ",*98,*97,*37*3+4,*35*3-4," ",*97,*38*3,*35*3-4," ",*98,*35*3-4,*36*3,*37*3,*38*3-4,*36*3-5," ",*37*3+5,*37*3," ",*39*3,*37*3+4
```

And that gives it a score of 177-60 = 117. So breaking the center rule still gave me a lower overall score.

Comment: Interesting answer... Is there an online emulator I can access to execute this code?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, but there are versions for Mumps that run on just about every platform - there's even versions that will run on a Raspberry Pi if you want a *very* small Mumps machine... :-)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 99 − 50 = 49

A subroutine that returns the required string:

```
{A.($c=h|d)."$c y".($f=f|k).u.($k=p|b)." ba".($j=c|p).($d=d|a)." a$k$d b$d$c$f".(jf|fc)." t$f u$j"}
```

See it printed thus:

```
perl -e'print sub{...}->().$/'
```

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 149 bytes -30 -10 = 109

```
L$=CHR$(&H75)O$=CHR$(98)S$=CHR$(97)?CHR$(65);"ll",CHR$(&H79);"o";L$;"r ";O$;S$;"se ";S$;"re ";O$;"elo";CHR$(&H6E);CHR$(&H67);" ";CHR$(&H74);"o",L$;"s
```

Answer (score 1):

## VBA, 119 - 40 = 79 Bytes

Anonymous VBE Immediate window function that takes no input and outputs `All your base are belong to us` to the VBE immediate window

```vba
L=Chr(&H75):O=Chr(98):S=Chr(97):?Chr(65)"ll "Chr(&H79)"o"L"r "O;S"se "S"re "O"elo"Chr(&H6E)Chr(&H67)" "Chr(&H74)"o "L"s
```

<sub>*This is largely a port of [12Me21's SmileBASIC Answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/110205/61846) - Hooray for BASIC languages*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 194 (254 bytes - 60 bonus)

```
[S S S T    S T S N
_Push_10_s][S S S T T   S S N
_Push_12_u][S S T   T   S S T   S S T   N
_Push_-73_space][S S S T    T   S N
_Push_6_o][S S S T  S T T   N
_Push_11_t][S T S S T   S N
_copy_2nd_space][S S T  T   S N
_Push_-2_g][S S S T S T N
_Push_5_n][S S S T  T   S N
_Push_6_o][S S S T  T   N
_Push_3_l][S S T    T   S S N
_Push_-4_e][S S T   T   T   T   N
_Push_-7_b][S S T   T   S S T   S S T   N
_Push_-73_space][S S T  T   S S N
_Push_-4_e][S S S T S S T   N
_Push_9_r][S S T    T   S S S N
_Push_-8_a][S T S S T   T   N
_Copy_3rd_space][S S T  T   S S N
_Push_-4_e][S S S T S T S N
_Push_10_s][S S T   T   S S S N
_Push_-8_a][S S T   T   T   T   N
_Push_-7_b][S T S S T   S S N
_Copy_4th_space][S S S T    S S T   N
_Push_9_r][S S S T  T   S S N
_Push_12_u][S S S T T   S N
_Push_6_o][S S S T  S S S S N
_Push_17_y][S T S S T   S S N
_Copy_4th_space][S S S T    T   N
_Push_3_l][S N
S _Duplicate_8_l][S S T T   S T S S S N
_Push_-40_A][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S S S T T   S T S S T   N
_Push_105][T    S S S _Add][T   N
S S _Print_as_character][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##VY5LCoAwDETXmVPM1UQKdicoePzYtGkdaSHMJ488R73LdW57cSdp7SGmMWaM@GlhNJrsPtTUikEISyUoA5UcwH86@YIZEFn@6vOOBeM6JfNOAkUawrPuAe4v) (raw with spaces, tabs, and new-lines only).

Uses the shorter alternative I've explained in the bottom [of this Whitespace tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48442/tips-for-golfing-in-whitespace/158232#158232), with the fixed amount being `105` in this case.

Comment: Very nice... I've was wondering when I've was going to see an esoteric answer creeping in!

Answer (score 1):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), Filename: 45 bytes + Content: 0 bytes - Bonus: 30 bytes = 15 bytes.

- Filename (escaped some characters): `Xx\202\330\330\100\362\336\352\344\100\304\302\346\312\100\302\344\312\100\304\312\330\336\334\316\100\350\336\100\352\346!.z\002.$.o.c!.a`

  - Printed version: `Xx‚ØØ@òÞêä@ÄÂæÊ@ÂäÊ@ÄÊØÞÜÎ@èÞ@êæ!.z.$.o.c!.a`
- Content: empty

### What it does

- Twice necesity ASCII codes before.
- Halve on this program.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nRhtV@I49/v@ipCt0AClLaLjEKOr6Myyq4yr7qwjMJ4KRaqlRVoUBeavz3Nv0iI4PmdfjkeS3Nzc19yXtOtE/e8/k34cD6Oqad54cX98XeqEA/Pjr8b50HE/OI/PbmAOJ@6gNAwjb@JFA/PaD6/NgeMpuFcqlwZesNj@KXJjYrhjPh440R2xrHKZu5NhOIrJUe1q7@hI1LgePw1dcuPGnTDoZbNyBVwHTtBlO2bXfTCDse@T8k7WzmaTwyd7578KqukJHjGGKQG5xbQpDoXqXE2MOU3Z/tmoX1ydnR@IsmWtp8CTT2f1i6MvV7VPp6eHtXNh8yYxAkK16f7e2a9Xnw9Pz@qfGlUgQ9rZ7JRIrUIiteS4KOzz@eLM5VtH3MHYd2KXRH08EA5jmD2Go2409L2YO77nRMS4ITltaheo9gud50QOxxxv/Hl0VDs@EFXJApRGhl0e9b1eLJl3CSImALfTD4n2M6NEEBtZ6xIS9V2wYRyGJPS7O1n0ghcTm3H3wfEJzZCe40cunc3eQCfL@FICiTOZRW6X5CJzYj6ZPIKfZzMn@T6T9mwGKktKgPMDW9AELOA/iPfvObhw6PmuzvSesHjHiVzgYFPiBUTv5RnpgTe4Gzkd7kSRO7j2n9DxIfh8LyDGQzy2Z/GIGLWIWHZ5vbKx@W7rPck1W0G@nZvdjNwhKc2cxzuS2z/8WG9MfWDSFZVNDtbVhyMviHskNzwJPwUNr37VqUVnD597H9zD0enjX5OLpy/Pl85efD447h4UjIy2tpab/QfWmiVorUmJZhHaFi1KwSR@@OiO9EiJoNO1Di1qFmOEtiinHAyZk1dDp7R4VqRVyjiK3hORoJT3wpHO4cb7XuCS3o7F2dTr6Skg2hYWk3gAjNCStWy2J0SXTQ91xiVLUmtGbT53wesEseTuYx89oeZHeo8hO/6asNpBQtKZFp/PF2x@ZCA5qCNHesQAgBjz3jjoxF4YkCO9I2XvZEBeFsVO567pFwpt0VlCgiOI47Np4jHqJzbwQXffMFgKh7@EhmG3E0HADvN5TnrCeCAhXB95@Wh6JZTWiY47oGBQEGbzcfL03DYN0zHRAsG2lTCnJYfsV0hJIdAZ7Thwo@Fu08Xllnjga11RcdrmLiW/gGhBAchVQU8kGUqdzK6ZzWYClthSQdh0LALD5kqyYGe87F7pg0QUJQR5NENSct6U5bUuSjjqJPIAhnRf8C9Ipm6HO8oTu69FrRbmvjRE6UxvEmVmYvgxKWMmAkqz1AuOsHCAS6r1KM76AMhFeTDZMAw60cMobpt53dm2WcFsFiDyDLUuM/CPO4n53ByaUyDDI0gQ82jb5vCfbPVh1gfFYzOfyTh8Po1Exmz23MQb3EGjeFdts2D6QLXxwQA2ugO@BwE6YKhmGEQgAAD7CDQHpgHbNsxSWfjchiB9peb6ipq56UnTK1htoYFfCwU@FLA2yhAUw29wgbNZYD5VIDFUV3d8HcUjXbOK64x3Xd@FgnHSNAyvzZVicPCrT5pfSbuA5zvmFI7oVAI0WqRZkqVFRfJvCWhIITKnniHKr3D/z0k/OSF5kgXTf8zxRfDUinD1wePaGs4AUSfWjFgKjWmUTUO0HWTPIZ8IrfGBkyehKXfxJSGWRRkyxA8xkCbb4olNr8QEDj/xJ3HF5yvWhpurm62CuTspPFXB6bsTA8YMjHkY12Bce6pCcXtbr8PGwRRT0C1cwdttj98WCioLAdptG6MjrY8QaqW8Zpo5BTDBHGBD08SiiZLnzRM9y7h5A2sCjRe/hvoo48C7gkjouaN40Aa7m1nInCaPeRrQAFIZAjbYVO44CJzLaRenWOWwZPcW/YCsyjmMYd1iudlMrbtAeuTG41GAlUdxKSABp9tNuRq4jq7jdJ3BNbQ16bqlIaDrPaSANYkQpgQis5Q3/zr/oNMsZEAwxyvJFuVYpeWz5p2A4IEAT@tgX9XBHHQJcZp5cmjo2eLoomS4@j6b3kHUAZm2gB@sB@ivfaC4v41Qvg8ug0lxP0GAySviKDowYLLOdwkkOcYhtKPOyBvGIhEUq5/rdr/REhSwEbSjcrlc5E70A4b6FH/XWVscSJlAtNUCp8yf@X2lPP622CCwsWMvbf3@siW1edk5X9lBpqj8y/6FfsqmpwLQpCSGkbienC4hjfVaUhN0w96GBqK2Xd7YZLu1KtbTBdpHpAUWGAffzJKJZMcBHwfYfLwQTWaLErurWVVjWZc/kRmcqi3B9vTjtCjtXUOXXoWQPX6rHi1ODPW0hcmAQdlYv4Dfpf1QtRFvbwZ6vXhfPCj6LzjTewFI0Hf5bnAT9/V7Jm9QHQpOfVv4vA73Z6zrByLJ2/fFetFm7BttWsb7Nt09KFS2qpUNbHoWbDyQ4UT/uMr7Sj8u1oqXxS9seixo6apKGmGM@cm9cUeU1wTg80tgK3se1exV3imnbGyx65Hr3GHGq0GurTTXN9qYOy9FpWLUksMKBSu9vqXO2RWobjUh1rGiKiR4P8VeMHb5HG2vsGvblS1E3Nl4x5gESxleuCsG7Iv4QvSaAcgcnclP9Mv8l2UdO0vGP9HPVw0QLW1erATAA7jltviZyVwLprcg2m@FvNLghFuwxWcM3mK9zeWArSNObtX61jDa4vOyA0ZLrHAygldcGPhP2SzIhL3Vnk5LoyqBKUU1MABkULM83pgVZz6@BBqQgzQEGBkgsST/RP@jeK84QiyzBNvmf8irpS5YAvxj@37p4NO/OLizfPB5IZSujqZyJeIvEOMlS/QxS65afqC277Cx74PLEGV5v4ueWUZJqiTi8TtIKisekymqjnm3ALlIx9ABuW7VoPIhY8pxQiKhR1@YyTKEvH6T1wckLbyKXyxM9QUKxBiwBhQD0batXaNera/4ThauFYr5VxSxkt0n@eC35Lbo0vDQJvpyFMl90ark0h2FmcWNud/xd@9Nv@qb94wtc4Vq@A9prr1Jcw1orkmaWNq/f2jsHR@K3MWkVbbKrfV1S/7bFoybuN5srW/AWKkomFWBf1wD3C4nMLX/slZzRQvw1nG9qfY2FEzNJZ1M6bllWeWSVgpLnUzJyf2UPsU0KRuFVP1T7VPj/LBxLr6/2pslj3/Sg5/AGbjQBb7CeOwQowM0lnYSai@nMW@5QfwWyo/HF67ogfsXnwCWjvy3933jVPaU0K5Cm4fflIw7Ygejop12gV9lUciTll7Kt5gGPV/Lxi6IzSm8o7BjELJXMzpEfvQaY9IJB9gYAXD0A/BFzG6FGI3KCgJ2RBHsh2TodYtu7A3c4rAzHBcfomfedWKXLatZ@Xs1Y8fziRFUyqk6oIReak23WnNUpmWbuZennVG2K@8qW@ublS14BMFjC6wi@2XVHzvq6fjv7YwPRmUnHCi@N9NejKYI96KVw/HT6ZnI5dJeElORB42fhz0MPsZYp@m1xeLrS6u1FtKiB9HfOF3bsISwE1kjQhefFu7hqXlPaCuA/ifZ7jQ1q610wy4weQCkSHAT@sSIvv8P)

---

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), Filename: 55 bytes + Content: 0 bytes - Bonus: 50 bytes = 5 bytes.

- Filename (escaped some): `Xx\202\330\330\100\362\336\352\344\100\304\302\346\312\100\302\344\312\100\304\312\330\336\334\316\100\350\336\100\352\346!.z\002.$.t.v.m.v.c!.a.t.p`

  - Printed: `XxØØ@òÞêä@ÄÂæÊ@ÂäÊ@ÄÊØÞÜÎ@èÞ@êæ!.z.$.t.v.m.v.c!.a.t.p`
- Content: empty

### What it does

- Move to bottom each of them.
- Hide last `!` to heap.
- Print all of them at once.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nRhtV@I49/v@ipCt0AClLaLjEKOr6Myyq4yr7qwjMJ4KRaqlRVoUBeavz3Nv0iI4PmdfDgeS3Nzc19yX0HWi/vefST@Oh1HVNG@8uD@@LnXCgfnxV@N86LgfnMdnNzCHE3dQGoaRN/GigXnth9fmwPEU3CuVSwMvWGz/FLkxMdwxHw@c6I5YVrnM3ckwHMXkqHa1d3QkalyPn4YuuXHjThj0slm5Aq4DJ@iyHbPrPpjB2PdJeSdrZ7PJ4ZO9818F1fQEjxjDlIDcYtoUh0J1ribGnKZs/2zUL67Ozg9E2bLWU@DJp7P6xdGXq9qn09PD2rmweZMYAaHadH/v7Nerz4enZ/VPjSqQIe1sdkqkViGRWnJcFPb5fHHm8q0j7mDsO7FLoj4eCIcxzB7DUTca@l7MHd9zImLckJw2tQtU@4XOcyKHY443/jw6qh0fiKpkAUojwy6P@l4vlsy7BBETgNvph0T7mVEiiI2sdQmJ@i7YMA5DEvrdnSx6wYuJzbj74PiEZkjP8SOXzmZvoJNlfCmBxJnMIrdLcpE5MZ9MHsHPs5mTfJ9JezYDlSUlwPmBLWgCFvAfxPv3HFw49HxXZ3pPWLzjRC5wsCnxAqL38oz0wBvcjZwOd6LIHVz7T@j4EHy@FxDjIR7bs3hEjFpELLu8XtnYfLf1nuSarSDfzs1uRu6QlGbO4x3J7R9@rDemPjDpisomB@vqw5EXxD2SG56En4KGV7/q1KKzh8@9D@7h6PTxr8nF05fnS2cvPh8cdw8KRkZbW8vN/gNrzRK01qREswhtixalYBI/fHRHeqRE0OlahxY1izFCW5RTDobMyauhU1o8K9IqZRxF74lIUMp74UjncON9L3BJb8fibOr19BQQbQuLSTwARmjJWjbbE6LLpoc645IlqTWjNp@74HWCWHL3sY@eUPMjvceQHX9NWO0gIelMi8/nCzY/MpAc1JEjPWIAQIx5bxx0Yi8MyJHekbJ3MiAvi2Knc9f0C4W26CwhwRHE8dk08Rj1Exv4oLtvGCyFwyehYdjtRBCww3yek54wHkgI10dePppeCaV1ouMOKBgUhNl8nDw9t03DdEy0QLBtJcxpySH7FVJSCHRGOw7caLjbdHG5JR74WldUnLa5S8kvIFpQAHJV0BNJhlIns2tms5mAJbZUEDYdi8CwuZIs2Bkvu1f6IBFFCUEezZCUnDdlea2LEo46iTyAId0X/AuSqdvhjvLE7mtRq4W5Lw1ROtObRJmZGH5MypiJgNIs9YIjLBzgkmo9irM@AHJRHkw2DINO9DCK22Zed7ZtVjCbBYg8Q63LDPzjTmI@N4fmFMjwCBLEPNq2OXyTrT7M@qB4bOYzGYfPp5HImM2em3iDO2gU76ptFkwfqDY@GMBGd8D3IEAHDNUMgwgEAGAfgebANGDbhlkqC5/bEKSv1FxfUTM3PWl6BastNPBrocCHAtZGGYJi@A0ucDYLzKcKJIbq6o6vo3ika1ZxnfGu67tQME6ahuG1uVIMDn71SfMraRfwfMecwhGdSoBGizRLsrSoSP4tAQ0pRObUM0T5Fe7/OeknJyRPsmD6jzm@CJ5aEa4@eFxbwxkg6sSaEUuhMY2yaYi2g@w55BOhNT5w8iQ05S6@JMSyKEOG@CEG0mRbPLHplZjA4Sf@JK74fMXacHN1s1UwdyeFpyo4fXdiwJiBMQ/jGoxrT1Uobm/rddg4mGIKuoUreLvt8dtCQWUhQLttY3Sk9RFCrZTXTDOnACaYA2xomlg0UfK8eaJnGTdvYE2g8eLXUB9lHHhXEAk9dxQP2mB3MwuZ0@QxTwMaQCpDwAabyh0HgXM57eIUqxyW7N6iH5BVOYcxrFssN5updRdIj9x4PAqw8iguBSTgdLspVwPX0XWcrjO4hrYmXbc0BHS9hxSwJhHClEBklvLmX@cfdJqFDAjmeCXZohyrtHzWvBMQPBDgaR3sqzqYgy4hTjNPDg09WxxdlAxX32fTO4g6INMW8IP1AP21DxT3txHK98FlMCnuJwgweUUcRQcGTNb5LoEkxziEdtQZecNYJIJi9XPd7jdaggI2gnZULpeL3Il@wFCf4u86a4sDKROItlrglPkzv6@Ux98WGwQ2duylrd9ftqQ2LzvnKzvIFJV/2b/QT9n0VACalMQwEteT0yWksV5LaoJu2NvQQNS2yxubbLdWxXq6QPuItMAC4@CbWTKR7Djg4wCbjxeiyWxRYnc1q2os6/InMoNTtSXYnn6cFqW9a@jSqxCyx2/Vo8WJoZ62MBkwKBvrF/C7tB@qNuLtzUCvF@@LB0X/BWd6LwAJ@i7fDW7ivn7P5A2qQ8Gpbwuf1@H@jHX9QCR5@75YL9qMfaNNy3jfprsHhcpWtbKBTc@CjQcynOgfV3lf6cfFWvGy@IVNjwUtXVVJI4wxP7k37ojymgB8fglsZc@jmr3KO@WUjS12PXKdO8x4Nci1leb6Rhtz56WoVIxaclihYKXXt9Q5uwLVrSbEOlZUhQTvp9gLxi6fo@0Vdm27soWIOxvvGJNgKcMLd8WAfRFfiF4zAJmjM/mJfpn/sqxjZ8n4J/r5qgGipc2LlQB4ALfcFj8zmWvB9BZE@62QVxqccAu2@IzBW6y3uRywdcTJrVrfGkZbfF52wGiJFU5G8IoLA/8pmwWZsLfa02lpVCUwpagGBoAMapbHG7PizMeXQANykIYAIwMkluSf6H8U7xVHiGWWYNv8D3m11AVLgH9s3y8dfPoXB3eWDz4vhNLV0VSuRPwFYrxkiT5myVXLD9T2HTb2fXAZoizvd9EzyyhJlUQ8fgdJZcVjMkXVMe8WIBfpGDog160aVD5kTDlOSCT06AszWYaQ12/y@oCkhVfxi4WpvkCBGAPWgGIg2ra1a9Sr9RXfycK1QjH/iiJWsvskH/yW3BZdGh7aRF@OIrkvWpVcuqMws7gx9zv@7r3pV33znrFlrlAN/yHNtTdprgHNNUkTS/v3D42940ORu5i0yla5tb5uya9twbiJ683W@gaMlYqCWRX44hrgdjmBqf2XtZorWoC3jutNtbehYGou6WRKzy3LKpe0Ulx6KA3g28mUHFgMcz/VPjXODxvn4nv6OtOkuHSWvPlJD34CZ@BC8/cK47FDjA5k@aWdhNrLaUxXbhC/hfLj8YUHeuD1xct/6ch/e9Y3TmUrCV0qdHf4V5JxR@xgVLTT5u@rrAV50tJL@RbToNVr2dj8sDmF5xM2CkK2aEaHyP@6xphrwgH2QwAc/QB8EbNbIUajsoKAjVAE@yEZet2iG3sDtzjsDMfFh@iZd53YZctqVv5ezdjxfGIElXKqDiihl1rTrdYclWnZZu7lRWeU7cq7ytb6ZmUL3j7wxgKryDZZtcWOejH@ezvjO1HZCQeKz8y0BaMpwr1o5XD8dHomcrm0hcQM5EG/52Hrgm8w1ml6bbH406XVWgtp0YOgb5yubVhC2ImsEaGLfxTu4YV5T2grgLYn2e40NautdMPmL@n7UyS4CX1iRN//Bw)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 18 - 60 = -42 bytes

```
“€Ÿ€žŠà€™ÊÂ€„€ª“.ª
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOcR01rju4AEfuOLji8AMh41LLocNfhJhCrYR6QPLQKqErv0Kr//wE)

```
“...“.ª  # trimmed program
“...“    # push "all your base are belong to us"...
     .ª  # in sentence case
         # implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), <sup><s>232 − 40 = 192</s></sup> 238 − 60 = 178 bytes

```
{iiiiii}iiiiic{iiii}iiicc{{d}ii}iiiic{{i}d}dc{d}ciiiiiicdddc{{d}ii}ddc{{i}ddd}ddddcdc{ii}ddc{d}ddddc{{d}iii}ic{{i}ddd}dddddc{ii}dddc{d}dddc{{d}iii}ic{{i}ddd}ddddciiic{i}dddciiicdc{d}iiic{{d}iii}dc{{i}dd}iiiicdddddc{{d}ii}ic{{i}d}dddddcddc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5BDoAgDARf5KPMrkbOHJu@vULLajxIAmw2k3Z47Dxbv7YIa3k8X5gyYEZf/cjN6cSoUDxICsk0P85LcI7JdhXFjVkfTpi4Hwzl5YqJl1Th2u7yes0e8/IiIm4)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 80 bytes - 60 = 20

Claiming all three bonuses.

```perl
('3?"5W939=8#>/'^p x$].J x 8)->($~,';66z#5/(z8;)?z;(?z8?654=z.5z/)'^z.Z x(33-4))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcGxCoAgEADQXzkq8A5SBz0xJN37gSCora1BmuSGft3eq/f7cO@oXBl4X9yyxjFbdVVo02k2aBBJZ5y@WaUQZGSLEhMVSVgklsB@FcNiSV1iDmjonPZEvf8)

### Explanation

Builds up the strings: `CORE'syswrite` and `All your base are belong to us` using the stringwise XOR operator with repeated strings where available, calling these strings as function references passing `$~` as the first argument to `syswrite` and the `All your base...` string as the second.

---

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 58 bytes - 60 = -2

This one contains mostly unprintables and utilises the inverse binary string operator `~`.

```pl
(~'.............')->($~,~'..............................')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc5NasMwEAXgvU/xFgUnUBlHKvFMF7nLSKM0AREb/9B0k6u7cutAyaZ5C/EWM5/Gy3Ca5@tVYXpU50s3jdV4bnGApGS@2qk3XoZopI/Gx9RePszYmmmoulR0sU9PjMVwaovPABOeHQ4y/j86z/Wad1hqImzjA3wtCi9KoED75clNOTfPAmxuZfU3xa@wW4zGMqy6DJF9QxNtWJ4GPrIDOz2C9lwD5dYcNi@31zu1GjYbJKTQIys4UgBLXspN16b5BHaLUT1kNVw2eMeUDfLgevlTMvRz22Puu@X2Gw)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 96 - 40 = 56

```python
exec("z='';[z:=z+chr(ord(x)^(34-3))for x i\x6e'^ss?fpjm?}~lz?~mz?}zspqx?kp?jl'];pri\x6e\x74(z)")
```

**Or with REPR 83 - 40 = 43**

```python
exec("z='';[z:=z+chr(ord(x)^(34-3))for x i\x6e'^ss?fpjm?}~lz?~mz?}zspqx?kp?jl']");z
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/L3viathan/Aceto), 23 bytes

3rd grade Hilbert curve, 53 bytes - 30 bonus = 23.

```
lo'm"  u
e"poptos
b cIcIp"
rep'fo
asab
 er 
Aluo
"l y
```

Comment: [50-30=20](https://tio.run/##S0xOLcn//z8nJ79UISlfictRobIoNTXn0GIupeQkhaLEAq58z8TiVK5cz/w0LvVkJXUuJYXiUi4FkCYA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 33 - 60 = -27 bytes

```
`mßPÚXmÞ-ãù“`i`à ö` d"m " Å
i°Id
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=YG3fUNpYbd4t4w/5k2BpYOCg9mAgZCJtICIgxQppsElk&input=)

The shoco library is powerful at compressing lowercase letters, but I had to do lots of experiment in order to get a compressed string without any of the banned chars.

#### Unpacked & How it works

```
`mßPÚXmÞ-ãù“`i`à ö` d"m " s1
`mßPÚXmÞ-ãù“`                 "mbasemarembelongmtomus"
              i`à ö`           Insert "allmyour" at the beginning
                     d"m "     Replace "m" with " "
                           s1  Discard initial "a"
                               Implicitly assign to U

Ui++Id
Ui      Add to the beginning of U...
  ++I     65
     d    chr(65) == "A"
```

Comment: [29 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=YG3fUNpYbd4t4w/5k2BpYOCg9mAgcW0guGiwSWQ)

Comment: [25 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVM&code=YOCg9gBt31DaWG3eLeMP%2bZNgaDY1ZClxbQ)

Answer (score 0):

## Google Sheets, 53 - 30 = 23

Speaking of Bases... Following rules 1 & 2:

```
="All your base are belo"&LOWER(BASE(775,33))&" to us
```

I believe this is optimal, unless the string can be compressed.

- Applying all three rules does not leave us with any useful functions. These are IMDIV, FV, PV, IF, PI, PHI, and MID. MID is almost interesting: we can gain access to `[TRUEFALS]` because we can do comparisons to get boolean strings, but this leaves way too many letters out.
- Similarly, even following two rules, we still don't have access to any useful alphabetic character yielding functions. (CHAR, BASE, TEXT)
- This means that we have to follow one rule or bust. I choose the most valuable one, `[NG012]`. Luckily the phrase only contains an illegal "ng", which we can easily get around with `BASE`.
- An alternative solution is to split all words by spaces into a column, then join by spaces, but that results in the same score and is harder to set up.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 104 - 50 = 54 bytes

```python
quit("A\x6C\x6C y\x6Fu%()c ba\x73\x65 a%()c\x65 b\x65\x6C\x6F%(#)c\x67 t\x6F u\x73"%{'':3*38,'#':77+33})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v7A0s0RDyTGmwswZhBUqgaRbqaqGZrJCUmJMhbkxkG@qkAgSALOSQCRUtZuqhjJY2FyhBMRVKAVpUFKtVle3MtYyttBRV1a3MjfXNjau1fz/HwA)

Prints the output to STDERR, which is allowed as stated on the I/O meta post. Uses a combination of plain characters, hexadecimal strings and some C-style string formatting with some addition and multiplication to avoid 0-2.