# 'abc' and 'cba'

Tags: code-golf, string, polyglot

Your task is simple, write a single code snippet that when executed in one language  outputs only the string `'abc'` and when executed in another language outputs only the string `'cba'`. The program should take no input.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge.

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe at all. The fact that the string is reversed is different enough from printing two different strings. I won't (vote to) reopen, though, as that would have immediate effect

Comment: I voted to reopen this post, because IMO printing the reverse of a String and a String is much different than 2 different ones. No answer can trivially be modified to fit this challenge. My own answer uses a reverse symmetry techinque when compared to the answers there. I agree with @LuisMendo.

Comment: Reopening now, as it has two votes in addition to mine

Comment: Is a leading newline allowed?

Comment: Can you print `ABC` instead of `abc`

Comment: I vote to reopen, some answers use the fact `cba` is `abc` backwards; [link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138303/12537), [link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138312/12537), [link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138349/12537), [link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138332/12537), [link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138348/12537), [link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138343/12537), [link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138302/12537), [link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138328/12537), [link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138347/12537)

Comment: `'ABC'` and `'CBA'` is ok, leading/trailing whitespace/newlines ok but must be the same for both outputs

Comment: @OliverNi Another reason it might not be considered a dupe is that the other question says "Different versions of the same language don't count", whereas that is allowed and indeed encouraged here

Comment: There are 8 Python 2/Python 3  answers to this question and somehow, all of them use different strategies?!

Answer (score 23):

## MATLAB / Octave, 41 bytes

```
disp(flip('abc',size(randsample(2,2),2)))
```

In MATLAB `randsample(2,2)` gives a 2×1 vector, so `size(...,2)` is `1`. Thus `flip` is applied along the first dimension, which is a singleton, so the original string `'abc'` is displayed:

[image]

In Octave `randsample(2,2)` gives a 1×2 vector, so `size(...,2)` is `2`. Thus `flip` is applied along the second dimension, that is, the string is flipped from left to right:

[image]

Comment: I think this would be a few bytes shorter if you use the less interesting `version` variant.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Thanks. I think it's too late to change now. Maybe post it yourself?

Comment: Nah, it's a boring version of this one... Also, I don't have MATLAB anymore so I won't be able to test it.

Answer (score 21):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E) / [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

```
_"abc
```

**[Try 05AB1E online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/XikxKfn/fwA)**

**[Try Pyth online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P14pMSn5/38A)**

**[This also works in Pyke, outputting `cba`.](https://tio.run/##K6jMTv3/P14pMSn5/38A)**

**[This also works in Recursiva, outputting `cba`.](https://tio.run/##K0pNLi0qzixL/P8/XikxKfn/fwA)**

Answer (score 16):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php) and [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 57 bytes

```
   		    	
 
 	
     	
	    
 	
     	
	   	
echo  cba
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgZNTAURyKXCBCAgbLITG5@RKTc7IV1BITkrk4uL6/x8A)

Comment: You can golf 3 bytes by removing the three trailing new-lines. [Relevant Whitespace tip.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/48464/52210)

Answer (score 15):

## 25 bytes

```py
print(1/2and'cba'or'abc')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69Ew1DfKDEvRT05KVE9v0g9MSlZXfP/fwA) ([Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/))

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69Ew1DfKDEvRT05KVE9v0g9MSlZXfP/fwA) ([Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/))

Comment: -1 byte by using `exit` instead of `print` (although this applies to every answer as of now).

Comment: @notjagan. `exit` prints to `stderr`, doesn't it? Not sure if it would be a valid answer.

Comment: @ThePirateBay Outputing to STDERR is allowed [as per meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2451/63641).

Comment: The challenge says code snippet and print though, it's not using default rules.

Answer (score 12):

## Vim / Notepad.exe, 10 bytes

```
cbaabc<esc><backspace><backspace><backspace>
```

Comment: Notepad isn't a programming language, but +1.

Comment: it is cheating :(

Answer (score 11):

-1 byte if I make `==0` into `>0` but that's already another answer

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 26 bytes

```python
print('acbbca'[1/2==0::2])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EQz0xOSkpOVE92lDfyNbWwMrKKFbz/38A)

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 26 bytes

```python
print('acbbca'[1/2==0::2])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQz0xOSkpOVE92lDfyNbWwMrKKFbz/38A)

`1/2` gives `0` (floordiv) in Python 2 and `0.5` (truediv) in Python 3. Thus, `1/2==0` gives 1 in Python 3 and 0 in Python 2 (actually, booleans, but those are just integers), so `'acbbca'[1::2] => 'cba'` is given for Python 3 and `'acbbca'[0::2] => 'abc'` is given for Python 2.

Answer (score 11):

## Excel / Google Sheets, <sub><s>41</s> <s>28</s> <s>27</s></sub> 24 Bytes

Anonymous worksheet formula that takes no input and outputs `"ABC"` to the calling cell in Excel and `"CBA"` to the calling cell in Google Sheets

```gs
=IfError(M("CBA"),"ABC")
```

In Google Sheets, `M(...)` is an alias for and autoformatted to `T(...)` (short for `Text()`). This call returns the text value of the passed variable, `"CBA"`. `"CBA"` is not caught as an error, so `"CBA"` is returned by `IfError(...,"ABC")`

In Excel, there is no `M(...)` function, and `M(...)` is not an alias and therefore `M("CBA")` returns the formula not found error, `#NAME?`. This is  caught by `IfError(...,"ABC")`, which in turn returns `"ABC"`.

---

### Previous Versions, 27, 28, 41 Bytes

See edits for explanations

```gs
=If(IsErr(A()),"ABC","CBA")
```

```gs
=If(IsErr(GT()),"ABC","CBA")
```

```gs
=IfError(If(Info("NUMFILE"),"ABC"),"CBA")
```

Comment: Neat!  ....You can save 2 bytes by using `iserr` instead of `iferror` and 1 byte by using "SYSTEM" instead of "NUMFILE": `=IF(ISERR(INFO("SYSTEM")),"cba","abc")`

Answer (score 9):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/) / [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
"abc"R
```

Try it online:

- [CJam](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/XykxKVkp6P9/AA);
- [05AB1E](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fKTEpWSno/38A).

#### How it works in CJam

```
"abc"    Push this string
R        Push variable R, predefined to the empty string
         Implicitly display stack
```

#### How it works in 05AB1E

```
"abc"    Push this string
R        Reverse
         Implicitly display top of the stack
```

Comment: Also works in Foo instead of CJam.

Answer (score 8):

With apologies to @HyperNeutrino for stealing most of his answer (I don't have the reputation to comment yet)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 25 bytes

```python
print('acbbca'[1/2>0::2])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EQz0xOSkpOVE92lDfyM7AysooVvP/fwA)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 25 bytes

```python
print('acbbca'[1/2>0::2])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQz0xOSkpOVE92lDfyM7AysooVvP/fwA)

Comment: Umm it's actually `<1` btw.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer No that's truthy for both languages

Comment: As @notjagan suggested, you can replace `print` with `exit` (which is [allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/2451#2451) by our rules) and therefore save 1 byte.

Comment: You should add the second language to your answer (Python3 I assume)

Comment: @Zacharý Thanks, I didn't realize the problem had been updated (the original was only python 2 and pyhon 3)

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (NodeJS) and PHP, 46 bytes

```js
<!--
strrev=console.log//--><?=
strrev("abc");
```

Prints `abc` in JS and `cba` in PHP.

[Try the JS online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f/fRlFXl6u4pKgotcw2OT@vOD8nVS8nP11fX1fXzsbeFiqloZSYlKykaf3/PwA)

[Try the PHP online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fRlFXl6u4pKgotcw2OT@vOD8nVS8nP11fX1fXzsbeFiqloZSYlKykaf3/PwA) (note that TIO doesn't hide the HTML comments (`<!--`...`-->`)

Comment: How is the `<!--` interpreted in Node?

Comment: @Challenger5 It's apparently interpreted as a one-line comment, exactly like `//` ([source](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/comments.htm)). Works that way in browser JS as well.

Comment: That is weird...

Comment: `--> blah blah` is valid comment in some JavaScript interpreter, you may just remove `//`

Comment: @tsh That doesn't seem to work in any of the TIO JS interpreters; where does that act as a comment?

Comment: @JustinMariner I had tested on Node v8.1.3. And the behavior defined in ES6 specification Annex B, which means all ***browsers*** that support ES6 should accept it as comment.

Comment: Might as well link [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-html-like-comments). And that's definitely weird when used alone. Fortunately it only works on a line where's there's no statement (only whitespace and inline comments)

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/) and Python 3, 42 bytes

```python
try:exec("print'abc'")
except:print('cba')
```

[Try it online! (Python 2)](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6So0iq1IjVZQ6mgKDOvRD0xKVldSZMrtSI5taDECiymoZ6clKiu@f8/AA)

[Try it online! (Python 3)](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6So0iq1IjVZQ6mgKDOvRD0xKVldSZMrtSI5taDECiymoZ6clKiu@f8/AA)

Thought I'd try something different...

Comment: I like this one, not the shortest but quite a generic framework, can be shortened a bit by using `try:long;print('abc')`

Comment: Or better still `try:cmp;print('abc')`

Comment: [Hmm... It doesn't seem to work...](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6So0io5t8C6oCgzr0Q9MSlZnSu1Ijm1oMQKLKKhnpyUqK75/z8A "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: That's not what I wrote, parantheses () still required around print

Answer (score 6):

## Python / Befunge, <s>20</s> 18 bytes

*2 bytes saved thanks to @karhell*

```py
print("abc")# ,,,@
```

[Try it online! for Python](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQykxKVlJU1lBR0fH4f9/AA)

Python sees `print("abc")` then a comment.

[Try it online! for Befunge](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/v6AoM69EQykxKVlJU1lBR0fH4f9/AA)

Befunge, removing all nops and useless commands sees `"abc",,,@` which puts `a`, `b` and `c` on the stack and then prints them (last in - first out).

Comment: A bit late, but you can shave off two bytes by replacing `>:#,_@` by `,,,@`

Comment: Save one more with `#,,<@` instead

Answer (score 6):

## Excel/Google Sheets, 28 bytes

Inspired by @TaylorScott, who used a function that only exists in Excel, I found an even shorter function that only exists in Google Sheets.  Conveniently, it is designed to return strings:

```
=iferror(join(,"cba"),"abc")
```

**How it works**

In Google Sheets, `join([arg1], arg2, arg3,...argk)` will concatenate *arg2* -> *argk*, optionally using the separator specified in *arg1*.  In this case, it successfully returns "cba."

Excel has no `join` function, so `iferror` sees a problem and returns "abc"

Comment: My first ever submission - hope I am doing it right....

Comment: Nice solution :)

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2 / Python 3, 28 bytes

```
print('abc'[::int(1/2*4)-1])
```

In Python 2 `int(1/2*4)-1` evaluates to `-1` and so prints `cba`. - [TiO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EQz0xKVk92soKxDbUN9Iy0dQ1jNX8/x8A)

In Python 3 it evaluates `1` so prints `abc`. - [TiO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQz0xKVk92soKxDbUN9Iy0dQ1jNX8/x8A)

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/)/[Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 20 bytes

```r
cat("abc")#u@o;o;o(;
```

[R - Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxREMpMSlZSVO51CHfGgg1rP//BwA)

[Cubix - Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/z85sURDKTEpWUlTudQh3xoINaz//wcA)

For R, `cat("abc")` then shameless abuse of comments.
For Cubix

```r
    c a
    t (
" a b c " ) # u
@ o ; o ; o ( ;
    . .
    . .
```

- `"abc"` Pushs a, b ad c onto the stack
- `)#` Increment the c, pushs number of element in stack
- `u` U-turn to the right
- `;(` Remove the count, Decrement the c
- `o;o;o@` Output cba and exit

Pushs the number on in stack

Comment: I am strangely pleased by the way that `cat(` is totally ignored by Cubix.

Answer (score 4):

## C and C++, <s>115</s>, <s>78</s>, <s>58</s>, 56 bytes

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){puts(sizeof('x')>1?"abc":"cba");}
```

78 bytes, thanks to [challenger5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61384/challenger5).

58 bytes, thanks to [aschepler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/18653/aschepler).

56 bytes, thanks to [hvd](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16385/hvd)

[Try it - C++!](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/XzkzLzmnNCXVprgkJTNfL8OOKzcxM09Ds7qgtKRYozizKjU/Tb1C3c7QXikxKVnJSik5KVFJ07r2/38A)

[Try it - C!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185My85pzQl1aa4JCUzXy/Djis3MTNPQ7O6oLSkWKM4syo1P029Qt3O0F4pMSlZyUopOSlRSdO69v9/AA)

Comment: 1) You can collapse the two `#ifdef`s to make a single one. 2) You can remove the space in `#include <stdio.h>`. 3) You can change `printf("%s",` to `puts(`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcZBCoAgEADA@75C9KKH@kDRV0RXrQUzYfUUvd3wMDC4nIhjKCqYe4g7t0DPeh1wOyravLU31gIUpRCTsBZr7jwJkM6jBBUzR5Do3XwJlMBs3xg/ "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: Or there's always the good old `sizeof('x')>1?"abc":"cba"` trick.

Comment: @Challenger5 Thanks for the comment

Comment: @aschepler Thanks for the trick, i've made the changes 58 bytes :)

Comment: `sizeof`'s operand does not need parentheses, it's not a function.

Comment: @hvd Thanks! You're right!

Answer (score 4):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam) and [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 8 bytes

```
'c'b'a]$
```

[Try it in CJam!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/Xz1ZPUk9MVbl/38A)

[Try it in Gaia!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/Xz1ZPUk9MVbl/38A)

#### Explanation

In both languages this defines a list of characters.

In CJam, `$` is sort, so it becomes `abc`.

In Gaia, `$` joins the list into one string, giving `cba`.

Comment: I've added Gaia to the [golfing language list](https://github.com/ETHproductions/golfing-langs); please let me know if I got any details wrong.

Comment: @ETHproductions Looks OK to me.

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8 & C, 95 bytes

```
//\
interface a{static void main(String[]s){System.out.print("abc"/*
main(){{puts("cba"/**/);}}
```

[Try it in Java 8 - resulting in "abc".](https://tio.run/##HcpBCoAgEADAe68QTxqUD@gZHavDZhZrpJJbEOLbLboOY@GGxgfj7LKXotRYoSNzrqANgxQJCDW7PS7sAHSipxPdNkxRpv6JZI7WX9SGD0lwmDVXdfVHmVK4KAquZ/iwVrLLuZQX)
[Try it in C - resulting in "cba".](https://tio.run/##HcpBCoAgEADAe68QTxqUD@gZHqvDupkslEVuQUhvt@g6DDa4QAylGDNUFNkfM6AXkBMDE4pro0msQFFZPiiGfkw62zuxX9vt5Hb/kJUEh9LU1R91zvvJSUl08GFtdPc8pbw)

**Explanation:**

```java
//\
interface a{static void main(String[]s){System.out.print("abc"/*
main(){{puts("cba"/**/);}}
```

As you can see in the Java-highlighted code above, the first line is a comment due to `//`, and the C-code is a comment due to `/* ... */`, resulting in:

```java
interface a{static void main(String[]s){System.out.print("abc");}}
```

---

```
//\
interface a{static void main(String[]s){System.out.print("abc"/*
main(){{puts("cba"/**/);}}
```

Not sure how to correctly enable C-highlighting, because `lang-c` results in the same highlighting as Java.. But `//\` will comment out the next line, which is the Java-code, resulting in:

```
main(){{puts("cba");}}
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) 2.0/JavaScript, <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```javascript
"abc"
//Uw
```

[Japt 2.0](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=ImFiYyIKLy9Vdw==&input=) outputs `cba`

[JavaScript](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@18pMSlZiUtfP7T8f3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RprmfwA) outputs `abc`

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal/Hexagony](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 19 bytes

```
ka3wiṘ,Qλa;b@;<λ;c/
```

[Try it Online! (Vyxal)](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=ka3wi%E1%B9%98%2CQ%CE%BBa%3Bb%40%3B%3C%CE%BB%3Bc%2F&inputs=&header=&footer=)

[Try it Online! (Hexagony)](https://hexagony.net/#lzN4Igxg9gJgpiBcIDWBDAzAdwJaA08ANAIqDdwCgNwBGAAqQDxGlgD0IeIWAdgA4CuALgiACMAJjQAWAKwA2AOwAOAJws2XPgFlocRCgBOAcxABfIA===)

The program is split into two main parts, `ka3wiṘ,Q` and `λa;b@;<λ;c/`. The first half is just basic Vyxal to print "cba" (though I cannot use `cba` because it messes with Hexagony's layout). The second part worked out really nicely, because in order to print in Hexagony, a semicolon is required, but in Vyxal, an unmatched semicolon gives an error. So to fix this, I use lambdas in order to match them, and it just so happened to fit into an exact 3x3 hexagon. Luckily, in Hexagony almost any character that isn't special is taken as its codepoint, so the lambda character is quickly overwritten by anything else that comes after it.

[image]

The lambdas are placed so each one proceeds a semicolon, even if they aren't used in the hexagony code (as indicated by the blue trail).

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 26 bytes

```python
print('abc'[::-(1/2>0)|1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQz0xKVk92spKV8NQ38jOQLPGMFbz/38A)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 26 bytes

```python
print('abc'[::-(1/2>0)|1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EQz0xKVk92spKV8NQ38jOQLPGMFbz/38A)

[25-byte version with `exit` instead](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P7Uis0RDPTEpWT3aykpXw1DfyM5As8YwVvP/fwA), which outputs to STDERR instead.

This is basically the same as `print('abc'[::[1,-1][1/2>0]])`, just that it's golfed.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ly](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Ly) / [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>20</s> 19 bytes

```
"abc"&&ov
;     oo<
```

[Try it with ><>!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/XykxKVlJTS2/jMtaAQTy823@/wcA)

[Try it with Ly!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/18pMSlZSU0tv4zLWgEE8vNt/v8HAA)

These languages are very similar, as Ly is based off ><>. However, Ly does not have 2D execution and interprets `&` differently, which I took advantage of here.

Both languages will start by pushing `abc` to the stack.

For ><>, the `&` instruction moves values to and fro the register. Two in a row will push a value to the register and then take it straight back, essentially a NOP.

For Ly, `&` is a modifier that makes an instruction perform its function on the entire stack.

`o` means the same thing for both languages, but since it is modified by `&` in Ly, it will print the whole stack, outputting `abc`. In ><>, it will only output `c` (as it is printed from the top down)

`v` is a NOP in Ly, which skips it and goes straight to `;`, ending execution. ><> will instead treat it as a pointer, sending the IP downwards.

It then hits another arrow, sending the IP left. Here, it meets two `o` signs, outputting `b` and `a`.

EDIT: Saved a byte (and fixed ><> crashing)

Comment: You can save a byte by moving the `;` to the second line. This also has the benefit that the ><> IP doesn't wrap around and go through the second line again, which causes an error.

Comment: shouldn't there be a ; for ><>? it wouldn't take any more bytes, just replace one of the spaces

Comment: How about `"abc"&&ooo;`? It makes Ly crash, but only after printing "abc".

Comment: …or `"abc"&&o!;o<` for 1 extra byte, if you want to avoid crashing.

Answer (score 3):

## CJam and ><>, 12 bytes

```
"ooo;abc
"4>
```

### What CJam sees:

```
"ooo;abc
"
```

String literal, which pushes the string `ooo;abc` (with a trailing newline) to the stack.

```
 4>
```

Slice off the first four characters of the string, leaving `abc`, which is output.

### What ><> sees:

```
"
```

Begins a string literal.

```
 ooo;abc
```

Forms the contents of the string literal. The character codes of the characters in the string are pushed to the stack in reverse order (so `c` is on the top).

```
"
```

The IP wraps around, hitting the `"` a second time, which ends the string literal.

```
 ooo
```

Outputs the top three characters on the stack: `cba`

```
    ;
```

Terminates the program. Neither the `abc` nor any part of the second line is executed.

### Solution with Error: 8 bytes

```
"abc"oo<
```

What CJam sees ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/XykxKVkpP9/m/38A)):

```
"abc"
```

Push a string literal to the stack.

```
    o
```

Output that string literal.

```
     o
```

Try to output again. The stack is empty, so the program crashes.

### What ><> sees:

```
"abc"
```

Push three characters onto the stack in reverse order.

```
    o
```

Print one character: `c`

```
     o
```

Print another character: `b`

```
      <
```

Start moving backwards.

```
     o
```

Print the last character: `a`

```
    o
```

Try to print another character. Since the stack is empty, the program errors.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2) and [Foo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Foo), 16 bytes

```
print"abc"[::-1]
```

### Python 2

```python
print"abc"[::-1]
```

[Try Python 2 online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EKTEpWSnaykrXMPb/fwA)

#### Explanation

```python
print"abc"[::-1]

print             # print... (duh)
     "abc"        # the string "abc"...
          [::-1]  # backwards
```

### Foo

```
"abc"
```

[Try Foo online!](https://tio.run/##S8vP//@/oCgzr0QpMSlZKdrKStcw9v9/AA)

#### Explanation

```
"abc"

"abc"               print the string "abc"
```

Answer (score 3):

## C (gcc) C++ (g++), 59 bytes

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){puts("abc\0cba"+(sizeof(' ')&4));}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Fission](https://github.com/C0deH4cker/Fission) / [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish) , 11 bytes

```
!R"abc"ooo;
```

[Try Fission Online](https://tio.run/##S8ssLs7Mz/v/XzFIKTEpWSk/P9/6/38A)

In Fission, a particle starts at `R` and prints `abc`.

[Try ><> Online](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/XzFIKTEpWSk/P9/6/38A)

In ><>, the IP starts at the top-left. `!` skips the next instruction, and `"abc"` pushes [a,b,c] on the stack. `ooo` then pops and prints three times, giving `cba`.

Both programs end at `;`

Answer (score 3):

### Javascript / Ruby, 27 bytes

```
0?print('abc'):alert('cba')
```

A shorter version without prints for interpreters (**14 bytes**) :

```
0?'abc':'cba'
```

**Explanation**

*NEW VERSION*
`0` is falsy for Javascript but truthy for Ruby, thanks to [pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/97857/pxeger)

*OLD VERSION*:
`''` is falsy for Javascript, but truthy for Ruby.

*OLD VERSION*:
For Javascript, `[]+[] = ""` as a string concatenation, since the `+` operand is only defined for numbers and strings, and the empty string is evaluated as `false`

Meanwhile, in Ruby, you can concatenate array using the `+` operand, and it is evaluated as `true`

<sub>(first participation in PCG ! :))</sub>

Comment: Can't you use `0` instead of `''`?

Comment: You're right, thank you very much for your insight, I'll edit my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/)/[K (Kona)](https://github.com/kevinlawler/kona), 30 bytes

```
NB. :`0:"ABC"
{}[] /.echo'CBA'
```

[TIO - J](https://tio.run/##y/r/389JT8EqwcBKydHJWYmrujY6VkFfLzU5I1/d2clR/f9/AA) & [TIO - K kona](https://tio.run/##y9bNzs9L/P/fz0lPwSrBwErJ0clZiau6NjpWQV8vNTkjX93ZyVH9/38A)

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/) and [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 23 bytes

```julia
print(["abc","cba"][1])
```

[Try Julia online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v6AoM69EI1opMSlZSUcpOSlRKTbaMFbz/38A)

[Try Python online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EI1opMSlZSUcpOSlRKTbaMFbz/38A)

Julia uses 1-based indexing while Python uses 0-based indexing

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E) and [2sable](https://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable), 6 bytes

```
…CBAžR
```

Prints `ABC` (OP said it was allowed) in 05AB1E and `CBA` in 2sable, using the fact that 2sable was similar to 05AB1E but the `žR` was added to 05AB1E after 2sable was abandoned.

[Try it online! (05AB1E)](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcOy5KTEo/uC/v8HAA)

[Try it online! (2sable)](https://tio.run/##MypOTMpJ/f//UcOy5KTEo/uC/v8HAA)

Comment: The specification states that it must be "abc" or "cba". By my word, I'd say that this is invalid, but I can ask OP.

Comment: I asked the OP and he hasn't responded. If this turns out to be invalid, I will remove it.

Comment: @OliverNi Umm, if it's invalid you can just append a `l` btw.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP + JavaScript, <s>29</s> 28 bytes

This works because PHP interprets `'0'` (same as the integer number `0`) as being falsy, while JavaScript assumes it is simply a non-empty string which is truthy.

```js
'0'?alert('cba'):print(abc);
```

This is meant to run with `-r` on PHP. In Javascript, just paste it in the console.

---

Thanks to [@Justin Mariner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69583/justin-mariner) for saving me 1 byte!

Comment: You could also use `"0"` instead of `+![]`: it becomes `0` (falsy) in PHP and is a string (truthy) in JS.

Comment: @JustinMariner You're right, but that's 1 byte longer.

Comment: Isnt it one byte shorter? `+![]?print(abc):alert('cba');` -> `"0"?alert('cba'):print(abc);`

Comment: @JustinMariner OH!!! That way!!! Yes, it is 1 byte shorter. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf) and [Lean Mean Bean Machine](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/lmbm), 35 bytes

```
 O
""
#a
!!
""
#b
!!
""
#c
& ,&
@U;
```

Braingolf: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/9fwZ9LSYlLOZFLURHMSIIxkrnUFHTUuBxCrf//BwA)
LMBM: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8lNyv3/X8GfS0mJSzmRS1ERzEiCMZK51BR01LgcQq3//wcA)

Outputs `abc` in LMBM, and `cba` in Braingolf.

### Explanation

LMBM is a 2d language, which allows us to selectively execute the code we want.
Meanwhile Braingolf is a 1d language, meaning it starts at the top left, and goes across each line, executing code. It terminates upon reaching the end of the code.

In LMBM, a marble is spawned at every uppercase `O` when the program starts. Each tick it drops 1 character and executes the character. LMBM terminates once all marbles are destroyed.

A double quote `"` in LMBM sets the marble to char mode, meaning the next character to execute is interpreted as a 1 char string literal, and the marble's value is set to the codepoint of the character.

However `"` begins and terminates a string in Braingolf, automatically pushing the contents to the stack. Thankfully an empty string does nothing.

`!` in LMBM prints the marble's value as a char, however this is the silent modifier in Braingolf. Thankfully in braingolf v1, modifiers are only held through no-ops, meaning they will be dropped when braingolf hits the empty string, which doesn't use modifiers (unlike v2 where they are held until used) so we don't have to make sure to consume that modifier before we try to print the stack.

In Braingolf `#` is the char literal identifier, causing the codepoint of the next char to be pushed to the stack.

After passing through all of the characters (and in LMBM's case printing the first 2) we hit the last 2 lines.
The 2nd to last line does nothing in LMBM, as it simply drops through the space, a no-op.

In Braingolf however, the ampersand `&` is the greedy modifier. Modifiers in Braingolf are held through no-ops such as the space, until an operator consumes them, so the first ampersand is held through the space until it hits the comma `,` Braingolf's flip operator. The greedy modifier is consumed here to cause Braingolf to flip the entire stack, rather than the top 2 items. Then another greedy modifier is hit.
This one is held through the newline to the at `@` sign, this prints the entire stack as ASCII.

Meanwhile LMBM simply drops through the space into the `U`, which prints the marble's value as ASCII and destroys the marble.
The `U` also has a function in Braingolf, it pops the top of the stack and pushes `range(0...n)`, but the stack is empty because we just popped and printed everything, so this does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net) / Brainf*ck, 31 bytes

*using the `-r` flag,*

PHP sees `die(abc)` and a comment, and since the compiler is forgiving, it outputs `abc` as a string instead of an empty variable.

Brainf*ck only sees the instruction characters, and the rest is seen as comments.

```
die(abc);#--[----->+<]>---.-.-.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@A8E//ILSjLz84r/6xYppGSmaiQmJWtaK@vqRuuCgJ22TawdkNYDQQA) (PHP)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v8/JTNVIzEpWdNaWVc3WhcE7LRtYu2AtB4I/v8PAA) (Brainf*ck)

Comment: FYI, you [don't have to count `-r`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2428/53880)

Answer (score 2):

## C / Common Lisp, <s>91</s> <s>88</s> <s>40</s> 36 bytes

```
//(princ"abc")
;main(){puts("cba");}
```

[Try it online – C](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/19fX6OgKDMvWSkxKVlJk8s6NzEzT0OzuqC0pFhDKTkpUUnTuvb/fwA)

[Try it online – Common Lisp](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74/19fX6OgKDMvWSkxKVlJk8s6NzEzT0OzuqC0pFhDKTkpUUnTuvb/fwA)

Both “normal” languages with very different syntax and semantics!

**Explanation**

For Common Lisp:

[`//`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_sl_sls.htm#SLSL) is a special variable used in the Common Lisp REPL to give the result of the value preceding the previous one, initially equal to `NIL`. Then we prints `abc`. The following line starts with a semicolon, which is used to start one-line comments.

For C:

the first line is a comment, and the other is the program. Note that the semicolon before the definition of the `main` function is syntactically correct.

*-1 byte thanks to @Zacharý*

Comment: Would it be possible to remove the space after `#include`, since it's read as `;include`? (Or at least from your explanation)

Comment: @Zacharý, yes, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### [Julia](https://julialang.org/) and [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/)/Matlab, 27 bytes

```
if'a'=="a""abc"else"cba"end
```

In Octave, both `'a'` and `"a"` represent the same string, therefore `'a'=="a"` is true. However, in Julia, `'a'` is a single character while  `"a"` is a one-character string. In Julia, `"cba"` is the output.

Ungolfed version:

```
if 'a'=="a"
  "abc"
else
  "cba"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

### Perl / Ruby, 18 bytes

#### Ruby

```
print'abc'.reverse
```

`print`s `cba` as we're calling `.reverse` on the string.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6AoM69EPTEpWV2vKLUstag49f9/AA)

#### Perl

```perl
print'abc'.reverse
```

`print`s `abc` concatenated with the result of `reverse` which by default works on `$_` which is empty and so makes no difference.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvRD0xKVldryi1LLWoOPX/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## Python and Ruby, 30 bytes

```
print(['abc','cba'][(0 or 1)])
```

Ruby: the logical `or` short-circuits on 0, which is a truthy value.

Python: 0 is false, and the logical `or` yields 1.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt)/[Japt 2.0](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0), 14 bytes

```javascript
;AÊ?"abc":"cba
```

[Japt](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=O0HKPyJhYmMiOiJjYmE=&input=) outputs `cba`

[Japt 2.0](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=O0HKPyJhYmMiOiJjYmE=&input=) outputs `abc`

Answer (score 2):

## [MAWP / 1+](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 71 bytes

```
1%(|"+1%+)1%()"+"+"+()();1%()"+"+"+()"+;1%()"+"+"+"+();77W2W1A!!;1M;2M;
```

Uses the % operator to remove all the stray 1's from the 1+ program. Rounded brackets are immediately skipped since there is no 0 in the stack for MAWP.

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v1.1?code=1%25(%7C%22%2B1%25%2B)1%25()%22%2B%22%2B%22%2B()()%3B1%25()%22%2B%22%2B%22%2B()%22%2B%3B1%25()%22%2B%22%2B%22%2B%22%2B()%3B77W2W1A!!%3B1M%3B2M%3B&input=) (MAWP)

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##jVVtb5tIEP7uXzHGqoAa8@KkSg/HH5JKra5KrShtVZ0oRRjWNTpYuN0lL2r7291ZMAbs2FcnQruzzzzzurPFk1jndLrZjGAtRMFdyypCFqVPInwkqSnKbJkyM8ozq8i5sF5f2K9fXTjnZ85fVkIFYQUj@J2scjZxJgmdFBXfYDAaWiVn1jKhFqH3sBWPwBlDRw/XcNsc3VZ24ZM0DBa8J4xkcksNmNrOOSJukojQiEDC4c0buP5n8vEKzk0bwW@vbsAxz3D1bvEZ3t3e3J8NVizPIAhWpSgZCQJIsiJnAgqGDqCURiJBu1spf@K1QpSnKamOeKMRk/9KMhhwA3gM83qr6Qb8@DUYxGQFOSVFWnKNI3YOC9zq7gDwl6yA5sjNRL3fylJCNbRnhuz7vQ7DOUzbY/mrPNSUzzz8TlxQYAwN2rN93CngrZKUgMhhSYA8kqgUJPYVvccidchjIjSnlSe0QA/zouOA5/gGqExtQSx8QBBCTUbCWOtpm1Gac7KVkZSjfzUcY6xk1WedGXBnwJILA64NWOC558t8GW3ybPyvwNg6EMlGQKJemiKYz0HV1H5yrmE8B6cnQjtmWGBQsbbQDxn0A4bJPsOdJzmKvNB0X5awd4hE13AJdp@lU6i/s2WYhtiYMSxZGP1LBB/uFaNXkOkzTo5UCGmMhnBju5jBZyJatKFXPg3nXaf@zJl9J6rPwoAok72LRXkbYlUr6cNaNtkCQ5cNi9XRW2O57CMUeQu/G4vsdmRy9/Mn4Riko7rAm8CcfoZI2uLGXRyv6yJvQb06rvfyOb2X/6@n9PS8ieMfx1oVluUiFORUDF@/doGTE8hvFZA8Cmnd2zprNF6fcOWy67Yt89zEfLlbyTsKJ4yPkEPez3XWWPaPYs2uvXDJNdlw2AQBDoZSaCrFx4IwF2@cfiLZRpclZ3GXIVqH2LOiJsFhd4LGRZqq5UHbpQwZMRRFOa41k8bxCnAR56UwH1iCxSlpEq1ZQ3PCpofa9UX5xEpyFLY/sqqhKmhzY7CTHfcOb45v4lMrEvnWaOpP9XBiICXq4YRGp2NPLm1fzie5mvoH8N07tMMeUspa33Vv7b7zsQrbxGq8Va9G/ZFb7e@y0s6OzrhCYBDQMJNPMMKVIMjChAaBUvM1TuubjfNC@6mMnRdjHVe6MpZ/mq7ps@5WGXe2UjC7uPgy/eJcDYcz58Ns@mG2MatuMjGvvwE) (1+)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby / C](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>26</s> 20 bytes

```ruby
puts(0?"abc":"cba");
```

-6 from Dom Hastings.

[Try it online! (Ruby)](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6C0pFjDwF4pMSlZyUopOSlRSdP6/38A)

[Try it online! (C)](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS/@vnJmXnFOakqpgU1ySkpmvl2HHlZlXopCbmJmnoVn9v6C0pFjDwF4pMSlZyUopOSlRSdP6f@1/AA)

0 is a truthy value in Ruby, so it prints "abc", and C prints "cba".

`puts` is a function that works in both languages.

Comment: You can save 6 bytes with `puts(0?"abc":"cba");`!

Comment: I assumed that the ternary operator didn't work properly with strings in C. Yeesh.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 65 bytes

```javascript
console.log(parseInt('abc--[----->+<]>---.-.-.',16).toString(16))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Pzk/rzg/J1UvJz9doyCxqDjVM69EQz0xKVlXN1oXBOy0bWLtgLQeCKrrGJpp6pXkB5cUZealawA5mv//AwA)

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 65 bytes

```javascript
console.log(parseInt('abc--[----->+<]>---.-.-.',16).toString(16))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v8/OT@vOD8nVS8nP12jILGoONUzr0RDPTEpWVc3WhcE7LRtYu2AtB4IqusYmmnqleQHlxRl5qVrADma//8DAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 27 bytes

```python
print(['abc','cba'][1/2>0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EI1o9MSlZXUc9OSlRPTbaUN/IziBW8/9/AA)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 27 bytes

```python
print(['abc','cba'][1/2>0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EI1o9MSlZXUc9OSlRPTbaUN/IziBW8/9/AA)

Comment: What is the purpose of posting another answer which is even more verbose than your first one?

Comment: @ThePirateBay It is a completely different approach

Comment: @ThePirateBay I think it's different enough. Besides, it's such a trivial task that (at least in my opinion), half of these answers are pretty much the same but reworded.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2 and Python 3, 31 bytes

```python
print(round(.5)and"abc"or"cba")
```

Uses the `and`/`or` trick from Erik the Outgolfer's answer, as well as the fact that Python 3 uses banker's rounding, while Python 2 does not.

[Try it - Python 2!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69Eoyi/NC9FQ89UMzEvRSkxKVkpv0gpOSlRSfP/fwA)

[Try it - Python 3!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69Eoyi/NC9FQ89UMzEvRSkxKVkpv0gpOSlRSfP/fwA)

Comment: Oh, thanks for having that as a note, I need to modify the MY interpreter now. And nice golf too!

Comment: @Zacharý is there any good reason to still support Python 2? :P

Comment: Yes. Because people still use Python2 (including me, since I have nltk and sympy on Py2)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 28 bytes

```python
print("abc"[::1/2and-1or 1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EQykxKVkp2srKUN8oMS9F1zC/SMEwVvP/fwA)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 28 bytes

```python
print("abc"[::1/2and-1or 1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQykxKVkp2srKUN8oMS9F1zC/SMEwVvP/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES8 & ES6), 24 bytes

```
_=>"".padEnd?"abc":"cba"
```

Comment: What about ES5 vs ES6 test `[].keys`

Comment: Or even ES5 vs ES3 test `[].map`...

Comment: @tsh; yeah, there's loads of options here. I went with this one 'cause it allowed me to use an arrow function, rather than an `alert`.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/) and [MY](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/my-language/src/74c388d9404ebafc001337b559bf3c89c26b1827?at=master), 22 bytes

[Try it online! (05AB1E)](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fKTEpWcn@6N5Tk85tfdSwQePcRgj9qGnNuU1wptr//wA)

Hex String in Python:

```
'"abc"?\x8e\x01\x06\x89(\x02\x06\x89(\x80\x03\x06\x89(\x80&'
```

Rendered in 05AB1E's codepage:

```
"abc"?Žʒε‰(αε‰(€βε‰(€&
```

Rendered in MY's unimplemented codepage:

```
_RrH_⌈≡16ǵ'26ǵ'+36ǵ'+←
```

#### How?

Here is what 05AB1E sees:

```
"abc"?Žʒε‰(αε‰(€βε‰(€&
"abc"                   -  The string "abc"
     ?                  -  Print (no newline)
      Ž                 -  Break on empty stack
       ʒε‰(αε‰(€βε‰(€&  - Unread junk
```

What MY sees (I added a feature which causes errors to produce `0`, in addition to fixing the `r` command.):

```
_RrH_⌈≡16ǵ'26ǵ'+36ǵ'+←
_                       Negate (0)
 R                      Convert to binary ([0])
  r                     Convert from binary (0)
   H                    Convert to hex ("0")
    _                   Negate (errors, so 0)
     ⌈                  Ceiling (0)
      ≡                 Match (0 0=>1)
       16ǵ'             'a'
           26ǵ'+        Prepend 'b'
                36ǵ'+   Prepend 'c'
                     ←  Output without a newline
```

I could have used `…`, but I don't want to divide by 0 to result in 0.

(Use the file `polyglot.py`)

Answer (score 1):

## C/><>, 58 bytes

```
#include <stdio.h>//^
int main(){puts(/*/*/"abc"//ooo;
);}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V)/Vim, 6 bytes

```
iabcæ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/PzMxKVn68LL//wE)

V: `cba`

Vim: `abc`

V and Vim are backwards compatible, but V has many more commands mapped.  In V, `æ` means `<M-f>lip` where it's meaningless in Vim.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript / Pascal, 40 bytes

**JavaScript**

Outputs "abc".

```js
{alert`abc`/*}begin write('cba')end.{*/}
```

---

**Pascal**

Outputs "cba".

```pascal
{alert`abc`/*}begin write('cba')end.{*/}
```

[Try it online!](http://rextester.com/SEQMD47402)

---

Pascal conveniently uses `{ }` for block comments and, in JavaScript, `{ }` are just scopes, which affect nothing in this context.

Answer (score 1):

### C and x86 DOS binary, 58 bytes

```
/* VX4!PZSXNN4s(D (D"5s@SCYAAA@!6cba*/main(){puts("abc");}
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth) / [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 14... [bytes?](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
<4"abcｊｊｊ±" \┐
```

[Try it in Pyth!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3C4%22abc%EF%BD%8A%EF%BD%8A%EF%BD%8A%C2%B1%22+%5C%E2%94%90)
[Try it in Canvas!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JTNDNCUyMmFiYyV1RkY0QSV1RkY0QSV1RkY0QSVCMSUyMiUyMCU1QyV1MjUxMA__)

---

#### Pyth explanation:

```
<4                # All but the last 4 characters of:
  "abcｊｊｊ±"   　# String literal
               \┐ # Char literal, printing suppressed
```

Python 3 translation:

```
print("abcｊｊｊ±"[:-4])
"┐"
```

---

#### Canvas explanation:

```
Code               | Explanation                         | Stack
-------------------+-------------------------------------+----------------
<4"abc             | Push "<4\"abc" to the stack         | "<4\"abc"
      ｊｊｊ        |Remove first three characters of ToS | "abc"
           ±       | Reverse ToS                         | "cba"
             " \   | Push "\" \\" to stack               | "cba", "\" \\"
                 ┐ | Remove ToS                          | "cba"
                   | Print ToS (implicit)                |
```

Comment: I don't think this is valid unless you can provide a hexdump.

Answer (score 1):

## brainfuck / Jelly, 24 bytes

```
-[+[>+<<]>+]>+.+.+.
“CBA
```

`“` is encoded as `0xFE` in Jelly's codepage. Jelly's codepage is backwards compatible with printable ASCII, so all other characters are encoded the same.

### To brainfuck

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fN1o72k7bxibWThuI9ECQ61HDHGcnx///AQ)

`-[+[>+<<]>+]>` sets a cell to 64. `+.+.+.` increments and outputs three times, printing `ABC`.

### To Jelly

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/183WjvaTtvGJtZOG4j0QJDrUcMcZyfH//8B)

The first line is parsed as valid Jelly, but is ignored.

The second line is a string literal with content `CBA`. The last line of the file is the main link, so this is printed.

Answer (score 1):

## Swift / JavaScript, 34 bytes

```
/*/*/alert`cba`// */*/print("abc")
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f9fXwsIE3NSi0oSkpMSE/T1FUACBUWZeSUaSolJyUqa//8DAA) (Swift)

Testing snippet (JavaScript):

```js
/*/*/alert`cba`// */*/print("abc")
```

This works by abusing nested block comments in Swift. Swift interprets the code as `/*/* Comment */*/print("abc")` while JavaScript interprets the code as `` /*Comment*/alert`cba`//Comment ``

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3 and Batch, 24 bytes

```
print('abc')#|echo cba
```

This program just takes advantage of operators in both languages.

**What Python Sees**

`print('abc') # This is a comment, do not run`

**What Batch Sees**

`oh noes! errors! run this -> echo cba`

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 79 bytes

```
#include<stdio.h>/*
proc M {} {puts cba}
#*/
#define M main(){printf("abc");}
M
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcm7DYAgFADAnimINEAhA2jcwCHgAfElCIRPRZgdvfYahLUYRgjdurM2i2l/LiVJLgnoTcekI/dWKRg9CZOKMOs8RvffqzFyMXLB2DzftIFNHJPca30)

---

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 79 bytes

```c
#include<stdio.h>/*
proc M {} {puts cba}
#*/
#define M main(){printf("abc");}
M
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcmxDYAgEADA/qcg0qCJMoDGDRgCH9RP9CUCFWF29NrD8UBsTRLjlZ1fYnL0TOeqBwjvg8KIUkUJOUWBm60gBw3S@Z3Y/3dbYtWX8BKnXXV2w66fK5jWPg)

Comment: i knew someone was gonna (ab)use comment quirks

Comment: @mekb If you see other answers, lots of people are doing the same.

Comment: this was the first i saw

Answer (score 1):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem) (ぬこ's intended specification) and Pxem (pxemi.7z: his actual implementation), 16 bytes.

Filename:

```
.wcba.p.d.aabc.p
```

Content is empty.

### What it does

ぬこ, the designer of Pxem, originally intended that `.w` should NOT get into the loop when stack is empty, but his reference implementation does not satisfy it: it gets into the loop when stack is empty. This is why none of we, implementers, have ever complied his intended specification at all.

Answer (score 0):

### JScript, VBScript, 42 bytes

```
rem=1;a="abc"/*
a="cba"'*/
WScript.echo(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

## C / ><>, 33 bytes

```
#//;ooo"cba"
main(){puts("abc");}
```

### What C sees

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///X1lf3zo/P18pOSlRiSs3MTNPQ7O6oLSkWEMpMSlZSdO69v9/AA)

```
#
​
```

Begin empty preprocessor directive.

```
//;ooo"cba"
​
```

Single-line comment.

```
main(){puts("abc");}
```

Print `abc`.

### What ><> sees

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X1lf3zo/P18pOSlRiSs3MTNPQ7O6oLSkWEMpMSlZSdO69v9/AA)

```
#
​
```

Reflect the code in the other direction.

```
       "cba"
​
```

String literal. Push the character codes of `abc` to the stack in order.

```
    ooo
​
```

Output each of those characters. Since `c` is at the top of the stack, it is output first.

```
   ;
​
```

End the program.

```
 //
main(){puts("abc");}
```

Never executed.

Answer (score 0):

## ><> and Underload, 14 bytes

```
"(abc)S"}}ooo;
```

### To ><>:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X0kjMSlZM1iptjY/P9/6/38A)

```
"(abc)S"
```

String literal. Push the character codes of `(abc)S` to the stack.

```
        }}
```

Move the TOS to the bottom twice.

```
          ooo
```

Output three characters (`cba`).

```
             ;
```

Halt.

### To Underload:

https://tio.run/##K81LSS3KyU9M@f9fSSMxKVkzWKm2Nj8/3/r/fwA

```
"
```

Unrecognized

```
 (abc)
```

Push the string `abc`.

```
      S
```

Output it.

```
       "}}ooo;
```

More unrecognized characters.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript and [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>18</s> 15 bytes

```
$Pw=P="cba";$Pw
```

Outputs `"abc"` in Japt and `"cba"` Javascript.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/XyWg3DbAVik5KVHJGsj@/x8A)

Comment: This doesn't work in JS.

Comment: @Shaggy Works fine when run the same way as [Oliver's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163324/16484), but I see where you're coming from. This is an old post and approaches to standard ways to answering were different back then.

Answer (score 0):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus)/[Whispers v2](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 29 bytes

```
x:"abc"
O
> "cba"
>> Output 1
```

**[Try Add++ online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/7/CSikxKVmJy5/LTkEpOSlRicvOTsG/tKSgtETB8P9/AA)**

**[Try Whispers online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v@/wkopMSlZicufy05BKTkpUYnLzk7Bv7SkoLREwfD/fwA)**

This exits with an exit code of **1** when run in Add++.

### How it works

#### Add++

Add++ goes through each line in a linear fashion, executing as it does so. The first line

```
x:"abc"
```

sets the **`x`** variable to the string `abc`. Then

```
O
```

outputs that string. Next

```
> "cba"
>> Output 1
```

(the Whispers code), compares the strings `abc` and `cba` lexicographically before throwing an error at the double `>>` on the fourth line.

#### Whispers

Whispers removes any lines which don't match one of it's [five regexes](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers/blob/master/whispers.py#L163), all of which only match lines beginning with `>`, making the code processed by Whispers

```
> "cba"
>> Output 1
```

Whispers' execution model is almost the exact opposite of Add++; it begins at the bottom line, and calls the lines indicated by the numbers as arguments.

```
>> Output 1
```

calls the function stored on line 1, then outputs the result. Line 1 is

```
> "cba"
```

, a nilad line which returns a single value and takes no arguments. Here, it returns the string `cba`, which is then outputted by the last line.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP & HTML, 15 bytes

```php
<?die(abc)?>cba
```

PHP exits with printing `abc`; `cba` is ignored.
HTML sees the PHP code as unrecognized tag (and ignores it), then prints `cba`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) / [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 27 bytes

```
"printf" "abc\n" '#' r.ÁR¦¦
```

[Try it online Bash](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/X6mgKDOvJE1JQSkxKTkmT0lBXVldoUjvcGPQoWWHlv3/DwA)

```
"printf" "abc\n" '#' r.ÁR¦¦
 │        │       └useless arguments
 │        └abc\n argument
 └printf command
```

[Try it online! 05AB1E](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fqaAoM68kTUlBKTEpOSZPSUFdWV2hSO9wY9ChZYeW/f8PAA)

```
"printf" "abc\n" '#' r.ÁR¦¦
 │        │       │ ││ │  └remove first two chars
 │        │       │ ││ └rotate stack 1 right
 │        │       │ │└reverse stack
 │        │       │ └push space character to stack
 │        │       └push # character to stack
 │        └push string "abc\n" to stack
 └push string "printf" to stack
```

---

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) / [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 24 bytes (without new line)

```
"printf" "abc" '#' r.ÁR?
```

[Try it online Bash](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/X6mgKDOvJE1JQSkxKVlJQV1ZXaFI73BjkP3//wA)

```
"printf" "abc" '#' r.ÁR?
 │        │     └useless arguments
 │        └abc argument
 └printf command
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fqaAoM68kTUlBKTEpWUlBXVldoUjvcGOQ/f//AA)

```
"printf" "abc" '#' r.ÁR?
 │        │     │ ││ │ └print stack without newline
 │        │     │ ││ └rotate stack 1 right
 │        │     │ │└reverse stack
 │        │     │ └push space character to stack
 │        │     └push # character to stack
 │        └push string "abc\n" to stack
 └push string "printf" to stack
```

Comment: `"printf" "abc" r.ÁR?` seems to work for 20. But I don't know either Bash or 05AB1E.

Answer (score 0):

## [A0A0](https://esolangs.org/wiki/A0A0) and [FiM++](https://esolangs.org/wiki/FiM%2B%2B), 123 bytes

```
(
>P97
P98
P99

)
Dear Princess Celestia: A!
Today I learned B.
I said "cba"!
That's all about B!
Your faithful student, C.
```

The parentheses at the top open a block comment in FiM++, so the A0A0 code in it is ignored by FiM++. A0A0 starts at the second line because of the preceding `>` and then print "abc", halting on the empty line after it.
FiM++ ignores the block comment and just executes a basic program that prints "cba". The first and last lines are for the class declaration, the second and fourth lines are for the main method, with the third line actually printing "cba".