# No trailing but(t)s please!

Tags: code-golf, string

This challenge was inspired by [Yeah But No But Yeah](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/172036/55735).

---

[maxb](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/79994/maxb)´s colleague recently sent him the following piece of JavaScript as a joke:

```javascript
let butScript = (nrOfButs) => {
    for(var i = 0; i < nrOfButs; i++){
        if(i % 3 == 0){
            console.log("Yeah")
        }
        if(i % 2 == 0){
            console.log("But")
        }
        if(i % 3 == 1){
            console.log("No")
        }
    }
}
```

Since the code is not only overly long but also incorrect, I´ll suggest to maxb´s boss to fire that guy and hire one of you folks instead.

I can´t guarantee anything; but I reckon there´ll be a decent wage, health insurance and possibly a company car in it. All You have to do is
A) correct the code, so the Number of Buts printed is the same as asked in the parameter
B) correct the grammar. (see below)
C) make it as short as possible.

He might as well block my calls after that because he doesn´t like pennypickers; but who knows.

### Input

a non-negative integer, in any convenient way

### Output

`Yeah` and `No`, mostly separated by `But`s. The code above and the examples below should clarify the pattern.
Output should never end in a `But`.
And a sentence should always end with a stop (`.`) or exclamation mark; i.e. put one after every `No` that is directly followed by a `Yeah` (without a `But`) and one at the end of the output.
A single trailing "Yeah." may be printed (if you want to think positive), but that´s not a must.

You may print the output or return a list of strings.
Trailing blanks are acceptable, as well as a single leading **or** trailing newline.

### examples (input => possible output)

```
input 0:

Yeah.

input 1:

Yeah
But
No.

input 2:

Yeah
But
No
But
Yeah.

input 3:

Yeah
But
No
But
Yeah
But
No.
Yeah!       <optional>

...

input 5:

Yeah
But
No
But
Yeah
But
No.
Yeah
But
No
But
Yeah.
```

Comment: These programs should be able to be a bit shorter, though the period could add 2-3 bytes depending on the language. I'll have to create my own solution in MathGolf, but I don't think I'll be able to beat Jelly and 05AB1E for this one.

Comment: So if I understand correctly: 1. A dot should be added between every `No Yeah` or `Yeah No`. 2. A dot should be added at the very end. 3. A single line only containing `Yeah` or `No` should be removed. 4. When a sentence ends with a `But` the `But` should be removed? (not sure about this fourth one)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I think you're overcomplicating it. You just have to output \$2n+1\$ lines of "Yeah\nBut\nNo\nBut\nYeah\nBut\nNo\nBut..." and end with a period.

Comment: @maxb Then what is that dot between `No` and `Yeah` doing there in test case `n=5`? And the trailing `Yeah.` is gone for `n=3`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen my bad, I completely missed the \$n=5\$ thing. I'm a bit confused about it too. It would make the challenge more interesting though, in my opinion.

Comment: Hmm, shouldn't the output for `n=0` be empty?.. It won't go into the `for(var i = 0; i < nrOfButs; ...` loop, so won't print anything there. And there is also the rule "_A single trailing "Yeah." should be avoided._" to consider. There are a bit too many unanswered questions, so I've voted to close as unclear for now.. Might change after some clarification and better (bullet-point) specified rules or step-by-step examples of the given test cases.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I´ll have to think that through once more. Wasn´t sure if I should allow the additional `Yeah.`; and I mentioned that in the sandbox; but nobody seemed to care. A single `Yeah.` somehow makes sense; yet a trailing one ... on the other hand: think positive. ... give me a minute.

Comment: talking about grammar ... Does english allow capital words in the middle of a sentence?

Comment: @Titus Usually not, unless it's a name, city, etc. Only German capitalizes all nouns if I recall correctly. :)

Comment: I believe that the correct grammar for the English [pro-sentences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-sentence) you specify would be "Yeah, but no.", and "Yeah, but no, but yeah." (or maybe "Yeah, but no ...but yeah."), plus the optional "Yeah."

Comment: ^ Oh, I just noticed that "Yeah." is not *always* optional.

Comment: Wonder if I should add that additional grammar. But I guess that would mean quite a lot additional work for the <s>three</s> four existing answers. Is there any agreement on that in meta?

Comment: Typo: output for 3 ends with "Yeah!" shouldn't it be "Yeah." ?

Comment: @JayCe Apparently either is fine: "_And a sentence should always end with a stop (`.`) or **exclamation mark**_"

Comment: @KevinCruijssen my bad thanks for clarifying. So a mix of both is allowed I guess.

Comment: Very loosely related:https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/171168/55735 :D

Comment: @maxb: The example for `5` contradicts your instruction to "output `2n+1` lines of "Yeah\nBut\nNo\nBut\nYeah\nBut\nNo\nBut..." and end with a period".  It has a "Yeah" followed by a "No".  The samples also don't match the provided reference implementation.  I'm left still not understanding the task.

Comment: @recursive The "reference implementation" is for the original challenge, which has no punctuation at all. Should my description be unclear, let me know and I´ll try to clarify. If in doubt, follow the examples: The longest sentence is `Yeah But No But Yeah But No.`; shorter sentences only at the end of the output.

Comment: @recursive I left another comment stating that I'd misunderstood the challenge. From my understanding, the order of the words should be the same as for my original challenge. However, the input dictates how many times "but" is present in the output. The output never ends in "but", and there needs to be a period between "yeah" and "no" if there's no "but" in-between

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 80 bytes

```javascript
a=>{s='';for(i=0;i<a+1;i++)s+=(i%2==0?'yeah':'no')+(i<a?'\nbut\n':'.');return s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tcxBCsIwEIXhvaeQgkyG0JJW3RjHXqSbWBNNKYkkrSDi2WOXuhXylj@Pb1APFftg71Pp/EUnQ0nR6RUJQBofmCUh7VHxWlrOMXJidtMQiRaeWt3gAM4DcrZcWujceZ46t8QKUAY9zcGt4zv13kU/6mr0V2aYQFx9l6L8e8WvZFid0W4y2tuM9i6jvUdMHw)

Comment: please give explanation why you downvote my answer so i can improve in another chance

Comment: Hi, welcome to PPCG! I'm not the one who downvoted, but I completely agree with your comment above that people should leave an explanation of why they downvote!.. Anyway, I think one reason is because the `i%2==0` check isn't really correct in comparison to the code in the challenge description. I admit that the challenge description is a bit vague tbh (as I mentioned in the comments below it). I can only guess here, but the downvote is most likely due to a different than expected output. (PS: And the `yeah`, `no`, `but` should be Titlecase instead of lowercase, but that's an easy fix. ;) ).

Comment: Some more general tips not related to this challenge: You might want to add a [Try-it-online link](https://tio.run/#) with test code for your answers. In this case [this could be a possible TIO-link](https://tinyurl.com/y9vdzfnu). In addition, [Tips for golfing in JavaScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2682/52210) and [Tips for golfing in <all langauges>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5285/52210) might be interesting to read through; I see a few parts you can golf in your current answer. :) Don't let this downvote discourage you, and enjoy your stay!

Comment: RE: the downvote: The post automatically went onto the low quality post queue due to it's length and content (a post from a new user with only a code-block will trigger this). Then when it is edited to actually fix that a downvote is automatically applied - the community here views this "feature" as a bug (it's not a very friendly welcome!). Please ignore it; check the format of the edited post too (I've also added a language tag for the code-block to add syntax highlighting).

Comment: thank you for your reply guys, i learn from my mistake

Comment: @Vico Welcome to the page. I added a TIO link for your answer. Please notice that test case 5 is wrong. You must fix it or your answer will be not valid for this challenge.

Comment: Btw, [73 bytes here](https://tio.run/##tcyxDoIwEIDh3cdoYu4uDURQF6DyIgyc2GpJ0xqKJD59XXU16T/@wzfzxnFa7HMtfLjpZFRiddEbOxQmLBiVVQCt7VhWLUWp0O7rHnyABt6aH0ASrZQd9@Pgr6918GMDJVAbBaUp@BicLl24o8ED0e77iOLvxK9ksMpo1xntY0b7lNE@E6UP)

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz [72 bytes](https://tio.run/##tcyxCsIwEIDh3ccIyN0RWrTq0jQWfAB3oUOPmtRISaSpff246irkH//he/LKcZjdayl8uJtkdWJ9NitPKGyYMWqnAZRrNCuKUqPbVi1cA9RwM/wAkuikbLjtO395L53vayiBVBSUhuBjmEw5hREt7og230cUfyd@JYv7jHaV0T5ktI8Z7RNR@gA) :)

Comment: **Downvotes have nothing to do with being welcoming**, again... it's just that somebody (the Community bot) thinks the post is low-quality, that's all.

Comment: Incorrect for N>3. There should be a new sentence after every "Yeah But No But Yeah But No."

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>105</s> 81 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,s=1:(n|s)*' 'and'\nBut\n'.join((['Yeah','No']*2)[:n+1])+'.\n'+f(n-3,0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIU@n2NbQSiOvplhTS11BPTEvRT0mz6m0JCZPXS8rPzNPQyNaPTI1MUNdR90vXz1Wy0gz2ipP2zBWU1tdD6hGO00jT9dYx0Dzf0FRZl6JQpqGqeZ/AA)

<sub>- 24 bytes, thanks to ovs</sub>

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>48</s> 47 bytes

```
.+
*
L$`__?_?|^
Yeah$&.
__
_¶But¶Yeah
_
¶But¶No
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0@bS4vLRyUhPt4@3r4mjisyNTFDRU2PKz6eK/7QNqfSkkPbQEJc8VxQnl/@//@mAA) Explanation:

```
.+
*
```

Convert to unary.

```
L$`__?_?|^
Yeah$&.
```

Match up to three `_`s at a time. Also handle the zero edge case as a match. Each match results in at least a `Yeah` with a trailing `.`.

```
__
_¶But¶Yeah
```

A match of 2 or 3 `_`s results in a `But` `Yeah` in the second position.

```
_
¶But¶No
```

The other `_`s turn into `But` `No`.

52 bytes in Retina 0.8.2:

```
.+
$*
M!`11?1?
%`^.*
Yeah$&.
11
1¶But¶Yeah
1
¶But¶No
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRYvLVzHB0NDe0J5LNSFOT4srMjUxQ0VNj8vQkMvw0Dan0pJD20BCXIZcUJ5f/v//pgA) Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
M!`11?1?
```

Match up to three `1`s at a time.

```
%`^.*
Yeah$&.
```

Add a leading `Yeah` and trailing `.` for each match. The `^.*` allows it to work for the zero case too.

```
11
1¶But¶Yeah
1
¶But¶No
```

Add in the `But` `Yeah` and/or `No` as above.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands),  <s>44</s>  <s>42</s> <s>34</s> 31 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

[<sup>Crossed out &nbsp;44&nbsp; is no longer regular 44 :)</sup>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/170188/crossed-out-44-is-still-regular-44)

```
[Ðd_#3‚ßÝ„¥æ€¸#sè'€³¶.øý'.«™,3-
```

Also prints the optional `Yeah.`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AUAAv/9vc2FiaWX//1vDkGRfIzPigJrDn8Od4oCewqXDpuKCrMK4I3PDqCfigqzCs8K2LsO4w70nLsKr4oSiLDMt//81) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##AUoAtf9vc2FiaWX/NUVOw5As/1vDkGRfIzPigJrDn8Od4oCewqXDpuKCrMK4I3PDqCfigqzCs8K2LsO4w70nLsKr4oSiLDMt/33Ctj//NQ).

**Explanation:**

```python
[               # Loop indefinitely:
 Ð              #  Triplicate the top value
                #  (which is the implicit input `n` in the first iteration)
  d_            #  Pop one copy, and if it's negative:
    #           #   Stop the infinite loop
  3‚ß           #  Take the max `m` of another copy of `n` and 3
     Ý„¥æ€¸#sè  #  Create an alternating list of "yeah" and "no" of size `m`
  '€³¶.ø       '#  Push "\nbut\n"
        ý       #  Join the alternating list with this as delimiter
  '.«          '#  Append a trailing "."
     ™          #  Titlecase each word in this string
      ,         #  Pop and print it with trailing newline
  3-            #  Decrease `n` by 3 for the next iteration
```

[See this 05AB1E tips of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `„¥æ€¸` is "yeah no" and `'€³` is "but".

Comment: Your indents seem kinda broken :) Though maybe it's just me

Comment: @seadoggie01 Hmm, do you have a screenshot perhaps? For me it looks [like this](https://i.postimg.cc/Bbpp0CN8/05_AB1_E_explanation_indentation.png). Although I do see messed up indentations with APL answers a lot, so I can imagine it happens with 05AB1E as well when using a font with different widths.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/x5vSNql I think that's not how it's supposed to look?

Comment: Oh... I just read your comment all the way through and saw the link, sorry. ("ADHD much?" "Yeah")

Comment: @seadoggie01 The indentation is intended this time. It's too long to put all after one-another, and this seems kinda logical to me. The highlighting color is due to the `'` (single quote) unfortunately. I could remove the highlighting completely if that's better, but then everything including the comments is just black. I wish there was a hightlighting specific for 05AB1E, but unfortunately I have to use the Python one, which doesn't work very well when I use single quotes, as you can see. ;)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 82 bytes

```javascript
_=>_>3?f(3)+f(_-3):[...Array(_+1)].map((a,i)=>i%2?'No':'Yeah').join`\nBut\n`+'.\n'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tcxBC4IwGIDhez9DiH0f5ke6uggq9QO6R8YcutXENlEL@vXrWtdg7/E9PL18ybmdzLgk1nXK68KLohQlrzRwjDWIhGN@IaLDNMk3iDjFKz3kCCA3BovSrLOKnRzL2VnJO0PqnbFNbY/PpbZNzKi2zLfOzm5QNLgbaNgirr5PlPxd9CtpSAPaWUCbB7R3Ae09ov8A)

Comment: @Titus there is a new sentence. Check it out again and compare to the given test case

Comment: Maybe I got the TiOs mixed up. Approved.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>80</s> 74 bytes

```c
f(a,i){for(i=0;-i>~a;)printf("%s%s\n","YeahNo"+i%2*5,i++<a?"\nBut":".");}
```

-6 bytes thanks to @Jonathan Frech

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY1BCsIwEEVdewoZCWRMKkXopmkVPIB7oRBCm@iATqWtK2mvHlsX7j483vt1Uj8c32IM0mnCT2g7SWVqEjpOzuCrIx6CBNGLvmLQcPXuvrq0oEgcdpkmpQp3gorP7wFy2AOaMW4bH4j9xkr7D1QcpGgwXyIWdZiRWT8d8Tx@p7acUqOULTKDizjGLw)

Comment: [74 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY1BCsIwEEVdewoZCWRMKkXopmkVPIB7oRBCm@iATqWtK2mvHlsX7j483vt1Uj8c32IM0mnCT2g7SWVqEjpOzuCrIx6CBNGLvmLQcPXuvrq0oEgcdpkmpQp3gorP7wFy2AOaMW4bH4j9xkr7D1QcpGgwXyIWdZiRWT8d8Tx@p7acUqOULTKDizjGLw).

Comment: Not working for `n=5` case.

Comment: Incorrect for N>3. There should be a new sentence after every "Yeah But No But Yeah But No."