# Create a program that prints the number of characters it has, in words

Tags: code-golf, self-referential

Create a program which prints the amount of characters its source has in English words.

If your program is nine letters long it should print "nine".

Capitalization is ignored: in case you're printing "one" (somehow) you can print "one", "oNe", "ONE" or anything else.

Base ten is required.

Proper spacing is also required.

In the (unlikely but just for specification) case your program reaches one billion characters or more, use the American number scale. A billion here is 10^9 and a million is 10^6.

Do not use "one hundred and one": use "one hundred one".

Do not use the hyphen. Print forty four, not forty-four.

Test cases with a fake program:

```
10.(96 0s later)..01 prints one HuNdreD ONE -- okay: proper spacing, no "and"
10.(96 0s later)..01 prints one HuNdreDONE -- not okay: wrong spacing
10.(96 0s later)..01 prints one thousand two hundred two -- not okay: base 3 rather than base 10
10...(999999996 0s later) prints nine hundred ninety-nine million nine hundred ninety-nine thousand nine hundred ninety-six: not okay, wrong number and includes hyphens
```

Golfy challenge, as always: shortest code wins. You're free to post after the green tick has been given, though. This serves more for completeness for hard to program languages. Malbolge, anyone?

Comment: `Proper spacing is also required.` Does this mean no trailing spaces in the output?

Comment: To solve it in Unary, is there a list of larger units?

Answer (score 67):

## [Poetic](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/index.html), 400 bytes

```
Type fourhundred chars? I say, I think I have an angle.
I say "Gosh, could I just go create some poem? Clearly it comes a long way, writing stuff I say."
I compose the entire written poem, and someone reads a tiny, tiny portion.
"Surely, it all is garbage," cried a big fat crybaby.
Would HE frankly notice how many long, tedious hours I took?
The crybaby whined a lot. I watched, then I ignored him.
```

[Try it online!](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/index.html?LZBNboUwDIT3nMJijbgCi6pqu@6TujbEJCkhRvkp4vSvE1opSmRnNN/Yj@sQWrUmV6NJYmhxnPJEH5T5GvAU5@OG1/GPEEccG2Ts7n/q3zS7gRatwUDzXXMhq7Qk4SKUdRc6VPaJXoJwChf5AvEumZiCRktng5zJF48il7quf@SxBwHKQ7MggpDE4pPc0iLxdh2QxdwQjUJAmmYLJ1i2G6JUvMax6z9rkoA28BwC@UyW08xWhh5hPcZmmr2llZEvXTPP19h93VO9v9KaOG4IH7X4RcjpSTvDv00AlBivNaNdU24LU92m7oHM/050YoU3ImgZoTi5LE7M0AaLqL2N2lbv/D4@nzObXw)

Prints `Four HunDrED`. (I tried to make it print some number in the 300s, but I can't seem to do so in under 400 bytes.)

Poetic is an esolang I made in 2018 for a class project. It's basically brainfuck with word-lengths instead of symbols.

Comment: ```Clearly it comes a long way, writing stuff I say.``` Beautiful poem, have a +1.

Comment: @A_ Thanks, it's always fun to create coherent sentences based on pre-determined word lengths.

Answer (score 38):

## [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/) (3 bytes)

```
一
```

[Try it online!](https://translate.google.com/?text=%E4%B8%80)

It's the Chinese character for "*one*" (matching the number of characters in the source code), though the score's due to the character itself being 3 bytes.

---

## [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/) (3 bytes)

```
tre
```

[Try it online!](https://translate.google.com/?text=tre)

It's Italian for "*three*".

Comment: You can add a `&tl=en` at the end of your URLs to force it to show in English. My Google translate was set to English to Persian from a previous translation and after opening your links, it was showing the resulting numbers in Persian :P [Here](https://translate.google.com/?text=دو&tl=en) is also a 2 chars version, converting Persian `دو` to English `Two`.

Comment: ...also (Latin-ised) [Hindi "do"](https://translate.google.com/#sl=hi&tl=en&text=do).

Comment: and albanian dy

Comment: `to` is Norwegian and Danish for two (and we also say `tre` for three). Google translate doesn't autodetect that one, though.

Comment: `cinco`, that means five in Spanish

Comment: *insert obligatory "google translate isnt a programming language" complaint*

Answer (score 35):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 40 bytes

```
+[+++++>++<]>.+++++++++.+++.++.+++++.+++
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fO1obBOy0tW1i7fS0YUAPgvXgnP//AQ)

The last three characters don't actually do anything useful, but it's easier to output `forty` than `thirty seven`.

The ascii code for `f` is 102, which is 2/5 of 255, found by the initial loop. After that, all the characters in the output just happen to be in ascending alphabetical order.

Comment: Whoops, I don't know why I was trying to use different cells for each letter... Nice

Comment: @HiddenBabel Thanks. `forty` turned out really well. I think for `NINETY` the optimum would be one cell for NNTY and one cell for IE

Comment: So I guess you already looked for `thirty` with one cell for `trty` and one for `hi`? I can't find a singular loop that will set both of them close by.

Comment: Indeed, forty is the only number whose letters are in ascending alphabetical order.

Answer (score 30):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 2 bytes

Well, MathGolf has a string compression library that seems to compress "two" to 1 byte. You need a command to decompress this.

```
╩_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///R1JXx//8DAA)

Comment: Now we're looking for a language where there's a 1-char command that prints `one`, or where the empty program prints `zero`. That's going to be interesting.

Comment: @Nat MathGolf can [use Code Page 437](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf#usage), in which `╩` is one byte (0xCA)

Comment: @Nat MathGolf has a built-in [dictionary](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/resources/dictionary.py), the first 256 words of which can be accessed using [`╩` followed by one byte](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt#L205). The word at index 95 (the code point for `_`) is `"two"`, so `"two"` is pushed to the stack and implicitly printed when the program exits. (I think, I haven't used MathGolf)

Answer (score 17):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 15 bytes

```python
exit("fifteen")
```

...prints to STDERR.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P7Uis0RDPS0zrSQ1NU9d8/9/AA)** (see the "debug" panel)

Comment: I had `print('sixteen')`, you win :)

Comment: `print'ten'`, in Python 2?

Comment: @JuanCa [yes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194486/53748)

Answer (score 17):

## [COW](https://bigzaphod.github.io/COW/), 800 bytes

```
MoO!!
MoO MoO!!
MoO MoO MoO!!
MoO MoO MoO MoO!!
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO!!
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO!!
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO!!
MoO MoO MoO MoO MMM MoO MoO MoO!!
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO!!
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO!!
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO!!
MoO MoO MoO MoO Moo MoO MoO MoO MoO Moo MOo MOo!!
Moo MoO Moo MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO!!
MoO MoO Moo MMM Moo MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO!!
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO!!
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO!!
Moo MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO Moo MOo MOo!!
MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo Moo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo Moo MMM!!
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO Moo MMM MoO Moo MOo Moo!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S84v///fN99fUZELSCqgsDB52EVwi@KXwSXr60u8ftJUkaYSp@p8Baxi/mAM1pGPRyVhe/KhYZBPff9QVzfchHwydaOEmj@ch8D5WMRwYUi4UeSjfKTUBzdV8f9/AA)

Prints `EIGHT HUNDRED`

Comment: I think ```ONE THOUSAND``` is expected.

Comment: @A_ `EIGHT HUNDRED` then! Mooooo!

Answer (score 16):

## CSS, 30 bytes

```css
body::after{content:'thirty';}
```

---

## CSS (Google Chrome only), 26 bytes

This should be saved in an empty file between `<style>` and `</style>` tag, doesn't work on FireFox or Stack Exchange's code snippets. Tested on Windows Chrome 77.

```css
:after{content:'twenty six
```

Comment: Never would have thought of this one: +1

Answer (score 15):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 4 bytes

```php
four
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P8/Lb@06P9/AA)

---

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 9 bytes

```php
<?= nine;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt5WIS8zL9X6/38A)

Comment: Your first example also works with `cat`.  (The unix command, not the animal.)

Answer (score 15):

## Malbolge, 40 bytes

```
(CB%#9]~}5:3Wyw/4-Qrqq.'&Jkj(h~%|Bd.-==;
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a code break-down, or if you can't say how it *works* then how it was produced?

Comment: There exists a certain [Malbolge generator](https://github.com/zb3/malbolge-tools). It is very useful in generating short Malbolge code. :)

Answer (score 12):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 10 bytes

```
84.69.78.@
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/fwkTPzFLP3ELP4f9/AA)**

#### How?

```
  - initially the main stack contains infinite zeros    [0,0,0,...]
8 - multiply the top of the stack by ten and add eight  [8,0,0,...]
4 - multiply the top of the stack by ten and add four   [84,0,0,...]
. - pop, mod 256, print character                       T
6 - multiply the top of the stack by ten and add six    [6,0,0,...]
9 - multiply the top of the stack by ten and add nine   [69,0,0,...]
. - pop, mod 256, print character                       E
7 - multiply the top of the stack by ten and add seven  [7,0,0,...]
8 - multiply the top of the stack by ten and add eight  [78,0,0,...]
. - pop, mod 256, print character                       N
@ - exit
```

Comment: As an IP address range this answer geolocates to the United Kingdom with Vodafone wireless broadband.

Comment: @PurpleP Ha ha awesome.

Comment: @PurpleP First thing I thought of when seeing this answer (IP address, not UK Vodafone)

Answer (score 11):

## [Piet](https://github.com/cincodenada/bertnase_npiet), 90 codels

[image]

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZJNSwMxEIbv/or3KIoh3x8ehGyStb0sYgteFLyIFDwIFk/qX68z2922nhzCMsySJ@/MO@@bl@1uJ6e4RkxwErbBBsgKmaEyf6WcT4VNsBHWwmlA3A23Yorlot6f7UmKWMc76SQnVoTUx0pL8AHNEOtPvIqJpYnVThCujBIsrIKz0BHOwFXEhqhYYJF71uOy5vX56onziWWIZSRLKAZ9RN9DZ5iG0o11BeOhiZVRLZRnNCQDLm6EFP6KstXEssSiQezfVwqZNBZWwQ2OTVEld0z0VJdIHbA4X83tCf920OWIFUhFQXUIhhukm3TICt1B9ugVOoVgYQyS5xw/QnwshRguCbc1B5YnVvYIHtYgFIQeocIEKOo3IUV0Fbmgd0g0LM9QiM/yJb7DPPztxArso4YigxoqTY0uBESP0nj8pM4F@MR/6Zcf3Tz4mIeHjRDPs67ILAVVeAmSg5bcCyuS7ONxReTor2P6yAL1th4XrA0TK/HsLTKp0PxspFX8N6roSMxu9ws)

### In pseudo-code:

The characters are pushed onto stack. To save space, their ASCII values minus 100 are stored. When the string is built, a loop pops, adds 100 to, and prints each character to STDOUT.

```
    ; Place sentinel 0 on stack
    push 1
    not

    ; Place 21 (y) on stack
    push 7
    push 3
    mul

    ; Place 16 (t) on stack
    push 4
    dup
    mul

    ; Place 1, 10, 5, 10 (e, n, i, n) on stack
    push 1
    push 10
    push 5
    push 10

    ; Check if top of stack is non-zero
    ; Place a 1 if it is, a 0 otherwise
    dup
    not
    not

write_loop:
    ; Turn DP (Direction Pointer) as many steps
    ; clock-wise as value on top of stack
    ; If we had a zero on stack, we continue into
    ; the yellow area and get trapped, ending execution
    pointer

    ; If not, we continue
    ; Add 100 to top of stack
    push 5
    push 4
    push 5
    mul
    mul
    add

    ; Pop and print character
    outc

    ; Turn DP one step to the right
    push 1
    pointer

    dup
    not
    not

    ; Check if top of stack is non-zero
    ; Place a 1 if it is, a 0 otherwise
    dup
    not
    not

    ; We're now back at beginning of the writing loop, sort of like a jmp write_loop
```

Comment: How many bytes is this?

Comment: @JoKing Depends on the fileformat for the image, which is why Piet is generally counted in codels.

Comment: Yes, but this is [tag:code-golf], so it is [measured in bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10996/76162)

Comment: @JoKing That is curious. I have not seen that comment on any other Piet answers.

Answer (score 10):

## [Emoji](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Emoji), 18 bytes

```
⛽eighteen➡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83Nz8r8///R7L2pmekZJampeR/mz5rxaN7C//8B)

---

## [Emoji](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Emoji), 8 chars

```
⛽eight➡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83Nz8r8///R7L2pmekZJR/mz5rxaN7C//8B)

Comment: ⛽➡  ...gasoline makes the car go?

Answer (score 10):

## [Piet](https://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) + [ascii-piet](https://github.com/dloscutoff/ascii-piet), 40 bytes (3×14=42 codels)

```
ttllldabknmEmqusbeeeeeute_rbacqtuljvff ?
```

[Try Piet online!](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJxNTEEKwzAM-4vOCsRt0zX5SulhdBkUuq2Q7TT69yk5zRZCtmR_sb5uGWmePT3H1tbRxAMjLzSjiaOwcNY0MLCvbl3_Iei-qkmxrvn6ERT3skZO1KO-IdbQQpR8IME5B2LfHtLmVZpyWZHu171kYnsen7c8nD-a3ycB)

[image]

Prints `FORTY`. A fantastic use case of a white trap :) Also I like the fact that the program is packed so perfectly.

#### How it works

A classic 3-row layout with a `1 DP+` at the left edge.

```
Commands        Stack
2 3 dup dup *   [2 3 9]
dup dup 1 - *   [2 3 9 72]
2 -             [2 3 9 70]   Setup the stack so that repeatedly adding and
                             printing gives FORT
dup outC + dup outC +
dup 1 DP+ outC + dup outC
                [84]   Print FORT, turning right at R2C1
>               [84]   No-op (stack underflow) to take care of the crossing
5 + outC        []     Finally print Y
```

---

## [Piet](https://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) + [ascii-piet](https://github.com/dloscutoff/ascii-piet), 50 bytes (4×13=52 codels)

```
ttttliametf M tt iillldedMnjlvjcfll i Mkmuuljcbjjj
```

[Try Piet online!](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJwtjNEOgjAUQ__lPnfJrsqQ_crCg8GZkKCSoE-Gf7cF1qVdt3P3s-F9r5ZLidiV4BFOd3jL7md4x9ajMEWoRu20yU8C5WJaXHVH90azG7EPHL8o0FDpgC5MSUDX97ClzpYthGCwaXzy7JGLrS6D5cdtWipsfM3fD99s_QNFMSv_)

[image]

Prints `fifty`. Not sure if I can do 40, but I guess pretty much unlikely.

#### How it works

The execution path: First row -> (turn right) -> 3rd-to-last column -> (turn right) -> last row in reverse -> (turn right twice) -> 3rd row -> transfer to 2nd row at the red 5 block -> end.

```
...>>>>>>>v X
 .. ....>>+>X
>>>>>>>.. v X
^<<<<<<<<..
```

Commands:

```
Commands          Stack
6 dup 3 * 1 - *   [102]   Push 102 ('f')
dup outC          [102]   Print 'f'
dup 3 + outC      [102]   Print 'i' (= 'f' + 3)
dup outC          [102]   Print 'f'
2 dup dup +       [102 2 4]
dup * - -         [116]   Add 14 to 'f' (= 't')
dup outC          [116]   Print 't'
5 inC + outC      []      Add 5 and print 'y'
                          (inC is ignored; it is to reuse the crossing purple cell)
```

Answer (score 9):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 6 bytes, 17 cycles

```
s;i>x@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/7/YOtOuwuH/fwA)

Now the letters `six` are in more natural order, and the program finishes one cycle faster.

#### How it works

For more thorough explanation, see the previous answer below.

```
 A B
C > D
 E .
Execution path: ABC>CBAD>ADB.>.CE
                ^^  ^^    ^^    ^
                s;  i;    x;    @
```

---

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 6 bytes, 18 cycles

```
x>i;s@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/7/CLtO62OH/fwA)

Inspired by [boboquack's 9-byte solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194788/78410). The following quote was a big hint:

> I'm slightly disappointed that I couldn't get `six` to work (that would be pushing it with *three characters, one output, one redirection and one termination*).

#### How it works (or, How I got to this solution)

A 6-byte program is laid out on a hexagon of side length 2, and the 7th instruction is necessarily a no-op:

```
 ? ?
? ? ?
 ? .
```

Since I needed at least one mirror, I tried out various mirrors placed at various places, until I found this:

```
 A >
B C D
 E .
```

Assuming the current memory is always positive (and there are no branches/mirrors/IP changers among `ABCDE`), the IP follows the path

```
A>ADCB>.CAD>DAC.BE
```

The cell `C` is run exactly three times, and the cells right before `C` are `D`, `B`, and `A` respectively. And the cell `E` is first run after three runs of `C`. This is exactly what we want: write one of `s`, `i`, or `x` on the memory and print it, and then terminate!

Now back to the actual source code:

```
 x >
i ; s
 @ .
```

And the execution path, linearized, with significant instructions emphasized:

```
x>xs;i>.;xs>sx;.i@
   ^^^  ^    ^^  ^
   ^^              Print 's'
     ^  ^          Print 'i'
             ^^    Print 'x'
                 ^ Terminate
```

Answer (score 8):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

Well, SOGL has a string compression library that seems to compress "three" to 3 bytes.

```
@0‘
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=QDAldTIwMTg_,v=0.12)

Comment: Gratz, unless a language exists which prints zero, nowt, or nought with an empty program this is probably as good as it'll get.

Comment: ...I stand [corrected](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194491/53748)!

Answer (score 8):

## Brainf***, 90 bytes

```
+[+[>>+<+<-]>]>[>+>+>+>+>+>+<<<<<<-]>.>-----.>.>---------.>++++++.>+++++++++++.<+><><><><>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fO1o72s5O20bbRjfWLtYu2k4bAW3AACiuZ6cLAnowBoSjDQYwGsKx0bazgcL//wE)

Answer (score 7):

## [Lost](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Lost), 30 bytes

```
v<<<<<<<>>>>>>>
>%?"thirt/J"+@
```

<s>Contains the unprintable character ESC with unicode value 27 after the `^` on the second line.</s> Thanks to *@JoKing* getting rid of the unprintable (for the same byte-count).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/v8wGAuwggMtO1V6pJCOzqETfS0nb4f///7qOAA) or [verify that it's deterministic](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/v8wGAuwggMtO1V6pJCOzqETfS0nb4f///7qO/3XDAA).

#### Explanation:

**Explanation of the language in general:**

Lost is a 2D path-walking language. Most 2D path-walking languages start at the top-left position and travel towards the right by default. Lost is unique however, in that ***both the start position AND starting direction it travels in is completely random***. So making the program deterministic, meaning it will have the same output regardless of where it starts or travels, can be quite tricky.

A Lost program of 2 rows and 5 characters per row can have 40 possible program flows. It can start on any one of the 10 characters in the program, and it can start traveling up/north, down/south, left/west, or right/east.

In Lost you therefore want to lead everything to a starting position, so it'll follow the designed path you want it to. In addition, you'll usually have to clean the stack when it starts somewhere in the middle.

**Explanation of the program:**

All arrows, including the reflect `/` in the string, will lead the path towards the leading `>` on the second line. From there the program flow is as follows:

- `>`: travel in an east/right direction
- `%`: Put the safety 'off'. In a Lost program, an `@` will terminate the program, but only when the safety is 'off'. When the program starts, the safety is always 'on' by default, otherwise a program flow starting at the exit character `@` would immediately terminate without doing anything. The `%` will turn this safety 'off', so when we now encounter an `@` the program will terminate (if the safety is still 'on', the `@` will be a no-op instead).
- `?`: Clean the top value on the stack. In some program flows it's highly likely we have a partial string on the stack, so we use this to wipe the stack clean of that potential string.
- `"`: Start a string, which means it will push the integer code-points of the characters used.
- `thirt/J`: Push the code-points for these characters, being `116 104 105 114 116 47 74` respectively
- `"`: We're done pushing code-points of this string
- `+`: Add the top two values together: (47+74=) `121`
- `@`: Terminate the program if the safety is 'off' (which it is at this point). After which all the values on the stack will be output implicitly. Using the `-A` program argument flag, these code-points will be output as characters instead.

*Two things to note:*

The top part could also have been `v<<<<<<<<<<<<<<` instead. Lost will wrap around to the other side when moving in a direction. So using `v<<<<<<<>>>>>>>` could be a slightly shorter path, and since it's the same byte-count anyway, why not use it. :)
Also, the first line contains an additional trailing `>` to make the byte-count from 29 to 30.

Comment: This is a nice find!

Comment: @ouflak Thanks, although I must admit it's very similar as the Hello World! answer in Lost. It took a while before I realized I could use an unprintable to output thirty, though. Otherwise I would have had to settle with forty with a bunch more no-op trailing `>`.

Comment: You can do [`/J`](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/v8wGAuwggMtO1V6pJCOzqETfS0nb4f///7qOAA) to avoid the unprintable if you like

Comment: @JoKing Ah, I tried some combinations with both addition and subtraction of the arrow, but forgot about the reflects `/` and `\`. Thanks, that indeed looks better. :)

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript, <s>16</s> 10 bytes

-6 each from Night2's suggestion in the comments

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/v6AoM68koSQ1L@H/fwA) (`alert` doesn't work in TIO, so I'm using `print`)

```
alert`ten`
```

---

### Javascript, <s>26</s> 20 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Pzk/rzg/J1UvJz89oaQ8Na@kMuH/fwA)

```
console.log`twenty`;
```

Comment: @Night2 The JS `print` function is used for printers, not console output, I think.

Comment: @Night2 Ah, makes sense. I'll update the TIO, but keep it as `alert` on here since it's more recognizable (sort of)

Comment: Where can I find some explanation regarding the syntax used here? I've never seen this before (ommiting the brackets), but it indeed works with any function. What's it called?

Comment: @TomášZato They're called tagged templates. I found some info on them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), in the `Tagged templates` section

Answer (score 6):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 3 bytes

-1 from Jono2906 for reminding me the string compression

2 can play the 3 byte game!

```
‘0⅀
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##y05N////UcMMg0etDf//AwA)

### Old answer, 4 bytes

You can't get shorter than 4. (Without using string compression of course.) 4 is the smallest English word that is the same length as the number it represents.

Just some good old-fashioned Ascii/auto-pushing Keg golfing!

```
four
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//8/Lb@06P9/AA)

### Explanation

```
four#   Push 4 onto the stack
#Implicit Print
```

Comment: Ah, didn't see your answer when I posted mine. Good job!

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
“Ɱ9»
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xHG9dZHtr9/z8A)**

Answer (score 6):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 64 bytes

```cs
class P{static void Main(){System.Console.Write("sixty four");}}
```

I had to see what a non-competitive language would score.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTc4vSv3/PzknsbhYIaC6uCSxJDNZoSw/M0XBNzEzT0OzOriyuCQ1V885P684PydVL7wosyRVQ6k4s6KkUiEtv7RISdO6tvb/fwA)

Comment: [sixty?](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTc4vSv3/PzknsbhYIUChurgksSQzWaEsPzNFwTcxM09Dszq4srgkNVfPOT@vOD8nVS@8KLMkVUOpOLOipFJJ07q29v9/AA "C# (.NET Core) – Try It Online")

Comment: Would be [nine](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTc4vSv2fnJNYXKwQUF1ckliSmaxQlp@ZouCbmJmnoVkdXFlckpqr51aal2xTXFKUmZeuA6Hs0mz/x9vaKeVl5qUq/beGqnPOzyvOz0nVCy/KLEnVSNNQUtLUtK6t/Q8A "C# (.NET Core) – Try It Online") if lambdas were allowed.

Answer (score 6):

## Shakespeare Programming Language, 800 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVFLDoIwEL3KHEAblsadJi7cGVgZ46LUESvlEyhRTo9TCUIBgSbTTOfz@t5Mnqqq2jgO7EuN@ZoO3KVSmLHdk79X7FSIcMV2QsNxyzyBMRrncog1ZmBKgMc3MFVX89qekwJkDvqBkBcRJHfbE4WP5HLwZfA1wTX0X3QzL0UeEkzJBoglBayWZcWpDOYLF6DplxTY3L8Mn@TfkO3a@Fc92KFWFyOMfBo@paao1khfwu3c@3xpJgS/YDL9xsZqAFuKi4IrNbc386mlZamwzg7@kKq3YKuaJjUqoA1U1Qc)

(Whitespace added for readability)

```
800 Bytes---- filler.Ajax,.Puck,.Act I:.
Scene I:.[Enter Ajax and Puck]Ajax:
You is the sum ofthe sum ofthe cube ofa big big cat a big big cat a cat.Speak thy.
You is the sum ofyou a big big cat.Speak thy.
You is the sum ofyou a big pig.Speak thy.
You is the sum ofyou a cat.Speak thy.
You is the sum ofyou twice twice the sum ofa big cat a cat.Speak thy.
You big big big big big cat.Speak thy.
You is twice the sum ofyou a big big cat.Remember you.Speak thy.
You is the sum oftwice you the cube ofthe sum ofa big pig a pig.Speak thy.
You is the sum ofyou the sum ofa big big big pig a cat.Speak thy.
Recall.You is the sum ofyou a big big pig.Remember you.Remember you.Speak thy.
You is the sum ofyou twice the sum ofa big big big cat a pig.Speak thy.
Recall.You is the sum ofyou a cat.Speak thy.
Recall.Speak thy.
```

Prints EIGHT HunDRED. The math to get from one letter to another was very complicated and there was little room for error. This is probably improvable in terms of code, but 700 is most likely impossible.
Little improvement saving 2 bytes in the actual code because I missed out on optimizing 2*(4+2) to 2*2*(2+1) for some reason.

Answer (score 5):

## Excel, 4 bytes

```
four
```

Uninteresting answer, not using a formula.

---

#### Excel, 5 bytes

```
'five
```

Using a formula, requires at least 3 extra bytes (`=`, `"`, `"`).

#### Excel, 6 bytes

```
="six"
```

#### Excel, 12 bytes

```
="tw"&"elve"
=T("twelve")
```

#### Excel, 14 bytes

```
=T("fourteen")
```

#### Excel, 16 bytes

```
=IF(1,"sixteen")
```

#### Excel, 18 bytes and upwards

```
=TRIM(" % ")
```

Insert required text, padded with required whitespace.

Answer (score 5):

## [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/), <s>164</s> 160 bytes

```
"One hundred sixty" is waiting at Writer's Depot.
Go to Writer's Depot: w 1 r 3 l 2 l.
Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.
Go to Post Office:n 1 r 2 r 1 l.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcyxCsIwFIXhvU9x6OJWaN06C47t5hzam3ix5Ibkhtanj1EQxOEsP5xPzcGltJMn3LNfI61IfOgTVnJswQm7YWXvYBS3yErxlHChINo1V4HKXx139Ig4Y8OArWtmXh45wCCYlMg7inDy9upzlqSYrOWFvthPGv1HGur6KpXyAg)

This also throws an error because I don't return the taxi to the garage so my boss fires me. It's not a requirement to not throw errors, though, so I guess I'm fired.

Comment: Yeah, that's all and well.

Answer (score 5):

## [vemf](https://selaere.github.io/vemf/doc/docs.html), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
"five
```

Outputs `five`. [try it online](https://selaere.github.io/vemf/wasm/index.html?code=ImZpdmU&fmt=0)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Looks like an interesting language.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 16 bytes

```python
print("sixteen")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ6k4s6IkNTVPSfP/fwA)

Also works in [Proton](https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@/@/oCgzr0RDqTizoiQ1NU9J8/9/AA).

Comment: I think you just beat me to this. Same code works in both Python 3 and Lua.

Answer (score 4):

## [ink](https://github.com/inkle/ink), 4 bytes

```
Four
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8zL/v/fLb@06P9/AA)

Predictably enough, it prints `Four`

Answer (score 4):

## [Turing Machine Code](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html), <s>60</s> 50 bytes

```
0 _ f r 1
1 _ i r 2
2 _ f r 3
3 _ t r 4
4 _ y r 50
```

[Try it online!](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?df0baa71e99110226ccde54ba7797a43)

As an added bonus, if that counts for anything, it has the number in the code as well.

**Edit:** *Found a shorter solution which still contains the number of bytes in the code.*

Comment: It doesn't count but nice stuff.

Answer (score 4):

### Batch, 10 bytes

```
@ echo ten
```

If you think the extra space after the `@` is ugly, the next possible answer is:

```
@echo twelve
```

Comment: Why not just `echo nine`?

Comment: @Night2 Because that echos the command `echo nine` as well as its output.

Comment: But running directly from command prompt, doesn't do that (unless it doesn't count as Batch).

Comment: @Night2 No, that would be a snippet, or a REPL, or something along those lines.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 3 bytes

```
“„í
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcOcRw3zDq/9/x8A)

Using dictionary

Comment: Works with `'` instead of `“` too. Also why legacy?

Comment: @Makonede yes it seems to work but honestly Idk osabie I wrote this following the docs, I was sure it has a dictionary. One of the most interesting esoteric languages for sure.. Maybe I 'll try to learn in the future!

Answer (score 4):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/),  <s>15</s>  9 bytes

```bash
echo nine
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I18hLzMv9f9/AA)

Thanks to:
- @Night2 for saving me 6 bytes

Comment: [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I18hLzMv9f9/AA "Bash – Try It Online"). By the way you can click on  icon in https://tio.run and copy/paste "Code Golf submission (Stack Exchange)" section here to have auto generated answer with correct formatting.

Comment: @Night2 Thank your for the improvment and the tip :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 9 bytes

```
n;i;@;e\\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/z/POtPawTo1Jub/fwA)

I'm slightly disappointed that I couldn't get `six` to work (that would be pushing it with three characters, one output, one redirection and one termination).

### *Not* <s>How it works</s>

This Hexagony program looks almost like normal code!

```
n;i;@;e\\
n;i;       Pushes n and prints it, then pushes i and prints it
    @;     Retrieves the bottom of the stack (n) and prints it
      e\\  Pushes e and terminates the program, printing implicitly
```

### How it works

[image: nine.png]

Input starts on the blue path, storing the value `n` then printing it with `;`. It picks up the value `i`, then jumps to the third line where it hits a mirror. This takes it to the diagonal path, reentering the value `i` then printing it with `;`.

From the bottom left corner, since the current value of `i` is truthy, it jumps to the red stream starting in the top-left corner, taking `n` then printing it with `;`. The two mirrors redirect it and then it jumps to the `e`. Finally, it jumps from the middle of the bottom edge to the middle of the top edge, printing the `e` with `;` and terminating with `@`.

---

Thanks to [Timwi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/668/timwi) for their [HexagonyColorer](https://github.com/Timwi/HexagonyColorer).

Answer (score 4):

## TI-Basic, 5 bytes

```
"FIVE
```

Also works with `"SEVEN"`.

Comment: One that's shorter (but not really) `"Six`

Answer (score 3):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 6 bytes

Push `six`. Implicit print.

```
 'six'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X0G9OLNC/f9/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## Lua, 10 bytes

```
print"ten"
```

Also works in many BASIC dialects that don't have a `?` shortcut for `PRINT`

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
`fr
```

[Test it here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=YGaMcg)

Answer (score 3):

## [Backhand](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Backhand), 6 bytes

```
"s"xiH
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pMzs5IzEv5/1@pWKki0@P/fwA)

Outputs "six".

Answer (score 3):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), <s>151</s> 60 bytes

```
[S S S T    T   S N
_Push_6_Y][S S S T  N
_Push_1_T][S S S T  S T N
_Push_5_X][S S T    T   S T S N
_Push_-10_I][S S S S S N
_Push_0_S_(with_two_additional_no-op_spaces)[N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S S S T S T S S T   T   N
_Push_constant_83][T    S S S _Add_top_two][T   N
S S _Print_as_character][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgZNTgQtEgQkwBRSBiCkocAEpqARInIsTqpILKPP/PwA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

Whopping -91 bytes thanks to *@JoKing* by using an `<` instead of `==` check in my Java program below and adding no-ops.

Shortest program generated with [this Java program](https://tio.run/##fZjdbuM2EIXv8xQEryQoK2SBbovaVhdZrNMIcGzAVpx1i6JQEm2iVJFdiU4bFH72lCJn@DM0chPzHFHkd2iKY@WpfCk/PN3/9fZ215R9z67Kuv3vhLHd/rap71gvSiE/Xrb1PXuWl6KV6Or24fc/WBkP3Rh7kgOke1E36azuxURf/4U1UrCMtdU/To/zritfh24R8fq07JXPf5suF/yU8cV8OnwUN0oVl8up0heL66X6zNdKr/Jv6mO6ns6HxjT/9bIYGvMcBgB/hj2Km@lM31tc5stiqt1hXNPOL7AphzfNYQAUahpoDzNhWw4@Lza2xUwMpTANKAwFGrOhhIggISkqJ86gTW7QJv6QcWNbBkgrs7xaGSCtDRDIfO1eRSBQBkhrC6Q1Al0sgEc1EEcLoAFhv3KXBRSgaAUkIBBES8OhpcGQ3/HGNAyGEoihhcFQ0u6/CxdDKcTQwmAoaTGURIxhf21MAzG0AAwQiKElYoCyD4PFAIEYWhoMLQ2G2tsbp2lQQCIMSoMDhgFCjUig3efUwwLDgoGBaOrCxrYQDBRwoUIs0EiFEqBAAhMq7whxiEAjkHrcN7aFQKAACBUCgUYglAAEEoBQIRBo72hzgC6v51@X069OE5FQApORCIUGUhkNWKiBy0gEQ8OQoUHQWEH6z@gI9lC2kPZwdjkDzx7WDm5guYe3h0089zB34ODh8J1wmd1Hhbp00cmhT23yFfhFgLpHltN7qIgffD2mSPhOENArGtQNAvpFhNr5@lhvGpAUF@KHAf1iYzcOyecVH98k6Ugx8u3gwVkci@YVKWLSYKRo@XYQC4uYZwSx3KJGzCCWV@SIS2O5RY@YQSy/CPo2jWWKomfQWF6RJCaN5RdN4oaHXRiLFFPfDmL5xdU/gzZHrCCaX3QDO4hHinDg04h@UQ7sICYt0vQCjWqLtu/QoH4Rpy6NSYo6tUlIv8hT92gJO5KQFH@vTGxChwb0fxRQlwYkPxKoTQL6PxqoSwPSHxHEVwHjeKxe6b5vO3jPY13V7xvBRup9Dt74GKtbwfrnsmkq9ZKXt6J6qLr06vzbn@vz2fX0lOXZT5/G0BuGwhuWesiMcY49hgmHMessH9eTj5/OxnWSmNnMCF3G@ak43WX2Tn3v7auo2O1Iw6YPlfgijT6KnSEYE5mcotjePNby2q68q77Ubdm96rGj2w91PHZ6d1kk0urvfdn00S7@zFfzFR@JOOncTrtMWHkwrfp71KVN1T6IxyhmE5PcwwmWwxvZWV07lNshl1fqcPKD8w2JrSibmbpXdjYjJuy9dchjS56wjz/iFDKTO95EbYi0bu@rfxcyrgrhrvfqtRfVc7rdi3QnBxZNG3HdK@OJbiR87DJK31HDxVpaecLl7uPJ@8zO0hyZ2F9qp29XiX3Xjr21G/4eTuQf@NcH7L335h8Wu4XsL2UndxpfrXgStZOzz7zgI77iMKlcxTbLzuITd34mV2LO7aM3DHc3wodKbL25hqvxVSke0/K2j9o4PrbdRZLdTX74We5aOXkBQ@t4dMrDyeHt7X8), which uses the printing approach of [this Whitespace tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158232/52210) to output in full uppercase.

Answer (score 3):

## R, <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
 "six" #space before the text
```

Previously:

```
"seven"
```

Comment: Also works in PHP without the opening PHP tag. In fact, with PHP you could have simply `four`

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 6 bytes

Ruby has an extremely convenient builtin p that prints the string.

```ruby
p'six'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0C9OLNC/f9/AA)

Comment: Are the quotes allowed?

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 10 bytes

```
print 'ten
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhId@7@gKDOvREG9JDXv/38A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 5 bytes

```
"five
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/Xyktsyz1/38A)

Comment: Welcome to Japt :) I'll be reopening my bounty (with slightly lower rep) for new users on Monday or Tuesday if you'd like to try for it. I'll count any solutions you post between now and then towards it, including this one. You're welcome to my solution, if you'd like; didn't see yours before posting.

Comment: Thank you @Shaggy ! I'll try it for sure even if I'm scared by the characters used since I do everything from a phone.. Btw I was sure there was some compression available in Japt, my bad I didn't checked.

Comment: This also works in TI-Basic (with all caps) `"FIVE`

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 6 bytes

```sh
<<<six
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fxsamOLPi/38A)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>25</s> 20 bytes

```c
f(){puts("twenty");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NQ7O6oLSkWEOppDw1r6RSSdO69n9mXolCbmJmnoYmVzUXJ1CJNVftfwA)

Comment: `"twenty"` works

Comment: @12Me21 I am a fool.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>12</s> <s>9</s> 6 bytes

Took me a little searching and I don't like requiring the extra spaces, but such are the vagaries of English numbers.

**Edit:** -3 bytes thanks to Night2. -3 bytes thanks to ngn.

```apl
⊢'six'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97f@jrkXqxZkV6iDe/zQA) And a slightly different version to get it to work on [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBI@6FqkXZ1aoAwA)

Comment: is `⎕←` required? dyalog prints results by default. if not: `⊢'six'`

Comment: @ngn Not in TIO https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HXIvXizAr1//8B

Comment: [but](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBI@6FqkXZ1aoAwA). [or](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97f@jrkXqxZkV6iDe/zQA). generally, in [kolmogorov complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bkolmogorov-complexity%5d%20apl) challenges we don't add `⎕←`.

Comment: @ngn In that case, I've added both.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 10 bytes

```r
cat("ten")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxREOpJDVPSfP/fwA)

Prints `ten`. This simple answer is much shorter than all the other options I could think of.

If a bit of fluff around the answer is allowed, we can go with

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 6 bytes

```r
"six";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/X6k4s0LJ@v9/AA)

which prints `[1] "six"`.

If a lot of fluff is allowed, we could even go with

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 4 bytes

```r
four
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/tOj/fwA)

which prints to STDERR `Error: object 'four' not found`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), 80 bytes

```
((((((((()()()())))((({({}){}}()){}){}()))[[]])())[][][])[]){({}<>)<>}<>........
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v9fAwY0IRAIgJxqjepazeraWiAfzACJR0fHxoIURMeCIJDSBKmysdO0sQOSelDw//9/XUcA)

The code to push `eighty` is 72 bytes and we add an extra 8 bytes to bring it to the correct amount.

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), 80 bytes

```
(((())()()()())((([]())())[][][])){({}(([]([]<>[])[]{}()){}){})<>}<>............
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v9fAwg0NTWgUBPIi44FC2hGx4Kgpma1RnUtWDQ61sYOKBAdC@QDhWtByMau1sZODwn8//9f1xEA)

This version pushes `EIGHTY` and requires 12 bytes of padding.

Answer (score 2):

## Commodore BASIC (TheC64/Mini, C64/128, VIC-20, PET, C16/+4) 25 tokenised and BASIC bytes

```
 0 print"seventeen
```

I could use the abbreviated `?` but when listed the program will show the full `print` keyword. In any case it would make no difference to the byte count as `?` and `print` use the same number of BASIC tokens.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 9 bytes

```perl
say"nine"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIpLzMvVen//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA0A)

Answer (score 2):

## [cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)), 4 bytes

```
four
```

There are plenty of literal "four" answers already, but not one written in `cat` yet.

Comment: Also works in [Text](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Text)

Answer (score 2):

## [VTFF](https://esolangs.org/wiki/VTFF), <s>1524</s> 600 bytes

-924 bytes thanks to Jo King

New answer:

Readable version:

```
VVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVFVFVFVVVVVVVVVVVVFVFVFVVVFVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVV
```

For info on how the lang works, I can't be bothered to rewrite it all, so see the old answer:

<s>Those bytes can be seen in the source code of this answer.</s> They could be earlier, but they're apparently gone now. Alternatively, here it is with Vertical Tab characters replaced with `V`s and Form Feeds replaced with `F`s:

```
VVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVFVVV
```

Try it out [here](https://codepen.io/programmer5000/full/pwJrVb/) by putting the string `"ONE THOUSAND FIVE HUNDRED TWENTY FOUR"` in "Generate", then copying the output of that into "Interpret".

Explanation: VTFF is a language I found by hitting `Random page` on the Esolangs wiki a lot. The only characters are the vertical tab (0x0b) and form feed (0x0c), hereafter referred to as just V and F. Each block of V characters separated by F characters represents a number in unary. 32 is then added to that number and it is then converted into a character. This repeats until a string is built. That string is then sent to a JS `eval` statement, the output of which is the output of the program. Because the positions of out characters on the Unicode code table matter, capital letters are preferable to lowercase ones, because their unary representations are 32 bytes shorter. That said, if it ended up being 32 or 64 low I was happy to sprinkle in some lowercases if need be, but thankfully that didn't turn out to be the case. I obtained this with 15 minutes or so of manual brute forcing, where it quickly became clear that the 1500s would be easiest. If you automated the process, I imagine you could dip into the 1400s. Maybe there's even a really lucky one where you don't need all four digits. `"FIVE HUNDRED"` comes out at a frustrating 499 characters, for example.

Bonus fact: if you did this in binary VTFF (an imaginary language I just made up where it's just VTFF encoded in binary), you could get this down to just `"FOURTY"` bytes.

Comment: Would binary work for "FORTY" as well? :P

Comment: By adding some excess code, you can get this to [`"six"  +  " HUNDRED"`](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVKhuDRXozintKhAL78opVghQtfYQFPX8L@yoKCgkCANgNCgNAqLyUKYAkK0dpoQTdQL0c4lQiQEJwT@VyrOrFBSUNBWUFBS8Aj1cwlydVECAA)

Comment: @JoKing Awesome, I changed it. I might give this another shot later today to see if there's something yet more clever to be done. Five hundred feels so close!

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 6 bytes

```sh
<<<six
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fxsamOLPi/38A)

Comment: ...[You could just use six, ya know...](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fxsamOLPi/38A)

Comment: @EasyasPi lol oops

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
`∧ḭ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%60%E2%88%A7%E1%B8%AD&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Pushes "three" as a dictionary-compressed string and implicitly outputs.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
"five
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fKS2zDEgBAA)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 10 bytes

```
prin "ten"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhId@7@gKDNPQakkNU/p/38A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Cascade](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Cascade), 9 bytes

```
"
n
i
n
e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/X4krjysTiIFMAA)

Don't know why I didn't think of this earlier.

Answer (score 2):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 5 bytes

```
five|
```

[Try it Online!](https://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=five%7C&inputs=)

This is pretty simple - it takes "five" as a variable then outputs it implicitly

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), 9 bytes

```
[I nineI]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70sLTG5JL9owYbQYFcrhcy8ktSigvycxJLUpaUlaboWK6M9FfIy81I9YyH8BVAKSgMA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language/Mathematica](https://wolfram.com/language), Multiple Solutions, Bytes vary

`four`

`"seven"`

`Print@"fifteen"`

`Echo@"fifteen";`

`Text[+"sixteen"]`

`FromCharacterCode@{70,105,102,116,121,32,70,73,118,101}`

All of these work and are quite trivial, except for the last one, which actually took a bit of thought.

Answer (score 2):

## Minecraft Command Blocks, 11 bytes

```
w @a eleven
```

Whispers `eleven` to every player

[image: @ whispers to you: eleven]

If `@ whispers to you:`  is not allowed

```
tellraw @a "twenty four"
```

outputs just `twenty four` and is **24** bytes.

[image: twenty four]

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://go.dev), <s>45</s> 40 bytes, to STDERR

```go
package main
func main(){print("forty")}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BgqWlJWm6Fjc1ChKTsxPTUxVyEzPzuNJK85LBLA3N6oKizLwSDaW0_KKSSiXNWoh6qDaYdgA)

- -5 bytes for using `forty`, by @The Thonnu

## [Go](https://go.dev), 59 bytes, to STDOUT

```go
package main
import."fmt"
func main(){
Print("fifty nine")}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BgqWlJWm6FjetCxKTsxPTUxVyEzPzuDJzC_KLSvSU0nJLlLjSSvOSwcIamtVcAUWZeSUaSmmZaSWVCnmZealKmrUQI6AmwUwEAA)

An extra character is needed here (in this case a newline on line 3) because if it is not, then the byte count cycles between `fifty eight` (59 bytes) and `fifty nine` (58 bytes).

Comment: [40 on first answer (STDERR)](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BgqWlJWm6Fjc1ChKTsxPTUxVyEzPzuNJK85LBLA3N6oKizLwSDaW0_KKSSiXNWoh6qDaYdgA)

Comment: For functions (not sure if allowed): [30](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BmoLE5OzE9FSF3MTMvKWlJWm6FvvSSvOSFdI0NBWquQqKMvNKNBSUSjIyi0oqlRQ0uWohiraCFYE0gdUpgNTD5BYsgNAA) and [41](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BmoLE5OzE9FSF3MTMvKWlJWm6Fjc1M3ML8otK9JTSckuUuNJK85IV0jQ0qwOKMvNKNJTSgFKVCvl5qUqatRANW8FKQAZoaCpUcymAVHNB5RYsgNAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 9 bytes

```
"NINE,,@#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9X8vP0c9XRcVD@/x8A)

### Explanation

```
"            Start stringmode
 NINE,,@#    Push "NINE,,@#", wrap to left
"            End stringmode
 N           Reflect (no fingerprint loaded)
"            Start stringmode, wrap to right
 NINE,,@#    Push "#@,,ENIN"
"            End stringmode, wrap to right
       @#    Jump over halt
     ,,      Print "NI"
    E        Reflect
     ,,      Print "NE"
       @     Halt
```

---

#### Slightly different (maybe nicer) solution

```
"Nine@,k3
```

Instead of bouncing back and forth over `,,`, this just iterates it with `3k,`. Also allows the subjectively nicer "Nine" instead of "NINE".

Answer (score 2):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 16 bytes

```forth
S" sixteen" TELL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//ByspFGdWlKSm5ikphLj6@Pz/DwA)

I tried doing `." <number>"` but that didn't line up with anything under 20. I guess I could have padded with whitespace or a `0 DROP` or something but that feels like cheating. Also this should work with any sane forth, not just gforth.

Comment: "any sane forth" Are there *in*sane forths?

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 10 bytes

```python
print'ten'
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EvSQ1T/3/fwA)**

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 16 bytes

```lua
print('sixteen')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0RDvTizoiQ1NU9d8/9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 5 bytes

```
five
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fKy2zLPX/fwA) Simply substitutes the empty input with the word `five`, which is the first word to have one fewer letter than its value.

Answer (score 1):

## BASIC, 6 bytes

```
?"SIX"
```

(Specifically tested in SmileBASIC: should work in most dialects, though `?` is often expanded to `PRINT`, I think it's usually still stored as one byte)

Answer (score 1):

## [Cascade](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Cascade), 9 bytes

```
"
n
i
n
e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/X4krjysTiIFMAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Scheme, 5 bytes

This works in any Scheme implementation, but Chicken Scheme is what I used.

`'five`

### EDIT: Alternative 4-byte solution

`four` outputs this:

`Error: unbound variable: four`

I think this counts, but if you don't like errors, the above solution is for you.

Answer (score 1):

## [bit**](https://github.com/Helen0903/bitch), 30 bytes

```
#116/#104/#105/#114/#116/#121/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8osSc74/1/Z0NBMX9nQwAREmAIJQxALLGZkqP///7/8gpLM/Lzi/7rJAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 3 bytes

```
¨◊ė
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9CKR9O7jkz//x8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 6 bytes

Note the space before the first quotation mark.

```powershell
 "six"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0GpOLNC6f9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 9 bytes

```ruby
puts:nine
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6C0pNgqLzMv9f9/AA)

Longer than the other answer, but does not output extra characters

Answer (score 1):

## Ceylon (Web IDE), 18 bytes

The Ceylon Web IDE allows to omit all the boilerplate which makes up a normal program, so we can use just the actual print statement:

```
print("eighteen");
```

[Try it online!](https://try.ceylon-lang.org/?gist=7ca2ca942e31a8f92356eea149e75a9e)

## Ceylon (with run function), 30 bytes

```
void run() { print("thirty");}
```

[Try it online!](https://try.ceylon-lang.org/?gist=b873ed569cd15407b34829dd5a72a7e0)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8 (full program), <s>75</s> 70 bytes

```java
interface M{static void main(String[]a){System.out.print("seventy");}}
```

-5 bytes thanks to *@CommandMaster*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNSsn@/z8zryS1KC0xOVXBt7q4JLEkM1mhLD8zRSE3MTNPI7ikKDMvPTo2UbM6uLK4JDVXL7@0RK8AKFiioVScWpaaV1KppGldW/v/PwA)

## Java 8 (lambda function), 9 bytes

```java
v->"nine"
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY1NCsMgEIX3OcWQlS7iBUJ7g2ZT6KZkMTW2mJpJiKNQSs5ulboZePO9nxkjdvP0Ttqh93BBS98GwBKb/YnawFAkwJV3Sy/Q4rbaCaLs8/do8vGMbDUMQHBKsTu3ZMm0qS9sCw@XWbXEklzygPiX3UdAWds/ns2i1sBqy4gFKS0oOCfr0JF@)

## Java 5/6 (full program), 40 bytes

```java
enum M{A;{System.out.print("forty");}}//
```

No online compiler, because I don't know any for Java 5 or 6..
The trailing `//` are no-ops, but outputting `forty` is shorter.

Comment: Can't you output `seventy` in the first solution?

Comment: @CommandMaster Lol, I indeed can.. :/ Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### **T-SQL, 10 bytes**

```
print'ten'
```

I guess is correct, right?
:)

Comment: What kind of SQL is this? I'm not aware of such a command/query, but I know you can do `SELECT'fifteen'`.

Comment: @Night2 It's Microsoft SQL Server. And yes, but that's 5 bytes more :P

Comment: you should probably make this T-SQL as the language

Comment: @MickyT Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 20 bytes

```
/o;."uytnewT.p^@!<..
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/18/31pPqbSyJC@1PESvIM5B0UZP7/9/AA)

This wraps onto the cube as follows

```
    / o
    ; .
" u y t n e w T
. p ^ @ ! < . .
    . .
    . .
```

[Watch it run](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=ICAgIC8gbwogICAgOyAuCiIgdSB5IHQgbiBlIHcgVAouIHAgXiBAICEgPCAuIC4KICAgIC4gLgogICAgLiAuCg==&input=&speed=10)

- `"uytnewT` open string and start pushing uytnewT onto the stack
- `"u` close the string and u-turn onto the lower line
- `p` bring the bottom of the stack to the top
- `<!` beginning of the print loop and test for 0

  - `@` halt if tested 0
  - `^y;/oe` redirect up, no-op, pop TOS, reflect right, output character, no-op and then onto the beginning of the print loop

Answer (score 1):

**Erlang, 5 bytes**

```
five.
```

Enter this code at interpreter prompt.

Answer (score 1):

### [dc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dc_(computer_program)), 6 bytes

```
[six]P
```

prints:

```
six
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Hexadecimal Stacking Pseudo-Assembly Language](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Hexadecimal-Stacking-Pseudo-Assembly-Language), 80 bytes

```
200079400000200074400000200068400000
200067400000200069400000200045400000
140000
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyguSMz5/9/IwMDA3NLEAATAbBME28wCwuYCc8yRJJA0mJhCFRmC6f//AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## Inform 7, 21 bytes

```
To q:say 21 in words.
```

This creates a function which takes no arguments and returns nothing, which prints the word "twenty-one".

Some boilerplate showing how to call the function:

```
X is a room.
When play begins: q.
```

Unfortunately, hardcoding the string tends to put me at a number of characters that's harder to print.

Comment: Does this output a hyphen? If so, that's against spec unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 29 bytes

```c
main(){puts("twenty nine");;}
```

It's an actual program...

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6oLSkWEOppDw1r6RSIS8zL1VJ09q69v9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/), 20 bytes

```python
print("twenty")#lol.
```

hey! that's python code length is actually 20 characters. I know, It's cheating but the comment is still a text.

```python
print("twenty")
```

prints the number. (15 chars)

```python
#lol.
```

a useless comment. (5 chars)

so 5+15=20 and 20 is twenty, right?

Comment: Please include the byte count in your submission. There's no reason to think that comments are cheating. As a hint, can you think of a smaller number that has a longer word, but fits without the comments?

Comment: Welcome to CGCC, I have updated your answer to include bytes count in the title and look better. If you like, you can use https://tio.run to provide an online working example of your code too. It also allows you to copy an auto generated answer with all the formatting ready to be posted. When you are done with your code, you can click on  icon and copy "Code Golf submission (Stack Exchange)" section here to post as an answer.

Comment: `print("sixteen")`

Answer (score 1):

Some answers with "production" (i.e. non-golfing) languages still not mentioned here:

## [C++ (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 55 bytes

```cpp
#include<iostream>
int main(){std::cout<<"fifty five";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E3OScxL//9fOTMvOac0JdUmM7@4pCg1MdeOKzOvRCE3MTNPQ7O6uCTFyio5v7TExkYpLTOtpFIhLbMsVcm69v9/AA)

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 23 bytes

```scala
println("twenty three")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8/7@gKDOvJCdPQ6mkPDWvpFKhJKMoNVVJ8/9/AA)

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>27</s> 24 bytes

```hs
main=putStr"twenty four"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oLQkuKRIqaQ8Na@kUiEtv7RI6f9/AA)

Comment: For Haskell you could do `main=putStr"twenty four"`

Comment: @SaraJ Thanks! Fixed.

Comment: For all of these you can remove the digits part and just leave the `fifty`/`twenty`

Comment: this is years old, but the C++ answer can be easily golfed down to print `fifty`, and the Scala answer seems to throw an error in TIO

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 5 bytes

```
five”
```

Just a string literal that gets implicitly output.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/Py2zLPVRw9z//wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 9 bytes

```
puts nine
```

prints

```
nine
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWCEvMy/1/38A)

## Tcl, a lot more bytes (not finished yet) currently 42

this will read the source code counts the characters and convert the number into an actual number word.

content of c.tcl:

```
puts [string length [read [open c.tcl r]]]
```

prints:

```
% 42
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 6 bytes

```
"Six"@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/18pOLNCyeH/fwA)

This ended up being both much shorter and much less interesting than I anticipated. 3 bytes are required for syntax, making it impossible to go lower.

Answer (score 1):

## [W](https://github.com/myu-sername/w), 5 bytes

```
five"
```

Implicitly prepends a quote. In order to specify your input, find prog.py and do this:

```
read = []

prog = 'five"'
```

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 26 bytes

Just a method that outputs a string literal.

```
System.write("twenty six")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9Kzfv/P7iyuCQ1V6@8KLMkVUOppDw1r6RSoTizQknz/38A)

Comment: The number of quotes in your first program is definitely not odd...

Comment: W automatically "prepends" a quote ```z```.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Interesting!

Answer (score 1):

## [Malbolge](https://github.com/TryItOnline/malbolge), 30 bytes

```
('B;_#!~[|:9zVw/.uQrOqon&Jl6"'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y03MScrPSU/9/19D3ck6XlmxLrrGyrIqrFxfrzSwyL8wP0/NK8dMSf3/fwA)

Created with [ZB3's Malbolge Tools](https://zb3.me/malbolge-tools/#generator)

Answer (score 1):

## Underload, 6 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K81LSS3KyU9M@f9fozizQjP4//@S1OISAA)
`(six)S`

## Explanation

```
(six)  Puts the text "six" onto the stack.
S      Prints it.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 4 bytes

```
four
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv7To/3@T/7qJAA)

The program just implicitly prints the string literal.

Answer (score 1):

## [International Phonetic Esoteric Language](https://github.com/bigyihsuan/International-Phonetic-Esoteric-Language), 8 bytes

```
"eight"o
```

Pushes and prints the string "eight".

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 6 bytes

```
"six";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fqTizQsn6/38A)

`;` is a comment.

Comment: Also a polyglot in R, and this exact 'program' was even [already submitted in R](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194559/95126)

Comment: And, as a bonus, the [other answer in R](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194627/95126) is also a polyglot in Pip

Comment: I've been trying to find easy challenges for R, but all of them somehow have an R solution

Comment: I don't think that should stop you from having a go.  I wish there were more challenges with more-than-one answer in R (or any other language).  It's really fun & instructive to see the different approaches.  Obviously, one of them will always be the shortest, but that isn't a problem.  I usually try to deliberately avoid looking at any other R answers if there already are any, and post my own answer if it ends-up different from whatever is already there, even if it's longer (and usually one of the other R golfers then makes it shorter for me anyway...).

Comment: For instance, [this recent challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/207736/95126) got 4 independent (and all different) R answers...

Answer (score 1):

## [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 30 bytes

```
99W3M!;98W!;1M;2A!;2M!;11MM3M;
```

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v1.1?code=99W3M!%3B98W!%3B1M%3B2A!%3B2M!%3B11MM3M%3B&input=)

prints in capitals.

Answer (score 1):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), 30 bytes

```
9a9m3a1o9s3s1o1a1o9a1o2a1o5a1o
```

Outputs `THIRTY`.

Answer (score 1):

## [StupidStackLanguage](https://esolangs.org/wiki/StupidStackLanguage), <sup><s>55</s></sup> 30 bytes

```
avvdqvdmdfwwddfifvvdfiifvfaaaa
```

[Try it online!](https://lebster.xyz/projects/stustala#606a1fe58be464182c58a0fd)

I found this by generating a list of numbers 1 - 100 as words, and then mapping said array with my StupidStackLanguage printing algorithm to generate an array of number printing programs. I then padded each program in the array with meaningless `a` characters until the number of characters it had equalled it's position in the array. Then, I just found the first program which had the same length as the number it printed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), Filename: 6 bytes + Content: 0 bytes = 6 bytes.

- Filename: `six.px`
- Content is empty.

Sorry for a boring post.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nRhrW9pI93t/xTAFMkMSkiBWZBhdRdulq9RVt2sF6pOSUKIhARIUCvSvd89MwkXb53nf3Q@SmTlnzv02OnbU//EameX93XJvp1uxnUpl741j2vv7e5Wys1@2vzh7exXnTcU29/edV6/RcOoOvGKpOPCC4jCMvKkXDV5Fbox0d8ImAzt6QKZZKjF3OgzHMTqr3x2dnfE6I/Fs6KKvbtwNg14@L3fdcDCwA4ceGI77aAQT30elg7yVz6eXL46uf@c4S1I8pA9XBCSIZufio1aXyUJf4hXbv5qNm7ur6xNeMs2d1eHFh6vGzdmnu/qHy8vT@jW3WAvpAcLZ@fHR1e93H08vrxofmlUggzr5/BxJrUIktWRiox6z5frO7a@uuIOJb8cuivriQjiMYfUUjp1o6Hsxs33PjpD@FSnZuaXi7G94qXBFfBXW/OvsrH5@wquSBSgtGDos6nu9WDJ3kEBMD9xuP0TZ1xQjjizUWSxIBrmPto9wBvVsP3IxzeeJxIr6Ltg1DkMU@g46yJdYBlVpwkMiTBeR6yAlMqbGzGAR/HwzFEn5m6ScUAGUlMaaBKjnP/L9fQb@GXq@SyjpcZN17cgF4hZGXoBIr0BRD0zN3MjuMjuK3MEXfya8GoJDjwKkP8YTaxGPkV6PkGmVdsq7b/Yq@0hptYNCR1l8HbtDVFzYTw9IOT5912jOwWJkOPaCuIeU4UX4IWh6jbtuPbp6/Nh7656OL5/@nt7MPn27tY/i68G5c6LqmWwupyz@A8esyXG9hVHWRLjD2xiDFfzwyR2TKBGB4FwXa1mTUoTbmGEGplOkuwnG2pWGq5gyH8zi8PIbtpxftXxV7fCsybwe8Q94KZ@HI73U4dzJ54ENGK1O577OS@yMUCa5oHora3bYcnnaPJmL02VvEnRjLwwQ7OaCEp0n8mAfs6e@8IZP0xOE0VVL1/1OSuwGCClSPf0RheAK6Ui8Mm9yGxLN9wL3wKTzQOVG62k6@9YxdMM2hOBBzUwZ4qKNjsuomCDgBe7aMbIgRkQuerBkS4kHmpGEit0xDjH6DaQKVCBXxWAgIBlKPQzHyOczAZV3pY3ghM4nPNCtVK/gYCJRUwlrfCNKIgR6MkJUtH8py0tdEuGwncoDGMul0O9fkExFXYLjWRqWuajdFkViFe54QVooMTPS/RiVRLUASouVF2xuik8EzgB/waoPB0pUAJMNw6AbPY7jjlEgds2iqtFSIZz1ZF@i4B93GrOlMTTmQIZFkGzLqGYx@EtBfVj1QfHYKGQyNgRhxDNGq@em3mC2MIp31zFUwweqzbc6sCE2@B4E6IKhWmEQgQBw2BeHxsDQAWzBaiULW1oQ@S/U3HmmpjK/aHmqKWN/yMVa1S0I6mHmOwTtSgvfEGgiH4bo7RWKJl@ieEyyprZD2QVEsdfhEL9WjTR5kmVDzdbeXlGodyDqHPAJzmI4QXar2dESWpQ5ru9CXU4osGWztgP4keCVklwvUjmilBZqfUYdFSjerGltxGgeQPoSYQQwAZRKo5XNdSCABesC/IB@4J8pF3s248mJCOppbUanKp/pZMankORcpG0vHJN7SPv7GqAxOkwsYLfuoWCwbaNAjBGjrRqHU3VWBfccTnX4ZuBbgG8OvrlZFar5T2qL8pFwMYGLx5IKAWDJAiJ41QogHYqFrGGsi6E8Nz77CMxiGKJNCLsUjAuSp8z4CntkwOcLdC8Zst4dBG3PHceDDpjSyEPNMljMVrkHR0kyA4DOJcQWh0u5dMRSVHnRpHppj4OpQDQiRaQbMamyWCR7B0iP3XgyDkTlTbiogoDtOCuuuthHX@LVPiP20KpX@3ZWHDje4@ogJxHCFYHIKBaMv6/fEpyHYgVWeSHZuh0lFfSq9cAhziEXV32gn/QBBZpjvCoSirD3Yn11XdFdckznD6rKgEyHw4@IGeG1Y6B4XBOn7FhVKSy04xQBFi@IC9GBAZV9zkFQjyiDLIy6Y28Y81RQiMTIdZ3vuIhpNIYRS26328sFOaFCH@0PQjv8RMoEom0QTqH/JObP/PGsMb1fAxAADqwt0B8bkNRmA7l@BhFMZYlYw2/IJZ1fckCTkuh66np0uYU0IfW0fBPdqtXz@XqttPuGHtah1WyhvRO0wAKT4LtRNATZScAmAQekDdF0te6Gh1mzqm/r8pdgBrfqW2dH5HzVP46qWDvf7hrJcWbTPta3hqB7khQZMCqdkBv43YKHSaf/NTAgDW2knWj@Bmc@4oAEs4fvBl/jPhlRGUUN6A@NGvdZA2JoQsgJT2vsSGtoFqXfccvU9zv48EQtV6rlXeCyYeOBDBfk3XPed@Rcq2u32ic6P@e4eFdFzTAWRcr96o4xq3PAZ7fAVrBnTEpY3kscs1uhX8au/SCKYv07/lxu7ex2spjOb3m5rNfTywmKaMykktyzytCM6pzviAaYIMG7IPaCicuWwv4Jdr1WrgjEg909SuWxlGHDPWFAP/FPiNR1QGbCoeyC3BY@bevY3TL@Bbl@boBoC3jzLAkewS332kcqqy6Y3oSMv@cyrMEJ92CLjyKBtUaHyY8YDcXiPtnf63qHf9x2wHiLlViM4XUSBv4snweZxCh0RHBxXEWwxEINkQQysWlBRMwzZz5tkg3IQSkCjAyQ2JJ/Sv7URglHyGeaYlvsTxlaSYClh3/WRlsXZ//i4sH2xW9roUhydSVXKv4aMd6yRF9UyueWHyTgBzFP98FlAmUb7gjPbKOkrVLgsQcoLM88JstUQ9ReFeoREalTIPfyN6mIlCZu4xJF@HPDSjYiwem9DB6QU32RvaI1NdYokGHAGFB0gVYzD/VGtfHMc7J1PaNYeEFR9LJRWg3ep7FCpNlBZF9@eRot2Sq6dcdhZh0vowP/cGT4Vd8YUbrNFfrh/0kz90uaOaCZkzRFc//xtnl0fsoVeF0Xh1PlVf1D8/q0eQ3190faxHBWouBF@sBEvVdrSIq9gXVfvbz11EV6F4ruLy79DJJ32sEaZRu4tkAPrL5@e26R@28Py@YlEm8zGIeVRST@QaE/ICsYa9ZqCvssK3EBtUmx0KZZGLbalhg/6BLDW0O0ai6HJL2L5H9QJiLTw4GYSOBw/NPhRkynjPRm@RmCGEUigIdo6DmaG3sDVxt2hxPtMfrGHDt26baa5f@tZmx7PtKDcmmlDihBiu15pb0UyrQtQ9k8f/SSVd4rV3belCvwUIAHCVhFjqvJhGonz6t/b2fxqErsJD5YvMlWQxBeIYx4WxHfD5dXXFFWQ5zIfw8mLk8MDwweK7Tbgql//exvt3Mh1jxIOhgn5SSVTtMjhNsBuAfuJs0@6fRJx4c3w2Vu1@TcSjWLEF7FExrBpfT2MgV3k4e/sMTPLOAVH/WRHv34Bw)

Comment: This challenge states to output the number of characters in your *program*, not your score (filename+program). So you have to add a byte: `zero.px`

Answer (score 1):

## BRASCA, 5 bytes

```
`five
```

[Try it!](https://sjoerdpennings.github.io/brasca-online/?code=%60five&stdin=)

### Explanation

```
`five      - Push "five" on the stack, char by char
<implicit> - Print the stack, reversed
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 bytes

Lucked out that the string compression found anything to compress in one of the smaller numbers.

```
`f r
`    // Decompress compressed string
 f r // Compressed string literal for "four"
```

[Try it here.](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=YGaMcg==&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Duocentehexaquinquagesimal](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Duocentehexaquinquagesimal), <s>39</s> 32 bytes

```
ÖtΛ‰[WåÙUYr™{—*l”î)‘RçÊí¹©ÓûŽUQ‹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFhiYxPzqGGRXbx1cWqKgm6mgrphsXWcNVDIWl0hXsHILq80x7qkqDQPqDRVQbdY11Ah3jo1OSNfQTdPQR2oLOnQMuPDW5yP7stQsrPR1tXTiY5VetSw0EvdDmimfn5BiX5@cWJSZiqUUoi3S4IIJxUlZuallSZnI1gKSf8PTys5N/tRw4bo8MNLD88MjSx61LKo@lHDFK2cRw1zD6/TfNQwI@jw8sNdh9ce2nlo5eHJh3cf3Rsa@Khh53@gW/4DAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 6 bytes

```php
O"six"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVltU9tIEv5s/4rBKbAky4ks2KotG5lKspCijgALye5WAReEPIapk2WdJEO4hPvrue6eF41sk73cLVWxrJmne7qf6enucZL@bZJ8eyGyJF1M@G5ZTcT85d24bY@k4qYxlFSPOV8CFSK7bQxVYiYxEz4VGWdpytJ5dksfbTP64fjjezaoX88/nLGwfv3t9RnbqV8Pjt@yn@vXs49sUIMPjs4t7PHHIwv68fj96/O/OaXLHPzYYv8e/OSa2dfnsKycTO7ignluLWCjwFajYjxmO/Xc8f7vOJnBJHn0leH33d0lDC5DGHQTMGnqIrCBeXNyckQg/NgjJ4fom2XI2TsJAHnL1vs4XXDXvciu3Hab/IBdubhiETvr7J8cON9OOqX43PnmwktnJBEeQHg8Awx8GbXboDCPi5I7LvvSbomsYmLUbsEoKfeZN11kCYyQcALv1Sz3yzy7CK@iL4EfPIGOlgB1hIdngAOvXqF6kbOHO1HxMo8T3m7B95Q7MA7ijjTDZ53L6jK7nF4W7MvTxZXjDl90XDKlJabMMdZGrPui6zKpQo9uwOhlBsO9nhwBO1s8Lbk98CTNSe548g82nRcsW8xueFEqe5gjyom4FZXWCqujOwPfeCSfHhsErMc8ZXmv57I@6wZdWAItFS4reLUoMqbDQYpRRIyWbbiPCxHfpFxbAUak8wdeOAmspw1hX78ybVxCbwkR8anrKnrEGtdFNPBhjyIzvGQdHjAViADJJovcwS1litM@g7dVg@VxL6U2acZlt1vb1OnKTQNh8MAYxUAJpAf4DpblcVmx6o6DsrioAKw2wNOM4oYmLnqijbVOzbPGwufApY1u1WSQ@Ri6lZhnYDZGbIAnI9GMlIs8R8JdHVV6xKbfjj@g3SIbdehQzjOIY0hVGLnKcsnKh645z3LgAAcwbQ0xXaGZOsgo00lXHbQbTY3TdJ44O4E/cNFBHDZOkIPZIk3j4tF2tN6fM2t7TrvGMlpQyS@yJWlaYoBLqKSwztP9N2@vf904@uXE8tfWeiPWqg1X1W409L47PH9GY8ULUhlnE/bPRaxfUe29vcT26hLS/3ddQ8XhGipIeKcp3MQ8UaYsFhlu0EhlW6@al45OlRT/ENmVSBjN3iymF@HOlbJD7vMWZQdjQJnDqaqmDkDB/800nXR02qFq46OSZQVwJowCWcfk@g3cLhtsN/1E5zEU91inKha8AyFoxjEiYXwaQwLBiQ4GVqcmAf1E31XBITo@vZnPU5i5aTLwrK@1W99zyPtxj2wzb1bMTNHG7C@1EYK2mqepY5vqs8CHAvE/mJytmIxF@P3r02MfS7EMNHg9vBgEQQDhBK7Aq34rxb/4p4rhY2TFqOUtMgBvPn6E9LkdDXRFxwSHRR0f9BnKxzYADg6P9j02hdw4apnQVuthFk7i3E95Rg2AxZXuhyRncO6eI2NZEEsTVjasN46gVgJK8S5xMYKaInDS5I1kli/tAJEkruoUgjSJK1ymfBBVcud4wMxK@4QcJVifIGMOtahq7wrIOI67FXye4h/urkSedodtVv@BOWTuLa9S6NecLWJ1C7nCWjURmTtibaxI4jPLi/ksr1jK43soqSzjDygDbfQUuj12enby/vTDp4PDP@wFxNShXcGqntwVmI99an1cuVsRdF0veDYR03btALW4VYFFEx4uFXVp/j44avpAPNzYYGKR0e5jEKlUWDv9pqZH4s3M23oGJfGf0lhjrgGDmwvhFOXznGeOtbDfKTpU@MGqaCbrHoRXFAY7P9O4ahUc2V9MwfQJOgUNGUSgj90awKEToDdcA5bW0eLAIOtF1NjgAQSkq7YM9NBatF@owYtYaHcgNY21J7@CJ/wzNGV4eFf83GgEEfX2G5iYVoBHK9EGq6RNXiz4LxByyh8K3Mhm2SQyVVA6x9TkOlhSXF1TxuMdt24TV7KbFj2nVs/ZLFHQPmHrhIFOaGTsdSExup0aqiewWvA4U2qfq0iqBNk7oFKFYuGkZgFPl7zGIGlyPxvUsa0tuhD1@wi9kk3rJTXPLW3W5kuvBHsceHOZPq@FZf6iKvXum5iQnZs0qGcMorQH6Q8zLIaWtT2yN241d1veLhENXTzTsRTKPcdulg6D3ABC4TCe9kh7GbrrQzWJK/1QPeSgV9Pk6u@oy4Xe0qdnpXKE8qu/Ep1WtGPj3bRXCnn17qxhYbnaruHBW@FB7us6FmZrXPMIE9lKSABKikOZMupewpUNQaN@n/QpoqgCLm@0ZLRqnP5X3yXm1XpiNr8rtLle6O/EZsMheRGgsdD2cqRol6xHrD8wLBMWqB/AOesP4IwNbHD4g@hdSI8NbBQhlNYd6pFAU05Eh@NAcR261H14EfHfXj4QNEmuQKWkBIslBr7jDeCOF7xbsmwOLbFIK5Gxh/gReGOTOdwwK37LC5DJ5xnPKhHjpQBO8pw9cHYX33MAKkUIr9gszhYQPo8vcRS9u0HGgQpiolykFf4EQIubhKchfRujl1yizJYzkCX1qO95ZPC8IQa220AFdNuOU6yNj@B1Nkn5hF3XZl8bLV/wm@yzrEVqZ8aorN/X7y7BWwrqWaY/mTy4S8G6VPgw6TXyYtTMinvMPvy79jFA0aH63WyLScAea/R9NOgzKxuijkBK6pIbyjqA2I0Iqo3VBY3hUGJozSfzIZvxWZJjmGVsfL33/7oy/gtcGWtXNtb4EilflCt7z7MvV11jMk7vsQYgNIhQF9CNdXbWL8Y9nXlsBca8rTr9oS/rasOeLalSiZH/@t/IqxxkqTHyo@7QRjfa3GVsVGfd5vQP30t0b1tfTBDXalxOTCokDGq8ihrSVppECUT0ekZMmvw7uCd/w7IbzYZ3zO5dlNhhs2tHqCW/Fw63LVreyStDZHVYPbsAsZUuJFMXD9@che1GQ3suiV5SOloueeG6krftmj4gNNI7NPgnDREahk/cisQ0/6YdsnujEDzEVXsDbJKoQZDxLyfpQYieOgmwOlzhYkiS4JnuMEUGk2JCvwnFSQVlqruZdLHnxBGXPXMpRWWmBkI3qH4XmMUiw2aVxcVt4pNSz4Pv9y7@@kTXVfxvGCcga5rXuKdv/wE)

Not much to explain; `O` is shorthand for OUTPUT.

Answer (score 1):

## 8086 DOS .COM file, 16 bytes

Hexdump:

```
0CD5:0100  B4 09 BA 08 01 CD 21 C3-73 69 78 74 65 65 6E 24 ......!.sixteen$
```

Assembly source:

```c
        // NASM syntax with C comments because no SE highlighting
        [org 0x100]
        section .text
        global start
start:
        // int 21:09: write $-terminated string in ds:dx
        mov     ah, 0x09
        mov     dx, str
        int     0x21
        // exit
        ret
str:
        db      "sixteen$"
```

---

## 8086 DOS .COM file, dirty exit, 10 bytes

This one prints "ten" and then does whatever, likely in the form of a crash.

```
0CD5:0100  B4 09 BA 07 01 CD 21 74-65 6E                   ......!ten
```

```c
        // NASM syntax with C comments because no SE highlighting
        [org 0x100]
        section .text
        global start
start:
        // int 21:09: write $-terminated string in ds:dx
        // but it prints even if it isn't $-terminated so why bother?
        // It's real mode, it'll find a $ eventually™
        mov     ah, 0x09
        mov     dx, str
        int     0x21
        // exit
        // jk
str:    // not $ terminated
        db      "ten"
```

[image: everything is fine]

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
`∧ḭ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%60%E2%88%A7%E1%B8%AD&inputs=3%0A7&header=&footer=)

Dictionary compression FTW!!!

Answer (score 1):

## [Barrel](https://github.com/LorenDB/barrel), 4 bytes

```
four
```

Implicitly prints the unknown instructions "four". However, this could potentially be voided by later modifications, so here's a safe 5-byter that uses a string:

```
'five
```

Answer (score 1):

## AWK, 20 bytes

```
BEGIN{print"twenty"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd06@6oCgzr0SppDw1r6RSqfb/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Emmental](https://github.com/catseye/Emmental), 30 bytes

```
#84.#72.#73.#82.#84.#89.######
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83NTc0rScz5/1/ZwkRP2dwIiI31lC2ANIhvYamnDAb//wMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 6 bytes

Very simple solution, `(q` quotes the name after it to prevent it from being evaluated, the parentheses are implicitly closed at the end of the line, and the result of the top-level statement is implicitly outputted,

```
(q six
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8nMq8zJLC74/1@jUKE4s@L/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## EEL - 78 Bytes

```
=83 !>=69 !>=86 !>=69 !>=78 !>=84 !>=89 !>=32 !>=69 !>=73 !>=71 !>=72 !>=84
```

**Explanation**

EEL (Easy Esoteric Lang) is an esoteric programming language created by me, easy to manage, hence the name. Below is a brief description of the language.

.-EEL is based on a vector of bytes initialized to zero, on which basic arithmetic operations can be performed, whose length is equal to 64Kb.

.-EEL allows the reading and writing of one byte at a time in the form of an ASCII character in the standard input and output respectively.

.-EEL has a brief help section which can be viewed from the interpreter.

.-EEL is extremely sensitive, so a wrong input byte can cause a wrong output.

.-EEL does not have an error/exception handling system, so it may crash unexpectedly if a fatal error such as division by zero occurs.

**Defined operations:**

**=000** -> Copy the value of number 000 to the current byte.

**+000** -> Add to the current byte, the value of number 000.

**-000** -> Subtract to the current byte, the value of number 000.

***000** -> Multiply to the current byte, the value of number 000.

**/000** -> Divide to the current byte, the value of number 000 (cannot be zero).

**%000** -> Calculate the modulo of the current byte and the value of number 000 (cannot be zero).

**>** -> Go to the next byte of the vector.

**<** -> Go to the previous byte of the vector.

**?** -> Read a ASCII character from STDIN and assign it to current byte.

**!** -> Write to current byte in STDOUT as an ASCII character.

**:** -> Open/close the space for comments.

**.** -> Exit the program.

**$** -> Reference to current byte.

*NOTES:*

The 000 number can be s current byte reference operator ($).

The 000 number (x) must be an integer number, such 0 < x <= 255.

There must be a space character u+0020 after each number 000.

[Try the EEL interpreter!](https://tio.run/##tVf9TuNGEP/fTzHQu6sdSMg3FAgVTXxcpJCgEOhVxyld7E2yarIbre1AeuKh@gx9MDq7dpwvB4lQjBTjndnf/HZmPDN20n3HeX4@SE0NA/CqivFUsv7AB7NqQRry2Xweb42AeXDF/v2HhGqdAT47wqWA956kFDzR8x@IpPswFQEMyITCmMoR8zwmOPgCAg9lDsLvw0i4rDcFwl1wmedLdh/4iOTDWIoJc6mrbfgD4gOx8K5tzXh5PvHpiHJfmR5L6lE5oa4Gu7cUCC7PUVHggaQOZaiUMVIHhnGQ0vA28aZge8KnkjnQILwfkD4F07YbFtQ5LiM4/uo9PzHuDAM87qnnu0xkBme45tIe4xRwQ/fWrnZa7W7Dbl50vkC5VCqUlxVaV9VWze42W00bskmSauvqDyjnkkTntRoUC0mS65vfoFhKklzeNKCYT5LU6rdQPEzc06pBIVHStL92oJwId9W2b6GceKR6E8qJtFs3HSgUkr1weWk3O1A6giSx3foMxXKiqHrTbqud6PgE6Re7cQW5bNEwVPpgvB3BPR@cAZEpracU0DXnjdYFVIzdO46Li1kA3yb4k83kvt9x9bd7Z@xWstkspM/0O4NZSmFChgEF0QMejO6VOsox85XICaRUOXs/9WlGAxi7e9H@c9dNUtvfhJmZEUhHANfBvS@J42@HkopQLoOhz8bD6XYoBxFKjak3@FUYYDqEc4FaFP6mUlgx6MeZh8nQCYb43msILB/BUCiMVRO6CrzaypkycSFmnDl9jNAiCxPq@ELG6qfL6pgfEyYC76Utv6otbUqwGsH5dbVe15mHEUNqPSlGcN2p4dui2BMsmH2u6hjir2cNgu0osN8l8@mqCjCukNTrhVWP8FVbMcSxgmiNKT9whsILveqNiUOhJyS@GyNVX71YPaPU7UfFSR9Y9CUZxdIP4eF6FHk4dCPtZqtjH2PjoDoYUVwwJCoeZPkYMgYT2EMIehLMD9bLSOajBaPA0@FFUIavbh@XQ@k@eIEzgCycwiOcViBfKq2jSToHiLwxj1KAL2s@C6SnHihBsHlmaaSTuLQEXEUQO4/arYtLmA3f1hrF94RNSFzviRzS1Q6pQPbmJQMjwni3T/2u9hd3zYlgroU7FJoSmpbxQ3c9tRA6FdvySbyEeELSLuPjwFfWTsI2j0@eubtSCjMrQ0I0G3ASjQt3/DMGbECHY/CnYwp/Dn7WmY3V2W6jp6wQ3BUQUlLXw4ANqWnGzJADHkedz7Qs2Klg7bZi5fk2Tb9nLrFH5QXd2bWIvNKPo7POLu@BoeE5lWWsH2vImMPeWic/XlfTM8dyMizG@HtEbC2U1sk61r2k5K8V3olccHTYhsree3DBYWUbLun34ILj0TZcUu/BBQeybbgcvItfWlvly8f34KKGzg1k9vZWObzFkBphNxhKp/9PQ/XmdnUhLoVvMY5TwQbrWDU1/Ess3mQ6muqTza@0np3F57cYxW@FZIN9gSOK/bXeeQu6@l5Ihtc9c@WT4gXvLS49Gcv/PYVtMRd1TE06NIqNOJBc9emn14wFsylgadrAT2ic/KMZIx4IonAspJ4x67ahqJLw9TXvlTHoS0kVmqNDjxrLvTU8d2jorALFI/j0KaKE01vpcNMsEFlNqXnh5iRJhJ3NNBePb0Vm0mjFWolTghNWAmQsRsNcioAVWsQIPT9XDvOwc1bJZXPh7WjxltOLxaL6LYR6uV8WJLlccWlXVisWYCfzHw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 5\log_{256}(96)\approx \$ 4.12 bytes

```
"five
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhZLldIyy1IhbKgQTAoA)

Pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

## [Z80Golf](https://github.com/lynn/z80golf), 10 bytes

```
00000000: 3e74 ff3e 65ff 3e6e ff76                 >t.>e.>n.v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q7IwSM/PSfv/3wAKrBSMU81NFNLSjFMVzEzT0oBcs1Qg19xMAR3YlejZperZ5emV/f8PAA)

```
  ld a, 't'
  rst 38h
  ld a, 'e'
  rst 38h
  ld a, 'n'
  rst 38h
  halt
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), 10 bytes

```
echo "ten"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704LzN3wYKlpSVpuharUpMz8hWUSlLzlCACUHGYPAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Aheui (esotope)](https://github.com/aheui/pyaheui), 52 bytes

```
발밦밞발밞다받받밞밞따댜먛뻐더희xxxx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xILc38///1hjmvNyx7vWEemDHvdfeS1xtmg9E8EJqy4XXPnNcrZr/ePeF175S3c9dUAMH//wA)

Contains 20 chars (16 hangul and 4 unused ascii) and prints `TWenty`. 19 seems to be out of reach. `NINTeen` barely fits, but the correct spelling of 19 is "nineteen".

```
밞바밣밞다밦발바발타밞밞따받탸먛뻐더희
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xILc38///1hnmvN0x5vWExiNG95PWGZa83zAGLzHnb3ACWnfd6yobXG2a/bd7xesXs17snvO6d8nbumv//AQ)

---

## [Aheui (esotope)](https://github.com/aheui/pyaheui), 40 bytes, solves for bytes instead

```
발박받밞밝발박따땨먛뻐더희
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xILc38///1hjmvN0x9vWH26w3zXm@YC@VO2fB66orXK2a/3j3hde@Ut3PXcP3/DwA)

Prints `FORTY`. The strictly increasing nature of `FORTY` is useful [again](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246257/78410).

Each Hangul character costs 3 bytes, so 40 bytes can fit 13 chars and a newline. Luckily `FORTY` can be printed in exactly 13 chars (4 for charcode differences, 5 for the value 70, 3 for "dup; print; add" loop, and 1 for halt).

```
발박받밞    Push 5, 2, 3, 9
밝발박따따  Push 70 (7 * 5 * 2)
빠맣다      Loop: dup; print as char; add
            Break when add fails
희          Halt
```

Comment: Because the challenge says "Create a program which prints the amount of *characters* its source has in English words." and not *"bytes"*, shouldn't this print "fourteen"?

Comment: @TheThonnu Good point. Added a solution for characters.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 15 bytes

```julia
print(:fifteen)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v6AoM69EwyotM60kNTVP8/9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 9 bytes

```
"ooooENIN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/XykfCFz9PP3@/wcA)

Prints `NINE` and halts with error (`E` is not a valid command).

Answer (score 1):

## [Zalgo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Zalgo), 54 bytes

```
t̝̐̄̇h̝̐̈̆i̝̐̉̆r̝̐̂̇t̝̐̄̇y̝̐̉̇
```

Escaped with each cluster per line:

```
t\u031d\u0310\u0304\u0307
h\u031d\u0310\u0308\u0306
i\u031d\u0310\u0309\u0306
r\u031d\u0310\u0302\u0307
t\u031d\u0310\u0304\u0307
y\u031d\u0310\u0309\u0307
```

Prints `thirty`. Pushing a constant and printing takes 4 characters, and the first number whose length in English is strictly smaller than 1/4 of its value is 30. For stylistic reasons, each grapheme cluster in this code prints its root character (e.g. `t̝̐̄̇` prints `t`). [Python code used to generate the source.](https://tio.run/##bY7RCoMgFIbvfYpzM1Tali0YY9CTbLsINQyGhhnU0zs1G8Hm1ff/R7/jsDhldO39CA1gp3rrFoxanSJGcuTtIMUaOmOBQ69hvCMIJ9bGCsJpivFR0YQbBeDnxOpK4C@yiFxZwuaascACDlBd6U9blrFOvm13dtqd1O6sKydUciZZ/Li8/s1WfRiiwfbakfBnmjGv2@Jb6jQ9Qqaz1NwISfDkutMNU0q9/wA)

---

## [Zalgo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Zalgo), 25 bytes, 1 grapheme cluster

```
I̝̝̝̐̏̆̐̎̆̐̅̆
```

Escaped:

```
I\u031d\u031d\u031d\u0310\u030f\u0306\u0310\u030e\u0306\u0310\u0305\u0306
```

Prints `one`. Validity of this answer depends on the definition of "character" in this challenge. [Python code used to generate the source.](https://tio.run/##bY9BDsIgEEX3nGI2BsZGS21ijIkH8AzqogGaNjFAoE3q6ZFSujCV1fvzP3/AfobO6DoEDzegRitKGp34vlAR8TnyupIU9vBWmnkkyovGKpljq4pRt822xoGAXoO/EohnvmWcZAKT/NnBKRQgOsf4VHMeWcIOqjNupmU5j1PBdntqWThhpyaWix6n1z9vqYsmsa7XA4uPwoy5fpXzp6J7VFoYqRgdh/ZwoYgYwhc)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
äφ╓Dr
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=84edd64472&i=)

Just unpacks to `"five"`, which is then implicitly output

Answer (score 0):

### [MSM](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Mutating_Stack_Machine), <s>11</s> <s>9</s> 6 bytes

```
xsi/..
```

The 3 letters are pushed on the stack, `/` swaps `s` and `i` to get the correct (reverse) order and the two 3 dots concatenate them to a single string. There are variants such as `'.xis.` or `?..xis`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZHdTsQgEIXvfQqCyQqRlu6FRmlIH2TTC7a/bFsgMFUb47NXyiZ6M2FyvjkMh5v6UKHx2kEWnG47v1gzddvOOVqDNgOCsUNLWJA20Hnnu1jRdUNuXgdzXb15iGRvV9MiBWgEcEFwPugA@aBhXK95Yxf@R/PX80tRvL0/9nrusuibOW/b7Bb2xradxF9B8zzH5d7LfjUNaGtIYMAUa9jENvrdW0@CDHlwswaCMS0JHO2oeyCUnk7hUtQl/Yx3k0C3apOFmCri1jASoGySBRVEyXBp5NyZAcbsXDPMsJRQOesIFZinhkSkjlyWNTVLZxW1/A4ebol@TjUKT0mY5FlgcZ8/oFw5N2/xBQn7X/qYqO7YJpP5UeMqVCRvXCZRCaC0jJnH5BD8lA/Ox28gPTnCisr@Cw)

Edit: -3 bytes thanks to @Night2

Answer (score 0):

### [SWI-Prolog](https://swi-prolog.org), 15 bytes

```
write(fifteen).
```

[Try it online!](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/)

Comment: Ten: `write(ten)`?

Comment: Apparently that works in the online version :)
But in the terminal versions, we have to close it with a dot.

Comment: You can always limit your answer to a specific version. This is code golf, doesn't matter if the answer is not cross-compatible.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

```
"five
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xyktsyz1/38A)

I don't think it's possible to get shorter than this. The overhead for compressed strings is 4 bytes already, so it's impossible to also get a 4-byte message in it.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pepe](https://github.com/Soaku/Pepe), 50 bytes

```
reeEEeeEEereeEEeEeeEreeEEeeEEereeEEEeEeereeEEEEeeE
```

[Try it online!](https://soaku.github.io/Pepe/#Y4YaY4YwZ6)

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 18 bytes

```cs
Write("eighteen ")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/F9anJmXrlBckliSmawQXFlckpqr55yfV5yfk2r9P7wosyRVQyk1Mz2jJDU1T0FJ8/9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [rusty_deque](https://github.com/bigyihsuan/rusty_deque/), 12 bytes

```
"twelve"~ol~
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
3∆ċ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIz4oiGxIsiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Simply push the number 3 and convert it to words.

Answer (score 0):

## [FerNANDo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/FerNANDo), 80 bytes

```
1 1
01
10 01
0 1 1 0 01 10 0 10
0 1 1 01 10 01 0 10
0 1 1 01 01 10 10 1
01 01
01
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0stykvMS8n//99QwZDLwJDL0EABSBooALkKIKYCSABIwIQgAoZoYhBhEOIC84Dk//8A)

Loops twice, printing "eig" on the first loop and "hty" on the second. Coincidentally, using the two-character names `01` and `10` increased the code to exactly the right length.

Answer (score 0):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 9 bytes

```
"enin">o<
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiXCJlbmluXCI+bzwiLCJpbnB1dCI6IiIsInN0YWNrIjoiIiwic3RhY2tfZm9ybWF0IjoibnVtYmVycyIsImlucHV0X2Zvcm1hdCI6ImNoYXJzIn0=)

Finishes with an error.

### [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 10 bytes

```
"net"ooo ;
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiXCJuZXRcIm9vbyA7IiwiaW5wdXQiOiIiLCJzdGFjayI6IiIsInN0YWNrX2Zvcm1hdCI6Im51bWJlcnMiLCJpbnB1dF9mb3JtYXQiOiJjaGFycyJ9)

Answer (score 0):

## [Code Beautify Number to Word Converter](https://codebeautify.org/number-to-word-converter), 1 Byte

If you input this:

```
1
```

You get `one`.

Comment: ...This isn't really a programming language though

Comment: @JoKing I know, but google translate isn't either!

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
‘ċŀ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWyx81zDjSfbRhSXFScjFUDCYHAA)

Compressed string literal.

Answer (score 0):

## [StackCell](https://github.com/Starwort/StackCell), 10 bytes

`"net":[;:]`

Explanation:

- `"net"`: Push the letters 'n', 'e', and 't' to the stack
- `:`: Duplicate the top element of the stack ('t')
- `[`: Consume the top element of the stack, and if zero jump to the next `]` in the source
- `;`: Consume and print the top element of the stack ('t' on the first iteration, then 'e', then 'n')
- `:`: Duplicate the top element of the stack ('e' on the first iteration, 'n' on the second iteration, and 0 on the third iteration)
- `]`: Consume the top element of the stack, and if non-zero jump to the previous `[` in the source