# The shortest way to find one unique value when all other values are the same

Tags: code-golf, array, search

In [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/245978/105327) at Code Review they tried to find the fastest way to return the unique element in an array where all the elements are the same except one. But what is the shortest code that accomplish the same thing?

#### Goal

Find the unique element in an array and return it.

#### Rules

- The input array will contain only integer, strictly positive numbers, so you can use 0 as the end of the input if your language needs it.
- The size of the array will be at least 3 and will have a finite size. You can limit the size of the array to any limit your language has.
- Every element in the array will be the same, except for one which will be different.
- You must output the value (not the position) of the unique element in any standard format. You can output leading or trailing spaces or newlines.
- You can take the input array in any accepted format.

#### Examples

```
Input                   Output
------------------------------
[ 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1 ]      2
[ 3, 5, 5, 5, 5 ]         3
[ 9, 2, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9 ]   2
[ 4, 4, 4, 6 ]            6
[ 5, 8, 8 ]               5
[ 8, 5, 8 ]               5
[ 8, 8, 5 ]               5
```

#### Winner

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so may the shortest code for each language win!

Comment: Do we assume the input array contains a unique element and others are the same?

Comment: @Amessihel yes, you don't need to check that, it is assumed.

Comment: The title feels too long for such a simple operation. Suggested: _Odd one out_

Comment: @LuisMendo nice title, the thing is that I just wanted to use the same title as the [original question at Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/245978/105327) but changing "fastest" with "shortest". :-)

Comment: Suggest adding testcases `[8, 8, 5]` and `[5, 8, 8]` since there isn't one were the last element is unique and 3 element arrays are a corner cases in themselves.

Comment: is [3] allowed as output for [3,7,7]

Comment: @Tornado547 outputting a value as a singleton list is [allowed under current consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11884/81203)

Answer (score 25):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 27 bytes

```python
lambda x:min(x,key=x.count)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCKjczT6NCJzu10rZCLzm/NK9E839BUWZeiUaaRrShjgIEGUEYsZqaXHBJYx0FUzhCkbEEa7BERijyJjoKEGSGImwBNsoCJPYfAA)

Answer (score 14):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 24 bytes

```r
a=scan();a[a!=median(a)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9G2ODkxT0PTOjE6UdE2NzUlE8hL1Iz9b6gAgkYg8j8A)

Comment: Alas for the lack of a built-in `mode` function.

Answer (score 13):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>32</s>  27 bytes

*Saved 5 bytes thanks to @xnor*

```javascript
a=>a.sort()[0]+a.pop()-a[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc5NCoMwEIbhvaeYZUJjrL/owl4kZDFYLYo4wYjXTyG1QSqFdzGLh4@ZcEfbraPZ4oWevRtah@0DpaV1Y1zd9Q2lIcN4jCrVrqPF0tzLmV5sYApScZR9DtAAwDkkCWTRL84FlCEvA84vuPGbzTnQ/5YLcVR9Z8NydcG1f6A@yYBL9wY)

#### How?

`a.sort()` sorts the input array in lexicographical order. We know for sure that this is going to put the unique element either at the first or the last position, but we don't know which one:

```javascript
[ x, ..., y, ..., x ].sort() -> [ y, x, ..., x ] or [ x, x, ..., y ]
```

Either way, the sum of the first and the last elements minus the 2nd one gives the expected result:

```javascript
[ y, x, ..., x ] -> y + x - x = y
[ x, x, ..., y ] -> x + y - x = y
```

We could also XOR all of them:

```javascript
a=>a.sort()[0]^a.pop()^a[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc5BCoMwEIXhvaeYZQJprFpFF/YiIcJgtVQkE4x4/RRSG6RS@Bez@HjMhBu6fnnZ9WLoMfix9djeUTpaVsbVVXcoLVnGO1SZ9j0ZR/MgZ3qykSnIxF7@OUADAOeQppAnv7gQUMaCjLg44SZsNsdA/1u@ib3qOxuXqxOuwwP1QUZc@jc)

Comment: Here's a bit of a different strategy that I think works: [TIO](https://tio.run/##dc5NCoMwEIbhvaeYZUJjrL/owl4kZDFYLYo4wYjXTyG1QSqFdzGLh4@ZcEfbraPZ4oWevRtah@0DpaV1Y1zd9Q2lIcN4jCrVrqPF0tzLmV5sYApScZR9DtAAwDkkCWTRL84FlCEvA84vuPGbzTnQ/5YLcVR9Z8NydcG1f6A@yYBL9wY "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: @xnor This is much better indeed!

Answer (score 10):

## x86-16 machine code, 14 bytes

**Binary:**

```
00000000: 498d 7c01 f3a6 e305 4ea6 7401 4ec3       I.|.....N.t.N.
```

**Listing:**

```
49          DEC  CX             ; only do length-1 compares 
8D 7C 01    LEA  DI, [SI+1]     ; DI pointer to next value 
F3 A6       REPE CMPSB          ; while( [SI++] == [DI++] );
E3 05       JCXZ DONE           ; if end of array, result is second value
4E          DEC  SI             ; SI back to first value
A6          CMPSB               ; [SI++] == [DI++]? 
74 01       JE   DONE           ; if so, result is second value
4E          DEC  SI             ; otherwise, result is first value 
        DONE: 
C3          RET                 ; return to caller
```

Callable function, input array in `[SI]`, length in `CX`.  Result in `[SI]`.

**Explanation:**

Loop through the array until two different adjacent values are found.  Compare the first to the third value.  If they are the same, the "odd value out" must be the second, otherwise it is the first.

*Example:*

Input `[ 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1 ]`, reduce until different adjacent values are found `a = [ 1, 2, 1, 1 ]`. If `a[0] == a[2]` then result is `a[1]`, otherwise result is `a[0]`.

**Tests using DOS DEBUG:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `lea di, [si+1]` is the same size but saves instructions.  IDK if we could justify taking the array length as "max index", avoiding the `dec cx`.  It's not an "interesting" saving, just calling-convention wanking, so not worth updating your test-result images.  And hard to justify; it's so standard to do pointer+length even in asm.  Nice idea overall to use `rep cmpsb` this way.

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
ʒ¢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//1KRDi/7/jzbUUTDSUQCShrEA)

Since `1` is the only truthy integer in 05AB1E, we can just filter (`ʒ`) on the `¢`ount.

There is also the Counter-Mode builtin, which returns the least frequent element in a list at the same bytecount:

```
.m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fL/f//2hDHQUIMoIwYgE)

Comment: Stax also has a built-in, but it outputs a code point...

Comment: When I read the challenge just yet I had `¢Ï` in mind, which is basically the same approach as your first. Didn't think about the least frequent builtin, but that's indeed a nice alternative. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thats neat, I had the same idea, but couldn't find `Ï` in the documentation. Maybe I just need to read all commands descriptions at some point ;).

Answer (score 8):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 5 bytes

```apl
⍸1=¯⍸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1HvDkPbQ@uB1P@0R20THvX2PepqPrTe@FHbxEd9U4ODnIFkiIdn8P80BUMwNAKRXGkKxgqmEAhkWwJFLWEQyDcBQzMgywKowgIA)

Regular Dyalog APL 18.0 has `⍸⍣¯1`, but it doesn't work here because it requires the input array to be sorted, unlike Extended's `¯⍸` which allows unsorted input arrays.

#### How it works

```apl
⍸1=¯⍸  ⍝ Input: a vector N of positive integers
       ⍝ (Example: 4 4 6 4)
   ¯⍸  ⍝ Whence; generate a vector V where V[i] is the count of i in N
       ⍝ (¯⍸ 4 4 6 4 → 0 0 0 3 0 1)
 1=    ⍝ Keep 1s intact and change anything else to zero (V1)
       ⍝ (1= 0 0 0 3 0 1 → 0 0 0 0 0 1)
⍸      ⍝ Where; generate a vector W from V1, where i appears V1[i] times in W
       ⍝ (⍸ 0 0 0 0 0 1 → 6)
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 32 bytes

```hs
f(x:y)|[e]<-filter(/=x)y=e|1<3=x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc7RCoMgFAbg@z3FuTTQjXJFjXyEPUHI8EKZzCJaFwW9uxN1Q6@m/4VwPn/OU7xf0hhrFdpue3EMkvdEabPKBV3YVuxMHmVP2WZHoSdgMIr5/gA0L3pa4QyqOAEM7pY4pgoP4OAPIVA5gh2hGOpfvvNAaCSd/9@l8TBpueKYJqkIpInE9bcu@TyQOpLWb/GPtPmiGeH2Aw)

## Explanation

The code, expanded with variables renamed to be more descriptive.

```hs
f (first:rest)
 | [unique] <- filter (/=first) rest = unique
 | 1 < 3 = first
```

`(first:rest)` is a pattern match on a list that destructures it into its first element (`first`) and the list without the first element (`rest`).

Each line with a `|` at the front is a case in the function (known as "guards" in Haskell). The syntax looks like `functionName args | condition1 = result1 | condition2 = result2 ...`. There are two cases:

1. `[unique] <- filter (/=first) rest`. This asserts that `filter (/=first) rest` produces a list containing only one element, which we name `unique`. `filter (/=first) rest` filters out all elements in `rest` not equal to `first`. If we are in this case, then we know that `unique` is the unique element, and we return it.
2. `1 < 3`. This asserts that 1 is less than 3. Since it's always true, this is a "fallthrough" case. If we reach it, we know that there are at least 2 elements not equal to the first element, so we return `first`.

Answer (score 8):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)  + coreutils, 12 bytes

```bash
sort|uniq -u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzi/qKSmNC@zUEG39P9/Qy4YNILQAA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ḟÆṃ
```

Explanation: `ḟ` (probably) removes all elements that are not the most common element (returned by `Æṃ`). I don't know why isn't the result a single-element list (perhaps it's a feature I didn't know about?), but that makes this even better.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjvmH2x7ubP7//3@0iQ4ImsUCAA)

Comment: The result of the Link `ḟÆṃ` [_is_ a single-element-list](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjvmH2x7ubP5/uP3opIc7Z/z/H22iA4JmsQA), it's just that when a full-program is run which results in a single-element-list the printed output is what would be printed if that single-element were the result. (i.e. `2RWWW` just prints `[1,2]` rather than `[[[[1,2]]]]`.

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>10</sup> 8 bytes

```
1#.|//.~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DZX1avT19er@a/7nSlMw1IEiIwhDAShmrKNgCkcKIAAUtAQrsURGIGETHSgyA/EswHosFAA)

#### How it works

```
 1#.|//.~  input:                  1 1 1 2 1
      /.~  group by itself:        1 1 1 1
                                   2
    |/     insert | (remainder) into both groups:        
                   1 | 1 | 1 | 1 = 0
                   2             = 2
 1#.       sum:                    2
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) / MATLAB, 19 bytes

```matlab
@(x)x(sum(x==x')<2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0KzQqO4NFejwta2Ql3Txkjzf5pGtIKhDhQZQRgKsZpcIHFjHQVTOIIJWoKVWSIjmJSJDhSZwUQswHotgNz/AA)

#### How it works

```matlab
@(x)                  % Define a function of x
          x==x'       % Square matrix of all pairwise comparisons (non-complex x)
      sum(     )      % Sum of each column
                <2    % Less than 2? This will be true for only one column
    x(            )   % Take that entry from x
```

Comment: this is the same byte count if you were to port the R answer `@(x)x(x!=median(x))`

Comment: @Giuseppe Good idea! And then `@(x)x(x~=mode(x))` is two bytes shorter. You should post that yourself

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that myself!! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 17 bytes

```matlab
@(x)x(x!=mode(x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0KzQqNC0TY3PyUVyNb8n6YRrWCoA0VGEIZCrCYXSNxYR8EUjmCClmBllsgIJmWiA0VmMBELsF4LIPc/AA)

2 bytes golfed thanks to [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207749/67312)!

Answer (score 6):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 18 bytes

```ruby
->a{a-[a.sort[1]]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYu7CoNAEEV7v@IiLBgYBTURLfRHhikmothl8VGI@u0ruCKBU9znuHxX19cubnTTmDWZfuPMqcjhmJHSTeYFhAJGTvg8@Ki6JtU/vnjTTeF9eb1KiCSdtgM27LrDLvMUhcaibmBsCANWQs8q8sLhTg)

The unique element will always be the largest or smallest, so remove all copies of the second element.

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>21</s> <s>19</s> 17 bytes

```
f[c=a_...,b_,c]=b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z8tOtk2MV5PT08nKV4nOdY26X9AUWZeSbSyrl2ag4NyrFpdcHJiXl01V7WhDggagchaHa5qYx1TCARxLIHiljAIEjDRAUEzENMCqMiilqv2PwA)

Comment: also `Tally[#][[1, 1]] &` for 18

Comment: @Kai `Tally` lists elements in order of first appearance. That function is equivalent to `#[[1]]&`. (besides that, it also contains redundant whitespace)

Comment: oops you're right, didn't test enough, I thought it would sort them by the number of times they appear. White space was inserted when I copied it out of mma

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 25 bytes

```r
a=sort(scan());a[a!=a[2]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9G2OL@oRKM4OTFPQ1PTOjE6UdE2MdooNva/sYIpCP4HAA)

Sort the input, giving `a`. Now `a[2]` is one of the repeated values. Keep only the element not equal to `a[2]`.

This ends up 4 bytes shorter than my best shot with a contingency table:

```r
names(which(table(scan())<2))
```

Comment: How do you know that a[2] is one of the repeated values and not the unique value? After sorting, the unique value must be either the first or last element. But couldn't a[2] be the last element?

Comment: @Stef `a[2]` is the second element (R uses 1-based indexing), and the array of guaranteed to have at least 3 elements.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that R used 1-indexing.

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 4 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @FryAmTheEggman

```
ho/Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyNfP/D//2gFCx0FUx0FC4VYAA)

### Explanation

```
 o   : Order implicit input
  /Q : by count of the element
h    : then take the first element
```

Answer (score 5):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 23 bytes

```powershell
$args-ne($args|sort)[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V8lsSi9WDcvVQPMqCnOLyrRjDaM/V/LxaVSklpcomCroMGloWCoA0VGEIaCpo4CGCgbAWWNdRRM4QguBZI1BspagnVZIiOIGrBeEx0oMkPWCJI1A8oCDbQAIjQpkKwpUNYCbCNIFsKxAFvPpQl1e41qNZdKFdAHKvFcaippCg5VXLX/AQ)

Takes input by splatting. We apply a filter to the original array getting rid of the dupes by sorting it and taking the 2nd element.

Comment: omg - `($args|group|where count -eq 1).name` doesn't even come close :(

Comment: and `$args|group|? c* -eq 1|% n*` too

Answer (score 5):

## T-SQL, 40 bytes

Input is a table variable

```sql
DECLARE @ table(v int)
INSERT @ values(1),(1),(2),(1)

SELECT*FROM @ 
GROUP BY v
HAVING SUM(1)=1
```

Another variation

## T-SQL, 54 bytes

```sql
DECLARE @ table(v real)
INSERT @ values(1),(1),(2),(1)

SELECT iif(max(v)+min(v)<avg(v)*2,min(v),max(v))FROM @
```

Comment: This is so straightforward and logical in SQL. Nice!

Comment: @640KB thanks for your comment. I added a more obscure solution as well, it is a bit longer unfortunately . However this syntax could be converted to other languages and hopefully allow short answers

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 4 bytes

```
oḅ∋≠
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/P//hjtZHHd2POhf8/x9tomOiY6xjEvs/CgA)

Takes a list and returns a singleton list.

### Explanation

```
oḅ∋≠  Input is a list, say [4,4,3,4].
o     Sort: [3,4,4,4]
 ḅ    Blocks of equal elements: [[3],[4,4,4]]
  ∋   Pick a block: [3]
   ≠  This block must have distinct elements (in this case, must have just one).
      Output it implicitly.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [RAD](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/rad), 13 bytes

```
⍵[1⍳⍨+/⍵∘=¨⍵]
```

The lack of a need for `{}` in this language really helps.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pM@f//Ue/WaMNHvZsf9a7Q1gdyHnXMsD20AsiI/f//v6ECBBoBAA)

### Explanation

```
⍵[1⍳⍨+/⍵∘=¨⍵]
     +/⍵∘=¨⍵  count of each element's # of occurrences
  1⍳⍨         first occurrence of a 1
⍵[          ] the argument at that index
```

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), <s>8</s> 6 bytes

**Solution:**

```
*<#'=:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7n2alZaOsbmv1P01dw1ABBI1ApLWxgikEWlsCRSxh0FrBBAzNrE0VLBQsrC2ASkAkkNb8/x8A)

**Explanation:**

```
*<#'=: / the solution
    =: / group the input
  #'   / count length of each
 <     / sort ascending
*      / take the first
```

**Extra:**

- **-2 bytes** thanks to `ngn` by dropping the lambda

Comment: `*<#'=:` is valid too

Comment: Ah nice, I was trying to get it to work without the lambda, will update!

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 30 bytes

```hs
f(x:y)|elem x y=f$y++[x]|1>0=x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02jwqpSsyY1JzVXoUKh0jZNpVJbO7oitsbQzsC24n9uYmaegq1CbmKBb7yCRkFRZl6Jgp5CmiaXgkI0EBrqQJERhKEQqwAGuroKRkAlOkAlxjoKpnAEk4coMYYqsQTrt0RGYIVIppjoQJEZkhEQJWZQJUDzLYAIVR6ixBSqxALsCkJKLFAdiqIk9j8A) Footer stolen from [coles answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207784/64121).

If the first element is not in the remaining list, return it, otherwise rotate it to the end and try again.

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 19 bytes

```
Tr[#/.Median@#->0]&
```

Inspired by [Kirill L.'s R submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207747/86341)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P6QoWllfzzc1JTMxz0FZ184gVu1/cHJiXnRAUWZeSbSygq6dQlq0cmysmo5CdbWhDggagchaIN9YxxQCQRxLoLglDIIETHRA0AzENNWx0LEAMSyAqqEMILO2NvY/AA)

Finds the median, replaces its occurrences in the list with 0, and sums the list.

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>3</s> 2 bytes

<sup>*-1 byte thanks to [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214)!*</sup>

```
◄=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9H0Ftv///9HG@uYQmAsAA)

Comment: [2 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9H0Ftv///9HG@uYQmAsAA "Husk – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
Ċ↓h
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C4%8A%E2%86%93h&inputs=%5B9%2C%202%2C%209%2C%209%2C%209%2C%209%2C%209%5D&header=&footer=)

### Explained

```
Ċ↓h
Ċ     # Get the counts of all items
 ↓    # Get the smallest item based on last item
  h   # Output the head of that list
```

Also, according to code-golf's statistics, only a small percentage of people who view my answers actually upvote them. So if you enjoy this answer, consider upvoting, it's free, and you can change your mind at any time (given you have ≥2k rep). Enjoy the answer.

Answer (score 4):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 24 bytes

```julia
~d=d[@.sum(==(d),[d])<2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY7LCsMgEEX3fsUsFaQQ0wQDFfIfgwuDLaT0ATGBrvLr1o5BQha9nMXA8c54Xx6jqz4xrt547E9heXJjuBcSvRUXZaM3yDhCJTdUHsBKoCjx07WEplBcSk26o163Jz/K7bPcaPfVlJZ02qkTB5fSkNZ09Z/Wh08VbRnD3oVwnWZYnTE4WLi9J@BODgLGF3gbvw)

Answer (score 4):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ṁo
```

Note that [output as a singleton list is a default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11884/114446).

##### Explanation

```python
Ṁo  # Implicit input
 o  # Remove all instances of                       from the input
Ṁ   #                         the mode of the input
    # Implicit output
```

##### Screenshot

[image: Screeshot]

Answer (score 4):

## [ATOM](https://github.com/SanRenSei/ATOM), 15 chars, 18 bytes

#### Code:

```
*2>($1$1==*)
```

#### Usage:

```
[1,1,1,2,1,1] INTO *2>($1$1==*)
```

### [Try it live here](https://sanrensei.github.io/ATOM/)

#### Explanation:

The ATOM language implicitly treats the expression as a function, where * is the parameter.

Therefore, it interprets the expression as

```
[1,1,1,2,1,1] 2>($1$1==*)
```

The  operator is an array filter, which takes an array on the left, and a function on the right. The expression to the right is implicitly parsed into a function.  Therefore, it is searching the values in the input array for all values where the following returns true

```
2>($1$1==*)
```

The  operator is array length, so it is searching for elements in the original input where ($1$1==*) evaluates to an array of length 1 i.e. the unique element.

The first $1 looks for the variable on the stack at index 1, which is the original array (index 0 is the element in the array that is being iterated through, since we are inside the where operator).

Another  operator is performed on the array. $1==* is now parsed to a new function, and $1 refers to the variable on the stack at index 1, which is the number being iterated through in the outer . The * refers to the immediate stack variable, which is the number being iterated through in the inner . Matches are returned, so if there are multiple instances of a number in the original array, the resulting array will be of length greater than or equal to 2. As such, only the unique element in the array will satisfy the 2>($1$1==*) clause.

Comment: Welcome to CGCC! And excellent answer! It can even detect multiple unique values!

Answer (score 4):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 4 [bytes](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=U0JDUyDihpAgK0BcMOKKlwpEZWNvZGUg4oaQIOKHjOKKjy0x4pa9wrEu4o2Y4ouv4oav4oqCwq8x4qe74ouv4qe7LOKHjOKItSjihpjCrzHii68rMjU2KSAtQFwwKzEKJnAg4oqCIjggYml0IGVuY29kaW5nOlx0IiBTQkNTICLih4ziio8tMeKWvcKxLuKNmOKLr-KGr-KKgsKvMeKnu-KLr-Knuyzih4ziiLUo4oaYwq8x4ouvKzI1NikiIOKKgitAXDDih6ExMjkiLiziiLY74oiYwqzCscKv4oy14oia4peL4oyK4oyI4oGFPeKJoDziiaQ-4omlKy3Dl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmt4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pah4oqU4omF4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqXL-KIp1xc4oi14omh4oi64oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oip4oqT4oqD4oqZ4ouF4o2Y4o2c4o2a4qyaJz_ijaPijaQh4o6L4oas4pqCzrfPgM-E4oiefl9bXXt9KCnCr0AkXCLihpB8IyIKJnAg4oqCImRlY29kZWQ6XHQiIERlY29kZSAiwqPCsS0xwrjChy7DjMKlwrPCsMKIMcKfwqXCnyzCo8K_KMK1wogxwqUrMjU2KSIg4oqCK0BcMOKHoTEyOSIuLOKItjviiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYU94omgPOKJpD7iiaUrLcOXw7fil7_igb_igpnihqfihqXiiKDip7vilrPih6HiiqLih4zima3ii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHiipTiiYXiip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_ihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipcv4oinXFziiLXiiaHiiLriip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziiKniipPiioPiipnii4XijZjijZzijZrirJonP-KNo-KNpCHijovihqzimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ5-X1tde30oKcKvQCRcIuKGkHwjIg==)

```
⊗1⍘⊚
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=RiDihpAg4oqXMeKNmOKKmgoKRiBbMSAxIDEgMiAxIDFdCkYgWzggOCA1XQpGIFs1IDggOF0=)

```
⊗1⍘⊚
  ⍘⊚  # inverse where, i.e. how many times does each element occur?
⊗1    # index of 1
```

Answer (score 4):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/), 34 bytes

```
{a[$0]++?c=$0:b+=$0}END{print b-c}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704sTx7wYKlpSVpuhY3laoTo1UMYrW17ZNtVQyskrSBZK2rn0t1QVFmXolCkm5yLUQlVMOC1cZcMGgEEQIA)

Takes positive integers separated by newlines. Let's call the unique number `u` and duplicates `d`.

- `{a[$0]++?c=$0:b+=$0}`: Executed for each line. `$0` contains the number on the line.

  - `a` is used as a dict that counts the occurrences of each number. `a[$0]++` increments the count, and evaluates to falsy if it was encountered the first time, truthy otherwise.
  - `b+=$0` is run exactly twice, when each of `u` and `d` is read the first time. Therefore, `b` is equal to `u+d` at the end.
  - `c=$0` is run for the rest of the time, and `$0` in this case is always `d`.
- `END{print b-c}` is run after all inputs are processed. `b-c` is `u`, and it is printed.

Comment: 33 bytes: [`a[$0]++?$0=b-$0:b+=$0{}END{print}`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704sTx7wYKlpSVpuhY3FROjVQxitbXtVQxsk3RVDKyStG1VDKprXf1cqguKMvNKaiEKoeoXrDTmMuIyBkGIAAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>56</s></sup> 39 bytes

```python
lambda x:[i for i in x if x.count(i)<2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCKjpTIS2/SCFTITNPoUIhM02hQi85vzSvRCNT08Yo9n9BUSaQnaYRbagDh0YgIlZTkwsuaayDCi0RbKC6/wA)

Comment: [Lambdafication](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fkpqmkKZRoWnFpZCWX6SQqZCZp1CcWgIRUcgESukl55fmlWhkatraGmpaFRRlgjlcabYx/3MSc5NSEhUqrKIzEborgLoUELpsjGL/QzSlaUQb6sChEYiI1dTkgksa66BCSwQbqO4/AA) gives 39 bytes. (Singleton list is a valid output format by default.)

Comment: You don't need to convert the input to a set, since it doesn't matter how many times you uselessly count the multiple element.

Answer (score 3):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 2 bytes

```
C⌡
```

Not a built-in!

`C` is "count occurrences in list" and `⌡` is "find the smallest by".

(the footer is "evaluate" and "call the function above", Gaia doesn't seem to evaluate input by default)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/3/lRz8L/qY/aJv6PVrBUMDQAEjAYCwA)

Comment: If Gaia does not evaluate input by default, shouldn't you include that in the answer? Note all the R answers that need to do a `scan()`.

Comment: @Charlie This submission is a function, not a full program (for some reason, Gaia actually calls lines of code functions)

Comment: I typically include the `e` in my Gaia answers, as I feel it's more correct; `e↑` always felt like such a gray area to me. I don't think I would have thought of using `⌡` for this though, this is pretty neat!

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 27 bytes

```
Keys@Select[Counts@#,#<2&]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773zu1stghODUnNbkk2jm/NK@k2EFZR9nGSC1W7X9AUWZeiYK@Q7q@Q3W1oQ4IGoHIWh2FamMdUwgEcSyB4pYwCBIw0QFBMxDTVMdCxwLEsACqhjKAzNra//8B)

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 62 bytes

```java
int f(int[] a){Arrays.sort(a);return a[0]+a[a.length-1]-a[1];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY5NCoNADIXXeoosZ2gd6qJQkC56gK5ciovUv44dR5mJFhHPbtNWCAkvvHx5LU4YteVr093QO4KWtRpJG3VzDmefhMP4MLqAwqD3cEdtYQk2bQlqwT3LAeXy9yrPBIEycRWNzgJmp/yAGSpT2YaeUZxHmMV5sm7BDvWExGPqdQkdo0VKTtvmC3WNl7CEQbA/gSsslyNwndeE1@nsqepUP5Ia@IaErd6/eEKqmkNINq3hun0A)

Thanks to JollyJoker for correct way.

Original completely own failing dumb#ss solution:

`int f(int[] a){Arrays.sort(a);return a[0];}`

Comment: Nice try, but fails the 1st test case: on [ 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1 ] results 1 instead of the required 2.

Comment: a[0]<a[1]?a[0]:a[a.length-1]

Comment: or `a[0]+a[a.length-1]-a[1]`

Comment: Thanks for the input. Trying to play with the Big Bois always makes me look like an #ss. I guess the "New contributor" tag kind of saved me from rougher comments hehe.

Comment: Suggest `int[]a` instead of `int[] a`

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>46</s> 45 bytes

```php
fn($i)=>array_flip(array_count_values($i))[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9RC4IwFIXf9ysu4YPCQNSKxKynoIeg3lVk2IaGuOFmENFvtzk17HIYh93vnruJUvT7oygFQhaLe9bYVuXEB9K25JWzuhL2aAveNSp/krqjckCcxMv6SA8pKpWEGFCCABLw8CR/NJBhGMp19eEbJMCw@Wnuz0hgkNDMh0sZcJGyxpO2i4g5ZWuQnVmxgwz@yyAblOnnM95SUpQ2TP8gUjtw4K0DaFFyeEje5LQp@J3apoVhlapUrTBYbL65nW/56XqJ0Kf/Ag)

Could maybe be golfed more using a custom solution, but the straightforward one is quite short already: returns the first value that is counted one time. Works with any type of value. If only PHP array functions were not prefixed with `array_`!

EDIT: saved 1 byte thanks to @640KB now uses `array_flip`, meaning that it still works for any value type but this time gets the last value counted one time

Comment: Yes, darn those long and redundant function names.  Turns out it's [45 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY9RC4IwFIXf9ysu4YPCQNSKxKynoIeg3lVk2IaGuOFmENFvtzk17HIYh93vnruJUvT7oygFQhaLe9bYVuXEB9K25JWzuhL2aAveNSp/krqjckCcxMv6SA8pKpWEGFCCABLw8CR/NJBhGMp19eEbJMCw@Wnuz0hgkNDMh0sZcJGyxpO2i4g5ZWuQnVmxgwz@yyAblOnnM95SUpQ2TP8gUjtw4K0DaFFyeEje5LQp@J3apoVhlapUrTBYbL65nW/56XqJ0Kf/Ag) if you use `array_flip()` instead of `array_search()` though!

Comment: @640KB nice one! I actually didn't know about `array_flip`, makes sense!

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, 14 bytes

Put the numbers in column A, and enter this formula in another column

```
=UNIQUE(A:A,,1
```

Comment: Per the community meta, you can actually drop the trailing `)` for -1 byte as excel will auto correct it to be there for you :)

Comment: Huh, I somehow forgot/didn't know about `UNIQUE()` when I did this one. Anyway, you can replace TRUE with 1.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz good point, thanks. Lol I typed this on my phone so I didn’t even test it first.

Answer (score 3):

[C GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 40 bytes

```
f(int*a){a=*a^*++a?a[-(*a==a[1])]:f(a);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NIzOvRCtRszrRVisxTktbO9E@MVpXQyvR1jYx2jBWM9YqTSNR07r2P1CZQm5iZp6GpkI1lwIQFBQBhdI0lFRTYvKUdBTSNEAmRcdqVhvqKECQEYxhUKupaY1fk7GOgikSIkKHJdgCS1REhD4THQUIMiNKOdAxFmBEhFqQMlNiFUNMhfu19j8A)

Thanks to [xibu](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90181/xibu) for -5 bytes!

Thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat) for -2 bytes!

Comment: [-5 Bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/7/IOk0jM69EK1GzushWKzEuMdow1j4xGkQp2iZGG8XGWqVpJGobalrX/geqU8hNzMzT0FSo5lIAgoIioFCahpJqSkyeko5CmgbIqOhYzWpDHQUIMoIxDGo1Na3xazLWUTBFQkTosARbYImKiNBnoqMAQWZEKQc6xgKMiFALUmZKrGKIqXC/1v4HAA) by [replacing return with an assignment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106067/90181) and reordering the code a bit.

Comment: @xibu that's amazing. I had no idea we could replace return with an assignment!

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 39 bytes

```c
f(int*a){a=*a-*++a?a[*a--!=a[2]]:f(a);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZHLCoMwEEX3fkUqFBJNwPcT6YdYF4NtiotKEbsSv93GaUQXhlzI5JybbNKKV9sui6RdPzrAJqgcEI7rwg1qNYlLBXXQNIWkwMp5US3yhq6njEwWWU@jXzfVRHyuE2yDN5e6EWAj5CQ@ZNch6hyv5jrr2hsRNiKukxxUjEq9l2F2kaDI@N/tPN04KuSfQRlJqH193HubSzr6jJ3ywMBDA48MPDbwxMDTlVtkeI7foSdeac1nP6Z2qP1G7YUjBOg/@wE)

```
f(int*a){      // function taking a 0-terminated array pointer.

 a=            // return using eax register trick.
 *a-*++a?      // compare current item with next item :
 a[*a--!=a[2]] // if different we move the pointer by the result of comparing the next item,
:f(a);         // if not we recursively call on the incremented pointer.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [12 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

```
BØ├┤ÅöÀ&iG£3
```

## Explanation

Unpacked: `$v{(${=v})#<2}`

```
$ Filter
  v{ block with index named v
    ( Start expression
      $ Filter
        { block with index named _
          =v Is current item equal to v
        }
    )
    # Length
    <2 Is less than 2
  }
```

Output implicit, input on one line split by spaces

Answer (score 3):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), <strike>169</strike> <s>105</s> <s>37</s> 25 bytes

*-12 bytes thanks to [@Yousername](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/91262/yousername)*

```
f(l)=l.max+l.min-l.median
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xdqzzxxcmi)

Comment: 25 bytes: `f(x)=x.min+x.max-x.median`

Comment: @Yousername `median` is smart

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby 2.7](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 15 bytes

```ruby
p$*.tally.key 1
```

Takes in the array of chars as input from the arguments `$*` passed to it.

---

## [Ruby 2.7](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 18 bytes

```ruby
->a{a.tally.key 1}
```

The following is the screenshot of SoloLearn code playground, which uses Ruby 2.7,

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>48</s> <s>46</s> 44 bytes

-2 thanks to @ceilingcat

```c
f(int*a){*a=*a-a[-1]?a[-(*a==a[1])]:f(a+1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVHbboMwDH3nKyymSQkENHZp01G2D8nyEEFZEzY6MfqE8u3MXMaIuodaR4njHDvHcR6953l/o@v841wcYP/dFvoUH1/6kui6DRTtApUFKlIiSuQrrgTPmRKJpPK5JCpMaGp7pMKn0jWh0HkeoA0RzQyr0uWoxFYKLiFDDszWQcJm3E8OWLa6fWDwtMC92o0puzVcwiObsXHjWIoj3CAfn7gM8vFdO3UxLuWpIRqbuEtBwx62uIUhXfW0OAPTTEwltBRGpmBcrsMf7KvBryqJf1uAz37TaLpwrFO9mqpXqINDBAbdK@vHsf9vVe9SyFuNSnDUqAWnPWfZvw9pDu25qVGHZ/sf)

Answer (score 3):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 22 bytes

```sh
<<<${@:#${${(o)@}[2]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moanx38bGRqXawUpZpVqlWiNf06E22ii2tva/JleagpGCsYIxkDYGscA0kAUWN1QwBNKGIBaYNgSLW4KhMYT@DwA)

`:#`Removes all elements matching the `[2]`nd element of the `(o)`rdered array, and `<<<`prints.

Answer (score 3):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 45 bytes

A closure that takes a mutable slice and returns the outlier.

```rust
|s:&mut[u8]|{s.sort();s[0]^s[1]^s[s.len()-1]}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY9RSsQwFEX_s4rrfEgi6WB1RjItxYWUCIM0UOhkpC-FQqYr8acfugF34yZcg0nbqXLhvdzz8i7J-0fbkRu_jMXpWFsuPGsqB4Pis3MmUd_JhbLbU-fKTumLpy2dW8dFTuW9fqEyjYW2TRU2k1QPy9JPzqYYV5F7PVJFGaaMa5BGweIZJeaWyqiHWLVc2KPcz1rJIdw4XLXSnYx6Wv1eKqlWp0LCfxe8hs6ZObfoUdu_N8IzAG9tbd0N3xjus-dBoMBG4q4XOZsmjQ0zPwRmeC8CHRhbfj2Oc_8F)

Explanation:

```rust
|s:&mut[u8]|{ // Take a mutable slice
  s.sort();   // Sort the slice. This means that
              // the outlier is now either the first or last
              // element, and every element in between must be common. 
  s[0]^s[1]^s[s.len()-1]
  // Since the slice must have at least three elements,
  // the first, second and last number must have distinct indices. 
  // One of these three is the outlier, and the other two are equal.
  // Xoring two equal numbers yields zero, and xoring zero with a
  // number n yields n. The operation is commutative and associative. 
  // Thus, by xoring the three relevant numbers we obtain the outlier. 

  // We could have also subtracted the second element since we know
  // it can't be the outliner, but this both looks less cool
  // and gives overflow problems when not using signed integers.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 30 bytes

```perl
s/\d+//;$_=s/\b$&\b//g?$_+0:$&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YPyZFW1/fWiXeFshMUlGLSdLXT7dXidc2sFJR@//fSMEQBv/lF5Rk5ucV/9f1NdUzMDT4r1sAAA)

#### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-a`, 31 bytes

```perl
//,(1-grep$_==$',@F)||say for@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19fX0fDUDe9KLVAJd7WVkVdx8FNs6amOLFSIS2/yMHt/39DBRg0gtD/8gtKMvPziv/r@prqGRga/NfNSwQA)

#### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-a`, 33 bytes

```perl
1-(@b="@F"=~/\b$_\b/g)||say for@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/99QV8MhyVbJwU3Jtk4/JkklPiZJP12zpqY4sVIhLb/IwQ2oRAEGjSD0v/yCksz8vOL/ur6megaGBv918xIB)

Comment: Note that in the input every element must be the same except one, so `[1 2 3 4 4 3 1 1]` would not be a valid input.

Comment: Changed my test case, but it doesn't really matter to the code.  It finds the unique element either way.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 8 bytes

```
ＩΦθ⁼¹№θι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwy0zpyS1SKNQR8G1sDQxp1jDUEfBOb8UKA0UytQEAev//6OjLXQUTHUULGJj/@uW5QAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Works by filtering out elements whose count is not `1`. (Singleton list output is allowed by default, although Charcoal's output for a singleton list looks like that of a bare string anyway.) Explanation:

```
  θ         Input list
 Φ          Filtered where
     №      Count of
       ι    Current element
      θ     In input list
   ⁼¹       Equals literal `1`
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 36 bytes

```r
n=scan();while(sd(n[-T]))T=T+1;n[+T]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8@2ODkxT0PTujwjMydVozhFIy9aNyRWUzPENkTb0DovWjsk9r@hAggaKRj@BwA)

Iterates over the indices, calculating the standard deviation of the array with the associated element removed; when the standard deviation is 0, the removed element is the unique value.

This isn't the [shortest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207747/67312) by a [long](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207744/67312) [shot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207748/67312), but it's a neat little R approach.

Comment: It's being a wild R battle, but this is a nice idea. :-)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>30</s> 29 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to Giuseppe, but still a long way to go to catch the [current leading R solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207736/the-shortest-way-to-find-one-unique-value-when-all-other-values-are-the-same/207747#207747)...*

```r
y=table(scan());names(y[y<2])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v9K2JDEpJ1WjODkxT0NT0zovMTe1WKMyutLGKFbzv6ECCBopGP4HAA)

Outputs a character string containing the value of the lonely element.

Edit: just realized that this is a worse version of the solution that [Robin Ryder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207736/the-shortest-way-to-find-one-unique-value-when-all-other-values-are-the-same/207744#207744) already discarded...

Answer (score 2):

## Wolfram Language (Mathematica) <s>17  29</s> 28 bytes

Code corrected due to comment by @att:

```
SortBy[Tally[#],Last][[1,1]]&
```

theorist managed to shave off one byte with this:

```
Cases[Tally@#,{_,1}][[1,1]]&
```

Comment: Fails when the unique element is the first element.

Comment: Yes,  Good catch! (I corrected the code.)

Comment: Also (saves 1 byte): `Cases[Tally@#,{_,1}][[1,1]]&`

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>68</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>59</s> 58 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!

```c
c;d;f(l,n)int*l;{for(c=0;--n;)l[n]-*l?d=n:(c=1);n=l[d*c];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLbboMwDIbveQoLCYlQ0AoU1jZlvZj2FBRNFYcNKUsr4AIN8ezMhEAZFJlg7O93iHFsfcVx18U0oZnOTE5yXhmMNtmt0ONgSy2LU8JCHlkGOycBP2LUJpQHLEyMOKJtdy9QovcyYCbgEziBXg99EHIIYEvxcQJOYbPJCQhFpqtaqSUqSs64qEcVVxbmEaGt0gt/rjnXidIogFcfqNKy@rS3YYQVG7BNac7gQEsXpC1J1wRvsjXmSOwgSh3mtoZdCe9Maf6a2UlmL3bcrwHvAeyffpIvAU8A8wqGIMohLxtijucdHWd03NHZjY43Ov5yUz7U9MVHv4qzuYPNyLS@p3WVJoKFxhEArv7UXwnH39fCgGKoqV7qD@dSH97x9vp/PXt3VVQIyWNieJLWcmqEe4Iy/01vmT5uT15kwJgiYrR6GmdPlJsaxrDU0DSRj@g8DVxm8fzP0immp0MvgWHyceg5@a8qUZUtE@PUg/UGWgJaeeHYi9LELuEuAZSRhFul7f4A)

Inputs a pointer to an array of integers and its length.
Returns the unique element.

**How**

We initialises a flag, `c`, to zero and go through all the elements starting at the last through to the second. We use the first element as a test value. When we find an element different from the first we cache its index in `d`. If an element is the same as the first, we set `c` to one. After looping we know that the first element is unique if `c` is still zero. Otherwise `d` is the index of the unique element.

Comment: @ceilingcat Interesting how the extra braces are worth it - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>26</s> 25 bytes

```
.+
*
O`
,A2,-2`
+`_¶_
¶
_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvqhGcoPNfT5tLi8s/gUvH0UhH1yiBSzsh/tC2eK5D27ji//831AFBIxDJZaxjCoFclkARSxjkMtEBQTMuC6CcBQA) Link includes test suite that converts from a comma-separated list to a newline-separated list for ease of use. Uses @xnor's algorithm. Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @FryAmTheEggman pointing out that I didn't need to remove the newlines before counting the `_`s. Explanation:

```
.+
*
```

Convert to unary.

```
O`
```

Sort.

```
,A2,-2`
```

Drop all entries except the first two and the last.

```
+`_¶_
¶
```

Subtract the second value from the sum of the first and last. Well, sort of. All this guarantees is that there are no `_`s left in between the newlines, so the number of remaining `_`s is the desired result, but without actually specifying where they are.

```
_
```

Count the remaining `_`s as a decimal integer.

Comment: I think you can save a byte doing the subtraction with a loop replacing `_¶_` with `¶`. I tried to save bytes by making the list always 3 elements by using deduplicate stages, but it didn't work out.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Thanks; for some reason I thought I had to delete the `¶`s...

Answer (score 2):

## [Assembly (as, x64, Linux)](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/index.html), 142 bytes (455 bytes code)

This runs on Linux only (for the syscalls) and only respects integers as bytes (input in ASCII).

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.text
.global _start
_start:
mov cx,0
r:
lea rbx,a
lea rsi,i
mov rdi,0
mov rdx,2
mov rax,0
push rcx
syscall
pop rcx
mov al,[rsi]
cmp cx,0
je s
cmp cx,1
je t
cmp cx,2
je v
cmp al,[rbx]
jne p
jmp w
s:
mov [rbx],al
inc cx
jmp r
t:
inc cx
cmp al,[rbx]
je r
inc rbx
jmp s
v:
cmp al,[rbx]
je r
mov [rbx+1],al
w:
inc rbx
p:
mov rsi,rbx
mov rdx,1
mov rdi,1
mov rax,1
syscall
mov rdi,0
mov rax, 60
syscall
.data
a:
.byte 0,0
i:
.byte 0,0,0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDNbsQgDITvfgrfS6Owhx54lWq1crK0JSIJwjRLnj7lp0Ft1RP@MjMmDDHrebD7M/FxdGYJ2t54XwJFXFbn9ZuJ0AUdA3Tvdh3I4o0D@QD1UDCvG45R9OAVWE3ohyioTmyEKbq/m2SoUxSXOlEOuU/@QD9G4J1Hshbc6gpnC1nxmpZcYZxdvWPSyCfJTOGkS6atUIkN8QrTotHBlD49gOufFkGQBbOMKVZED@kZ3/w7r5OWhUTFybCpfyzn4idZVj9UC7l6a24i49mAbK3I1oVsFfxpLGn40je1u1MgIAXdsAeNfbKZH5AQjqPHHuUX)

Comment: Output seems to be the opposite than expected. For `[0 1 0]` it returns 0 rather than 1.

Comment: I also saw this on tio but it actually works on my computer. Nevertheless I linked tio to at least make the rest triable :-(

Comment: Functionality aside, you can compact the code by removing newlines here and there (labels can share a line with a mnemonic). Also, `mov [rbx+1],al` `inc rbx` can be changed to `inc rbx` `mov [rbx],al`. [438 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZVBBbsMgELzvK3gARTiHHPhKFUWLQ1oibCOWOvj1LotrV01PntmZYbyLRG6wYXlDWlflx@zClZYxYxHjFJO7@wIqu5JBfYTJYhBXypgybB8zTLPoi9SQTHAoki0SoSHy0gPL6earvqEiTxtCzsQv@qxpoIV6DAHiFJmyAYN8r09coB/iVvBwgnbWMcs7OzGbG2sxWy48ifCokydQ@8k2lhjAjz2XsJYgmx/6Gk7NV1kzEszmv@Npds@fgtj6eP9d4r274xbdcYHu2PzlTlU760NUN8wIaJRdshO6mvwvlnpdteiE/gY "Assembly (as, x64, Linux) – Try It Online")

Comment: x86 answers can be scored by their assembled byte count. https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12339/how-are-bytes-counted-in-assembly?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'll correct that as soon as I'm not on mobile.

Comment: @gastropner is it possible to leave out the space after a label name?

Comment: Welcome to CGCC! I'd also highly recommend reading [Tips for golfing in x86](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132981/tips-for-golfing-in-x86-x64-machine-code) as it has lots of very helpful information. As said in post shared above, it's often more advantageous to submit your machine code answer as a function using either a known ABI or your own custom calling convention. That way the main logic is easier to see, more portable and should be much shorter. If you submit as machine code, I'd encourage including the listing with inline comments as well.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ü l1
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=/CBsMQ&input=WyA5LCAyLCA5LCA5LCA5LCA5LCA5IF0KLVE)

Groups (and sorts) by value and then filters items of length 1.

Answer (score 2):

## [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
{⍵[⊃⍋+/⍵∘.=⍵]}
```

-1 byte thanks to @streetster

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@/@lHv1uhHXc2Peru19YHsRx0z9GyBdGzt/7RHbRNwS3M96puqAFShkKZgqANFRhCGgoLCo965QFLBCEmVsY6CKRyBJMGKjJFUWIJNsERGUIOQzTHRgSIzmC0wYIakygJsjwWyEtP/AA)

### Explanation

```
{⍵[⊃⍋+/⍵∘.=⍵]} 
     +/⍵∘.=⍵  - a list of the number of occurences of each element
   ⊃⍋         - grab the first index
 ⍵[         ] - extract that element
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation to the solution? Is there any part of my [k](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207779/69200) solution that can help to golf this?

Comment: I don't think there's any part of the K solution that will help, but I will surely add an explanation!

Comment: Can you use 'grade up' to get something like *this* K solution? `{x@*<+/x=\:x}` - rather than checking for equality with 1, get indices to sort ascending and take the first?

Comment: Tacit form: `⊢⊃⍨∘⊃∘⍋1⊥∘.=⍨` ([TIO](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v//UdeiR13Nj3pXPOqYAWIAyd5uw0ddS4EsPVug@P@0R20TCKrietQ3VQGoUCFNwVAHiowgDAUFhUe9c4GkghGSKmMdBVM4AkmCFRkjqbAEm2CJjKAGIZtjogNFZjBbYMAMSZUF2B4LZCWm/wE)) Not so pretty, but saves a byte.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>50</s> 42 bytes

```c
f(int*b,int*e){b=(*b^*e--?:f(b,e)^*e)^*e;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDtboMwDPyNn8JCqpQPo7Xr99JsD9IyaUBAQRSmjl9DPDtzWDdtPsVy7s6nKHlS5fk0lcK3vcoodCeHzAqVvSqXJC9PpcjISb6EY8bp@uZbIQdgK/bn1A6wooDHucOatnfAkbnjL2BDATuCA4sHGM0c0YQI3BFuCfeEG8I1slR2t/Ak9HZJnV0af/rwn64rRSMf7hPL0nTaNmevdSpxgChsqMxVaLHXHUGEXMq1xTeh2ZomKwMRx@Ocr2rLflOfLLtMrbWEKHq/sVSKeFFgTKqWvPBDXVr8V/YZ47/6ori0MfGfuYqQIyWLI4zTFw)

Answer (score 2):

## [MY](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/my-language), 17 bytes

```
ωω9Ġ'ƒ⇷(⍉Σ1=⍸ω@⍰←
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y638//985/lOyyML1I9NetS@XeNRb@e5xYa2j3p3nO90eNS74VHbhP///0cb6hjqGAGxYSwA)

### Explanation

```
ωω9Ġ'ƒ⇷(⍉Σ1=⍸ω@⍰←
ωω                  push the argument twice
  9Ġ'               push "=" in the codepage
     ƒ              turn it into a function
      ⇷             keeping the left argument the same, and mapping over each element 
       (            apply that
        ⍉           transpose
         Σ          sum (now we have how many times each element occurs)
          1=        whether the elements are 1
            ⍸       the indeces of that
             ω@     the actual element
               ⍰    it's in an array, so pick a random element from it (since theres only one)
                ←   output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 38 bytes

```
method(x,x unique sum-x average round)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcQ7DoAgDADQq3SEpA44mngTFxKKNuGjQA23r/ENj6tG2HY4NNO4ajATJ0jhRwi65GWCf6n5k6BVKcFqNIn7MA4drvjvrIW7cRmp6Ac)

### Explanation

```
                                       // x = [1,1,2,1,1,1]
method(x,                            )
         x unique                      // Uniquified x: [1,2]
                  sum                  // Sum:          3
                      x average        // Average of x: 1.1666666666666667
                                round  // Round to the closest integer: 1
                     -                 // Minus: 3-1 = 2
```

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 44 bytes

The built-in solution.

```
method(x,x uniqueCount map(reverse)min last)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcIxDoAgDADAr3QsCYuOJk5@w4XEEptAQSiG39fJ3HGxCNsOp2XSu1w4/YQh/Aw6yhCFHCo2eql1cpkFUujqLGLirrj65ecc1MaiSewD)

### Explanation

```
                                             // e.g. x = [1,2,1,1,1,1]
method(x,                                  ) // Method (taking x):
         x uniqueCount                       // Uniquified counts.   [[1,5],[2,1]]
                       map(reverse)          // Put counts in front. [[5,1],[1,2]]
                                   min       // The one with the smallest count. [1,2]
                                       last  // Return the current item. 2
```

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 44 bytes

(Comparison answer, if I just ported Arnauld's solution anyway)

```
method(x,x sortInPlace()first+x pop-x at(1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8z/n6ZgZasQ8z83tSQjP0WjQqdCoTi/qMQzLyAnMTlVQzMts6i4RLtCoSC/QLdCIbFEw1BT83@aRk5mMZCpY6hjpAMigYIKBUWZeSU5ef8B)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 17 bytes

```
O`
^(.*¶)\1+

1G`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@qEZyg898/gStOQ0/r0DbNGENtLi5D94T//w11QNAIRHIZ65hCIJclUMQSBrlMdEDQjMsCKGcBAA) Link includes test suite that converts from a comma-separated list to a newline-separated list for ease of use. Explanation:

```
O`
```

Sort the input lines so that the unique line is now either first or last.

```
^(.*¶)\1+
```

If the first two lines are identical then remove them and all following identical lines.

```
1G`
```

Take the first remaining line.

Comment: Very nice! I had held off posting for a while because I felt like I was missing something, glad to see there was something better out there after all :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 47 bytes

```python
i=sorted(input())
print(i[0],i[-1])[i[0]==i[1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzLCsMgEEX3foU7tVio6css/JJhVonQ2aikFtqvt2YaQuEszlzunfKpj5yGNuU5yqCUahSeealx1pTKq2pjRFkoVU1wQktwdGhg9RAIHGLrGxHfcdLrC3O4N5DObgw/kShAnq287nAycmH8h/OL3bjx2fu@w@55vrvnV18)

A long way from the shortest Python answer but just another way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), 112 bytes

```
(()){{}({}<{({}<>)<>}<>>){({}<>)<>}<>(({}[({})])<({}({}))>)((){[()]<{{}({}<(({}[({})])<({}{})>)<>{}>)<>}>}{})}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XUwxCoAwEPvOZRQcj/tI6VBdFMHB9ejbz1zpIBISEkiyPe28j7ZfESKAexfv6ikGNarhm4S@kKhQGWXAwKkXQdW5/7Vocu59nFhmXkXEQqxDJ14)

### Explanation

Very broadly speaking this cycles the list until the first two elements are unequal.  Then it deletes the front element until the second two elements are the same.  Once that is done it outputs whatever is on the front.

Ok that wasn't quite true.  I said

> Then it deletes the front element until the second two elements are the same

But it actually deletes the 1st *and the 3rd* elements until ...

This doesn't actually make a difference to the output though, to see why let's look at the cases.  First the easy cases with more than 3 elements

```
b a a a a ...
```

In this case the second two elements are equal (`a = a`) so it stops and outputs `b`.

```
a b a a a ...
```

In this case the second two elements are unequal (`a /= b`) so it removes the first and third elements.

```
b a a ...
```

Now we are back to the first case.

Now for the cases with three elements.

```
b a a
```

In this case the second two elements are equal (`a = a`) so it stops and outputs `b`.

```
a b a
```

In this case the second two elements are unequal (`a /= b`) so it removes the first and third elements.

```
b
```

Now we want to run the check again, but there is only one element.  Luckily Brain-Flak pads the bottom of the stack with zeros so this is really the same as

```
b 0 0
```

And we assumed input was positive `b /= 0` so we are back to the case above.

---

So that works fine but *why* do we do it?

The thing about Brain-flak is that in order to do any non trivial checks with an element we need to pop it from the stack.  That means that if we want to do things in place, like check if one element is equal to another, we need to pop those things and put them back.  So here we save bytes by not putting the third element back when we are checking equality.

This saves us two bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 43 bytes

```lua
t=arg table.sort(t)print(t[1]+t[#t]-t[2]|0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/xDaxKF2hJDEpJ1WvOL@oRKNEs6AoMw9IRxvGapdEK5fE6pZEG8XWGGj@///fEAyNIDQA)

Returning method stolen from [Arnauld's solution.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207751/96508)

#### Alternate Solution, 49 Bytes:

```lua
t=arg table.sort(t)print(t[t[1]<t[2]and 1or#t]|0)
```

#### Notes

Lua's table indexing starts at `1`, and boolean logic generally returns the value rather than an actual `bool`.

Comment: -1: snippets are not allowed. In JS answer you are referring to a function is declared and `a` is a name of its argument. This is not the case for your answer, which does not declare callable function and uses variables for input and output, which is not allowed as well.

Comment: Sorry, was not familiar with the rules when I first started. Fixed to make it a full program.

Comment: Great! Turned -1 into +1 now. Also, just learnt that `|0` can be used to convert numbers to integers (I knew about `//1`, but this is new for me). P.S.: it's recommended to use https://tio.run to provide examples. It also provides code in format that can be directly copied as a Codegolf.SE answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 49 bytes

```python
def f(n):n.sort();return (n[0],n[-1])[n[0]==n[1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYtBCoAgFAWv4vILFkkbKzrJ5y@ClIJ4iVnQ6a2gYRazmXjnZUdbyuyDCgTdoz72lEkPyeczQRG4EQOurGj@ehzBVqTEtCJTIH9NG62I5zu9FFbOfHbmD6fkAQ)

Comment: Why are you sorting the input outside your code? (you may not assume the input is sorted because there are test cases where it is not) Also, this does not work correctly even for the test case included in your TIO link...

Comment: @my pronoun is monicareinstate Thank you, for mentioning my blunder, and i corrected the code

Comment: The second option is wrong. This still doesn't work: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFNI0/TKk@vOL@oREPTuii1pLQoT0EjL1rXMFYnL9ogVjMaRNragkVi/xcUZeaVaKRppJYl5mhk5hWUAnUBwf9oBWMdKDKCMBRiAQ "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate sorry, I oversight it. Edited the code, now it works perfect

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (<strike>61</strike> 60 bytes)

My first attempt in this community, so there's room for improvement:
<strike>`x=>{[a,b,c]=x.filter((e,i)=>x[i-1]!=e);return !c&&x[1]-a?a:b}`</strike>

```
x=>{[a,b,c]=x.filter((e,i)=>x[i-1]!=e);return!c&&x[1]-a?a:b}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc7RCoIwFMbx@57ieCMbTEVN0WL2IGMXc80wRGNaDKJnX2A2JAn@F@fix8e5iocYpW5vU9APZ2Ubag2tnkyQmkhOTdi03aQ0Qoq0mFaGtUHMParwUavprnvwpO8bFvNAnMShflk59OPQqbAbLqhBDGKylHwO4ACAMUQRJLtfnBLIXLN0ON3gct4s1wH/t7wnS/l31i3nG1zMDxQr6XBm3w)

**Explanation:**

```
x.filter((e,i)=>x[i-1]!=e)
```

The array is filtered to remove any element that is the same as array[index - 1].
These are then unpacked into variables `[a,b,c]`.
The three scenarios are 1) [same, unique, same] 2) [unique, same] 3) [same, unique]

```
return !c&&x[1]-a?a:b
```

If c is undefined, i.e. the unique element was on the end of the array - and if 'a' *(which is by now either array[0] or array[last element - 1])* is not equal to array[1], then a is the unique element. Otherwise, we have scenario 1 or 3, either way - return 'b'

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of code golf! I look forward to seeing more of your posts!

Comment: Also, [-1 byte by removing the space between `return` and `!`](https://tio.run/##dc7RCoIwFMbx@57ieCMbTEVN0WL2IGMXc80wRGNaDKJnX2A2JAn@F@fix8e5iocYpW5vU9APZ2Ubag2tnkyQmkhOTdi03aQ0Qoq0mFaGtUHMParwUavprntP@r5hMQ/ESRzql5VDPw6dCrvhghrEICZLyecADgAYQxRBsvvFKYHMNUuH0w0u581yHfB/y3uylH9n3XK@wcX8QLGSDmf2DQ "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed that whitespace lol.

Answer (score 2):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 11 bytes

```
.-[sort[1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/19PN7o4v6gk2jA29v//aAVLHQUjIFKIBQA)

### Explanation

```
.           # The input
 -          # With all occurances of ... removed:
  [sort     #    The sorted input
       [1]] #    's second item
```

Comment: For input `[9, 6, 6]` it fails to return `9`.

Comment: @Charlie I hope it is fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <s>28</s> 23 bytes

```factor
[ histogram keys last ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9NCsIwEIX3PcXzAgVbW6oeQNy4EVfiYijRFu2PmXFRSs8ek5AWF@aDLN43j2HuVEqnzeV8PB12IOauZLB6f1RbKkZDUsUsJDVLbU2vlcjQ67oV7KMxgn0j1p7E/5NNVkiCSZEFXO5MGszWzm8Xpp/OxpOHhuvkwWQoLHPuTBZM4d1/UyzbZzOZKyp7UffQ1OCpBsaLWHAzDfWIzRc)

Get the last (second) key in the histogram of the input, which will always have the smaller count.

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 25 bytes

```
{.BagHash.invert.Hash{1}}
```

[Try it online!](https://glot.io/snippets/ggsertdqni)

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 85 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVHda8IwEH/vX3GUPSTQBXQfaFkftrEHYWMPsr0UkUzTmpnGmlyHRfzbu5iomx6/HMnd7z5jZ1zxbvX1LWYIb1xq2EYAc1FA5R6Em9Km8GgMb/MxGqnLCU3hQ0uEDLbQ7YkF2aRjsc5HGic027DSrJr6qSVyLjRKbCmreP3JVSMsmTIldIkLygqpUBhnmPYhy6BH2VK0li0En3fg5IcrQGHxmVthXbFXaZFE4MX3Q3oJBPTDhSZn7psE7k648A190PA/Lhi3CQTcXzgGPuGAemPQXhUrA@TYMDxc/zVP/UqPMzVarhvxokTltuPmKk5B9MCq3ZpRaWLjka4bTOFqe6Swahl@gcR5nMABk5juEnhvMLDPKsQh6y7an13U/QI)

```scala
def f(x:Seq[Int])=x.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length).filter(_._2 == 1).keys.head
```

This Scala code defines a function `f` that takes a sequence of integers `x` as input, and returns the unique element in the sequence.

Here's a breakdown of what the function does:

- `x.groupBy(identity)` groups the elements in the sequence `x` by their identity (i.e., their value), returning a map where the keys are the distinct values in `x`, and the values are arrays of elements in `x` with that value.
- `.mapValues(_.length)` transforms the values in the map to their length, i.e., the number of elements in `x` with that value.
- `.filter(_._2 == 1)` filters the key-value pairs in the map to keep only those where the value (i.e., the count of elements with that value in `x`) is equal to 1.
- `.keys` returns the keys (i.e., the distinct values in `x`) of the filtered map as a set.
- `.head` returns the first (and only) element of the set, which is the unique element in `x`.

So the entire function finds the unique element in `x` by grouping its elements by their value, counting the elements with each value, filtering for the value with count 1, and returning it.

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC, <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
min(Ans)max(Ans)/median(Ans
```

Takes input in `Ans`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 4 bytes

```
SġⁿL
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCJTxKHigb9MIiwiIiwiWyAxLCAxLCAxLCAyLCAxLCAxIF0iLCIzLjQuMCJd)

Sorts the array, groups by adjacent items and takes the minimum by length

Answer (score 2):

## [HBL](https://github.com/dloscutoff/hbl), 10.5 [bytes](https://github.com/dloscutoff/hbl/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
+(1.)('1.)(<(1.2
)(%.
```

[Try it!](https://dloscutoff.github.io/hbl/?f=0&p=LSgrKDEoJS4pKSgnMSglLikpKSgxKDIxKCUu&a=KDEgMSAxIDIgMSAxKQ__)

Port of [Arnauld's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207751/106959).

-3 bytes thanks to [@DLosc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)!

## Explanation:

### Helper function:

```
+(1.)('1.)(<(1.2­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
+                 # ‎⁡Add:
 (1.)             # ‎⁢The first element of arg1
     ('1.)        # ‎⁣The last element of arg1
          (<      # ‎⁤Negate below:
            (1.2  # ‎⁢⁡The second element of arg1
```

### Main function:

```
)(%.­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
 (%.  # ‎⁡Sort arg1
)     # ‎⁢Call the function above
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: @DLosc Thanks! Also, I've added the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```
a=>a.minBy(x=>a.count(x==))
```

It finds the minimum number in the list according to the number of occurrences in that same list, since the odd one out will only have 1 occurrence.

[Try it in Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ysthakur/5R2iFwTUQkCJl0BWitKGRw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-m`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ü l1
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW0&code=/CBsMQ&input=W1sgMSwgMSwgMSwgMiwgMSwgMSBdLApbIDMsIDUsIDUsIDUsIDUgXSwKWyA5LCAyLCA5LCA5LCA5LCA5LCA5IF0sClsgNCwgNCwgNCwgNiBdLApbIDgsIDUsIDggXV0)

```
ü       sort and group
  l1    take lenght 1 result
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 24 bytes

```
N`
L0`^(\d+)(?!¶\1)|\d+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvqhGcoPPfL4HLxyAhTiMmRVtTw17x0LYYQ80aIEfl/39DHRA0ApFcxjqmEMhlCRSxhEEuEx0QNOOyAMpZAAA)

This works by sorting the input (one number per line) and then outputting the first number if it is different from the second, and otherwise outputting the last number.

The test case code was taken from [Neil's Retina answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207760/31625) which uses an arithmetic method to determine the answer after sorting.

Comment: You inspired me to write an answer which could be backported to Retina 0.8.2, and was shorter to boot!

Answer (score 1):

## Google Sheets, 28

Closing parens already discounted.

- Column `A` is input.
- `B1` - `=SORT(A:A)`
- `B2` - `=FILTER(B:B,B:B<>B2)`

## Excel 2016, 35

- Column `A` is input.
- `B1` - `=MAX(A:A)`
- `B2` - `=IF(MODE(A:A)-B1,B1,MIN(A:A))`

If the mode is the same as the max, then it's the min, otherwise max.

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 8 bytes

```
psf:<][~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f@/oDjNyiY2uu7/fwsFCwVTAA)

Explanation:

```
ps       # Parse input string as a block
  f:     # Frequency list - returns block of blocks with format {frequency value}
    <]   # Take the minimum block, in this case calculated based on the first element (frequency)
      [~ # Take the last element (value)
         # Implicitly output
```

Answer (score 1):

## C# 42 Bytes

```
r.GroupBy(a=>a).First(a=>a.Count()==1).Key
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Are you sure C# *requires* all that whitespace?  If it doesn't, removing it could be a easy way to shorten this.

Comment: @AdHocGarfHunter Thanks! You're right. Have edited it further

Comment: Also if I understand the code correctly groups can't be size zero?  So `<2` should be a shorter way of checking `==1`.  If you want tips for golfing in C# from someone who actually knows C# we have [a tips page for the language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173/tips-for-code-golfing-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - 6 bytes

I'm not quite sure why this doesn't return an array.

```
f!t/QT
```

## Explanation

```
f!t/QT
f!t/QTQ implicit Q added
f     Q filter on each element T of input for 
   /QT  number of times t appears in input
  t     minus 1
 !      is equal to zero
```

Comment: Made me chuckle a bit.

Answer (score 1):

## [Postgresql](https://postgresql.org/), 51 bytes

```postgresql
SELECT unnest($1::int[])GROUP BY 1HAVING count(*)=1
```

Takes input as an integer array. Outputs as a row containing the unique value. If there is more than one unique value, it returns all of them in unspecified order.

If the type is specified in the extended query protocol or a function parameter, it can be reduced to 44 bytes

```postgresql
SELECT $1.unnest GROUP BY 1HAVING count(*)=1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3], 39 bytes

```python
lambda x:x[[*map(x.count, x)].index(1)]
```

Comment: Guessing by the header, it looks like you copied the post from TIO then removed the link. I suggest to fix the post by copying the whole content back.

Comment: I had taken the format from https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207741/97553 but it is different from my code.

Comment: Well yes, as Bubbler said you deleted the link and didn't replace it with anything can you at least fix the header and optionally add a link to somewhere you can test this, such as TIO?

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 6 bytes

```
~$.1=-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v05Fz9BW9///aEsFIwVLGIwFAA)

```
~        # Parse the input to an array
 $       # Sort the array
  .1=    # Get the second number in the array, this will always be the repeated number
     -   # Remove all copies of the repeated number
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 3 bytes

```
ĐṀ\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yISHOxti/v@PNtQBQSMQGQsA)

```
Đ        implicit input (S); duplicate on top of stack
 Ṁ       get median (m) (I never got around to fixing a bug in the mode operator, but they do the same thing here)
  \      take the set difference between S and m; implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 33 bytes

```arturo
$=>[t:tally&|select[k,v]->v=1t\0]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?YK9SuP)

Answer (score 1):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 29 bytes

```
!!vr:r@:&=&$?$n;
 ~>:@$:@=0$.
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiISF2cjpyQDomPSYkPyRuO1xuIH4+OkAkOkA9MCQuIiwiaW5wdXQiOiIiLCJzdGFjayI6IjMgMyAyIDMiLCJzdGFja19mb3JtYXQiOiJudW1iZXJzIiwiaW5wdXRfZm9ybWF0IjoibnVtYmVycyJ9)

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 105 bytes

```go
func(N[]int)int{m,o:=make(map[int]int),0
for _,n:=range N{m[n]++}
for k,v:=range m{if v<2{o=k}}
return o}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VU_BagMhEL37FUNOLrGlSduwWeovhNyXpUjQIFt1se5exC_JZQn0m0r-pka30sKTcea9mXlzuZ7NfIOBnXp25qCY1EiqwVj3uBLKrdDELAj6NTrxUN-kGPUJH9pOalfF5xUxDVWs51ixoY2VxJAnJIyFd6IbapmOcw9etbpbr0MiejL9EspLAdPb1hvah4Asd6PVYMKy8Pu-MLnCFXjEP6Gh0HbJgEc5bAhkbPMnkIV4JvBaUKr7JNz_ReFeCGTsSin21hElr9O4f3mdx4flaH73mK-Lfj062qj70JgTEJhXVRQu581zjj8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 65 bytes

Not the best Java answer, but still really close using a Stream approach.

```java
l->l.stream().reduce(0,(a,b)->l.indexOf(b)!=l.lastIndexOf(b)?a:b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZBBT8IwFMfvfIrnTl0sjYKQAQ7ikQTjgaPx0G2FDLuxtB2BGI7e/Aj65fgi85V1KNFoXtq0r7/37/@9Fd/w9ip5rooykmkMseRawz1Pc3hptQDS3Ai14LGAGSYAjhlYkBXWsdKkks1SbW6niC2FGoP0R0jtbak23KDiDCSElWyPJdNGCZ4RnymRlLEgV5RwGvn2Kc0TsX1YkMi/CCVDE2Z6ykz4MPKrkdV0Lp30Zp0mIDZcEmtKbAsRG5FQcG4YY1BwxTP/m3UldCkNhCDZ9y7ulOI7zbi27ZC66tgKwHynjcjYujSsUCghc0Kav8Kw1pt4h/dX8Ibe4eMNPP@yzn7N4hffGc6YzA0qLh@fgKulbmweO4IOniiua2qjY3e8OU810nVIl/bqsE/nSKMyQIVBE@dI3yE31EYf4KdKzyE9GtAA4C8kQB//IoGzekJwSPvqEw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>40</s> 24 bytes

```
{minBy{r->count{r==it}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@59WmqeQm5iZp6GpUM1VlpijkJOYm5SSaKXgmVfiWFSUWKkHlNG1A3HtFWz/V@dm5jlVVhfp2iXnl@aVVBfZ2maW1NbW/i8oyswrycnTyIRq80/TMNZRgCMTOFtTD2KDhqYmV@1/AA)

It doesn't seem to have a count function where you can simply pass the lambda parameter.

-16 bytes thanks to [Seggan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/107299/seggan)

Comment: you can omit the `IntArray` part as lambdas on CGCC can have types inderred if needed

Answer (score 1):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 34 bytes

```
? }:=
? $ :
: } {
} : +;=$!@
${?"=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/fXqHWypbLXkFFwYrLSqFWoZqrVsFKQdvaVkXRgUul2l7J9v9/IwVDZPgvv6AkMz@v@L9uCgA)

Examines windows of size 3 until a window with two different numbers is found, and then XORs the three numbers to get the answer.

Given a window of `a b c`, the test is done by checking if `(a^b) + (b^c)` is nonzero. It is trivially zero if `a == b == c`, and we can be sure that it is strictly positive (and therefore nonzero) when `a != b` (i.e. `(a^b) != 0`) or `b != c` (i.e. `(b^c) != 0`) since all the input values are positive.

Also, a redundant work is saved by keeping an XORed value in the stack across iterations.

```
Intro:  ??:}${
??   take two numbers from input [a b]
:}   copy 2nd input to aux.stack [a b | b]
$    XOR                         [a^b | b]
{    pull 2nd input back         [a^b b]

Loop:  ?:}$}:=:{+=   [a^b b] -> [b^c c]
?      take next number from input [a^b b c]
:}     backup c                    [a^b b c | c]
$      XOR                         [a^b b^c | c]
}:     move b^c and copy a^b       [a^b a^b | b^c c]
=:{    swap tops, copy, pull       [a^b b^c b^c a^b | c]
+      add; keep going if zero     [a^b b^c a^b+b^c | c]
=      swap tops                   [... b^c c | ...]

End:  ;=$!@  [a^b b^c a^b+b^c | c]
;=    drop and swap tops   [a^b c | ...]
$!@   print a^b^c and halt
```

Answer (score 1):

## [YASEPL](https://github.com/madeforlosers/yasepl-esolang), <s>46 32</s> 30 bytes

```
=a=1'±" "=d¥0,1`1!+=e¥a,1}3,d<
```

enter in numbers seperated by a space and nothing else (like `4 4 4 6 4 4`)

### explanation

```
=a=1'±" "=d¥0,1`1!+=e¥a,1}3,d<           packed
=a                                       declare increment variable "a"
  =1'                                    get user input and set it to "1"
     ±" "                                split "1" by every space
         =d¥0,1                          get the first item from "1"
               `1        }3,d            while e == d...
                 !+                      increment a by one
                   =e¥a,1                get item at "1" index "a" and set it to "e"
                             <           print variable "e" when finished
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 28 bytes

```scala
l=>l.minBy(x=>l.count(_==x))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sODkxJ9F4TbSSbmpFQU5iZp5S7M2m_KSs1OQSBV8gV6GaS0EhJTVNIRfI0UgsSi-2UnAsKkqsjA4uKcrMS4_VtFIIzcssUbAFq1RQKACKluTkaaRp-GQWl2iY6sCgpSWEoampCVRYywUkyhJzFNKsFDQ0glMLoz3zSmI1be2AlKaC7dLSkjRdiz05tnY5ermZeU6VGhUgZnJ-aV6JRrytbYWmJkTJwloIvWABhAYA)

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC 4, 43 bytes

```
1  RSORT I:IF I[0]-I[1]GOTO@0
2  ?MIN(I)@0?MAX(I)
```

---

Receives array input through `I[]`. The first value printed is the answer, other printed values are to be ignored. Works by reverse-sorting the list of integers (from largest to smallest values) and comparing the zeroth and first elements. If their difference is non-zero, then the odd one out is the larger value (`MAX(I)`); otherwise, the odd one out is the smaller value (`MIN(I)`).

Answer (score 0):

## [gbz80](https://rgbds.gbdev.io/docs/v0.6.0/gbz80.7) [machine code](https://gbdev.io/gb-opcodes/optables/), 11 bytes

Function that takes the list pointed to by `hl` and returns in `a`. Requires zero-terminator.

```
46 23 2A B8 28 FC 4E B9 C0 78 C9
```

Disassembly:

```
Search:
    ld b, [hl]
    inc hl
.loop:
    ld a, [hl+]
    cp b
    jr z, .loop
; this is for if the first two are different.
    ld c, [hl]
    cp c
    ret nz
    ld a, b
    ret
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 66 Bytes

```
u(int*a){int*i=a;for(;!(*a-*i);++i);return*a-a[1]&&*a-a[2]?*a:*i;}
```

We iterate over the array until we find an element that's different from the first one, then return the first element if it's different from both the second and the third, otherwise the element that the loop stopped at.

The following optimizations were made:

- Dereferencing a pointer is shorter than indexing an array. Since the elements of an array are stored together, we can use a pointer as an iterator, letting us write `*i` instead of `a[i]`. Similarly, we can always write `*a` instead of `a[0]`.
- For the sake of conditionals, `a-b` is equivalent to `a==b` since every nonzero integer evaluates to true.
- The return type defaults to `int` so we don't need to specify it.
- Ternary operators are shorter than if-conditions, and in this case, it's possible to only use one check. The drawback is that the for-loop gets executed even if it isn't needed.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf Stack Exchange!