# Hell0 W0rld! scored by ASCII values

Tags: code-challenge, hello-world

Write a program that outputs `Hell0 W0rld!`.  It must match this output exactly, including capitalization, zeroes instead of o's, exactly one space, etc.  Trailing new lines are allowed.

Lowest score wins.  Scoring is based on the sum of the values of each character in the language's code page - otherwise Unicode values should be used.  New lines are treated as spaces.

Here are a few example scores:

```
abc //Score: 294

print(Hell0 W0rld!) //Score: 1597

//Score: 1454
multi
line
code
```

You can check your ASCII score by inputting your code [here](https://tio.run/##fVJNT8MwDL33V5ieUk1knBk7wIRgEjDEToA4hNZtM9KkStwNhPbbS/qxtQgJXxz52c/PdjZiK043yUddy6I0lmDjA7wiqfg6FlqjnQVjpBCU8yuZLTVh1oBl9a5kDLESzsG9kDr4DsBbH3ckyLutkQkUHmVrslJnIGzmXt@iNrUraGw6fRTWISxMgpBaU8BSlxUd8b44buA5hOFsQDqx4Ho/B427Q5StvxxhwaWOhopdLhWyPp/nwj3gJ7EoOiYMshpre07mhwZc@@w7qZGNKBuT6X@cf3nH3CGEv8n2wfAaLWkhVFwpQegHNBaPyHAXL9MDfgtDiL9cP60G@tRYJjWB9ElnM@8uWhlcoc4o91OBnEyi31pb0nnnuEgSNmLfClXhKmUtSZwLe0lMRtFoO6MR@nuYinjpL0pKs7Ad5dzvYNI16Cv3wb6un01lu09xY9DBLVo8@QE).  You can view individual ASCII values [here](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: Tabs are lower than spaces, but I seem to be getting a higher score using tabs. Are whitespace characters taken into account? That would shave a nice chunk off my score(s).

Comment: @ouflak Whitespace counts. Only change is that new lines count as spaces. So yes, tabs are cheaper than spaces.

Comment: @Evordor, got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

## [Lenguage](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Lenguage), score 0

Well, this is quite boring and obvious, but it seems to achieve the perfect score (assuming I understand the challenge correctly). To fix this loophole, you should probably add the program's length to the sum of the code points; I'm pretty sure that won't break the relative order of the current answers.

The program is

```
2282524454641945458940768311481012240407465625061984267694778013056442426959468031225640633070772676474431950201473533908
```

null bytes. Fortunately, 0 multiplied by the number above is still 0.

I believe this decompresses (alternatively, it *compresses*) to the automatically generated (with the help of a random web page that claims "Original Java program not from me") brainfuck program:

```
-[------->+<]>-.-[->+++++<]>++.+++++++..[-->+<]>------.[--->++<]>.---[->+++<]>.+[-->+<]>++++.[----->+<]>++.------.--------.-[--->+<]>.
```

It almost certainly could be golfed (but I haven't tried), but that is unnecessary.

Comment: Since the JavaScript submission was not a serious contender, I've edited it out of the answer.

Answer (score 16):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), score <s>513</s> 252

<sup>-261 points thanks to @Dorian</sup>

Posting this separately from my other answer, as this one is arguably less cheating. I've been waiting for somebody else to do this for a while, but nobody did. I tried multiple languages. Pyth has extremely short code for this (`Cl"..."`, if I remember correctly), but it turned out it can't input null bytes, and most other golfing languages I found have painfully large char codes for quotes (and I couldn't write this piece of code in the rest).

```
"ǝǝǝǝǝǝǝǝǝǝǝǝ...ǝǝǝǝǝ"gтB
```

Where there are 174047470094320053473995 `ǝ` characters, that conveniently happen to have a value of 0 in the code page.

Explanation:

```
"ǝǝǝǝǝǝǝǝǝǝǝǝ...ǝǝǝǝǝ"        push the long string
                      g       pop and get its length
                       тB     push 100 and convert to that base
```

You definitely shouldn't try the full version online, [but you can try online the version with the length finding part skipped.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f0NzEwMTcxNzAwNLE2MjAwNTYxNzY0tL0YpPT//8A)

Comment: I make this one 513 too. (I went with the same approach in Jelly for 998 - two different ways. Expensive quotes indeed.)

Comment: You can also use `B` to convert the number directly to a string. That will lead to a score of only 252 `"ǝǝǝ...ǝǝ"gтB`. [Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f0NzEwMTcxNzAwNLE2MjAwNTYxNzY0tL0YpPT//8A)

Comment: @Dorian Are you sure that can produce a space character? I tried that. UPD: turns out it can; will update slightly later.

Answer (score 12):

## [7](https://esolangs.org/wiki/7), 41 characters, code point sum 81

```
32002453003001200522231203103002440537403
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYjBDQBADIJWsmrT/SfzvIQHcIkI0CugTGNJqqL5hzZWZyh5)

Unlike with many of my 7 programs, there's nothing particularly clever going on here; this basically just prints a string in the simplest possible way (which in 7 involves encoding the string into a piece of source code, evaluating it, analysing the resulting stack element to figure out what source code is most likely to have created it, and then giving the resulting source code directly to the output routines).

The reason this scores so well is that 7 has a code page consisting of only 8 characters, and the code that's used to represent string literals tends to use only `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5` (as those commands have much easier-to-analyse effects on the stack than **`6`** and **`7`** do, so it's more likely that the original source will be accurately reproduced by the **`6`** command). This means that none of the code points in the bulk of the program will go above 5 (the assignment of code points to characters in 7 is the obvious one), leading to an *average* code point value of around 2½ (for this program, happenstance means it's more like 2). Thus, although there are a lot of characters in the program, the sum of the codepoints continues to stay low. (Unlike the Lenguage answer, the code point sum + character count is also very low, so this answer isn't even really cheating.)

Answer (score 10):

## [COW](https://bigzaphod.github.io/COW/), Score: 117799

```
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO Moo MoO MoO
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO Moo MoO MoO
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO Moo Moo OOO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO Moo MOo MOo MOo
MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo Moo MoO
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO Moo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo
MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo
MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo
MOo MOo MOo MOo Moo MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO Moo MOo MOo MOo
MOo MOo MOo Moo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo MOo Moo OOO MoO
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO
MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO MoO
MoO MoO Moo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S84v///fN99fgUzMNTL05g9Se/PB2N9/OIQz0C/@cMyFxCYeQ8JrGKdJrP4mL6xooReRXkfLDXzpOZ@4tAzN14PAv/n//wMA)

My cow could not understand that the lower score in this challenge is better, so they scored very high! I kept telling them: "Please score lower, it is better", but they kept responding: "MoO"!

Comment: But the score is a perfect sample input for Is It Double Speak!

Answer (score 8):

## HTML, Score: 959

```html
Hell0
W0rld!
```

If newlines (`\r` and `\n`) would have been count as their ASCII code (`10` and `13`) the score would be **937** or **940** because in HTML, new lines in "inline" elements are rendered as space.

Comment: How does one "run" a html page? This is the browser parsing a file, not your code actually doing anything :/

Comment: @RobQuist, so isn't the browser interpreting my HTML code?

Comment: @RobQuist, also please see this: ["Answering in non-programming languages is allowed"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10421/do-submissions-have-to-be-answered-with-a-programming-language/10426#10426)

Comment: In my opinion, no, since its not a programming language but markup.

Answer (score 7):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), sum = <s>966</s> <s>868</s> <s>853</s> [843](https://tio.run/##fVE9T8MwEB1gCmM3JKRTJkcWLjOlA@oASECRKibEYBK3cXGcyL60INTfHi4fbVIhcctF7929e89Zy428XCefVaWzIncIawJEidqIRSytVW4SBEX5YXQMsZHew5PUNvgJgKrDPUqktsl1AhmxbIFO2xVIt/Jv71Ez2i7UNR6/SOcVzPJEwdLlGTzYosQD3y3HNT2FMJz0TGsIfNenYNV2j7LFt0eVCW2jfmObaqNYNy9S6Z/VF7IoOgz0tupqbvLp/oCwNP2orWIDybr08j/Nv7pD7RDCY7Fd0H8NHmkmTVwaiYoC5k4dGG2R/BFC8a96pWXuWE3pBqZ201wURtkVphQANOfRsa1Whjw1k3Eq3S0yPcg6MNS9bl6iKOj/oLEsbIxdUyLeSnWbu2BXVWfA7@fz0ck58NHr/O6UXfDwFw)

```
� +HOO��� +�UOG�(�+"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//@fW0Hbw99fmFlKQVs41N@dRUNWW@n/fwA)

-15 score from cutting out the `0` (with a bit of help from [the awful old Python script](https://tio.run/##nY7JDoJAEETvfkWLy8w4giyuuB79Aw@ASwAVg4MZNMG4/DoOagxcTfrQSdWrqtP1vI@YkabbiEMCAQO@YTsfGzoxSxDDGBBSDlHAsOXuOY64h10iJwQyv5v5pbkfhiosVB56ZcmxTFPWHFJkc6gIpgjEBdsPj8rmqqlMbSQ9l9XK3bbrMyo3WrXRZLzG1u3hEFXTjXan2@sPhgj8MPYF@KuP31VUdGFEs55E5NMmKsGJB@yMM/37XY7fEXm6IP8zKJ@Vpi8)).

-10 score from A__'s idea to use `"` and implicit print over the costlier `,`.

Based on a comment by Night2, as well as [Jo King's old 32-byte quine](https://tio.run/##y05N///fpcqpyinMIzjAzdM1MNhNI04tTs1Kx9xES1fT1FxLmev/fwA).

```
� +HOO��� +�UOG�(�+"        Push the shifted codepoints beginning-first.
� +     � +                 ('H' and 'W' are pushed as sums,
                             because '+' is cheaper than '\'.)
                  +         Add
                 �          29
                   "        then rotate the stack
                (           once for every item on the stack.
```

If newlines weren't treated as spaces for scoring, this would be 832:

```
 +GNN���TNF�� +(�+"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//@fS0Hb3c9PiElSQVsoxM@NWUNOW@n/fwA)

Comment: Ah, thanks for catching that--my guess was it was some sort of CRLF issue but that didn't explain why the difference is 22.

Comment: Score: [843](https://tio.run/##fVE9T8MwEB1gCmM3JKRTJkcWLjOlA@oASECRKibEYBK3cXGcyL60INTfHi4fbVIhcctF7929e89Zy428XCefVaWzIncIawJEidqIRSytVW4SBEX5YXQMsZHew5PUNvgJgKrDPUqktsl1AhmxbIFO2xVIt/Jv71Ez2i7UNR6/SOcVzPJEwdLlGTzYosQD3y3HNT2FMJz0TGsIfNenYNV2j7LFt0eVCW2jfmObaqNYNy9S6Z/VF7IoOgz0tupqbvLp/oCwNP2orWIDybr08j/Nv7pD7RDCY7Fd0H8NHmkmTVwaiYoC5k4dGG2R/BFC8a96pWXuWE3pBqZ201wURtkVphQANOfRsa1Whjw1k3Eq3S0yPcg6MNS9bl6iKOj/oLEsbIxdUyLeSnWbu2BXVWfA7@fz0ck58NHr/O6UXfDwFw). [TIO](https://tio.run/##y05N//@fW0Hbw99fmFlKQVs41N@dRUNWW@n/fwA)

Answer (score 6):

## [MineFriff](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Minefriff), Score: 3725

```
Cff3,a*a,9*c,a*b4,6*8,8*a7,ff2,8*6,9*c,:a*a1,9*8,`
>l?#;o~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y83MS00rykxL@//fOS3NWCdRK1HHUisZSCeZ6JhpWehYaCWa66SlGQEZZmAZK6ASQyDLQieByy7HXtk6v@7/fwA)

This ain't winning any competitions any time soon I tell you (I dread seeing what Scratch's score would be...). I'll post an image of what this looks like in-game soon, but first I have to actually re-install the python-in-minecraft mod and actually get it all working first.

See y'all soon! (I hope...)

### Actual In-Game Progess Report

#### 10 mins in

- I managed to *finally* get Forge opened on my mac. That really shouldn't have taken 10 minutes but it did
- Minecraft 1.8 (unmodded) still hasn't launched/finished downloading.
- Still downloading the actual mod
- All star seems like a nice song to listen to while doing this

#### 14 mins in

- Minecraft 1.8 finally opened
- Mod finally downloaded
- All star finished playing
- Moving on to actually using forge

#### 17 mins in

- Forge successfully has installed and I'm loading in the mod now
- Jake Paul is *apparently* number one. Send help please.

#### 20 mins in

- Help received. No longer listening to cringey songs
- I think I've properly installed the mod. No clue if it works because minecraft doesn't want to load.

#### 23 mins in

- And I downloaded the wrong version of the mod. Oops. Nothing broken, just wasted, oh, I don't know, **6 minutes**. Sigh.

#### 27 mins in

- I still can't read the documentation. Apparently, I needed to drag *all* the folders from the extracted zip into the mods folder
- Starting to think about downloading the minefriff world

#### 30 mins in

- **MOD IS FINALLY INSTALLED**
- Thank goodness. Robbie Rotten is now number one. No help needed this time.
- Time to see if everything still works.

#### 34 mins in

- About to test if actual interpreter works in-game. Wish me luck!

#### 36 mins in

- Nup. Game crashed. :(

#### Tomorrow

- I'll be trying 1.10 instead of 1.8

#### Next day, 1 min in

- Minecraft 1.10 has somehow deleted itself from my list of available installations. Now I have to manually find it somewhere and then somehow get Forge to make a 1.10 profile. Problem is, I won't be able to work on it for another 4 hours. See y'all then!

Comment: Boy, what a journey

Comment: Cliffhanger!!!!

Answer (score 5):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), Score: 959

"Classic" answer. PHP outputs by default.

```php
Hell0 W0rld!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fIzUnx0BHIdygKCdF8f9/AA)

- Polyglot with [Carrot](https://tio.run/##S04sKsov@f/fIzUnx0Ah3KAoJ0Xx/38A) and [Canvas](https://tio.run/##S07MK0ss/v/fIzUnx0Ah3KAoJ0Xx/38A) and [Charcoal](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98jNSfHQCHcoCgnRfH/fwA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/),  score: 1360

```bash
echo    Hell0   W0rld!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I5/TIzUnx4Az3KAoJ0Xx/38A)

Comment: If you can replace the spaces with tabs, you can save 23*2 = 46 points: https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I5/TIzUnx4Az3KAoJ0Xx/38A - Bash word-splits on any whitespace char.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Thanks for the improvment

Answer (score 4):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), Score: 1051

```
Hell0 W0rld\!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fIzUnx0Ah3KAoJyVG8f9/AA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), Score 1207

```sh
<<<"Hell0 W0rld!"
```

[Try it online, with a self-scorer!](https://tio.run/##ZY@xDoIwFEVn@xVXaEwbF3BEdHHxDxyMQ1MeQtJQ05ZFwrcjKkSjb7q5LyfnvbuvhiHP8@hIxiQ4Jc4Uy2hgMQ7K6NaoQPDaOsrG6nciLnKeyOjTOFIF6gbetk4TytrQH8e7OZ1FKdNLP6YrBaQ@wNTNF8A74bNM/nlHwt9MHWAb6Eo5pQM5z1hpHfRTP4G8my@cTP0WhWULId4/Yb1DrCElK@zoJV1Z7Fcb8Nd2eAA)

Using `<<<Hell0\ W0rld!` is shorter, but more expensive: `\` = `92`, but 2⨯`"` = `68`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), Score: 1105

```forth
." Hell0 W0rld!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//6ykpeKTm5BgohBsU5aQoKv1PLlIwUCiOUVLQi0GVilFSUkjKL81LKVaITsmPVYjOjFVIdlDQVojOyc8viFXQ@w8A)

Prints the given string to stdout.

Answer (score 4):

## [bit**](https://github.com/Helen0903/bitch), Score: 2519

```
#72/#101/#108/#108/#48/#32/#87/#48/#114/#108/#100/#33/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8osSc74/1/Z3Ehf2dDAEERYQAkTIDYGCluYQ9iGhiZwaQOglLH@////8gtKMvPziv/rJgMA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), Score: [863](https://tio.run/##fVHLTsMwEBQcc@sXYJmLowiXI6L0gCqQkAhCyhFxMK7bbHHsyHZaEOq3h82jTSok9rLRzO7sjLMRW3G1WX7WNRSldYFsEOBVAM0zKYxRbhZFZfWhQRKphfckFWCin4hg9bgPImDbWliSAlmWBQdmTYRb@7f3uB3tFpqaTl@F84os7FKRlbMFeTJlFY58vywbek4onQ1MZ4j4vs@JUbsDyrJvH1TBwcTDxi4HrVg/z3PhX9RXYHF8HBhsNdXeTOaHA9zg9DMYxUaSTcHqP82/umNtSuip2D4avkaPtBBaVloEhQGtU0cGTEB/iGD860FpZR1rKGhhbHftRa6VWYccAxBIkvjUVieDntpJmQt3HxiMso4M9a9rq8BL/D9BG0ZbY7eYKOmk@s19tK9rGj@m6eTsZpKlD@dUJpcXvw)

```
")FMM8SME"c+#
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=IilGTU0RATgRU01FAiJjKyMf)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), Score: 2021

Thanks to GammaFunction

```c
A(){puts("Hell0 W0rld!");}
```

Also, just for fun, here is a C program that had a score of 1 using overflow.
It's a base64 encoded rar file
https://pastebin.com/SJMcRnLj

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/99RQ7O6oLSkWEPJIzUnx0Ah3KAoJ0VRSdO69n9mXolCbmJmHlAFUBVQAAA)

Comment: Trailing newlines are allowed, so `puts` saves a bit. Also, functions are allowed by default unless "full program" is specified in the challenge.

Comment: @GammaFunction how would I make it into a function?

Comment: [Like this](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/99RQ7O6oLSkWEPJIzUnx0Ah3KAoJ0VRSdO69n9mXolCbmJmHlAFUBVQAAA "C (gcc) – Try It Online"), using the footer to call the function. I called it `A` because it's the least expensive valid C identifier.

Comment: what an interesting year for me to see this answer in

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), Score:1213

Just the string. Nothing interesting.

```
“Hell0 W0rld!
```

### Score: 1744

Simply a compression.

```
“ØƲṡhḍḊF®Ḍ?»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9qZWxsef//4oCcw5jGsuG5oWjhuI3huIpGwq7huIw/wrv//w)

[Code page summator](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1chKzUnp1IhM7cgv6hEITk/JTW@IDE9VUchJTO5JDM/L7Gokqsotbg0p8TWgCstv0ghUyEzT0HpUcOcwzOObXq4c2HGwx29D3d0uR1a93BHj/2h3UpWXJwQDdq2cOP0MvNSUis0MjW5Cooy80o04BIwAYgOzf//AQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [Turing Machine Code](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html), Score: <s>7105</s> <s>6279</s> 5175

```
0   _   !   l   !
!   _   d   l   "
"   _   l   l   #
#   _   r   l   $
$   _   0   l   %
%   _   W   l   &
&   _   _   l   '
'   _   0   l   (
(   _   l   l   )
)   _   l   l   +
+   _   e   l   ,
,   _   H   l   -
```

*Implemented suggestions by Naruyoko*
*Shaved off another 1100+ using tabs instead of spaces*

[Try it online!](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?88544f229a9ed9e797048baf6d6273bb)

## [Turing Machine But Way Worse](https://github.com/MilkyWay90/Turing-Machine-But-Way-Worse), Score: <s>69695</s> 55343

```
0   0   0   1   1   0   0
0   1   1   1   2   0   0
0   2   0   1   3   0   0
0   3   0   1   4   0   0
0   4   1   1   5   0   0
0   5   0   1   6   0   0
0   6   0   1   7   0   0
0   7   0   1   8   1   0
0   8   0   1   9   0   0
0   9   1   1   10  0   0
0   10  1   1   11  0   0
0   11  0   1   12  0   0
0   12  0   1   13  0   0
0   13  1   1   14  0   0
0   14  0   1   15  0   0
0   15  1   1   16  1   0
0   16  0   1   17  0   0
0   17  1   1   18  0   0
0   18  1   1   19  0   0
0   19  0   1   20  0   0
0   20  1   1   21  0   0
0   21  1   1   22  0   0
0   22  0   1   23  0   0
0   23  0   1   24  1   0
0   24  0   1   25  0   0
0   25  1   1   26  0   0
0   26  1   1   27  0   0
0   27  0   1   28  0   0
0   28  1   1   29  0   0
0   29  1   1   30  0   0
0   30  0   1   31  0   0
0   31  0   1   32  1   0
0   32  0   1   33  0   0
0   33  0   1   34  0   0
0   34  1   1   35  0   0
0   35  1   1   36  0   0
0   36  0   1   37  0   0
0   37  0   1   38  0   0
0   38  0   1   39  0   0
0   39  0   1   40  1   0
0   40  0   1   41  0   0
0   41  0   1   42  0   0
0   42  1   1   43  0   0
0   43  0   1   44  0   0
0   44  1   1   45  0   0
0   45  1   1   46  0   0
0   46  0   1   47  0   0
0   47  0   1   48  1   0
0   48  0   1   49  0   0
0   49  0   1   50  0   0
0   50  1   1   51  0   0
0   51  0   1   52  0   0
0   52  0   1   53  0   0
0   53  0   1   54  0   0
0   54  0   1   55  0   0
0   55  0   1   56  1   0
0   56  0   1   57  0   0
0   57  1   1   58  0   0
0   58  0   1   59  0   0
0   59  1   1   60  0   0
0   60  0   1   61  0   0
0   61  1   1   62  0   0
0   62  1   1   63  0   0
0   63  1   1   64  1   0
0   64  0   1   65  0   0
0   65  0   1   66  0   0
0   66  1   1   67  0   0
0   67  1   1   68  0   0
0   68  0   1   69  0   0
0   69  0   1   70  0   0
0   70  0   1   71  0   0
0   71  0   1   72  1   0
0   72  0   1   73  0   0
0   73  1   1   74  0   0
0   74  1   1   75  0   0
0   75  1   1   76  0   0
0   76  0   1   77  0   0
0   77  0   1   78  0   0
0   78  1   1   79  0   0
0   79  0   1   80  1   0
0   80  0   1   81  0   0
0   81  1   1   82  0   0
0   82  1   1   83  0   0
0   83  0   1   84  0   0
0   84  1   1   85  0   0
0   85  1   1   86  0   0
0   86  0   1   87  0   0
0   87  0   1   88  1   0
0   88  0   1   89  0   0
0   89  1   1   90  0   0
0   90  1   1   91  0   0
0   91  0   1   92  0   0
0   92  0   1   93  0   0
0   93  1   1   94  0   0
0   94  0   1   95  0   0
0   95  0   1   96  1   0
0   96  0   1   97  0   0
0   97  0   1   98  0   0
0   98  1   1   99  0   0
0   99  0   1   100 0   0
0   100 0   1   101 0   0
0   101 0   1   102 0   0
0   102 0   1   103 0   0
0   103 1   1   104 1   1
```

*Tabs instead of spaces, saving over 14,000*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RdVBjhwxCIXh9eQ0LhswXCf77CLN8Ts1/nmOetGFqiV/emD675/f39@fz/j6@Tzv5/3@xdPzNbua593qap3KurLzS@/Kz7voKk61u9qnyp8z3ipPVf2uOHHo@BZczoNOoAfRI9L7cH4v1Hl4a7Heh/M@@vAH2SPa@3Dep@qkFu88vHnIN/FN@WbndQPDN@WbZDatz5/4pnwT31RwM6jlm2Q35Zv4pnyT/JZ8i24u@Rb5rdnnr@7obSm@pfwWXV3yLXxLvkV@S76Fb8m36O6Sb5GfjT7f8Jl8hs@Un81znslnPXN36PCZfIbP5DN8Jp/hMw2f4TP5DJ8rP6e/Lp/jc/mc/Fw@x@fyOf31ey24F675c3wunzN/rvwcn8vn9DfkC/IL@YL5C/mC/EK@4H6E5i/whXzR9/ZeXOYv5At8IV/gC/mC/LZ8G9@Wb5Pf1vxt8tvybXxb@W36u@Xb9HfLt3uz3NVCf7d8m/ux5dv4UvOX@FK@JL9Ufkl@KV/S35Qv8aV8iS/lS3wpX/buu8uP/FK@pL@l/Ir5K/mK/Eq@Ir@Sr8iv5Cv6W/IV/S3NX@Er@QpfKb8iv7rrmfye8X9B9//FuCt69I4ed0mP3tLjrunRe3qc/D6ffw)

Comment: You could probably improve by changing the state name to a much earlier character, and move left instead of right.

Comment: @Naruyoko, Done, and added a couple of other improvements as well.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), score 722

```
⍘Ｌ”y；；；(...231699726063762276300861 in total...)；；；”γ
```

Port of @someone's 05AB1E answer. Explanation: If you convert 231699726063762276300861 to base 95 using the printable ASCII character set then you get the desired output. Only printable ASCII characters are automatically turned into string literals, so our null bytes have to be quoted with `”y”`. Using Charcoal's code page, the special characters have the byte values 148 + 204 + 9 + 121 + 0 + ... + 0 + 9 + 231 = 722.

As proof of concept, you can see it just for the letters `He`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7cKxCYAwEADAWUMaC0Gws8sC9oJkAzvbzJAhskBGeAfxjstL2vOW1ohxXrM9o9RjtltVVVVVVVVVVVVV9c9Hqf2N@AA)

Answer (score 3):

## Malbolge, Score: 6087

Just because I can.

```
('<;_#!7[}4{2VxTv-QsqNo'K+k)"Fgf|Bcc>=O<;(Kq7XXm3TjSng-x+)((`%d#"E~Y|{{>g,;;ut
```

Comment: 6081 is (presumably) your score, but it's not in *bytes*.  You could list the byte count separately for interest if you wanted, or just remove that word.

Comment: Whoops, that was a typo, thanks for noting.

Answer (score 3):

## x86-64 machine code (Linux executable w/ system calls), score 1508

274 bytes: 18 code bytes, 12 data bytes, and 244 zero-padding bytes to make a rel32 = `00 01 00 00` instead of some larger number in the lowest byte.

The natural character-set of x86 machine code is 1 binary byte.  No argument can be made for word, unlike with a RISC with fixed-length instructions.

Hexdump of the `.text` section of the executable (actually from assembling the same thing into a flat binary for `hexdump -C`).  I'm not counting the metadata bytes of the whole executable emitted by the linker.

```
00000000  8d 35 00 01 00 00 5f 04  0c 92 04 01 0f 05 04 30  |.5...._........0|
00000010  0f 05 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000100  00 00 00 00 00 00 48 65  6c 6c 30 20 57 30 72 6c  |......Hell0 W0rl|
00000110  64 21                                             |d!|
00000112
```

Disassembly (`objdump -d -Mintel`).

```
0000000000400080 <_start>:            # Entry point
  400080:       8d 35 00 01 00 00       lea    esi,[rip+0x100]        # 400186 <msg>

0000000000400086 <_start.lea_ref>:
  400086:       5f                      pop    rdi      # fd = argc = 1
  400087:       04 0c                   add    al,0xc
  400089:       92                      xchg   edx,eax
  40008a:       04 01                   add    al,0x1
  40008c:       0f 05                   syscall         # write(argc=edi, msg=rsi, msglen=rdx) leaves RAX=msglen
  40008e:       04 30                   add    al,0x30
  400090:       0f 05                   syscall         # exit(edi=1)
        ... (a bunch of 00 bytes)

0000000000400186 <msg>:
         48 65  6c 6c 30 20 57 30 72 6c 64 21    db "Hell0 W0rld!"
```

Note that Linux static executables start with all registers = 0 (except RSP which points to `argc` on the stack).

`add al, imm8` has opcode `04`, and is the lowest opcode that takes an immediate.  Using that to turn a `0` into a number we want, and `xchg`-with-eax for another zero, is the best way I've found to construct small numbers under these scoring rules.  `push imm8`/`pop` is somewhat worse, and `mov reg,imm8` has a high opcode.

**The opcode map at http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64.html was very useful for this.**

---

**Built with `nasm -felf64 hell0.asm && ld -o hell0 hell0.o` from this source:** (Including a mess of commented out possibilities, many with their instruction bytes to remind me why I didn't use them.)

If `MSGXOR` is `%define`d to a non-zero value, link with `ld -N` (aka `--omagic`) to make `.text` read+write.  In that case, the `%if` includes a loop that XORs every byte of the string.  `0x60` and `0x64` are both equal.  Subtraction with `0x30` doesn't save enough, and subtraction with larger values wraps around for too many bytes creating larger bytes.

```
BITS 64                     ; for flat binary.
%define MSGXOR 0x60

default rel
_start:
    lea    esi,[rel msg]  ; small positive offset.  Truncating the address to 32-bit is ok in a non-PIE
;    mov esi, msg         ; better than   rsi, msg  or strict qword
 .lea_ref:

;    add    al, 1        ; nr_write.  04  add al, imm8 is the lowest-opcode immediate instruction
    ;cmovnz edi, eax     ; 0f 45 f8    RDI is the highest-numbered register, and mode=11 is killer in ModRM
;    xchg   edi, eax          ; 9x
;    mov    edi, [rsp]        ; 8b 3c 24
    pop    rdi                ; 5f      fd = argc=1

;    lea    edx, [rax+msglen]     ; 8d 50 0d
    add    al, msglen
    xchg   edx, eax                ; len = msglen

%if 0
    lea    edi, [rax]   ; 8d 38
    add    edi, eax
    mov    esi, eax
%endif
;    push  "Hell"  ; 68 48 65 6c 6c  ; then would need to deal with 64-bit addresses

;    add cl, msglen    ; 80 c1 0c
;    mov cl, msglen    ; b1 0d

%if MSGXOR != 0
    add al, msglen-2      ; last byte is a '!' which grows when XORed with 0x60
.loop:
    xor byte [rsi+rax], MSGXOR 
    sub eax, strict dword 1      ; longer immediate makes the backwards jcc farther from FF
        ;sub al, 1; 2c 01
    jnc  .loop                   ; }while(rax>=0); jnc has a lower opcode than jge or jns


;    lea ecx, [.loop]     ; at the top: 8d 0d 00 00 00 00       ; loop back with an indirect jump so the loop exit can jump forwards?
;        push  rcx    ; 51
;        ret          ; c3
;       jmp  rcx    ; ff e1   nope, doesn't look good.  Just have to eat the nearly-FF rel8

;    loop .loop   ; e2 f2 
.break:
;;; AL = -1     after the loop
   add    eax, strict dword 2
%else
   add    al, 1                  ; RAX = 1 = _NR_write
%endif
; %else EAX = 0 still

;    add    al, 1 + !!MSGXOR      ; RAX = 1 = _NR_write
;    mov    al, 1
    syscall                      ; write(argc, msg, msglen) returns RAX=msglen

;    xor    al, 60 ^ msglen
    add    al, 60-msglen       ; or sub to wrap to 231 _NR_exit_group?
;    or     al, 60
;    mov    al, 60     ; exit.
;    mov    eax, 60
    syscall

 padbytes equ 0x100 - ($ - .lea_ref)   
 times padbytes   db 0

; in the same section as the code so we can control the rel32 to have one non-zero byte of 01
X equ MSGXOR
;msg: db "Hell0 W0rld!"
msg: db 'H'^X, 'e'^X, 'l'^X, 'l'^X, '0'^X, ' '^X, 'W'^X, '0'^X, 'r'^X, 'l'^X, 'd'^X, '!'  ; last byte not XORed
msglen equ $-msg
;ml: db msglen

;msg: db 0x28, 0x5, 0xc, 0xc, 0x50, 0x40, 0x37, 0x50, 0x12, 0xc, 0x4, 0x41   ; with ^0x60
```

Score counted with `hexdump | awk` with a custom format to dump bytes in decimal, and awk to add them up.

```
nasm hell0.asm -o hell0.bin && 
 <hell0.bin hexdump -e '32/1 "%d " "\n"' |
 awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)tot+= $i;} END{printf "score = %#x = %d\n", tot, tot}'
```

**With MSGXOR = 0x60, score = 1668,  the loop does *not* pay for itself with this short message**, especially with `0` digits instead of `o` lower-case ASCII.  `cmp al,imm8` is `3C`, but `cmp/jcc` and counting *up* towards `mslen-1` instead of materializing `msglen` and `msglen-2` separately might help.  But it wouldn't help enough; **we're 160 score away from break-even.**

```
# with MSGXOR = 0x60
0000000000400080 <_start>:
  400080:       8d 35 00 01 00 00       lea    esi,[rip+0x100]        # 400186 <msg>

0000000000400086 <_start.lea_ref>:
  400086:       5f                      pop    rdi
  400087:       04 0c                   add    al,0xc
  400089:       92                      xchg   edx,eax
  40008a:       04 0a                   add    al,0xa

000000000040008c <_start.loop>:
  40008c:       80 34 06 60             xor    BYTE PTR [rsi+rax*1],0x60
  400090:       2d 01 00 00 00          sub    eax,0x1
  400095:       73 f5                   jae    40008c <_start.loop>

0000000000400097 <_start.break>:
  400097:       05 02 00 00 00          add    eax,0x2
  40009c:       0f 05                   syscall 
  40009e:       04 30                   add    al,0x30
  4000a0:       0f 05                   syscall 
        ...

0000000000400186 <msg>:
  400186:       28 05 0c 0c 50 40      # not really instructions, deleted disassembly
  40018c:       37
  40018d:       50
  40018e:       12 0c 04
  400191:       21                      .byte 0x21
```

I can't find a way to jump backwards that isn't horrible.  Register-indirect jump sucks, and short displacements need a `0xF?` byte.  Padding with any non-zero byte to change the displacement costs at least as much as it reduces the `rel8` displacement, and `00 00` is `add [rax], al`.  Hmm, Possibly with a 256-byte-aligned address in RAX, we could pad with `00 00` without modifying memory?  But `xchg` with EAX is a `9?` byte and getting an address into RAX is costly.

But if we have a pointer in RAX, we can't use `add al, 1` or `sub al, 1` to loop.  In 32-bit code we'd have `4?` `inc`/`dec`, but not RIP-relative addressing.  x86-64 `inc`/`dec` are terrible, using the `ff /0` modrm encoding.

(**I considered using a linker script to set the absolute virtual address to something even lower**, but LEA's opcode is lower than `mov r32, imm32`.  Hrm, for EAX there is `05` `add eax, imm32` with an absolute address.  So looping another reg with inc or dec might be viable.  Or looping EAX with a pointer-compare, especially if I can make the absolute data address something like `00 00 01 00` just outside the low 64k where Linux disallows memory-mapping by default.  But then I'd feel like I had to count the linker script or its resulting metadata.  Or if I'm messing around with the metadata (ELF headers) in the executable, maybe have to count the whole thing instead of just the .text section.)

32-bit code needs `int 0x80` for system calls, not `0f 05` syscall.

Comment: (On 2nd thought, you could maybe argue for scoring x86 instructions as variable-length integers, presumably little-endian.)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), Score: 1452

```
echo'Hell0 W0rld!'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I1/dIzUnx0Ah3KAoJ0VR/f9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [evil](https://web.archive.org/web/20070103000858/www1.pacific.edu/~twrensch/evil/index.html), Score: 12853

Hard-code the characters

```
zaeeeaeeewzaeeaeeaeawzuueeueueawzuueeueueawzaeeeaeewzaeeeeewzaeeeeeuewzaeeeaeewzuueeueeaaawzuueeueueawzaeeaeeaewzaeeeeeaw
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy3LzPn/vyoxNTUVhMtBLDBKLK8qLU1NLQVCVCZUKYSBoEtTkaQgylMTEzG0ghFMT2L5//8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), Score:2151

```
72.101.108.108.48.32.87.48.114.108.100.33.@
```

### Explanation

```
72                                          Push ord code of 'H'
  .                                         Output
   101.108.108.48.32.87.48.114.108.100.33.  And so on
                                          @ And exit.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/f3EjP0MAQiC3A2MRCz9hIz8IcxDA0NIGKG@gZG@s5/P8PAA)

Answer (score 2):

### [MSM](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Mutating_Stack_Machine), Score: 1465

```
!dlr0W 0lleH...........
```

It is great that `!` is not an MSM instruction. Half of the program pushes onto stack, half of it concatenates them.

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), score: 5822

```
++++++++++[>+++++++>++++++++++>+++++++++++>+++++>+++>+++++++++<<<<<<-]>++.>+.>--..>--.>++.>---.<<.<++++++.------.<-.>>>+.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGw6i7aAMO4QYEhPKtkMRtQED3VigiJ4dEOnq6oEJMF8XyLCx0bOBKNXTBQM9G6CsHVDt//8A)

Answer (score 2):

## Befunge, Score: 1385

```
"!dlr0W 0lleH">:#,_@
```

This is my first legitimate code golf so it's probably not the best. Still not sure how the scoring system works. Is lower or higher better?

Comment: Lower score is better.

Comment: @pppery thanks, I'm guessing it's the addition of all the ASCII values?

Comment: That understanding is correct.

Answer (score 2):

## 80186 machine code (MS-DOS .COM format), score: 1799 (2061 bytes)

Nothing particularly special about this except that I used literal values on the stack to save score over `MOV` statements. To be able to use the same value for the function number and string location, I used just a little bit of padding.

```
68 00 09 58 50 5A CD 21 C3
(2039 zeroes) 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
48 65 6C 6C 30 20 57 30 72 6C 64 21 24
```

### TASM (ideal mode) source

```
IDEAL
P186

MODEL TINY
CODESEG
ORG 100H

MAIN:
    PUSH 0900H
    POP  AX
    PUSH AX
    POP  DX
    INT  21H
    RET

PADDING DB 7F7H DUP (0)
HELLO   DB "Hell0 W0rld!$"

END MAIN
ENDS
```

Comment: Oh the luxury of having a system call that takes implicit-length strings :) Related: [my x86-64 Linux version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/194535/hell0-w0rld-scored-by-ascii-values/194665#194665), score 1508.  For this, can't you arrange for the offset of `HELLO` to be `0200h` or something, and save 7 score?  Also, if your `AX` has a known value on process entry, you can use `05` `add ax, imm16` instead of mov or push.

Comment: Isn't `MOV AX, 0900H`(`B8 00 09`) smaller?

Answer (score 2):

## HTML, score: 936

```html
Hell0 W0rld!
```

HTML treats any whitespace as a space.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), Score:1584

Prints the string...

```python
print"Hell0 W0rld!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EySM1J8dAIdygKCdFUen/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), Score:1245

```ruby
$><<"Hell0 W0rld!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X8XOxkbJIzUnx0Ah3KAoJ0VR6f9/AA)

Comment: I think the quotes means it doesn't match the output exactly and is thus invalid. You probably have to go with the score 1245 solution `$><<"Hell0 W0rld!"` instead...

Answer (score 1):

## [shortC](https://github.com/aaronryank/shortC), Score:1166

ShortC version of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194539/85052).

```
AJ"Hell0 W0rld!"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87ILypJ/v/f0UvJIzUnx0Ah3KAoJ0VR6f9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

### Scratch 3, score: <del>2908</del> 2012

In ScratchBlocks Syntax.

```
define
say[Hell0 W0rld!
```

Defines an anonymous function. When called, it returns `Hell0 W0rld!`.

http://scratchblocks.github.io/#?style=scratch3&script=define%0Asay%5BHell0%20W0rld!%5D

Answer (score 1):

## [ink](https://github.com/inkle/ink), Score: 959

```
Hell0 W0rld!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8zL/v/fIzUnx0Ah3KAoJ0Xx/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [str](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/str), Score: 1081

```
`(ELL7RLD`32+o;
```

There are a lot of unprintable characters that don't show up above, see the TIO link for the full code.

Adds 32 to each character to get a lower score (the naive solution has a score of 1321)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky4p@v8/QcPVx0eAwVwgyMeFMcHYSDvf@v9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), Score: 1091

```
"Hell0 W0rld!"@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/1/JIzUnx0Ah3KAoJ0VRyeH/fwA)

I honestly can't find a way to do this cheaper. The costs of string manipulation are just not worth the savings that can be gained. Eg. subtrating 30 from each character the output string saves `360` but costs `289` to undo plus another `165` in control logic (`454` total). Encoding the operational part of the program *inside* the string saves `32` (one fewer `"`) but costs `187`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), Score [998](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page)

```
“¡¡¡...(22405534226214299955809248283 more ¡'s)...¡¡¡‘Lb⁹Ọ
```

\$254 + 0 + 0 + \cdots + 0 +252 + 76 + 98 + 137 + 181 = 998\$

[Proof of concept A](https://tio.run/##7cIxDYAwEABAg1VB0oXUAFvZEcDQBRmEDSd9I48OksvdWlvbMqOP9wIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA4J@in2WJ/Z7PkfkB)
\$35 \times 256 + 33=8993\$ `¡`'s prints `#!`

[Proof of concept B](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/IyMTA1NTYxMjIzMjQxMjS0tLU1MLA0sjEwsjCMulR486Hu3v@/wcA)
\$22405534226214299955809248289\$ `¡`'s *would* print `Hell0 W0rld!`
(just a few too many characters for TIO)

#### How?

```
“¡¡¡...¡¡¡‘Lb⁹Ọ - Main Link: no arguments
“¡¡¡...¡¡¡‘     - list of code-page indices = [0,0,0,...,0,0,0]
           L    - length = 22405534226214299955809248289
             ⁹  - literal 256
            b   - to base = [72,101,108,108,48,32,87,48,114,108,100,33]
              Ọ - to characters = "Hell0 W0rld!"
```

---

Base decompression using Jelly's code-page as digits would also score 998:

```
“¡¡¡...(22716232902740826769901577500 more ¡'s)...¡¡¡‘LṃØJ
```

\$254+0+0+⋯+0+252+76+219+18+179=998\$

Answer (score 1):

## [Assembly (nasm, x64, Linux)](http://www.nasm.us/), score: 9942 (114 bytes)

```
extern puts
global main
section .data
a: db "Hell0 W0rld!",0
section .text
main:
mov rdi,a
call puts wrt ..plt
ret
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rcw9DsMgDEDh3adwM6eIOSfoDTobcCMkAxF2/y5f2mTp/t5HqlyCvM@VtIzBL@NecbubwiotkGChXEE5Wm4VXSIjoAVTwOnCIh6vvks6TbP/R/ZjYP8WKO2BPeWZIJLIAeOzGzq3iUFnG@MTb0Krji8)

Simple assembler code which does the job (taken from original NASM's 64-bit hello-world, with unnecessary things being cut and some labels renamed to minimise the score). Probably can be golfed further.

Comment: Normally I'd golf in machine code, not asm source.  But sure, it's just as valid as other languages.  Yes as you suspected you're missing some optimizations.  If you link into a non-PIE executable, you don't need `wrt ..plt`.  And you can tailcall `puts` with `jmp puts` instead of call/ret.  You also don't need to put the string in a separate section from `main`.  (And if you did, the default section is .text so you could have just put the data *after*).  You do need `extern puts` and `global main`, though, for NASM.  With GAS syntax you wouldn't need extern.

Comment: 68 bytes: https://tio.run/##Jcs7DsIwEEXR3qt49Bi5DhtgBzQUGcejZGD8UWxIWL1RRHOrc6lWjl6/NlGN/QqV9MImbQEwTxNsyrYIY2FVd8md98ZrQnm3ambNnhSRJJkjQ8wfcJAzmWcsf0ND8OPtmHF3q4bTw429/wA I'll leave it to you to calc the score.  Note the removal of the space after `a:`, and the newline after `main:`.  Also the space after `db`.  And using backticks instead of double quotes around the string for `\0`.  I tried omitting the `\0` to depend on whatever's after it in the `.text` section, but I didn't get lucky with zero padding.  Anyway, it links fine with `nasm -felf64 hell0.asm && gcc -no-pie hell0.o`

Comment: Hmm, I forgot about the scoring system for a minute.  Note that uppercase letters have lower codepoints, so `MOV EDI,A` / `JMP puts`.  And `EXTERN puts` / `GLOBAL main`.  And `A:DB"Hell0 W0rld!",0`.  Also use tabs instead of spaces, and tab instead of `:` on labels.  But double-quotes with `,0` is better than backticks with `\0`.  IDK what I was thinking there, it's not even a saving in bytes.  https://tio.run/##SywuTs1NyqnUzUsszv1vrZCTmZetUJ5ZkqGgoJCenKygm5evW5CZqpCRmpNjoJf/3zUixDXIT6GgtKSYy93H38nRRyE3MTOPC0Rw@vqHcbq6eOo4cnn5BnCC1ThyujgpeYA0K4QbFOWkKCrpGPz/DwA

Answer (score 1):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), Score [959](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fmVdQWmKr7pGak2OgEG5QlJOiqP6/oCgzr0SjuDRXI78oRSNeMy2/SCFeITNPAaxaU5Pr/38A)

```
Hell0 W0rld!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/3yM1J8dAIdygKCdF8f9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [International Phonetic Esoteric Language](https://github.com/bigyihsuan/International-Phonetic-Esoteric-Language), Score: 1192 (WIP language) (OLD)

```
<Hell0 W0rld!>o
```

No TIO interpreter yet, but is runnable by cloning the repository above, and calling `python3 main.py "code here"`.

```
<Hell0 W0rld!>o

<Hell0 W0rld!>  ;push string "Hell0 W0rld!"
              o ;pop, print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), Score: 1420

Boring answer coming through. One thing to note, using " instead of ' saved 10 score points.

```r
cat("Hell0 W0rld!")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxREPJIzUnx0Ah3KAoJ0VRSfP/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), score: 2438 (118 bytes)

```
[S S T  T   S S S T S S N
_Push_-68_!][S S T  T   N
_Push_-1_d][S S S T T   T   N
_Push_7_l][S S S T  T   S T N
_Push_13_r][S S T   T   T   S T S T N
_Push_-53_0][S S T  T   T   T   S N
_Push_-14_W][S S T  T   S S S T S T N
_Push_-69_space][S T    S S T   S N
_Copy_0-based_2nd_-53_0][S S S S T  T   T   N
_Push_7_l][S N
S _Duplicate_top_7_l][S S S N
_Push_0_e][S S T    T   T   T   S T N
_Push_-29_H][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S S S T T   S S T   S T N
_Push_constant_101][T   S S S _Add_top_two][T   N
S S _Print_as_character][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##NYvBCcAwDAPf0hRarZRA8ysk0PFdW8Ef6yxO3zP3WO91jwgJUB6JhSzuENxlNuFYHmSFynLPxtQiSD/W6/XKHRnxAw) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

Uses [this Whitespace tip of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158232/52210) to print the output. The optimal constant is generated by [this Java program](https://tio.run/##fZJta9swEMff91Pc7pWEUuPBypgdUVoYzLD0xZytg1KG7KiJOkX25EsgjHx2T67tPGyjbyR0/7uf7ulZbdXl8@Jn25ZWNQ3MlHG/LwDqTWFNCQ0pCte2MgtYB4nl5I1bPjyC4p0bQG8Ar5uNJZCgHuLH9EUxjqBZK2t10wmZI73UPprdfP/x7ebz148TyOT7q/SUMrp/GWmIvf5UedbxjMxSM317FadGiCGDYw4ScUKTWo5RfVyxIw1F0mcYLTXdBkPD@CEcgGSAz6v7lQlKrUp9a5zyu57LikvD04Ovl4wi/WujbMNqfo35XY4JceGPLrWk8bEfbvPEfGS1W9KKcZgeKj1J4p/iT4gnfTxijnIW7Ob8y/7Mdw3pdVRtKKpDLWQdwz5cohihAtPQWBSZQEgAxWu9yPjw7d9kdp7@i9f@IhzDCg0zeo3dDdgNDdkqH6aCeY6CuWl8jXNMMEd@vg5lMm4VVWeoTuUzRatIFQ1znP9v7iRkOX33IYwwsOfDzvR985o23gUPvMO@kn3btp@0tTHcx94u3vwB). In addition, I use one duplicate for the `ll` and one copy for the `0` to save bytes/score.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, Score: 1644

```
alert("Hell0 W0rld!")
```

You can't really do much with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

### Rust, score: 2788

```
fn    main(){print!("Hell0 W0rld!")}
```

I was able to save some score by using a tab, but it's hard to make a short answer in Rust.

Answer (score 1):

#### x86 machine code - 72 bytes, score : 9253

I'm using [`write()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) syscall for printing a string.

```
     1                                  global _start
     2                                  section .data
     3 00000000 48656C6C                msg db  "Hell"
     4                                  
     5                                  section .text
     6                                  _start:
     7                                  
     8 00000000 8D0D[00000000]              lea ecx, [rel msg]
     9 00000006 43                          inc ebx
    10 00000007 80C204                      add dl, 4
    11 0000000A B004                        mov al, 4
    12 0000000C CD80                        int 0x80
    13 0000000E 80EA03                      sub dl, 3
    14 00000011 C60100                      mov byte [ecx + 0 - 0], 0
    15 00000014 800130                      add byte [ecx + 0 - 0], "0"
    16 00000017 B004                        mov al, 4
    17 00000019 CD80                        int 0x80
    18 0000001B C60120                      mov byte [ecx + 0 - 0], 0x20  
    19 0000001E B004                        mov al, 4
    20 00000020 CD80                        int 0x80
    21 00000022 42                          inc edx
    22 00000023 66C7015730                  mov word [ecx+ 1 - 1], "W0"
    23 00000028 B004                        mov al, 4
    24 0000002A CD80                        int 0x80
    25 0000002C 80C203                      add dl, 3
    26 0000002F C701726C6421                mov dword [ecx + 3 - 3], "rld!"
    27 00000035 B004                        mov al, 4
    28 00000037 CD80                        int 0x80
    29 00000039 99                          cdq
    30 0000003A 42                          inc edx
    31 0000003B C6010A                      mov byte [ecx + 0 - 0], 0x0a
    32 0000003E B004                        mov al, 4
    33 00000040 CD80                        int 0x80
    34                                      
    35 00000042 31DB                        xor ebx, ebx
    36 00000044 B001                        mov al, 1
    37 00000046 CD80                        int 0x80
    38                                  
    39                                  
    40 00000048 48                      .size: db $ - _start
```

Output : `Hell0 W0rld!`

Answer (score 1):

## 80186, score 1727

```
A:  org  $0100
    mov  sp, $0200
    popa
    int  $21
    ret

    db $200-$ dup 0
    dw $0000  ; DI
    dw $0000  ; SI
    dw $0000  ; BP
    dw $0000  ; Ignored
    dw $0000  ; BX
    dw $0300  ; DX
    dw $0000  ; CX
    dw $0900  ; AX
    dw $0000  ; IP for RET

    db $300-$ dup 0
    db "Hell0 W0rld!$"
B:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZHRSsMwFIbv8xS/o4KjFpPNiznxolXB3g0nuNuUpGOQJiGpSp@@Zu1gw1DP1cn3/YfkEO69bCrVZTX3Td/na8C4PZBQRilBqMZ8A97eBrQ4IWssH5qDbkN0wYaDky0ZGlEFRmmWQHxZjCPiJ8yHAh7xUkZoG6NiE6Fyr42TIo7uzmh5umMXpZ4v0MOI8jhVblAbh/fXj/Myy7/LVJi9SaUoPqlT4iqZkWLdazwF76SVvEWR5UNUGS7AUXWtRO1Mg@uMpaM65jVScCK1wDhHxMFbxTvc6Dt2fBKdhw8QYDS9X0XyHzetJs2UuOD9Lw)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 13 bytes, 1027 score

```powershell
"Hell0 W0rld"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X8kDSBkohBsU5aQo/f8PAA)

Answer (score 1):

### Pascal, 884 ≥ 3387 (ASCII) ≥ 6645 (EBCDIC)

The programming language Pascal is independent from any “code page”.
The Pascal ISO standards call this circumstance “implementation-defined”.
The theoretical minimum score should be about 900.
If you tailored your source code to ASCII, you’ll capitalize keywords and identifiers and use tabs as token separators (the blanks outside the `string` are meant to be tabs):

```pascal
PROGRAM A(OUTPUT);BEGIN WRITE('Hell0 W0rld!')END.
```

If you tailored your source code to EBCDIC, you’ll keep keywords and identifiers lower-case and also use tabs:

```pascal
program a(output);begin write('Hell0 W0rld!')end.
```

In yet another character encoding other letters may be particularly “expensive” and you might trade longer code for “cheaper” letters.

Answer (score 0):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), score: 1584

Thanks to its lightweight syntax, we can get rid of the parentheses.

```
"Hell0 W0rld!"print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8z//1/JIzUnx0Ah3KAoJ0VRqaAoM6/k/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## VBScript, 1523 score

```
MSGBOX "Hell0 W0rld!"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Windows Batch, 1278 score

```
ECHO Hell0 W0rld
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Noether](https://github.com/beta-decay/Noether), Score: 1107

```
"Hell0 W0rld!"P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8tPLclILfr/X8kjNSfHQCHcoCgnRVEp4P9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Bits](https://github.com/nayakrujul/bits), score: 3973

```js
1001000000101001100001100111110000001111110101111111100000010010001100000100011101
```

If you're interested, this is 82 bits = 10.25 bytes.

#### Explanation

```js
1001000    // H
000101     // e
001100     // l
001100     // l
1111100000 // 0
011111     //  
1010111    // W
1111100000 // 0
010010     // r
001100     // l
000100     // d
011101     // !
           // [Implicit join and output]
```