# Hello ASCII World!

Tags: code-challenge, restricted-source, hello-world

Construct a full program which outputs `Hello, World!`. The score of your submission will be equal to the sum of all of the ASCII values of the *distinct* characters. The lowest score wins!

### Rules

- It must be a full program which takes no input
- It must only print to STDOUT, nothing else
- It must be strictly less than 1000 bytes long
- It may only include [printable ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) (meaning no `\n` allowed)
- The objective is to find the lowest score for every language, so no answer will be marked "accepted"

### Example

Here is an example submission in Python, which has a score of *1279*:

```py
print"Hello, World!"
```

Finally, here is a [TIO link](https://tio.run/##JY7NCsIwEITvfYppLrZQClbwIFYQFRTECgqeSxIxEJOSRNCnr9n0OD/f7A6/8LKmGUf1HqwL8D@fZfzVO48WXoaizJ7WQSsjoQzFtQ9CmdrJXpDri3KVgTqcCmRFDW6FjAvWiYKXUavnZG1aLBr0Rkxy3WLeLAlAOlr3IgIxIUZqn7YwOGUC2K7bH67d6XJnVaIrsEt3x/Z87h6HfZ7njMryq@jriZnduHVyNavgP@8inSjHMWXsKLW2FR7WaZGzPw) to score your submission.

Comment: [This answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/110722/92237) shows how to write any Python program using only `exc="%` (which would have a score of `452`), but it would be insanely long without newline.

Comment: On further thought, the above scheme is impossible without newline :(

Comment: @SurculoseSputum [This one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165171/78410) uses 9 chars `exc%'(1+)`, no newline. [CJam](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165188/78410) can do it in just 3: `')~`.

Comment: Would it then be preferrable to include newlines, or maybe add a penalty for solutions which are too long?

Comment: And if you won't change the text "Hello, World!", [Stuck will win as always.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55425/78410)

Comment: There. I've added a 1000 byte limit, so the submissions don't get out of hand.

Comment: (Sort of) [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/194535/hell0-w0rld-scored-by-ascii-values).

Answer (score 14):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) `-zexecstack` `-Wl,-e$` `-nostartfiles` on Linux x86-64, <s>876</s> 914 bytes, score <s>798</s> 293

```c
$=1111+1111+1111+111+111-11-11-11-11+1+1+1;$$=1111111111+111111111-11111111+1111111+1111111-111111+1111+1111+111+111+111+111+111-11-11-11-11+1+1+1+1+1;$$$=111111+111111-11111-1111+111+111+111-11-1-1-1-1-1;$$$$=111111111+111111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+1111111+1111111+111111-1111-1111-1111-1111-111-111-111+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1;$$$$$=1111111111+1111111111-111111111-111111111-111111111-111111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111-1111111-1111111-1111111-111111-111111-111111+11111+11111-1111+111+111+11+1;$$$$$$=111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111-11111111-1111111-1111111-1111111-1111111-111111-111111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111-111-111-111+11+11-1-1;$$$$$$$=1111111111+1111111111-111111111-111111111-111111111-111111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111-1111111-1111111-111111-111111-111111-111111-111111-1111-1111-1111-1111-1111+11+11+11+11+1;$$$$$$$$=11111-1111-1111-111-111-111-11+1+1+1;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xVPLDoMgEPwZbts9eG76HT2bDZqmxCbFQ9OP71YrII9FvZXH7ASBHQYk7ImY1aWZCiQwd4wa/OpZLXOXAoFhPgTph3Jv2MzjcvlkEG@GjbTc13lVpBFKVidZxAr4DkmLZVdcWm3aYQe0htmViKX/DnP/vORt10SGB8VIaiQo3Q1X@k9Pd4ME6evwZ3CHkB/U@psxf6gzbW8Z3/qlyY4t3Rmv5oRaMQ6PaeA5djej7Rc)

Charset: <s>`A[]={+,-1};`</s> `1+-$=;`

Same method as the previous answer, with even more hacking to supply a custom entry point named `$` (which has the smallest ASCII value among `a-zA-Z_$`). Credit to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58613764/4595904) for identifying the flags and assembly setup to make this work. Also got a hint from [ceilingcat's awesome linker hack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210828/78410) to remove `[]{}` from the code.

Assembly: (NASM syntax)

```c
bits 64
global _start
_start:
  mov edx, 13
  pop rax
  push rax
  lea rsi, [rel s]
  pop rdi
  syscall
s: db "Hello, World!"
```

Uses the `argc=1` set up on the stack to load the value 1 to `rax` and `rdi`. The instructions are slightly mixed up in order to get the minimal code length in C.

[Here](https://tio.run/##tVFNb6MwEL37V8xlZTtAYyBfopv9Db0ja0UTJ3FFDAKybbPqb0/HU0TDSo16WQ7jx8x7b8bj@rU7VC69XLZmB1uzqY511RrhZMYAzrCGePjuocX/XGPh@WBLA85zAOwOHPxawznDM8LTEwNktl0jzjIEHnBNTFMOXJjAAqZTtP9SFY1VP9cQUYvgu@Rxj@D2ZK3JcKrpFG@sMNWY7tQ44PzuqbJOtHkWxVoyNlrTw3/b0zensa4@dUKysu2wpflTlILnHALoC18grrlkOE5pnECphB8wy8Cb@HGUxsWJGUSjumTudKSLYSa3Gm0IBLGnq5dYqSGVDKmrZHqVxPSuasDiTNAUbm@ECoduITbTQzdcFSSTSZr0@0OLleo9/J4w562ct/IazerGuk54LFljvAkP@8Udi1oMrxcSX8pegNSPGRDI28qHm9LL5eRau3dmC5tD0cCxsO73o3W5RsO/@Jrq5bEIMaotRfVvnK8oEp4RXhEznRMn7ZnkNNLtCH/E@ad6QXixuYrESQgnvdN8@VlZJlfcGbFi9nb/Dg) is the Python script that generates the "ones decomposition" from the `xxd -i` output (C include-style hex output) of the compiled binary.

---

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) `-zexecstack` on Linux x86-64, 891 bytes, score 1154

```c
main[]={1111+1111+1111+111+111-11-11-11-11+1+1+1,1111111111-111111111-111111111+11111111-1111111-111111-111111-111111-111111+11111-1111-1111-1111-1111+111+111+111+11,1+1+1+1,111111111-11111111-11111111-1111111-1111111-1111111-1111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+11111+11111+11111+11111-111-111-111-111-111-11-11-11,1111111111+1111111111-111111111-111111111-111111111-111111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111-1111111-1111111-1111111+111111+11111+11111+11111+11111-1111-111-111+11+11+11,1111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+11111111+11111111-1111111-1111111-1111111-1111111-111111-111111-111111-111111-11111-11111-11111-11111-11111+1111+1111+1111+1111-111-111-111-11-1-1-1-1,1111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+11111111+11111111-1111111-1111111-1111111-1111111+111111+111111+111111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111-1111-1111-1111-1111-111+11-1-1-1-1-1,11+11+11};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTMvOta22hAItFEIENZFQtpgqGMIB7pYWNroQrp4KG0EB43QRsU6GJbr4mTgorUJUpikLnYMQUghoY0/UPAGFB4GUV7B7mq4c7VhCKtz8bK0iQ1aXYIULlIbC4ER2BBIuvsp8hNJ6QR3QoZGgS6yNyDxUWv9//@/5LScxPTi/7pVqRWpycUlicnZAA)

Uses [ceilingcat's minimal Turing-complete charset](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/110834/78410) `main[]={1+,};`, plus `-` to meet the code length limit.

Assembly: (NASM syntax)

```c
bits 64
global _start
_start:
  mov edx, 13
  lea rsi, [rel s]
  mov eax, edi
  syscall
s: db "Hello, World!"
```

Essentially calls `write` syscall once, and goes into arbitrary instructions formed by the string literal, causing segfault.

Comment: This is a brilliant solution (I’ve upvoted it). But I think the language should be "C (gcc)/x86".  It won’t work using gcc on a non-x86 machine.

Comment: In fact, I just tried it on two x86 machines (one Linux and one OS X), and it failed to print "Hello, World!" on both.  I don't know what the difference is between these and TIO, where it worked.

Comment: One more comment: This program writes an error message to stderr (when it crashes), which I understood wasn't allowed in OP's specs ("It must only print to STDOUT, nothing else"). I could reduce my dc score, for instance, if spurious output to stderr was allowed, and that's probably true of some of the other solutions as well.

Comment: @MitchellSpector This code is supposed to work in x86-64, with executable stack (`-zexecstack` flag in the compiler/linker). And as pointed out in the linked answer, you might need `const` in some environments. The error messages are printed by the OS, not the program.

Comment: Thanks -- I missed that flag because it wasn't included with the language name in the answer heading, but it's clearly needed.  That got it to work correctly on my Linux system.  But I still can't get it to work under OS X, where I believe the equivalent compiler option is `-Wl,-allow_stack_execute` -- but even with that option, it doesn't print "Hello, World!".  I tried it with and without the `const` keyword before `main`.  If you know how to get this to work under OS X, I'd be interested.

Comment: I should also correct my earlier statement about output to stderr.  Not only is the error message printed by the OS, not by the program, as you said, but it's actually printed to stdout, not stderr (which surprised me when I checked).

Comment: @MitchellSpector I found that the syscall numbers are different on OS X (the `write` syscall number seems to be `0x2000004`). So you'll need `mov eax, 0x2000004` instead of `mov eax, edi` in the assembly, which will entirely change the code.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense -- thank you. I've never done much x86 programming (lots of 6502 programming back in the day, and then some 68020, but only occasional assembly-language coding since then).

Comment: I think you can eliminate braces by just declaring your array and then assigning each element individually?

Comment: You could also use a digraph, perhaps.

Comment: [score 248](https://tio.run/##jVPBCsMgDP0Zb5kHz2XfsXMJtozJBrOH0o9fJnjR9qmJMT6DkMdLZLsyi5i7S0ZVIOB5TSa/r4zGGQLwBBqxJHWhlOgAPnV5ghhVKMv0dqFHocuVCSlv1D5GoiBFnF4R0gNFe/DAuL4smmYBWk3NUJ8SCcXYknKKaHT0AvJErxIJfJZzE7JPIj9ewrxGsYffPcdt5pfYR7hZb8S@Pynx3ZZn8PEP "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 6):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 652 bytes, score 120

```
'))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))')))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))')))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))''(((((((')))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))')))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))'))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))''((((((
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/X12TACCogIa6B50hMHPU1TUgQH0gXTGIjKLIEFho/v8PAA)

Uses `')(`.

Answer (score 5):

## Stuck, 0 bytes, score 0

An empty program prints "Hello, World!"

Just as suggested in the comments, Stuck wins!

Comment: Can we please stop the low-effort stuff? 1+ though.

Answer (score 5):

## HQ9+, 1 byte, score 72

```
H
```

There is no TIO implementation for `HQ9+`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Malbolge](https://github.com/TryItOnline/malbolge), 71 bytes, 3963 points

```
(=<`#9]=}5YXy1Uvv-Q+q)Mn&Jk#j!EC$dc.?}_<)L'8%oXW2qj|Q@yx+iba'Hd]\E!YX|z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y03MScrPSU/9/1/D1iZB2TLWttY0MqLSMLSsTDdQu1DTN0/NK1s5S9HVWSUlWc@@Nt5G00fdQjU/ItyoMKsm0KGyQjszKVHdIyU2xlUxMqKm6v9/AA)

Uses the following unique characters

```
!#$%&'()+-.12589<=?@CEHJLMQUWXY\]_`abcdijknoqvxyz|}
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 321 bytes, score 399

charset: `\013456`

```
\043\1333311\05313311\0531133\135\133\043\13311\0534011\0534031\135\133\043\1331343\05311354\135\13331\05341\054101\0544\053104\0544\053104\054111\05444\0541\05331\05443\05344\054111\054114\0544\053104\054100\05433\135\135\135\046\1330\133\1330\0540\135\135\133\116\141\155\145\163\133\135\133\133\043\135\135\135\046\135
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY9BCsQwCEWv9D9qT@MmDIWZRXe9f0YjaUMbMGr@0@jRzu9@tPP3ab07VJwSh3SY8AoiCsFSnFApiumFL0LCV7XpFKXwvJUYTgcEfcZkyZWkIPUwuurKkO9qIN01eBl0yyngtZEMBgsSrwwk/qNFrmGb@Lr/veGzrfXe/w)

I feel it's best to try to explain this one. First, Mathematica allows character inputs with octal triplets (From this point on, I'll be using my local copy), after decoding, looks like so

```
#[1000+31111][#[3304+11135][#[10000+13003][31+41,101,4+104,4+104,111,44,1+31,43+44,111,114,4+104,100,33]]]&[0[[0,0]][Names[][[#]]]&]
```

All of the addition is just to avoid getting a 2, 7, 8, or 9, which in octal have 2s and 7s, which are trivially avoidable, all the other characters are the minimum needed to get `Names[]`. When the actual functions are shown,

```
Print[FromCharacterCode[List[72,101,108,108,111,44,32,87,111,114,108,100,33]]]
```

Where all the functions are hidden inside a `Names[][[1234]]` so that they can all be numerically decided, but `Names[]`, at minimum, needs `\13456` to derive everything else, the 0 is needed to turn Names's string output into Functions, as `0[[0,0]]` returns `Symbol`.

I know that after making this whole thing it can be golfed to do without 0, as the only time it comes up is in addition, inside the octal for the `+` symbol, and getting the symbol header, meaning that if 0 can be derived elsewhere then in the charset 0 can be switched to +, lowering the score by 5. All it would need is to not use commas inside list. The only function that I recall that can do this is the Append family, but calling Append instead of each comma makes the program over 2k in size.

In case you want to see how it was generated, I will put most of my code [here](https://tio.run/##vVTfa9swEH7PX3FVoA@dymychNEsxdAtrNCOds3YgyKKmyiJwbaKpEBo8N@e6SQ5PxzY4/Sg@@58@nTf2ecyMytRZiafZbvdh12jn1kpNOPDTmeRb5h@5XAzghej8mr5S7wX2UywDgBoivsWNyDTisD1LRBCvR95NyIUSOxxjDjxOEHc87iHuO9x32JPMPCBQSDcvMKNdadTAl9v4b4yYimUr4mNc6VNOpF3q0xlMyPUnZwLtuEUvlBIuDtfo5xqXRo5k@vKsI1X9Sjn68LL2dbupvuF8@Bl/aaFeWZ7Us1IFCe9/oBY4kM0Pa1lw7kvuB0O0cAOF/AoyjehnllI/JYvc6Nd1f2Q3PQ8XyxCjW1e@JxCiMNYydKTHEdhorJKv0u9J7DrIdcG0hS2EYWoZmjimsI2Dtb6Cdok@AEfCHA1GT20vYPt15ydibLLvuRP5L8qO4hDFPSdwLhR2RZ3lNPoTMJJD5s@NcJ9tN2hf3XC53rjdvxCtVETOYYRHH2q32crmT5JnZtcVgwnlELXMmN5lg0uh50yr@wZnFYkIl3mpsSTMfJkG2oIxxDhrPUQm3syOC7RF3eejf3dM7knnbPXeSgdX1d7LMkPURSSwh@pivkFzlK4iza8nF@yiLGIRpyz8C9irItxTppGLVU2F1bzRJqsSK9@V7Y36VXrMpvntDPbHz6ErS/zQVRLs3IxCo7H4Xq3212/Y/pf)

Answer (score 4):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), <s>460</s> <s>383</s> 442 bytes, score <s>268</s> <s>236</s> 226

*-32 score thanks to @Adam by utilizing `A1`*

*-10 score thanks to @emanresu A and @UnrelatedString by using `E` to EVAL `O"Hello, World"` instead of using `O` directly*

```
E+++++++++++++++A+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1A1A+11+11+11+1A1A+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1A1A+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1A1A+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1A1A+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1A1A+111A1A+11+11+11+11A1A+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1A1A+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1A1A+111A1A+111+1+1+1A1A+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1A1A+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1A1A+11+11+11A1A+11+11+11+1A1
```

Characters used: `E+A1`

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##pVhrc9NGFP3eX6GoNNZaimIzTDtYUTIhDR2mxVCSlmltg1erta0iS0aPJGCrf53eu3qt/IQpZDKS9ux97bmPzT/0jsYs8hbJSRC6/AvzaRwrvwbedJZcR1EYKfwh4YEbK@JtmeWA1zSKeXNd2lOi3qRB4s0P426SiNP5koVBnEQpS8JIo2SZzLzYjMM0YtymGax4i7czL@HxgjKuFetzmrCZdvpOGwxHw8Ewhu9Zb6Svvh@8GwajtjYMVo8IaZ@SbMH5B1iNeJJGgSIJH3RGq1WQ@n6WC3MMZnfI0ueJQm3H5A@caRKcWIUI3GLbNr3Ah54MsaVnM04dsF2joMb0eTBNZsSgAzYiWRKC414w3WpVlolwKLd/vb6@sQcjKw/Vn9RP@TJOaOIxZYGnoDlk6Zgb4bEmEMU7GoEPHYueCTGFfovqeu4fs8X3AR2ZpSzLm2iMFPawTPI1i9JAhD0K75WA3@eMyFzupNMt33d4J4SY9SLg@unc4dEOXLkIuGdh6HMa7ABWq1nBqt8gGBH1K@LloVsjWZwuULohRL13aUKBa7mjkpItzhTv9b5tnhTvTdCGG@UHGcY/@mhegaCKB1bTgPFwknstuXF8LBkPfMyfyiig8CoERUg2@FNyvc6m2@cjMrg8@XvUPjW6FeXp8TEeMMrU1FsVtZHMTeeLyplx6cwjkZ8ZGWd@MqtdOaptPT6mjWObyjhFxh01gVlO5kUazzT8Sqw8Va77f75486r/8rp/ay@zImFeuDxI1jhwyP0BPfn8foS/OydP30MI1gMghIKx2T42eQgCNjXjI7Z6Ew9weYhyHAYKzPWmAcqRPBnUmFFFzdzgHSjM4LvQc5XOEZ5PablVJ6hcl7XxH8GHILwPFK@yTGk1TGuNmzEXLpAyvlJ0v5ZeQ1ffDCkEtEgXStZJVSzUnKKuK3Gl3F9zRqdS6SAZ1OC98JMmfJ76e@HtJtz17mQv6yU8icYhlKJe0mRmAm8CJkk9Bb93HZJ6RYMgTBRQBWeiOJ@UzzwKVTA1dL9Rd63wB3pQH4hP/VDStwjv9@urxa9WRxo965Cvcr7d/grv@cMiDJCkNOHCICUJoTYGfAp8u@MKGMcjMNLfUUnO5HPbWW/OG6gG8Wva96Eh7ue9VL0r4veLkkpyzqOQRgkpKwi227UcUBGsEXVfZxDyCucPhJKFczCTiy2mWgXjG3fJwcFvZXSgOR4MDlLIsanUc9TWiMAcFw9vRu0LMuyeGo8FrTAawCxHJhJowGElH2KomQ93CFZb2JbYatVSW/hAapfqoRWLHlg19wJgkqt8TEMgFA9YmOJn7vaUR0uajbe1dGF/M4@MboesVp21mlUMCPtqFjoxLgCFws3Sg6BalxnxBafQe@QKdIDx1ai1l/EVSj5U@Fh0V9hF3ZtPAevRzI74x9SLuKZOYpUYSxyRxZIjLbGZ57vvF1HIeIyo53/0r25fvOrf1L35OdSAfa1ZYkl@wDCZV2IGjtTpxElLs6ol8eqiJ7JOX5nkNGcMx3ka52N8cWE@ds9YORu75Ww8sYVFZmkKKjua7KDTSw96dzBVaDRN5zhwPFq6ejdTQIkyQS@hozrYSC2eB3ZCMumMMRAaMxyDr40U8ImtjRUozqb5c0Dn3HbyZ1Ad22xzdhUbNNM0K1RVWfIqrqL2xAsDTdUrqVV4HKUcOcVWqtuqoai6Y@Yyqi6uqxu16ZXzD2eJ6cWCvwaMS9mkUKVEfOrFCRcukiWEtou9qrwgrd0lNLUPJinzFIY8BxL1gbLE/6RAL1DYjEbwBjOLHwZTqElWTRA6sh1JIwSm6lzy0RZJBjdQzZHygMi1px6j8vuGtZUGaj9U7lAyFMrUd9FWocI9glopZRUGnBhVCNTXqqER@7y4kqmq4djP0smERyb1/ZBpMIC7IQaJah1gRAcmcgMo78CVkjhg@AeL6eDqPWQc17rQhcWKuMmZmFtvPUh8dRiohDCbmbHvwQ2xYygn9WRfVhpGMtmyN7lljdY98UPw9cnjp0@e/vjT46c/tsXXiAZuOMewyfuvVYPa5xgy2ghtDWldthBSJXoe3sIqR@5uYMBFaWYuyZxE4fwKGHAVujBoFncn0ivNlY/TZAXuMsGZTTbymTCSyp@u8k/F5VL8lpfHYrnqQ03ndjiq/i42FQXR5A/eehWXsEeVAnHXal6AGsjfKiR6LBtSJpOM/hm5dV6Nb41gl5bFiRumiXkfQeMGgXmeE4M2YvaqKajWWkhTh0NxPSz//AFUu9ihoEB0jDL9AUt6W8Fj7JLfjYlRTU@yTTqQFctJfXDYcgsvG2E42UDiDWEbsr2BxA69DXm6gRT3gi3IHzZlhtvtfLeBFPP3FuRZhaxIU27B2aDaIu85371numvPxe49WPy37jmu9mi0zPDGX2wuim29Rg6uDm6jPWczNy1pW75qbAuYLcEaVQYvt6sVqJQu@s2UpmZxU3fsSr/TEP62Er7EPmo10tcia4m3lcwvchHQ/u1zujVYbNP3X6RNImi13YbTuK4Z2Aik17KWVemIQlYrVW1G7aZQ4AoV5aYDqlzb3dRcgcusxwH/guowX9YVwSE602uTdBe7ct06/m3Jta95iQccRGf85Vpv/rvUu91tP3r3siuvNd8kWPl/B2CnwH2y9P@BX98mvX6LigPi/5eJu3/k9fX4fxmbwBEcKawv/wE)

(Code used to generate this Knight code: [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##ZZAxC8IwEIX3/IrzQJpYRaOLCB0cBAfBwcEhBIc2YiEmJUkHEX97TawFwSHJe7n3vuGaR7hZs1o3rus8FJAdca@0tlM4W6erEWZEx29hXUVLBlfroITagJektJWKI9whsW1o2nDRtQ8pLEnKmZTTGwI/07wQwsznnPOpGcc7yV7FIyXpoXkBVCtDPZtxBhPAHD/EQyL@0CIbhgJuEXI4iIX8FCKx93zwvV1@bXK45UhI42oTaMKwrx7ea3YqrVMbePr2Tv82oAIVk9STjL0y1nVv))

Comment: You can actually do this without spaces, e.g. https://controlc.com/d04bd5eb. You can probably modify your code to get rid of spaces as well.

Comment: Here's the equivalent for your code: https://controlc.com/8ce83f01

Comment: @Adam Wow doing `A1` is actually super smart, editing my answer now.

Comment: If you have the willpower, `E` has a lower charcode than `O`.

Comment: @emanresuA [Not that hard with the existing code :P](https://controlc.com/a345f983)

Comment: @UnrelatedString Bro that's actually big brain, wowow

Answer (score 3):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), <sup><s>106</s> <s>652</s> <s>192</s></sup> 428 bytes, score <sup><s>332</s> <s>272</s> <s>272</s></sup> 204

```
11 11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+P11 11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+P11 11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+P11 11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+P11 11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+P11 11+11+11+P11 11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+P11 11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+P11 11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+P11 11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+P11 11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+P11 11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+P11 11+11+P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/9/QUMHQUBsFIcEALNLI6gjJk2YaCaoxFMA4xBtEsZW4zaRmsCBkA/7/BwA)

4 characters used: `+1P` and the space character.

Comment: You need to sum the *codepoints* of all characters you use in your program.

Comment: @a'_'  You're right - I misread the scoring in the challenge. It's fixed.

Comment: You may be interested in the bounty to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11336 for the dc solution with the lowest number of unique characters

Comment: @user41805 Thanks, I hadn’t seen the bounty. (I haven’t had time to do any code golf for a while.)

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 134 score

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++..+++.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++.------.--------.-------------------------------------------------------------------.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fexRQBegRJaunR1Dp0PboiIxdMvSB04EuGEApJAYFQO//fwA)

Alas, could have scored 89 if not for the 1000 character limit.

## [Boolfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/boolfuck), 102 score

```
;;;+;+;;+;+;+;+;+;+;;+;;+;;;+;;+;+;;+;;;+;;+;+;;+;+;;;;+;+;;+;;;+;;+;+;+;;;;;;;+;+;;+;;;+;+;+;+;+;+;;;;+;+;;+;;+;+;;+;;;+;;;+;;+;+;;+;;;+;+;;+;;+;+;+;;;;+;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8rPz0krTc7@/9/a2lobCMEEDEIRTBiNDeJhiIMFUcWRzLNGMhahD42vjWqYtvX//wA)

"Standard".

Comment: I was going to make a brainf*** solution (generated with Python) and it was exactly your solution, so I upvoted it. Nice going! :)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>344</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>254</s></sup> 242 bytes, score <sup><s>1624</s></sup> 1575

Lowered score by 49 thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)!!!

Saved 12 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!

```c
h;t;u;i;a;main(c){u+=u=i+=i=a=c+c+c;t=u+u+u;putchar(putchar(t+t)+u+u+a+c+c);putchar(putchar(putchar(h=t+t+t))+a);putchar(t+i+c+c);putchar(u+u+i+c+c);putchar(t+t+u+a);putchar(h+a);putchar(h+i);putchar(h);putchar(t+t+u+u+a+c);putchar(u+u+i+a);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY5BCoBACEWvM4N0AvEw4qJxUUToKjr75ARRM/EXH/3/iTLNIrUWNHRUZFxY1yT5cCAnBVJiEgihkUMINzcpvKfHDSy3ALjV8i9/vFA0o5uB35KB9lQ7NKwa5l@o9IN@hpG6vxqvB33WegE)

Uses characters: `()+;=achimnprtu{}`

Comment: You can get rid of `1` by retrieving it from `argc`, leading to [1575 points](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/ROtM6NzEzTyNZszrRNlkbA1pn2iZqY0DrgtKS5IzEIg1UcaB6TbhUJhoHFRIplYjMRbIGVR0W29GdTJwNmdhMx@dALG4Aydf@/w8A).

Comment: @Arnauld Very clever - thanks! :-)

Comment: @Arnauld Why not? Thanks! :-)

Comment: @Arnauld Knocked down to a quarter K - thanks! :-)

Comment: Yeah, that's a nice round figure. And that's why I didn't submit the [254-byte](https://tio.run/##dY5BCsNADAO/k2D6AuHHCB9qH1JK2D2Fvn3rJYdsQoIusvDIttfbrDVHQQURWBifyeaNapJCKIWoGhIoWiUF1yIpfGsx5zqln8ehLwk7fsR@b4UjGWem11yivZ0PDS5xe2b46dqe9K@1Pw) version. ;)

Comment: @Arnauld Yeah, let's stick with 256. Sweet number! :D

Comment: @Arnauld Sorry, can't help  myself. Now we're down to 8-bit numbers - thanks! :D

Comment: @ceilingcat Wow, very nice! Shame the score is independent of the byte count. Thanks anyway! :-)

Comment: [score 1445](https://tio.run/##dY9NCgMxCIVvUyaYnkA8jAQpLtKFCC6Gnj1NUjoM84Or@N77ninPVymtVQx0NFRkrKzvRdJqQEYKpMQk0AedDPpgmLoskh81S67k4Omwg@nkkfpLmyG6IUaox@brGKYATucS3dO2/ei5VkaDXZB29JOiNxf9WPNHNxd05qe1Lw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Grass](http://www.blue.sky.or.jp/grass/), score 324, 623 bytes

```
wvwwWWwWWWwvWwwwwWWwWWWwWWWWwWWWWWwWWWWWWwWWWWWWWwWwwwwwwwwwwwwWWWWwWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWwwWWWWWWWWWWwwWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWwwWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwWwwwwwwwwwwwWWwwwwwwwWWWwwwwwwwWWWWwWWWWWwwwwwwwwWWWWWWwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwWWWWWWWwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwWWWWWWWWwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwWWWWWWWWWwwwwWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwWWWWWWWWWWWWWwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 618 bytes, score 265

```
((((((()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())()()()()()()()())()()()()()())[()()()])[()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()])(((((((()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())()()()()()()()()()()()())()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())[()()()]))[()()()()()()()])[()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/XwMCNCmFmhqDAuIX0IyG0LEwBvEwVlODOkE16EMQHkbogURGqCFr/v//v65uYnFyZiYA)

Used characters: `()[]`

Uses `()` (one), `(...)` (sum and push), `[...]` (negate). Can definitely be shorter by using `[]` (stack height) but it's not the point of the challenge (as long as the code is under 1000 bytes). Looks like the program can't fit into 1000 bytes using only `()` and `(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 574 bytes, score 564

```python
exec"%c"%(111+1)+"%c"%(111+1+1+1)+"%c"%(11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1)+"%c"%(11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11)+"%c"%(111+1+1+1+1+1)+"%c"%(11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1)+"%c"%(11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1)+"e%c"%(11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+"%c"%(11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+"%c"%111+"%c"%(11+11+11+11)+"%c"%(11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+"%c"%(11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+"%c"%111+"%c"%(111+1+1+1)+"%c"%(11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+"%c"%(11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1)+"%c"%(11+11+11)+"%c"%(11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P7UiNVlJFYg0DA0NtQ01tZE42igC2jgRAhKjGtMO7DqJMhVFUSoJLiXHdyh6QK7H0IxmHqkWEmUZ5U7HqwddDd6I@f8fAA)

Used characters: `exc"%(1+)`

Constructs the string `print'Hello, World!'` using the characters `"%c(1+)`, then `exec`s it. Using the raw `print` with any single extra character costs more than this.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), score: 282 (251 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage))

```
0>>>0>>>>>>>>>0>0>>>0>>>>>>>>0>>>>>0>>>0 0>>>>>>0>>>>>>>>0>>>>>>>>0>>>>0>>>>>>>0>>0 0>>>>>>>0>>>0 0>>>>>0>>>>>>>>>0>>0>>>0>0>>>>>>0 0>>>>>>>J 0>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>B
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fwM7ODoQhwMAOhW8AJw0UDJCFMBgGCA5cKYpGZDuglsBMhKv3UkCooj1w@v8fAA)

Five characters used: [`0> JB`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8Ezbw@3@Ov//G9jZ2YEwBBjYofAN4KSBggGyEAbDAMGBK0XRiGwH1BKYiXD1XgoIVbQHTgA)

**Explanation:**

1. First we construct the number `39138530688472073059231607`. We do this per digit, by pushing a `0` and increasing it by 1 per `>`, after which the entire stack of digits is joined together with `J`.
2. Then it pushes another `0` with 107 `>`s to get the number `107`.
3. After which it will convert `39138530688472073059231607` to base-107 with `B`, which is `"Hello, World!"`.

Answer (score 2):

## Help, WarDoq!, 1 byte, Score: 72

```
H
```

[Try It Online!](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l%3AQ%7B%22HhEeLlOoWwRrDd%2C!AaPpQq%22Q%7C%5B%22Hh%22%22ello%22a%5B'%2CL%5DSa%22Ww%22%22orld%22a%5B'!L%5D%5D%3Am*%3A%60%5B%7Briri%2B%7D%7Briri%5E%7D%7Brimp%7D%7Brizmp%7DQ%60Q%7B%5C%2B%7D*%60L%5D%2Ber%3A~N*%7D%3AH~&input=H)

Answer (score 2):

## [H](https://esolangs.org/wiki/H%F0%9F%8C%8D), 2 bytes, score 223

```
hw
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDBCsIwDIbve4osJwtDBG9C776BF28uI4XQ1m5Qffpaaw@Tbv8lkHz5CPHvhZ09p/RwI4EG5IhdN7kAYiyBsfAdHGcvZjng3aK6dJDjg7G5cSURN0ApPYKZyprWyIxAMlOBf8GbCzIOUMofHGMLV3MLc9w1t2dE3jFnqmZlzr1N8xYcW7h8bJUK9xqfLUyv/NCTUil9AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Bits](https://github.com/nayakrujul/bits), score: 97

There are only 2 distinct characters in Bits, `0` and `1`. These have ASCII values of \$48\$ and \$49\$, so the score is \$97\$.

If you're interested, this is actually only 10 bytes (80 bits).

```js
10010000001010011000011000011110111000111111010111001111010010001100000100011101
```

#### Explanation

```js
1001000 // H
000101  // e
001100  // l
001100  // l
001111  // o
011100  // ,
011111  //  
1010111 // W
001111  // o
010010  // r
001100  // l
000100  // d
011101  // !
        // [implicitly joined and output]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 234 bytes, score 259

```
llllllll+++l+++++lllllllllllll+++++l++++++++llllllllllll+++++l+l+++++++llllllllllll+++l+++++++++lllllllllll+++l++++++++lllllll++ll++l+++++llll+++l+l+lll++l+$llllllll++++++l++l+llllll+++lll+++++llllllll+++++++lll++l+l+l+llllll++++l++$H
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/PwcKtLW1QRhIIgOIiDYUYJHJwS4F16KNQxwuBMZwIaiZEBltFRTLtMFiCKNyUN2LMBhqBkIpSKeKx///AA)

Used characters: `l` (length of stack), `+` (add top two numbers), `$` (swap top two numbers), `H`.

`$` was needed because some characters (space, H) were impossible to create at that specific stack height; it is cheaper than any number literal (minimum being 0).

---

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 182 bytes, score 315

```
ssP0ssssssPPPP0ssssssPPPPPPPPPPPP0sssssssPP0ssssssPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP0sssssPPPPPPP0ss0ssPPPPPPPPPPPP0ssssssPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP0ssssssPPPPPPPPPPPP0ssssssPPPPPPPPPPPP0ssssssPPPPP0ssssPPPPPPPPH
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/v7g4wKAYDAKAAIkJA1ChYqyScHkExwCrdqyaikkQMkCW9Pj/HwA)

Used characters: `0` (push zero to the stack), `s` (add 16 to top), `P` (increment top), `H` (halt and print everything on the stack as characters).

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 540 bytes, score 1563

```c
main(){putchar(11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1);putchar(11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1);putchar(11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1);putchar(11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1);putchar(11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1);putchar(11+11+11+11);putchar(11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1);putchar(11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1);putchar(11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1);putchar(11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1);putchar(11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1);putchar(11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1);putchar(11+11+11);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6oLQkOSOxSMPQUBsdIaCmNR5lSOqJVadNlunk6MKlEEOQdAuo7STcdtAygDBVaVrX/v8PAA)

This is just a straightforward solution that prints the ASCII code of each character in turn, like some of the other solutions here.  I'm not aware of any tricky way to reduce the score in C.

Comment: [287 bytes, score 1563](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6oLQkOSOxSIPWtCEEaBtqasNYIATjaQIZ2jBZVIwshKQDWRqMwExthA3aSNagaNVGFcZmpXXt//8A "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, 35 bytes, Score: 1916

```
fn main(){print!("Hello, World!")}
```

I don't know if you can get any shorter in Rust.

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 18 bytes, score 1005

```bash
echo Hello, World!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I1/BIzUnJ19HITy/KCdFESIUnJxflGqlYGhgYPofAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net), 13 bytes, score 802

```php
Hello, World!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fIzUnJ19HITy/KCdF8f9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), 732 bytes, score 372

```
1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1o1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1o1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1o1o1a1a1a1o1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1o1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1o1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1o1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1o1a1a1a1o1s1s1s1s1s1s1o1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1o1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1s1o
```

Uses `1`, `a`, `s` and `o`.

Without the size restriction, naz `-u` could achieve a theoretical score of 257 by foregoing `s`.

Answer (score 1):

## [G*](https://esolangs.org/wiki/G*), 15 bytes, score = 914

```
p Hello, World!
```

Answer (score 1):

## [2/9 of an esolang](https://esolangs.org/wiki/2/9_of_an_esolang), 1 byte, score = 64

```
@
```

Comment: But the article says "Every line of code must be exactly 21 characters"

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 386 bytes, score = 818

```perl
say chr 11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1,chr 11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1,chr 11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1,chr 11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1,chr 111,chr 11+11+11+11,chr 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+11+11,chr 11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1,chr 111,chr 111+1+1+1,chr 11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1,chr 11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1,chr 11+11+11
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIhOaNIwdBQGx0hoA4OFUhKiVCiTaqZWDVgaITwtbFAhCxRFmBYQaFLcWtAUfD//7/8gpLM/Lzi/7q@pnoGhgYA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 387 bytes, score 601

```
ecHO cHR 11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1,cHR 11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1,cHR 11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1,cHR 11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1,cHR 111,cHR 11+11+11+11,cHR 11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1,cHR 11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1,cHR 111,cHR 111+1+1+1,cHR 11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1,cHR 11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1,cHR 11+11+11
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8vM/f8/NdnDXyHZI0jB0FAbHSGgDg4VSEqJUKJNqplYNWBoROaTZA1BKyh0KW4NKAr@/wcA)

Chars: `ecHRO, +1`

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 430 bytes, score 191

```
++++++++++++C+++++++++++11 11 11 11 11 11 1 1 1 1 1 1C++++++++++11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 1 1C+++++++++++++++++11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1C+++++++++++++++++11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1C111C+++11 11 11 11C+++++++++++11 11 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1C++++++++111 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1C111C+++111 1 1 1C+++++++++++++++++11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1C+++++++++11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 1C++11 11 11
```

[Try it online!](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2BC%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1C%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1C%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1C%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1C111C%2B%2B%2B11+11+11+11C%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1C%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B111+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1C111C%2B%2B%2B111+1+1+1C%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1C%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1C%2B%2B11+11+11&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 1 byte, score 119

```
w
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0lNTEnLLM7Q/f@//P9/AA)

Not so interesting

Comment: As this is code challenge and has special scoring, please also specify “score 119”.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 409 bytes, score 558

```
=CHAR(11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1)&CHAR(11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1)&CHAR(11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)&CHAR(11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)&CHAR(111)&CHAR(11+11+11+11)&CHAR(11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)&CHAR(11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)&CHAR(111)&CHAR(111+1+1+1)&CHAR(11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)&CHAR(11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1)&CHAR(11+11+11)
```

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJnWphcNkTKJ6yJmTg?e=Ts6uFw)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA (Immediate Window), 396 bytes, score 457

```
?CHR(11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1)+CHR(11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1)+CHR(11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+CHR(11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+CHR(111)+CHR(11+11+11+11)+CHR(11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+CHR(11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+CHR(111)+CHR(111+1+1+1)+CHR(11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+CHR(11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1)+CHR(11+11+11)
```

Similar to the Excel answer. Uses 2 fewer unique characters.

Comment: You don't need the `+`s between `CHR(...)` calls when printing - should get you down to ~ 384 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 61 bytes, score 2527

```go
package main;import."fmt";func main(){Print("Hello, World!")}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BgqWlJWm6FjdtCxKTsxPTUxVyEzPzrDNzC_KLSvSU0nJLlKzTSvOSwcIamtUBRZl5JRpKHqk5Ofk6CuH5RTkpikqatRBDoGbBzAQA)

The boilerplate hello world, compressed onto 1 line.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2), 4528 bytes, score 156

```
..+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+C..+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+C+..+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+C+..+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+C+..+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+C+..+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+C+..+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+C+..+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+C+..+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+C+..+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+C+..+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+C+..+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+C+..+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+.+C+
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyIiLCIiLCIuLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuK0MuLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rQysuLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuK0MrLi4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLitDKy4uKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rQysuLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rQysuLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rQysuLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuK0MrLi4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLitDKy4uKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rQysuLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuK0MrLi4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rQysuLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuKy4rLisuK0MrIiwiIiwiIl0=)

`.` on its own represents 0.5, so this adds up a bunch of 0.5s, converts them to characters, then concatenates them together. This actually does better than using the builtin [`kH`](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyIiLCIiLCJrSCIsIiIsIiJd), which has a score of 179.

Answer (score 0):

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 439 bytes, score: 1706

Port of the 540 byte C answer. Unique characters:

```
main([])->o:fwrte1+,.
```

Which is of length 23, sum 1706.

```erlang
main([])->io:fwrite([11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1,11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1,11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1,11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1,11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1,11+11+11+11,11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1,11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1,11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1,11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1,11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1,11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1,11+11+11]).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy3KScxL100tTi7KLCj5/58rNzEzTyM6VlPXLjPfKq28KLMkVSPa0FAbHSGgDhZZJGUEpLVJMYsExWjyOjjMwGkKZdbhNpF6PoRLxmrq/f8PAA)

Comment: Newlines are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 468 bytes, score 1234

```java
\u0063\u006c\u0061\u0073\u0073\u0020\u0041\u007b\u0070\u0075\u0062\u006c\u0069\u0063\u0020\u0073\u0074\u0061\u0074\u0069\u0063\u0020\u0076\u006f\u0069\u0064\u0020\u006d\u0061\u0069\u006e\u0028\u0053\u0074\u0072\u0069\u006e\u0067\u005b\u005d\u0061\u0029\u007b\u0053\u0079\u0073\u0074\u0065\u006d\u002e\u006f\u0075\u0074\u002e\u0070\u0072\u0069\u006e\u0074\u0028\u0022\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064\u0021\u0022\u0029\u003b\u007d\u007d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZFLDoMwDERPVCk4TkLu0g0lsKDrcv2gjC3ZKmLzFp7J@JNjOZfX0b69v38h5Aiu4DRYopHCIEv9A6JSEvzk3lZLk1eawy6ZH5wZld2pbGpulqDqBnUeTK5LoX9PLvBg8uRyqNpGmlBvMyfrTptNKLuLR@p6k1t39WBOgsqzS14dd9s3FdfLX1jSJkuTLaL8SxP2fgE)

Note: I'm stumped on how to make it have less score. Oracle really does make it hard to golf.
Thanks to @ceilingcat for and halfing the score.

Answer (score 0):

## Zsh, 464 bytes, score 552

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##rZKxCsMwDER3f8WBPUhoiWrZEPAHde/WkG935amlbUIaig1PHHcSAt1v195ba2mhyIlIVd7/8zGvO76XwGGjnOu/E9to8qmeGP/T6D/utB37YnOpRzTUKUQk5OpYoJfsJNhQI3JxMEwdCpsdAhuW1a0lhHESRHWSXMWzYl4VMRWbxbJLhbk/AA)       charset: `<${(#)1+}`

```bash
<<<${(#)$((11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1))}${(#)$((11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1))}${(#)$((11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1))}${(#)$((11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1))}${(#)$((111))}${(#)$((11+11+11+11))}${(#)$((11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1))}${(#)$((11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1))}${(#)$((111))}${(#)$((111+1+1+1))}${(#)$((11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1))}${(#)$((11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1))}${(#)$((11+11+11))}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 107 bytes, score 815

```julia
print('i'-11-11-11,'p'-11,'n'-1-1,'n'-1-1,'p'-1,',',','-11-1,'n'-11-11-1,'p'-1,'r','n'-1-1,'p'-11-1,','-11)
```

characters used `print('-1,)`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v6AoM69EQz1TXdfQEIJ01AvUwVQekNJFokHCOuoQCFYKkTKEsiHSReqoGgwheoAMzf//AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## AWK, 57 bytes, score 1632

Escape sequences are in octal.

```
BEGIN{print"\110\145\154\154\157\54\40W\157r\154\144\41"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd06@6oCgzr0QpxtDQIMbQxDTG0NQEis1jgJSJQTiIWQQRMwEKGCrV/v8PAA)

[Score count](https://tio.run/##LY5Bi8IwEIXv/RXTXGyhFNOtLshWcNcigrSCgpdeShIxoElJsrAi@9u7mXQPQ@a9ed9Mhqe7aVWMo3wM2jiwTxtF7NYbCxVY4ZI0umoDd6kESIXj3DouVW5Ez9G1SbqKADMMA2h5DUxz4TdowxOWei2vk7Wu4K2AXvFJflRAiyUCEI7mPfeAnyAj7jbsgsFI5YB8tdv62O6bM8kCnQFp2jNsDof2Um/jOCYYFj8Sfz0xsxPTRqxmGdjvRxJOpOP4We/2zSskSEfpvKPloqOL8r/eO/@U8wu2ZvJKb1Dy@wc)

Comment: Why the literal “W”? With `\127` your score would drop to 1595.

Answer (score 0):

## [KonamiCode](https://esolangs.org/wiki/KonamiCode), 168 bytes (score 415)

```
v(^^^^^^^>^^)<<v(^>>^)<<v(^>>^^^^^^^^)<<v(^>>^^^^^^^^)<<v(^>^>^)<<v(^^^^>^^^^)<<v(^^^>^^)<<v(^>^>^^^^^^^^^)<<v(^>^>^)<<v(^>^>^^^^)<<v(^>>^^^^^^^^)<<v(^>>)<<v(^^^>^^^)<<
```

Characters used: `^v<>()`

Answer (score 0):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 378 bytes (score 309)

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````:o`````````````````````````````:o```````::oo```:o,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,:o,,,,,,,,,,,,:o```````````````````````````````````````````````````````:o````````````````````````:o```:o,,,,,,:o,,,,,,,,:o,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,o
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z@BSsAqnzhpK6v8fDBfh3KAaggBF5DjdCtkpyJso4rj8///BwA)

Uses four instructions, increment top of stack, duplicate top of stack, decrement top of stack, and print as a character.

```
 :,o`
```

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB, 15 Bytes (score 802)

```
'Hello, World!'
```

Comment: As this is a [code-challenge], I've edited in your score, per the challenge spec

Answer (score 0):

### Pascal, 1449

1. **2189**:
   The boilerplate Hello World reads:

   ```pascal
   program p(output); begin writeLn('Hello, World!') end.
   ```
2. **2080**:
   Since Pascal is case-insensitive we can capitalize keywords and identifiers.
   This lowers the score because capital letters come before lower-case letters:

   ```pascal
   PROGRAM P(OUTPUT); BEGIN WRITELN('Hello, World!') END.
   ```
3. **1706**:
   Now, as some keywords are non-optional and our program needs definitely needs at least one string or `char` literal in conjunction with some `write`, we can reuse the preexisting letters in our `Hello, World!` string.

   ```pascal
   ProGrAM P(oUTPUT); BeGIN WrITe('Hello, World!') eNd.
   ```

   The now lower-cased letters already appear as part of `Hello, World!`.
   Only `H`, `l`, `,` and `!` are “new” letters which aren’t found in the rest of the `program`.
4. **1449**:
   Let’s avoid any characters from set of `['H', 'l', ',', '!']` by using “preexisting” letters and the built-ins we can use with them.
   If we are running this `program` on a system using the ASCII character set as its base, we can use `pred('I')` to retrieve the value `'H'` *without* writing a `char` literal `'H'`:

   ```pascal
   ProGrAM P(oUTPUT); BeGIN WrITe(Pred('I')); WrITe('e'); WrITe(Pred(Pred(Pred('o')))); WrITe(Pred(Pred(Pred('o')))); WrITe('o'); WrITe(Pred(Pred('.'))); WrITe(' Wor'); WrITe(Pred(Pred(Pred('o')))); WrITe('d'); WrITe(Pred(Pred(Pred(Pred(Pred(Pred(''''))))))) eNd.
   ```

   This `program` merely requires an ISO standard 7185 “Standard Pascal” processor (level 0 sufficient).
   It has a total size of **216 bytes** thus below the eight, uhh… whoops, *one thousand* byte limit.

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 71 bytes (score 2563)

```cs
class a{static void Main(){System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTc4vSv3/PzknsbhYIbG6uCSxJDNZoSw/M0XBNzEzT0OzOriyuCQ1V885P684PydVL7wosyTVJzMvVUPJIzUnJ19HITy/KCdFUUnTurb2/38A)

I'm just starting with C#, so maybe there's a way to do it even shorter

Comment: Welcome to CGCC! [67 bytes (score 2487)](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTc4vSv3/PzknsbhYIbG6uCSxJDNZoSw/M0XBNzEzT0OzOriyuCQ1V885P684PydVL7wosyRVQ8kjNScnX0chPL8oJ0VRSdO6tvb/fwA "C# (.NET Core) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 59 characters, score 858

```
\A=\110\145\154\154\157\054\040\127\157\162\154\144\041@END
```

(Doh. After all these years, now I discovered that Gema function names are case insensitive.)

Sample run:

```
bash-5.2$ gema '\A=\110\145\154\154\157\054\040\127\157\162\154\144\041@END'
Hello, World!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/P8bRNsbQ0CDG0MQ0xtDUBIrNYwyAtIEJUNzIHMw3NDOCyJmAxA0dXP1c/v8HAA)