# List of programming languages that can run code at runtime

Tags: tips

What all languages have a construct similar to python's `eval`, so you can write code during runtime and run it?

A list would be helpful for certain programming challenges - ones where it is obvious an `eval` is either necessary or highly efficient.

Comment: I'm not sure on the answer format, would a community wiki answer be better? Or one language per answer?

Comment: You can cross C++ off the list! T_T

Answer (score 7):

A few I recall:

- Lua: `loadstring("2 + 2")`
- *Script (Coffee, Java, Type, Action): `eval("2 + 2")`
- Erlang / Elixir: `Code.eval_string("a + b", [a: 2, b: 2], file: __ENV__.file, line: __ENV__.line)`
- J: `". '2 + 2'` (eval it right away) or `3 : '2 + 2'` (define a function; `(3 : '2 + 2') 0` runs it)
- Ruby: `eval "2 + 2"`
- Perl: `eval "2 + 2"`
- Bash: `a="ls | wc -l"`, `eval $a`
- PHP: `eval("2 + 2")`
- Lisp, obviously: `(setq test'(+ 2 2))` and `(eval test)`
- Python: `eval('2 + 2')`
- ColdFusion: `<cfset x = "int(2+2)">` and `<cfset y = Evaluate(x)>`
- FORTH: `S" 2 2 + ." eval` (note: it depends on the implementation; most use either `EVALUATE` or `eval`)
- VBScript, VBA: `Execute('2 + 2')` (note: for VBA as far as I recall, it's `eval`)
- Smalltalk: `Compiler evaluate:'2 + 2'`
- APL: The `⍎` primitive executes a character vector that contains a valid APL expression: `⍎ '2×3'` or `⍎ 'S←A String'`. The former will execute the mathematical expression and return `6`; the latter will create a variable `S` in the APL workspace, and assign it the value A String
- PowerShell: `invoke-expression '2 + 2'`
- R: `eval(parse(text = "2 + 2"))`
- Io: `doString("2 + 2")`
- Burlesque: `"2 2.+"pe`

Other languages:

- Java: see `ScriptEngine` functionality.
- C, C++: they can execute shellcode
- D: via `mixin`s, `int a = 0;` and then `mixin("a = 2 + 2;");` (note: the string must be constant and known at the compile time)

Comment: APL, using the `⍎` primitive - if `S` is a character vector containing a valid APL expression, `⍎S` will execute it.

Comment: R: eval(parse(text = "2 + 2"))
There is a reason it's not great for golfing

Comment: @AshleyBaldry well, it's not _too_ bad; that can be golfed to `eval(parse(t="2 + 2"))`

Comment: `"2 2+".V` (regular eval) or `"2+2".E` (python-eval) could be added for 05AB1E and `“2 2+”V` or `“2+2”V` for Jelly (`V` uses either regular or Python eval automatically). Maybe this would be better suited as a cw answer so everyone could add to it (and you could maybe also add TIOs to verify each eval). But +1 for listing all of these yourself already. :)

Comment: Bytecode could technically work too. You can dynamically load more bytecode while running.

Comment: C certainly have the ability to run code without executing shell code -- a myriad of security holes are based on buffer overflows forcing the executable to run injected code. Nothing stops the programmer to do the same. 

Comment: Any language which is self modifying can 'run code at runtime'. Interpreters usually can do this easily, examples being many assemblers, Befunge and other fungoids, but also many shells. And don't forget [The Story of Mel](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/net.jokes/k2JVKQzJSpY) for a brilliant use of self modifying code.

Comment: [T-SQL has EXEC](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1550/html/commands/X30305.htm).

Comment: `SNOBOL4` has `EVAL(s)`.

Comment: feel free to add them yourselves if you find something, it gets some rep points

Comment: `BASIC` has `DEF FN F(X)=X+X`

Comment: Wait, is C golfing by including parts written in raw shellcode a reasonable strategy?

Comment: maybe; would need to investigate that - code can contain unprintable characters, or you may construct unprintable shellcode

Comment: But then jumping into that shellcode might be a problem due to type issues (unless [it is the entry point](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201711/78410))...

Comment: JavaScript: `eval(str)`

Comment: ^- it's already there.

Comment: @Bubbler gcc lets you use [goto](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7M6Pb8kX0tNKaYiNSmmIi1Vybr2//9/yWk5ienF/3WrUitSk4tLEpOzAQ "C (gcc) – Try It Online")