# 99 ways to say "I love you"

Tags: code-golf, metagolf, pristine-programming

Inspired by this [blog post](http://matt.might.net/articles/i-love-you-in-racket/).

Write a program that outputs 99 distinct programs (in the same language) that output the string `I love you`.

How the programs are separated from one another in the output will be defined by you. However, Each byte of output can only belong to at most 1 of the 99 programs.

**Constraints for Output Programs**

1. If **any string** of characters is removed, then the program must not output `I love you`.
   e.g. `console.log('I love you');;;` is invalid because `;;;` can be removed
2. If **any two strings** of characters are both removed, then the program must not output `I love you`. This is to prevent inconsequential application of pairs of characters, that pass rule 1 because removing any *single* string will break the program.
   e.g. `print((('I love you')))` is invalid, because `((` and `))` can be removed

**There will be two categories of scoring to participate in.**

1. Standard code golf—smallest source code wins
2. Combined code golf—smallest source code + output wins

### Leaderboard

Here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

```js
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_ID = 198052; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like https://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";
var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";
var OVERRIDE_USER = 48934; // This should be the user ID of the challenge author.

/* App */

var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

function commentUrl(index, answers) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER;
}

function getAnswers() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(answer_page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      answers_hash = [];
      answer_ids = [];
      data.items.forEach(function(a) {
        a.comments = [];
        var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/);
        answer_ids.push(id);
        answers_hash[id] = a;
      });
      if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false;
      comment_page = 1;
      getComments();
    }
  });
}

function getComments() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      data.items.forEach(function(c) {
        if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER)
          answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c);
      });
      if (data.has_more) getComments();
      else if (more_answers) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });  
}

getAnswers();

var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/;

var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i;

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function process() {
  var valid = [];
  
  answers.forEach(function(a) {
    var body = a.body;
    a.comments.forEach(function(c) {
      if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body))
        body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>';
    });
    
    var match = body.match(SCORE_REG);
    if (match)
      valid.push({
        user: getAuthorName(a),
        size: +match[2],
        language: match[1],
        link: a.share_link,
      });
    
  });
  
  valid.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aB = a.size,
        bB = b.size;
    return aB - bB
  });

  var languages = {};
  var place = 1;
  var lastSize = null;
  var lastPlace = 1;
  valid.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.size != lastSize)
      lastPlace = place;
    lastSize = a.size;
    ++place;
    
    var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html();
    answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".")
                   .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user)
                   .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language)
                   .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size)
                   .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link);
    answer = jQuery(answer);
    jQuery("#answers").append(answer);

    var lang = a.language;
    if (/<a/.test(lang)) lang = jQuery(lang).text();
    
    languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link};
  });

  var langs = [];
  for (var lang in languages)
    if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang))
      langs.push(languages[lang]);

  langs.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.lang > b.lang) return 1;
    if (a.lang < b.lang) return -1;
    return 0;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i)
  {
    var language = jQuery("#language-template").html();
    var lang = langs[i];
    language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang)
                       .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user)
                       .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size)
                       .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link);
    language = jQuery(language);
    jQuery("#languages").append(language);
  }

}
```

```css
body { text-align: left !important}

#answer-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#language-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b">
<div id="answer-list">
  <h2>Leaderboard</h2>
  <table class="answer-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="answers">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="language-list">
  <h2>Winners by Language</h2>
  <table class="language-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="languages">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="answer-template">
    <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="language-template">
    <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Does the code have to be pristine (there is no way to produce the same result by removing any number of characters) or just following the constraints you mentioned? e.g. from Benji's program: would `print(chr(207%134)) ...` be allowed even if taking out `20`, `%1`, and `4` would result in `print(chr(73)) ...` which yields the same result?

Comment: Can we use functions instead of programs?

Comment: _There must not exist a string of characters that, when removed, does not lead to_ Could that be rephrased to remove the two negations? I find it very confusing

Comment: @Zimonze just the rules above. In your example, it takes the removal of 3 strings of characters to be reduced, so it's still valid.

Comment: @LuisMendo I wrestled with the wording for this a decent amount, it seems to really want to be a double negative and that was the best wording I came up with. I'm open to suggestions (from anyone).

Comment: These double negatives are killing my chance at understanding this question. Could this be reworded without the double negatives?

Comment: Perhaps try: "Your solution must *fail* to output `I love you` if you remove any one or two strings of characters. Removal of 3 or more strings of characters is not required to fail.". Then just copy the two examples.

Comment: Isn't this a [tag:metagolf] challenge?

Comment: I don't understand the rule `However, Each byte of output can only belong to at most 1 of the 99 programs.`. Can you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork, I guess Mason tried to disallow solutions where there is 1 function declaration + 99 function calls. With the rule you quoted that would be counted 99 function declarations + 99 function calls, cutting the benefit of using such cheatish combination.

Comment: "_How the programs are separated from one another in the output will be defined by you._" Can be we have no separator? The output still contains all programs.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen That seems to be how most answers are doing it, so it must be allowed

Comment: @KevinCruijssen you can do whatever you want as long as you can show where each program starts and ends

Comment: So each output program must consist of only 2.55 distinct bytes, on average? That's less than are in the "I love you" string itself.

Comment: @user253751 If you look at the answers that's clearly not the case. Where are you getting that number from?

Comment: @Mason I bet that number comes from a misreading of _“Each byte of output can only belong to at most 1 of the 99 programs”_, and frankly I also have no idea what that rule means. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @Lynn It seems to mean that when the output is split up into programs no byte of output can be given to two programs, e.g. abcc cannot have both the programs abc and cc since the third byte belongs to two programs.  It can much more clearly be said as programs do not overlap.

Answer (score 19):

## [JavaScript (JavaScript shell)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Introduction_to_the_JavaScript_shell), 65 bytes

total: (64 + 3366 = 3450) bytes

```javascript
for(i=99;i++<198;)print(`\\u0${i}="I love you";print(\\u{${i}})`)
```

```javascript
\u0100="I love you";print(\u{100})
\u0101="I love you";print(\u{101})
\u0102="I love you";print(\u{102})
\u0103="I love you";print(\u{103})
\u0104="I love you";print(\u{104})
\u0105="I love you";print(\u{105})
```

It is trivial.

JavaScript allow escape sequence in variable name. [`console.lo\u0067('Hello world')`](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/OT@vOD8nVS8nP6bUwMDMXEPdIzUnJ1@hPL8oJ0Vd8/9/AA) is prefect valid. I don't think this feature is useful anyway. But...

No TIO link, since the TIO version is out-of-date. You may download JavaScript Shell from https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/72.0.1/jsshell/ .

---

## [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/45), 76 bytes

total: (76 + 2475 = 2551) bytes

```javascript
for(i=99;i++<198;print(v+'="I love you";print('+v+')'))v=eval('"\\u0'+i+'"')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY8xT8QwDIX3@xVWFycKVMdGVcLCdCuI7YYLrdsLtHGUpEUV4reXUMpiyX5P33t@N7OJTbA@3UZvWwojuw9aVh@4D2YEDS8pWNeXwXxe1o6DsLqqaqvUw111X/usJTEr1MUJBp4JFp6K/YwqCxKlnDXNZhBYnM/TEZVVWKBcL2Umj0LWh03dE/M6cms7S20O349lID@YhgRuZLzBDrNxIJc9x0OXZwT9CF@woaKs4VdTGiZHsTGeBLmGW3p9Pj3x6NlR7helLLOtT9cavv9K/EdneMMu8kDlwL3YYIDwtiSKwFPyU8of/AA)

Output:

```javascript
Ā="I love you";print(Ā)
ā="I love you";print(ā)
Ă="I love you";print(Ă)
ă="I love you";print(ă)
Ą="I love you";print(Ą)
ą="I love you";print(ą)
```

This one is shorter when counting total length. And it is much more trivial.

---

## [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/45), 85 bytes

total: (86 + 36927 = 37013) bytes

```javascript
for(n=99,p="(L='I love you')=>",q="print(L)";n--;p+='x=>')p='('+p,q+=')()',print(p+q)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY@9bsMwDIT3PAXhRWL8k2YMDGXpFCBTi25dXJt2lcqiYslBjSLP7qpxinYhyOPxw/FUXSpfD9qF3Dvd0NCz/aBpdgN3Q9WDAtmOtg6aLUiEL9is55YHadVulzmVyKMSBzB8IZh4FKj2SXZWiRu0DfKISWnzvHSpEp9qL9ApIUXqsnMUUKLIFp9LzzivN3DFIvBziFonsfDO6CDFqxWxN7omuc0g32JxYm3vevT2EsvVnbOEjjNdKvNv7LnRraYmvnMXi4GcqSJT/EUQmWiXJp4YstH9sGpj9aD28fUb1GMJP7tUwWjJ15UjSbbmhl6eDo/cO7YUeR6xiLYuvJdwXeL8hojwmq1nQ4XhTt5gIOBtCuSBx@DGIHD@Bg)

Output:

```javascript
((L='I love you')=>print(L))()
(((L='I love you')=>x=>print(L))())()
((((L='I love you')=>x=>x=>print(L))())())()
(((((L='I love you')=>x=>x=>x=>print(L))())())())()
((((((L='I love you')=>x=>x=>x=>x=>print(L))())())())())()
```

This is my original solution.

Comment: TIL SpiderMonkey has a `print` function

Comment: What's wrong with [this 56 byter](https://tio.run/##TY/BboMwEETv@YpVVMl2SEhyjCi99JRrq94qNRQW6tR4LdsgoYhvp1tIpV4s78z47fha9EUovXZxF5yu0Ldkv3GYnKfGFy3kIOvOllGTBangBvvNVJOXOj9kOkkeT6dMOa9tlJePh5se8/UZDPUIA3XrbHFmQ13UtNnDqNJIr5H1Rqo0OKOjFO9W8N3oEuVxC7ujSq@k7V3nbCtVtlpY9148Y1@Yf2NLla41Vtz4LqYenSmYKeanYitqwUGDljOHVc1ngPyJ/zSjgsrg10ty6CyGsnAo0ZZU4dvL@ZlaRxa5QFAq5VgTvzIYlxJ/qxlekg1kMDXUyBkGAj6HiAGoi66LQk0/ "JavaScript (SpiderMonkey) – Try It Online")

Comment: Note that your 86 bytes solution produces 100 programs, you can cut 1 byte using `99` (and that would remove this horrific longest last line)

Comment: @ExpiredData `_XY="I love you";print(_XY)` can be reduced to `_X="I love you";print(_X)`.

Comment: Ah I see thanks @arnauld

Comment: What I meant is that the output programs are not pristine because the ``\`` can be removed (e.g. `u0100="I love you";print(u0100)`).

Comment: @Arnauld Ah, nice catch. Fixed by +1 byte (and switching to newer version.

Answer (score 10):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 718 bytes, score: 34180 (33462+718)

```
[S S S T    N
_Push_1][S S S N
_Push_n=0][T    T   S _Store_1:n][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S S S T N
_Push_1][S N
S _Dupe_1][T    T   T   _Retrieve_1:n][T    S S S _Add][S N
S _Dupe_n+1][S S S T    T   S S T   S S N
_Push_100][T    S S T   _Subtract][N
T   S T T   N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_EXIT_WITH_PRINT][S S S T    N
_Push_1][S N
T   _Swap][T    T   S _Store_1:n+1][S S S T N
_Push_1_newline][S N
S _Dupe_1_newline][S S S T  S T T   T   N
_Push_23_space][S S S T N
_Push_1_newline][S T    S S T   N
_Copy_0-based_1st_23_space][S N
S _Dupe_23_space][S S S T   N
_Push_1_newline][S S S N
_Push_0_tab][S T    S S T   S N
_Copy_0-based_2nd_23_space][S N
S _Dupe_23_space][S N
S _Dupe_23_space][S S S N
_Push_0_tab][S T    S S T   N
_Copy_0-based_1st_23_space][S N
S _Dupe_23_space][S N
S _Dupe_23_space][S S S N
_Push_0_tab][N
S T N
_Call_Subroutine_PUSH_INTEGER][S S S N
_Push_0_tab][S N
S _Dupe_0_tab][S N
S _Dupe_0_tab][N
S T N
_Call_Subroutine_PUSH_INTEGER][S S S T  N
_Push_1_newline][S S S T    S T T   T   N
_Push_23_space][S N
S _Dupe_23_space][S S S T   N
_Push_1_newline][S N
S _Dupe_1_newline][S T  S S T   S N
_Copy_0-based_2nd_23_space][S S S N
_Push_0_tab][S N
S _Dupe_0_tab][S T  S S T   S N
_Copy_0-based_2nd_23_space][S N
S _Dupe_23_space][S S S N
_Push_0_tab][S N
S _Dupe_0_tab][S T  S S T   S N
_Copy_0-based_2nd_23_space][S N
S _Dupe_23_space][S S S T   N
_Push_1_newline][S T    S S T   N
_Copy_0-based_1st_23_space][S N
S _Dupe_23_space][S S S N
_Push_0_tab][S T    S S T   N
_Copy_0-based_1st_23_space][S N
S _Dupe_23_space][S S S N
_Push_0_tab][S T    S S T   N
_Copy_0-based_1st_23_space][S S S T N
_Push_1_newline][S S S N
_Push_0_tab][S N
S _Dupe_0_tab][S N
S _Dupe_0_tab][S T  S S T   S S N
_Copy_0-based_4th_23_space][S N
S _Dupe_23_space][S S S T   N
_Push_1_newline][S T    S S T   N
_Copy_0-based_1st_23_space][S N
S _Dupe_23_space][S N
S _Dupe_23_space][S S S T   N
_Push_1_newline][S S S N
_Push_0_tab][S N
S _Dupe_0_tab][S N
S _Dupe_0_tab][S T  S S T   S S N
_Copy_0-based_4th_23_space][S N
S _Dupe_23_space][S N
S _Dupe_23_space][S S S T   N
_Push_1_newline][S T    S S T   N
_Copy_0-based_1st_23_space][S S S N
_Push_0_tab][S T    S S T   N
_Copy_0-based_1st_23_space][S S S N
_Push_0_tab][S N
S _Dupe_0_tab][S T  S S T   S N
_Copy_0-based_2nd_23_space][S N
S _Dupe_23_space][S S S T   N
_Push_1_newline][S S S N
_Push_0_tab][S N
S _Dupe_0_tab][S N
S _Dupe_0_tab][S N
S _Dupe_0_tab][S T  S S T   S T N
_Copy_0-based_5th_23_space][S N
S _Dupe_23_space][S S S N
_Push_0_tab][S N
S _Dupe_0_tab][S T  S S T   S N
_Copy_0-based_2nd_23_space][S N
S _Dupe_23_space][S S S T   N
_Push_1_newline][S T    S S T   N
_Copy_0-based_1st_23_space][S S S N
_Push_0_tab][S T    S S T   N
_Copy_0-based_1st_23_space][S S S N
_Push_0_tab][S T    S S T   N
_Copy_0-based_1st_23_space][S N
S _Dupe_23_space][S N
S _Dupe_23_space][S S S T   N
_Push_1_newline][S T    S S T   N
_Copy_0-based_1st_23_space][S N
S _Dupe_23_space][S N
S _Dupe_23_space][S S S T   N
_Push_1_newline][S T    S S T   N
_Copy_0-based_1st_23_space][S S S N
_Push_0_tab][S N
S _Dupe_0_tab][S T  S S T   S N
_Copy_0-based_2nd_23_space][S N
S _Dupe_23_space][S N
S _Dupe_23_space][S N
S _Dupe_23_space][S S S N
_Push_0_tab][S N
S _Dupe_0_tab][S N
S _Dupe_0_tab][S T  S S T   T   N
_Copy_0-based_3rd_23_space][S N
S _Dupe_23_space][S S S N
_Push_0_tab][N
S T N
_Call_Subroutine_PUSH_INTEGER][S S S T  N
_Push_1_newline][S S S N
_Push_0_tab][S N
S _Dupe_0_tab][S N
S _Dupe_0_tab][S N
S _Dupe_0_tab][S S S T  S T T   T   N
_Push_23_space][S S S N
_Push_0_tab][S N
S _Dupe_0_tab][S T  S S T   S N
_Copy_0-based_2nd_23_space][S N
S _Dupe_23_space][S N
S _Dupe_23_space][N
S T N
_Call_Subroutine_PUSH_INTEGER][N
S N
S N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][N
S S T   T   N
_Create_Label_EXIT_WITH_PRINT][S N
N
_Discard_n][N
S S T   N
_Create_Label_PRINT_LOOP][S S S T   S S T   N
_Push_9][T  S S S _Add][T   N
S S _Print_as_character][N
S N
T   N
_Jump_to_Label_PRINT_LOOP][N
S S N
_Create_Subroutine_PUSH_INTEGER][S S S T    N
_Push_1_newline][S S S N
_Push_0][S S S T    N
_Push_1][T  T   T   _Retrieve_1:n][T    T   S _Store_0:m][N
S S S S N
_Create_Label_TAB_LOOP][S S S N
_Push_0_tab][S N
S _Dupe_0][S N
S _Dupe_0][T    T   T   _Retrieve_0:m][S S S T  N
_Push_1][T  S S T   _Subtract][S N
S _Dupe_m-1][N
T   S S T   N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_DONE_WITH_TAB_LOOP][T   T   S _Store_0:m-1][N
S N
S S N
_Jump_to_Label_TAB_LOOP][N
S S S T N
_Create_Label_DONE_WITH_TAB_LOOP][S S S T   S T T   T   N
_Push_23_space][S N
S _Dupe_23_space][S N
S _Dupe_23_space][N
T   N
_Return_from_Subroutine_PUSH_INTEGER]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##hZJLDsMgDETXnlP4alUVqdlVSqQen@IfBuGqWQA242cI83md93G9H8@jNWYm9AFErLMlwNQ/9gTLkkQkm9TDkLlIK2SWMt@jKW1khWgKPBJTjBDChiANLrKXs1yd5CKxnqUMeOnMftu9fL7NJl3VM7w6UhbFHv29wMrcTvUjsRHzAbL7aI7if6xvu9GkREbAQbqwd1O/WCR2AYbFYkHqNITXnGnG0mLtY6RoWRhD6a19AQ) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

The output Whitespace programs are output without delimiter. Each program will be as follows, where the `x` is variable in the range `[3,102]`.

```
[S S S (x_amount_of_T   )N
_Push_n][S S S T    T   S T T   T   T   N
_Push_constant_111][S S S (x_amount_of_T    )N
_Push_n][T  S S T   ][T T   S _store][S S S T   T   S N
_Push_6_u][S S S N
_Push_0_o][S S S T  S T S N
_Push_10_y][S S T   T   S S T   T   T   T   N
_Push_-79_space][S S T  T   S T S N
_Push_-10_e][S S S T    T   T   N
_Push_7_v][S S S N
_Push_0_o][S S T    T   T   N
_Push_-3_l][S T S S T   S S N
_Copy_0-based_4th_-79_space][S S T  T   S S T   T   S N
_Push_-38_I][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S S S (x_amount_of_T    )N
_Push_n][T  T   T   _Retrieve][S S S (x_amount_of_T )N
_Push_n][T  S S S _Add][T   S S S _Add][T   N
S S _Print_as_character][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP]
```

In the 1st program, `x` will be 3, so the four `Push n` parts will push the integer `7` (binary `111`; three 1-bits); in the 15th program, `x` will be 18, so the four `Push n` parts will push the integer `262143` (binary `111111111111111111`; eighteen 1-bits); etc. up to `5070602400912917605986812821503` (binary with 102 1-bits).

[Try it online for the 15th program](https://tio.run/##dY5BCoAwDATP2VfM10QKehMUfH7ETaGH0kBg2UyyeY/zafe17S0TiLlkmyFnImxT4A8ZxDpqGCVr3E@pq59gsEiwjHLO4gnc3pYyPw) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

I've used [this Whitespace tip of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158232/52210) to print the output `I love you`. The optimal constant `111` is generated by [this Java program](https://tio.run/##fZJLa@MwEMfv/RTDnCSUmhS2h9oRpYU9GJoe6uwDSllkV03UdWSvNA6EJZ/dK9d2HtvSi4TmP/PTvF7VRp2/Pv9u26JU3sNcGfv3DKBu8tIU4ElRuDaVeYZ1kFhGztjl4xMo3rkB9AZw2jclgQT1OH1K3hRjCfxalaX2nZBa0kvtovnNz1/fb@6@fZ1AKq@SY8jo/TDCEHv9pXKswxmZJmZ2cTlNjBBDAocUJOKEJrUco/q4fEsa8rhPMFpqug0Gz/g@HIBkgC@qHysTlFoV@tZY5bY9l@Xnhid7XycZRfpPo0rPan6N2X2GMXHhDi61pPGxG27zwlxUarukFeMw21d6lMS74o@IR208YA5yGuzm9Mv@zLae9DqqGorqUAuVlmEfLlGMUIFJaCyKVCDEgOKzXqR8@PZ/MjtN/81rdxaOYYOGGX3G7gZsh4ZslAtTwSxDwayU02vE2M7CtcAYM@Sna1HE43JRdYLsVD5XtIpU7pnl/KP5k5DF7MtVGGVgL4bd6fvnNDXOBg@8x76iXdu2KZTVRsO2av4B). In addition, I use one copy for the space to save bytes.

I've also used this same tip with a constant `9` in the generator program to output the Whitespace sub-programs. After that I've used loads of duplicates, as well as copies for the spaces where possible.

#### Explanation in pseudo-code:

**Generator program:**

```
Store n=0 at heap-address 1
Start LOOP:
  Retrieve n from heap-address 1
  n = n + 1
  If(n == 100):
    Call function EXIT_WITH_PRINT
  Store the updated n+1 at heap-address 1
  Push the codepoints of "NNSNSSNTSSSTSSST" minus 9 for the output program
  Call subroutine PUSH_INTEGER
  Push the codepoints of "TTT" minus 9 for the output program
  Call subroutine PUSH_INTEGER
  Push the codepoints of "NSSNNSTTSSTTSSNSSTSSTSNTTTSSNSSSNTTTSSSNSTSTTSSNTTTTSSTTSSNSTSTSSSNSSSNSTTSSSSTTTSST" minus 9 for the output program
  Call subroutine PUSH_INTEGER
  Push the codepoints of "NTTTTSTTSSS" minus 9 for the output program
  Call subroutine PUSH_INTEGER
  Go to the next iteration of LOOP

Function EXIT_WITH_PRINT:
  Discard n that was still on the top of the stack
  Start PRINT_LOOP:
    Add 9 to the value at the top of the stack
    Pop and print it as character
    (this will fail with an error since there is nothing more to pop, when we're done with
     the final character to stop the program)
    Go to the next iteration of PRINT_LOOP

Subroutine PUSH_INTEGER:
  Push the codepoint of "N" minus 9 for the output program
  Retrieve n from heap-address 1
  Integer m = n
  Store m at heap-address 0
  Start TAB_LOOP:
    Push the codepoint of "T" minus 9 for the output program
    Retrieve m from heap-address 0
    m = m - 1
    If(m == 0):
      Call function DONE_WITH_TAB_LOOP
    Store m-1 at heap-address 0
    Go to next iteration of TAB_LOOP

  Function DONE_WITH_TAB_LOOP:
    Push the codepoints of "SSS" minus 9 for the output program
    Return to the caller of the PUSH_INTEGER subroutine, and continue from there
```

**Sub-program:**

Variable as explained before is integer `n` (which has `x` amount of binary 1-bits).

```
Integer t = 111 - n
Store t at heap-address n
Push the codepoints of "uoy evol I" minus 111
Start LOOP:
  Retrieve t from heap-address n
  t = t + n
  Add t (which is 111 again) to the value at the top of the stack
    Pop and print it as character
    (this will fail with an error since there is nothing more to pop, when we're done with
     the final character to stop the program)
    Go to the next iteration of LOOP
```

Since we use the variable `n` four times (`t = 111-n`; `store t at heap-address n`; `retrieve t from heap-address n`; `t = t+n`) with other pieces of relevant code in between the pushes, we need to remove four string-sequences in order to still have a valid `I love you` output, complying to the rule stating you can't remove one or two string-sequences.

Answer (score 7):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 81 bytes

#### Output: 4275 bytes

```javascript
for(n=100;--n;)console.log(`console.log('I lo'+Buffer([${n}^${118^n}])+'e you')`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/Lb9II8/W0MDAWlc3z1ozOT@vOD8nVS8nP10jAZmj7qmQk6@u7VSalpZapBGtUp1XG6dSbWhoEZdXG6uprZ6qUJlfqq6ZoPn/PwA)

Answer (score 6):

### Batch, 131 + 3564 bytes

```
@for %%a in (a b c d e f g h i j k)do @for %%b in (. / \ "," ";" [ ] + "=")do @echo @for %%%%%%a in (love)do @echo%%~bI %%%%%%a you
```

This produces 99 variants of the same code:

```
@for %%k in (love)do @echo=I %%k you
```

The `for` variable (here `k`) loops over the 11 values `a` to `k`, while the other character that changes is the separator after `echo`, which can usually (as here) be any of 11 characters, but five of them need quoting to use in a `for` command, so I've omitted space and `(`. The programs are all irreducible because they need to get the word `love` to appear in the output.

Comment: ? `@for /L %k in (1 1 99) do @echo @set a%k=I love you^&^&echo %a%k%`

Comment: @mazzy That doesn't produce irreducible programs.

Comment: @mazzy Additionally, the programs don't even work since variable expansion happens at parse time by default.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 86 bytes

86 code + 10289 output = 10375 total

```python
x=0
while x<99:print(f"print(chr(len('{(bin(x)[2:8]).zfill(73)}'))+' love you')");x+=1
```

sample segment of output:

`print(chr(len('0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000110000'))+' Love you')`

Comment: @Arnauld It does... I'll see if I can fix that

Comment: You might want to look carefully at the first line of your sample segment of output... There are two strings which can be removed to leave `73` in the `char()`.

Comment: There is also `100-90` which can be simply `10`.

Comment: I think I have finally made it so that if any character(s) are removed, it will break.(I'm new to code-golf, so thanks for the help)

Comment: This currently outputs only 98 programs. [Suggested 77-byte version](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8LWgKs8IzMnVaHCxtLSqqAoM69EI00JQidnFGnkpOZpqFdrZKRWaFRoG5ppataqa2qbWWpqqyv45JelKlTml6prKmlaV2jbGv7/DwA), with a shorter output.

Comment: This solution is expandable all the way until needing to output 9444732965739290427392 different programs. Awesome!

Comment: @Arnauld you can save byte in your shortened solution by using `x=16` and `x<115` which is addition of 2 characters. But you get to remove `+16` so you net save 1 character

Comment: @Arnauld Another 2 bytes savings by removing the parens around hex(x)

Comment: `{(bin(x)[2:8]).zfill(73)}` -> `{bin(x)[2:].zfill(73)}` save 3 bytes

Comment: `Love` should not be capitalised

Answer (score 5):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <sup><s>87</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>160</s></sup> 120 bytes

#### Output: 3822 bytes (Total: 3942 bytes)

```c
i;main(j){for(;i<99;printf("main(){printf(\"%%c Love You\",%d^%d);}\n",j,j^73))j=3+i++*4,j=strchr("$,2MOPW]_",i)?6*j:j;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///P9M6NzEzTyNLszotv0jDOtPG0tK6oCgzryRNQwkso1kN5cYoqaomK/jkl6UqROaXxijpqKbEqaZoWtfG5CnpZOlkxZkba2pm2RprZ2pra5noZNkWlxQlZxRpKKnoGPn6B4THxivpZGram2llWWVZ1/7/DwA)

Fixed pristine-errors kindly pointed out by [Expired Data](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85908/expired-data).
Fixed pristine-errors kindly pointed out by [Kaddath](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90841/kaddath).
Saved 50 bytes thanks to [gastropner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75886/gastropner)!!!

Prints 99 unique lines like:

```c
main(){printf("%c Love You",3^74);}
```

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 96 bytes

## Output: 2516 bytes (total 2612)

```php
<?php for(;($i+=2)<773;)if($i<99||--$i%100>67&&$i>299)echo"I<?=chr(".(33+$i++)."-$i)?>love you";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdbNbhpBEATge55ihBwL7LS9szPdPRMwnHPKC/ji4MWsRFjETxJLfndSSHGUSHXwwV1rVD3fsuvdenc@zxa79S6shv14Or7qbx/aycw9TSf9Cr/Oan17E7nqP8ammZtfX1/187bWSbdcD6Mvs8XDcr0fj@7GKd3ij28ndyNcPFnMN8OPLrwOp9H0fLk0jB63j9uvp@PudAy7/fCyf/p@CN2vbnk6ds@fR9Nwf7PcDId@@xKOTy9h2y27w@Fp/xqOQzish59/ru2HbRhWYd8dTpvjp/ANn7Yd8NN1z91z6Lfvnx3646HbrG7uw2L@4cN7z6SS/un2d1zEyDhHqWycJbZs7hKVzLWRWNg8SRvZ3KTNbF6ldTK3VlLD5liWbWtFElvXoyS2r2fJbF93yWzf0khm@5YkyvYtJsr2LVWU7VtbMbZvVTG2b4Uu2zc2UazSIIu3NHBxtnKMjXihQZISaWBSMg2qFLZ2bFupDQ1UaqJBkUo3T7iz6a2NI0nGkyTJI01wn3miiSNRmlQkTr9zaOC0AY4y0bPMEQ0KbRDRoNAGOOZEzzm3aFBogxYNKm0AgkQNcosGlTZo0aDSBunyTaz0URIlG0@SZOqj8MnUR@GTnT@yKhLWTeGTqY/CJ1MfhU@mPgqfTH0UPpn6KHwy9VH4ZOqj8MnUR@GTqY/CJ1MfhU@mPgYfNZ7g6Ud9DD5KfQw@Sn2suTwb6csAPkp9DD5KfQw@Sn0MPkp9DD5a@OsIDaiPwUepj8FHqY/BR6mPwUepj8FHqY9fHvnGkyRGfRw@Rn0cPkZ9HD5GfRw@Rn0cPkZ9HD5GfRw@Rn0cPkZ9HD5GfRw@Rn0cPkZ9HD5GfRw@Rn08XV68lf7rEMWNJ0n8P5/zbw)

Example program:

```php
I<?=chr(35-3)?>love you
```

Still quite new at code golf, hope I get this right. Wanted to encode the space as 32 is the lowest number and wanted to do something else than port an existing answer. Got me into troubles with the 2 strings removing part, but I think this time it passes

(Edit: one line was missing, programs count was 98)
(Edit2: separator is now `:`, as `-` was in the code, and total count was wrong)

**Edit3: This time I think it's OK** (got much more complicated than planned):

- I had to remove all the intervals of the form `x99-x67` that can be reduced by removing the `x`'s
- Had also to remove all the interval of the form `3xx-2xx` that can be reduced by removing the `xx-` and `xx`
- Tried to keep only `--$i%100>67&&$i>299` as a condition but unfortunately it goes to `1003-971` and a bit beyond that all can be reduced to the form `103-71`
- new code is manupulating `$i` with -- and ++ to avoid to add prenthesis and do `($i-1)%100>67` in test and `"-".($i-1).")` in display
- no separator anymore, as per a question's comment
- removed the space after `echo` (thanks to @Ismael Miguel answer)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 23 bytes (combined score 1688 bytes)

```
тGN"•«À¢ÒÙΓʒγ•"тN-…O₃BJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9vc2FiaWX//9GCR04i4oCiwqvDgMKiw5LDmc6TypLOs@KAoiLRgk4t4oCmT@KCg0JK//8) or [try one of the output programs](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f0vJRw6JDqw83HFp0eNLhmecmn5p0bjNQyND/UVOz0///AA).

```
тG                       # for N from 1 to 99:
  N                      #  N
   "•«À¢ÒÙΓʒγ•"          #  string "•«À¢ÒÙΓʒγ•"
               тN-       #  100 - N
                  …O₃B   #  "O₃B"
                      J  #  join the entire stack
```

Each subprogram looks like:

```
1                       # 1 (N)
 •«À¢ÒÙΓʒγ•             # compressed integer 11971423964735158206
           99           # 99 (100 - N)
             O          # sum the entire stack
              ₃B        # convert to base 95
```

Comment: @downvoter care to explain what's wrong with this answer?

Answer (score 3):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 33 bytes

Programs separated by `:`

Output is 1385 bytes

```python
в&(c|&:&I+,&:&,`- love you:`,⑹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N////wiY1jeQaNSs1T20dIKmToKuQk1@WqlCZX2qVoPNo4s7//wE)

Programs:

```
ѻв- love you:Ѽг- love you:ѽд- love you:Ѿе- love you:ѿж- love you:Ҁз- love you:ҁи- love you:҂й- love you:҃к- love you:҄л- love you:҅м- love you:҆н- love you:҇о- love you:҈п- love you:҉р- love you:Ҋс- love you:ҋт- love you:Ҍу- love you:ҍф- love you:Ҏх- love you:ҏц- love you:Ґч- love you:ґш- love you:Ғщ- love you:ғъ- love you:Ҕы- love you:ҕь- love you:Җэ- love you:җю- love you:Ҙя- love you:ҙѐ- love you:Қё- love you:қђ- love you:Ҝѓ- love you:ҝє- love you:Ҟѕ- love you:ҟі- love you:Ҡї- love you:ҡј- love you:Ңљ- love you:ңњ- love you:Ҥћ- love you:ҥќ- love you:Ҧѝ- love you:ҧў- love you:Ҩџ- love you:ҩѠ- love you:Ҫѡ- love you:ҫѢ- love you:Ҭѣ- love you:ҭѤ- love you:Үѥ- love you:үѦ- love you:Ұѧ- love you:ұѨ- love you:Ҳѩ- love you:ҳѪ- love you:Ҵѫ- love you:ҵѬ- love you:Ҷѭ- love you:ҷѮ- love you:Ҹѯ- love you:ҹѰ- love you:Һѱ- love you:һѲ- love you:Ҽѳ- love you:ҽѴ- love you:Ҿѵ- love you:ҿѶ- love you:Ӏѷ- love you:ӁѸ- love you:ӂѹ- love you:ӃѺ- love you:ӄѻ- love you:ӅѼ- love you:ӆѽ- love you:ӇѾ- love you:ӈѿ- love you:ӉҀ- love you:ӊҁ- love you:Ӌ҂- love you:ӌ҃- love you:Ӎ҄- love you:ӎ҅- love you:ӏ҆- love you:Ӑ҇- love you:ӑ҈- love you:Ӓ҉- love you:ӓҊ- love you:Ӕҋ- love you:ӕҌ- love you:Ӗҍ- love you:ӗҎ- love you:Әҏ- love you:әҐ- love you:Ӛґ- love you:ӛҒ- love you:Ӝғ- love you:ӝҔ- love you:
```

Comment: To my understanding, separator `:` isn't count into the byte count. So, output should be count as 1385 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>34</s> <s>31</s> <s>30</s> <s>28</s> 25 bytes

*Combined Score*: very very big `(25 + no. permutations of "I love you"*20)`

*-3 bytes thanks to @KevinCruijssen*

```
…I„Î€îœ¦v'"y'""œ{•B‹<•è"J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcMyz0cN8w73PWpac3jd0cmHlpWpK1WqKykdnVz9qGGR06OGnTZA@vAKJa///wE)

---

## Optimised for Combined Score

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>32</s> <s>30</s> 27 bytes

*Combined Score:* `27 + 1980 = 2007`

```
…I„Î€îœт£¦v'"y'""œ{•B‹<•è"J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATkAxv9vc2FiaWX//@KApknigJ7DjuKCrMOuxZPRgsKjwqZ2JyJ5JyIixZN74oCiQuKAuTzigKLDqCJK//8)

This may take a while to run...

---

#### Explanation

```
…I„Î€î                       # Compressed string "I love you" 
      œ                      # Get the permutations of this string 
       ¦                     # Remove the first one ("I love you")
        v                    # loop over these and do...
         '"y'"               # the string with the value in (e.g. "I love yuo"
              "œ{•B‹<•è"     # string literal with œ{•B‹<•è value
                        J    # join these and print e.g. "I love yuo"œ{•B‹<•è
```

#### Explanation of the output programs:

```
"I love yuo"                   # a string which is a permutation of "I love you"
            œ{                 # get the sorted permutations of this string 
              •B‹<•è           # get the value at index 750832 which is "I love you"
```

Comment: [One of the output](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fkMuAy1TT0ODcpsPLD2941DDnUcO8w32PmtYcXgfkeP3/DwA) can [be reduced](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f0MBU09Dg3KbDyw9veNQw51HDvMN9j5rWHF4H5Hj9/w8A).

Comment: Doesn't the second one produce much more than 99 programs?

Comment: I trust you, knowing nothing about 05AB1E, but I get a huge list and "The output exceeded 128 KiB and was truncated" with the TIO link

Comment: @Kaddath should be fixed now

Comment: still pretty much chinese to me :D (no offense to them) but yep, that works!

Comment: @kaddath added an explanation hope that is useful

Comment: `“€í„Î€î“` can be `…I„Î€î` (also fixes the lowercase `i` to uppercase `I` in the sentence)

Comment: ^ You may need to fix the index integer, since the sorted permutations might be in a different order due to the uppercase `I`.

Comment: Good point and thanks @KevinCruijssen

Comment: The first program is invalid, since 1) it outputs more than 99 programs 2) not all output programs are distinct as required. 1) can be fixed by doing `тLè` instead of `¦`, 2) can be solved by adding `Ù` after `œ`. [TIO](https://tio.run/##AToAxf9vc2FiaWX//@KApknigJ7DjuKCrMOuw5nFk9GCTMOodicieSciIsWTe@KAokLigLk84oCiw6giSv//) (note that it now loses to the second program in individual score, but beats it in combined score. also the indices are wrong now, my bad).

Comment: @Grimmy Well it does output 99 programs.. it just then goes on to output more, as far as I'm concerned that meets the challenge criteria... And yes second one I will fix.

Comment: @ExpiredData no it obviously doesn’t meet the spec. If that kind of thing was allowed, you could just enumerate all strings and argue that the answer is somewhere in there. (Also, regardless of spec-compliance, changing it to output only 99 programs gives a better combined score than your current “optimized for combined score” answer).

Comment: @Grimmy whatever there's a clear difference between your ridiculous example and this.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>200</s> <s>181</s> <s>172</s> 165 + <s>3992</s> <s>3828</s> 3540 bytes

```
m="I love you";q=?",?';%w[print $><< puts].map{|e|q.product(q){|c,d|8.times{|i|puts e+c+"#{m.chars.rotate(~i)*""}#{c}.chars.rotate(#{i+1})*#{d*2}"}};puts e+"'#{m}'"}
```

This combines different ways of printing (`print`, `$stdout <<`, `puts`), different ways of quoting the string (`''`, `""`), and different rotations of the string `"I love you"` to make `(((8 * 4) + 1) * 3) =` 99 irreducible programs.

### Golfy Tricks

- Uses `%w[]` as a whitespace-separated string array
- Use `*""` and `*''` instead of `.join`
- Use different combinations of quotation marks (`""`, `''`) instead of different combination of splitting a string (`chars`, `split(//)`), and just use the shorter (`chars`)
- Use `puts` instead of `$stdout<<` as the third way of printing (I didn't think it would be allowed because it also appends a newline where the others don't, but maybe this is fine?)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VczdCsIgGIDhW5HPYr8IdRRsa8ddQ3SwnJCQ0zkthn7duhV00vH78lh/XVNSHZzIXT8EWbWHZu56qPus2T7PxsrJkc2xbYnxbrkwNZgQRZyZsXr03OVzESKvx3hgTiqxhCjj9ySi4hXQoBi/DXZhVrvBifwlixIAaeD4H2iQ1Q6Lkoax3CMgNj8Fsg@CGWBKbw) for the initial generator code.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdbNSgNBEEXhfZ4iDEKpi4C/cRHc@xhRAgrBCZOZQJ5@pCrp6qah67j/Fs2hudQwfZ7n@TD8/I7d9LHc96fd8tx3q6/v7XBcDf24HXe3D3f3Xbe4oN5VhR4LdHZVoacCLV1V6LlAO1cVeinQyVWFXsuHu6rQukB7VxV6K1DUSeQfnRxFnRxFnRxFnRxFnfLDg06Ook4JSe4kzf8kuZM0/5PkTtL8T5I7SfM/Se4kzf8kuZM0/5PkTtL8T5I7SfM/hZ08ZtTJUdTJUdTJUdTJUdQpPzzo5Cjq5MgzTbK4ed9saLDMwF6ZgbkyA2tlBsbKDGzV5c3xVJmBpcI@ItwnGZgp7JMMjBT28TfHE4V9roYGygzskxmYJzOwTmZgnMzANl3eHE@TGVgm7JMawi5hn2RglbBPMrBJ2CcZWCQz5SAdpvGIF5QaOqDU0P2khs4nNXQ9qaHjyd4Mt5MaOp2ojwj3SYbuJuqTDF1N1MffDDcT9bkavJjU0MGkhu4lNXQuqaFrSQ0dS/ZmuJXU0KlEfVJDOpSoTzJ0JlGfZOhIoj7J0Imkphykef4D) for the generated code.

This now has some `"I love you"`s appended with a newline, and some not. I hope this is okay.

EDIT: Saved <s>lots of</s> *even more* bytes thanks to Value Ink!

---

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 53 + 2375 bytes

This is the cheap way of using a unicode range as variable names.

```
(?ÿ..?š).each{|v|puts"#{v}='I love you';puts #{v}"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X8P@8H49PfujCzX1UhOTM6prymoKSkuKlZSry2pt1T0VcvLLUhUq80vVrUHCCiBhpdr//wE) for the generator code.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdRJThoAAIXh/X8Kdx6i6QF6jSbdNbFpSxN3oKKiyCSIEwrO8zxPLHzvXPQCb/sd4Ptd@D45Gn0Ov45/G/s58e/H2OREYfzLr8LfP2OfQ1QMriIqJS@hqeRTaDr5NJpJPoPKyctoNvksmks@h@aTz6NK8gpaSL6AFpMvomryKlpKvoRqyWuonryOGskbqJm8iVrJW2g5@TJqJ2@jTvIOWkm@grrJu2g1@SpaS76G1pOvo43kG2gz@SbqJe@hreRbaDv5Nuon76NB8gHaSb6DdpPvor3ke2g/@T46SH6ADpMfoqPkR@g4@TE6SX6CTpOforPkZ@g8@Tm6SH6BLpNfoqvkV@g6@TW6SX6DbpPforvkd@g@@T16SP6AHpM/oqfkT@g5@TN6Sf6CXpO/orfkb@g9@Tv6SP6B0v8a4vS/izj97xJO/3sKp/89jdP/nsHpf5dx@t@zOP3vOZz@9zxO/7uC0/9ewOl/L@L0v6s4/e8lnP53Daf/Xcfpfzdw@t9NnP53C6f/vYzT/27j9L87OP3vFZz@dxen/72K0/9ew@l/r@P0vzdw@t@bOP3vHk7/ewun/72N0//u4/S/B6PRfw) for the generated code.

Comment: 1) Replace the `$stdout<<` version of printing with `puts` for some byte saves; I'm pretty sure the trailing newline isn't a problem for the challenge. Also `.join` to `*""`. 2) Use `%w` notation for your arrays, for example `%w(print $><< puts)` saves lots of bytes over `['print','$><<','puts']`. 3) Use `8.times` and modify `i` as necessary instead of doing `if i>0`: `-i` becomes `~i`, and `#{i}` becomes `#{i+1}`.

Comment: I also meant you should change `.join` to `*""` in your array... `%w[.join *'']` becomes `%w[*"" *'']` which you can golf further to `%w["" '']` if you do `*#{d}`. Also, `map` is better than `each` in 99% of cases

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't think of mixing up the quotation marks!

Comment: I can also swap out the `%w[chars split(//)]` with different quotation marks around the string.

Comment: Since it's come to you using the quotation marks for both parts: `q=?",?';q.product(q)` then `*"+d*2` works. Also, you can do `puts e+c+"#{m....` instead of interpolating, since they're just basic strings!

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 63 <sup>+ 3167 = 3230</sup>

```powershell
1..99|%{$z=$_%10;"''+(echo you $($_-$z)/10) love $z I)[4,2,0]"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/31BPz9KyRrVapcpWJV7V0MBaSV1dWyM1OSNfoTK/VEFFQyVeV6VKU9/QQFMhJ78sVUGlSsFTM9pEx0jHIFap9v9/AA)

Sample output:

```powershell
''+(echo you 0 love 1 I)[4,2,0]
''+(echo you 0 love 2 I)[4,2,0]
...
''+(echo you 1 love 0 I)[4,2,0]
''+(echo you 1 love 1 I)[4,2,0]
''+(echo you 1 love 2 I)[4,2,0]
...
''+(echo you 9 love 8 I)[4,2,0]
''+(echo you 9 love 9 I)[4,2,0]
```

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 2575 <sup>= 101 + 2474</sup>

Inspired by Jo King's [answer for Perl](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198209/80745).

Minimal total output for Powershell (84+2153) was written by [Andrei Odegov](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198185/80745)

So make sure to upvote them both as well!

```powershell
1..99|%{$n=$_
'"I "+("'+-join(0..6|%{[char](($n-shr$_)%2*32+'LOVEYOU'[$_])
' '*!($_-3)})+'"|% *wer)'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/31BPz9KyRrVaJc9WJZ5LXclTQUlbQ0ldWzcrPzNPw0BPzwwoGZ2ckVgUq6GhkqdbnFGkEq@paqRlbKSt7uMf5hrpH6oerRIfq8mlrqCupaihEq9rrFmrqa2uVKOqoAW0SFO99v9/AA)

Sample output:

```powershell
"I "+("lOVE YOU"|% *wer)
"I "+("LoVE YOU"|% *wer)
"I "+("loVE YOU"|% *wer)
"I "+("LOvE YOU"|% *wer)
...
"I "+("loVE You"|% *wer)
```

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 2672 <sup>= 99 + 2573</sup>, bonus track

```powershell
1..99|%{$p,$d="0$_"[-2,-1]
$e,$l,$c,$r='I love you'-split"^(.{$p})(.)"
"'$l$d$r'-replace$d,`"$c`""}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctNCoMwEAbQvaeQ4StRmITanQsP0DOUWksy0MJAQuwPYj177Nu/FL@S54eoltI51/e/w4rECAMdcaOLPbHtrhWEoQzPyIM51xo/Ui/xbeyc9PmisXH/tbWNa6kiA0VANjZL0rsXBJ4IfiLaStkB)

It generates 10 distinct programs for each char of the input string. The length of string `I love you` is 10 chars. This is enough for 99 iterations

Sample output:

```powershell
'1 love you'-replace1,"I"
'2 love you'-replace2,"I"
'3 love you'-replace3,"I"
...
'8 love you'-replace8,"I"
'9 love you'-replace9,"I"
'I0love you'-replace0," "
'I1love you'-replace1," "
...
'I love yo8'-replace8,"u"
'I love yo9'-replace9,"u"
```

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 94 + 2890, bonus track 2

```powershell
1..99|%{$n=$_;$i=0
'"=I='+-join(' love you'|% t*y|%{$_+'='[1-($n-shr$i++)%2]})+'"-replace"="'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/31BPz9KyRrVaJc9WJd5aJdPWgEtdydbTVl1bNys/M09DXSEnvyxVoTK/VL1GVaFEqxKkNl5b3VY92lBXQyVPtzijSCVTW1tT1Si2VlNbXUm3KLUgJzE5VclWSb32/38A)

Sample output:

```powershell
"=I= =love you"-replace"="
"=I= l=ove you"-replace"="
"=I= =l=ove you"-replace"="
"=I= lo=ve you"-replace"="
"=I= =lo=ve you"-replace"="
...
```

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 96 + 3094

Specially for those who love to turn `99` into `9`. ٩(^‿^)۶

```powershell
2..100|%{"-join('"+-join(('I love you '*$_)[($_+10)..$_])+"'*$(2+($_-$_%10)/10))[$($_+10)..$_]"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/30hPz9DAoEa1Wkk3Kz8zT0NdSRvC0FD3VMjJL0tVqMwvVVDXUonXjNZQidc2NNDU01OJj9XUVgIKahhpAwV1VeJVgeL6QKwZrYKsSqn2/38A)

Sample output:

```powershell
-join(' I uoy evol'*2)[12..2]
-join('l I uoy evo'*2)[13..3]
-join('ol I uoy ev'*2)[14..4]
-join('vol I uoy e'*2)[15..5]
-join('evol I uoy '*2)[16..6]
-join(' evol I uoy'*2)[17..7]
-join('y evol I uo'*2)[18..8]
-join('oy evol I u'*2)[19..9]
-join('uoy evol I '*3)[20..10]
-join(' uoy evol I'*3)[21..11]
-join('I uoy evol '*3)[22..12]
-join(' I uoy evol'*3)[23..13]
...
-join(' uoy evol I'*10)[98..88]
-join('I uoy evol '*10)[99..89]
-join(' I uoy evol'*11)[100..90]
-join('l I uoy evo'*11)[101..91]
-join('ol I uoy ev'*11)[102..92]
-join('vol I uoy e'*11)[103..93]
-join('evol I uoy '*11)[104..94]
-join(' evol I uoy'*11)[105..95]
-join('y evol I uo'*11)[106..96]
-join('oy evol I u'*11)[107..97]
-join('uoy evol I '*11)[108..98]
-join(' uoy evol I'*11)[109..99]
-join('I uoy evol '*12)[110..100]
```

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 123 + 3141

...and in a normal order. https://coub.com/view/27d6eh

```powershell
$s='I love you';(2..122|%{"-join('"+-join(("$s "*$_)[-($_+10)..-$_])+"'*$(2+($_-$_%10)/10))[$($_-1)..$($_+9)]"})-notmatch$s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYpRCsIwEESvEpYtyXZJNPkT6QE8QylBJFAlNmJaRdSzxxQ/Bt68mVt6hnseQ4ylYO7kQcT0COKVFrlXzhjr3Kd5g76k86Qk8B8UYBbQoqdeK/Rst2SMRj8Qg2xROa629qYOmxrqcRW2vlbgHQ3wJT2l@XqcTyPmUn4)

Sample output:

```powershell
-join('u I love yo'*2)[2..12]
-join('ou I love y'*2)[3..13]
-join('you I love '*2)[4..14]
-join(' you I love'*2)[5..15]
-join('e you I lov'*2)[6..16]
-join('ve you I lo'*2)[7..17]
-join('ove you I l'*2)[8..18]
-join('love you I '*3)[9..19]
-join(' love you I'*3)[10..20]
-join('u I love yo'*3)[13..23]
-join('ou I love y'*3)[14..24]
-join('you I love '*3)[15..25]
...
```

Comment: For your first answer, what's to stop me turning the `99` into `9`?

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 75 bytes, 2178 + 75 = 2253

```perl6
unique("'I love you'.tclc.say",{S:x(8)[\w]~^=' 'x 2.rand}...*)[^99+1]>>.say
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/780L7OwNFVDSd1TISe/LFWhMr9UXa8kOSdZrzixUkmnOtiqQsNCMzqmPLYuzlZdQb1CwUivKDEvpVZPT09LMzrO0lLbMNbODqT6/38A)

Outputs variants of:

```perl6
'I love you'.tclc.say
```

string part has a randomised unique case. `tclc` is short for "title case, lowercase", which capitalises the first letter and lowercases the rest.

```perl6
"..."         # Starting from the base program
     ,{                        }...*  # Generate an infinite series of
       S:x(8)[\w]~^=             # String xor the first 8 letters
                    ' 'x 2.rand  # Randomly space or nothing, 
                                 # Essentially flipping the case

unique( ... )                 # From the unique elements
             [^99+1]          # Take 99, skipping the first
                    >>.say    # And print each
```

The reason I don't include the first unique element is so that a variant with correct casing isn't produced, since that would be reducible.

Answer (score 1):

R, 84 Bytes

```
for(x in 1:99){cat("assign(intToUtf8(",x,"),'I love you');get(intToUtf8(",x,"))\n")}
```

Comment: I think this doesn't satisfy condition 2. For any values of `x > 9` (i.e more than one digit), then you can remove two strings (one digit from both numbers) and it will still print 'I love you'.

Answer (score 1):

## [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w) `n` `d`, 34 bytes

Different programs are separated as different list items. The `n` flag joins the input with newlines.

```
•u≡`â!=Ç¡l╪G⌠±×èe↔/.╫ù{¶c×█)←╢k0ôF
```

## Uncompressed

```
99''a146+C"C'"a73+C"C-C@ love you@+"++++M
```

## Explanation

```
99                                      M % Map in the range from 1 to 99
  ''                                      % A single quote '
    a146+                                 % Add the current item by 146
         C                                % Convert the current item to a character
          "C'"                            % Add a string C'
              a73+C                       % Add the current item by 73 (creating a difference of 73)
                   "C-C@ love you@+"++++  % Prepend the string and join the whole stack
```

## Program explanation

```
'ⁿC'JC-              # Create the number 73
       C" love you"+ # Convert to character and append "love you"
```

Comment: Aha! `'I4"#Mpu~!:O`&` [COPY](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/P0Hd00RJ2begtE7Ryj9B7f9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 70 bytes

```cs
for(char i='ÿ';i++<355;Write($"var {i}=\"I love you\";Write({i});"));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/Lb9IIzkjsUgh01b98H5160xtbRtjU1Pr8KLMklQNFaUyoFR1Zq1tjJKnQk5@WapCZX5pjBJUGiihaa2kqWn9/z8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>85 + 2647 = 2732</s> <s>83 + 2251 = 2334</s> 79 + 1818 = 1897

```
0..226|?{[char]::isletterordigit($_)}|%{"`$$([char]$_)"}|%{"($_='I love you')"}
```

-398 thanks to mazzy

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/30BPz8jIrMa@Ojo5I7Eo1soqszgntaQktSi/KCUzPbNEQyVes7ZGtVopQUVFA6IGKKIEFgLK2ap7KuTkl6UqVOaXqgOF//8HAA)

Sample output:

```
($0='I love you')
...
($â='I love you')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zci1UgIAAADQ3a9g4A7c7BgcbLG7NgNFRUEQECe7u86u0d3FUT8MZ@@98SUTuWgqHYvG44VCOFhSF4oE4olsNJBPZELFReFgKVPGlDMVTCVTxVQzNUwtU880MI1ME9PMtDCtTBsTYdqZDqaT6WK6mR6ml@lj@pkBZpAZYoaZEWaUGWPGmQlmkplippkoM8PMMjFmjplnFpg4s8gsMQkmySwzKSbNrDAZJsvkmFUmz6wxP5/Wl/VN/a5bG9amtWVtWzvWrrVn7VsH1qF1ZB1bJ9apdWadWxfWpXVlXVs31q11Z91bD9aj9WQ9Wy/Wq/VmvVsf/6tQ@AM)

Comment: nice. you can remove `{` and `}`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/30BPz8jIrMa@Ojo5I7Eo1soqszgntaQktSi/KCUzPbNEQyVes7ZGtVopQUVFA6IGKKIEFlKJt1X3VLdWiddWV8jJL0tVqMwvVVeq/f8fAA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: You can reduce programs by removing the `$0=` and `;$0` parts

Comment: I'm agree in this case. The constraint 1 violated: If `$0=` is removed, then the program outputs `I love you'

Comment: I thinks this [84+2153](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/30BPz8jIrMa@Ojo5I7Eo1soqszgntaQktSi/KCUzPbNEQyVes7ZGtVopQUVFA6IGKKIEFlKJt1X3VLdOADIUcvLLUhUq80sTlJRq//8HAA "PowerShell – Try It Online") was the best

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>123 + 4247</s> <s>94</s> 90 + 2124 bytes

Heredoc abuse. Takes 49 different alphanumerics (A-Z, _, a-v) and constructs 2 programs that print the text using the appropriate heredoc. That's only 98 programs, though, so it adds one more print at the end. Each program is 3 lines long, except the last one.

This beats IMP1's Ruby solution in the combined code golf score, but falls behind in standard scoring.

```ruby
l="I love you"
(?A..?v).grep(/\w/){|i|puts"$><<<<"+i,l,i,"puts <<"+i,l,i}
puts"puts'#{l}'"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P8dWyVMhJ78sVaEyv1SJS8PeUU/PvkxTL70otUBDP6ZcX7O6JrOmoLSkWEnFzgYIlLQzdXJ0MnWUQGIKcH4tF1gNiFBXrs6pVVf6/x8A)

[Generated code](https://tio.run/##bcpJagIBAETRfZ9CJMcIAed5nt2I89TaatuCp@8EiiJFJX/5@I9k9U7Tj6/Pn3JBLRNGr23mHSVBLrglzzjzR7HmFfNcTbEWFAtcTbEWFYtcTbGWFEtcTbGWFctcTbFWFCtcTbFWFatcTbHWFGtcTbHWFetcTbE2FBtcTbE2FZtcTbG2FFtcTbG2FdtcTbF2FDtcTbF2FbtcTbH2FHtcTbH2FftcTbEOFAdcTbEOFYdcTbGOFEdcTbGOFcdcTbFOFCdcTbFOFadcTbHOFGdcTbHOFedcTbEuFBdcTbEuFZdcTbGuFFdcTbGuFddcTbFuFDdcTbFuFbdcTbHuFHdcTbHuFfdcTbEeFA9cTbEeFY9cTbGeFE9cTbGeFc9cTbGGiiFXU6wXxQtXU6xXxStXU6yRYsTVFOtN8cbVFOtd8c7VFOtD8cHVFGusGHM1xfpUfHI1xZooJlxNsb4UX1z/0eyvZIM0/QY)

#### Old solution, 123 + 4247 bytes

Beats out IMP1's (non-Unicode) Ruby solution in the standard code golf department, but falls behind in combined code golf scoring. Unlike their use of multiple output solutions and rotation, I chose to shuffle the string after setting a seed with `srand`.

```ruby
99.times{|i|srand i;puts"srand #{i};puts'#{[*0..9].shuffle.zip('I love you'.chars).sort.map(&:last)*''}'.chars.shuffle*''"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/39JSryQzN7W4uiazprgoMS9FIdO6oLSkWAnCUa7OrAXz1ZWro7UM9PQsY/WKM0rT0nJS9aoyCzTUPRVy8stSFSrzS9X1kjMSi4o19Yrzi0r0chMLNNSschKLSzS11NVroZIwvUAhpdr//wE)

[Generated code](https://tio.run/##fVcxjhsxDOzzCnYGUhxs73q9Rl6gZ1wSHVIQYXAOBej1znAtrpuQ/UCiOMPh6FO/98fj/vn@@ycdv/3Rv/eDtNJZK5Ec3n78ev@8v91/6ccH16@Hw5cn8vRENipVlLtQiDyPM6lS4d40PnN6IjuL4FjSFiLnJ5J6KyxVkzovA1lZhaT1EiIXr5Ok18ZFQ@T1ieQmHVej1BC5jjPt2Whn4RB5G29vuF@FkzNPR38SNWHpSaGnk78Jja9SKIE6TdKpFWVKCpgcqqURV@oxdBCF40oTa1cMHUxVLgI5tQw6qOJOhFdJS541uDKNNJbSk1MHWVxBVqeSSPrkbAFUoasW83o@@qAAKDYBMXSwRQUKbJUlftZ5sAVJNYG0elKATxWxtgIVxrNynh1qb6pQYQy97M9i3QiLoYuf2jDTIskQnAdbOA7SQqkJdN2JbWhXWutgq3HdBrbEtU6DrUJmK416YlanvVmMMRCJB2YabFViq1UlrnVythpsgE3cMXSwVcxaOtSdPMtnCyKgfGCmxd0FOO0oOIa6D9q0qICvGDrYgqd3EhvxGHpzzyoVXcimYHYnFKwhtJVjCubBlhoBG7sx9LWwpNvMxM@a3QnNMmu6BefZVwHaSjY2MXSwBU0rDA7UxlBnCwbbbbzjvs7Xl2VgwWqNjWgebIF@24alJgXcnILK5loaS/sy2FK0FbyWbGnvs2UwKCvWwGWfLWxOTX3gMtjCmQDDNJNTZz8VfoV4Q3EHLp4whJGabBvEUGeLKlwbESvpgLPFFaSaE8XQdQ8uWkyESa3uhHY5pZ61HN1fuzkGJx1YfG9hVk0tPYEOtjCtIAyKiTuwTG5EGEILD3FfF4@D6JWaGyUFOFtwDCRCSDGGDraw41Et1BVP7DLYwtu3nJFIe1l9cVpqtn0cQ50tTEHHlk8i2fW4R2ekbDO5GOqzVbfh0kQuV2cLDwINWXS/Tp7exLJbSfR69b3VralQVhK03QlpS6X4ksRQny21LWuJJIZe978LbMuWXAxd96xtckE6j6EvJ7RiNTGi1VMGFIBdTIkG1tMrEdmWS1bcenZ7k@2z0WIK1ukV9BhBj5JaZ7cM5KaOlRg3ax1s4UyUi7SXnOqfLdgF/hpprZ7gsYhp@2rG0PX11cSO68kyWj1llC3sU9LX29H/MJaKsb8TqDuh2ARYhI@hnuBtFTN2ctyB284WPrumgqQATxlQFf46Wcy57bOFX2Q1eAx1JwT7ah/UBHrdf5xqv/OadGB1f8UyNAb@d@rj8Q8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 74 bytes

**Output: 2178** (after removing newline delimiters) for a category 2 score of **2252 bytes**

```sh
for p (echo print '<<<');for v ({1..7} {a..z})<<<"$v='I love you';$p \$$v"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fck9CoAgAAbQq3yEpC5CLQ2ae3doiTAKIsXM6O/sVm995zomlgbr4cBMP1o4Py0BVClFufwjgl2FENWDqxPifPhXGYk1bTDbaHDYjUri0BISs8RxIxgDzfaeQ@dlegE)

Uses method from [this Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198076/86147), setting a unique variable before printing. In zsh, variables must be alphanumeric, so we limit to 33 names and then print out programs using `echo`, `print`, and `<<<` to get our 99.

There is optimization to be done for category 2, [this tweak scores 77 + 2145 = **2222 bytes**](https://tio.run/##Fck9CoAgAAbQq3yEpC5CLQ2Ze3doiTAKIsXM6O/sZtMb3rVNkcXROFgwPUymA6ybV5@kUkrK6z8D2F0IUb24eyGul6fKSGhoi8UEjdPstCa2IyRkkeOB1xqKHQOHysv4AQ), and more can probably be found.