# Sum in 2540 sums

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source, code-shuffleboard

<sup>This is my attempt to pair [code-shuffleboard](/questions/tagged/code-shuffleboard) with [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf).</sup>

You need to write a full program or function that sums all codepoints of the input string. If there is no input, you can output any number, including `0`.

### Rules

- The input will always be in printable ASCII.
- The sum of the codepoints of your source must be exactly 2540.

  - If your language uses its own code page, you should use it to calculate your program's codepoints.
  - If you used Unicode in your code you *have* to use Unicode bytes to calculate your program's length.
- Null bytes (which don't contribute to your codepoint sum) are banned.
- The program must **not** work with any consecutive substring removed.
- The conversion of codepoints are required.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Your score is the length of your source code, the shorter being better.

Comment: Does it need to be a complete program?  Some of the answers are *functions*.

Comment: If I'm using 05AB1E, do I have to count it in the SBCS?

Comment: Is there any reason you picked `2540`? Just curious.

Comment: This doesn't seem to meet the precise definition of [tag:pristine-programming] in the tag wiki since pp requires the program to *error* while this requires the program to *not work*.  Not sure though if the tag wiki should be editted or the tag should be removed.

Comment: If there is no input, is it required to output 0?

Comment: Seems there're [some](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/198052/99-ways-to-say-i-love-you) [other](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/196824/biggest-irreducible-hello-world) problems with [tag:pristine-programming] that requires the program to *not work*.

Comment: Some answers are accepting an array of integer code-points while most are performing conversion from strings, are the former acceptable or is the conversion to code-points a requirement?

Comment: About the score being the length of the code, does that mean I can use a character count instead of bytes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>11 10</s> 9 bytes

*Thanks @MariaMiller for finding the right Unicode character, saving 1 byte!*

```python
ࠂ,=sum,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY8xUsQwDEV7n@LjbZwZQ0O3M0vNDbYACuMoJEPW8tgKAy0n4WjcJChOwTaW7f/09ZW/ZOR0vx5QwwdBRkLlpURC5J4QKqqUKb15CCOOFN93ZrlgDkLFNOwEa@36@/PtT6r4VV93W192nTH0SdFtmN4PEKrSLIYlRZk4mYELKqaEp1cbrIeeYa@PNM/sceYy9zf25WiArGHEVQ97@6CMjnS1a8b/4bZZmZVrMXm43sjsBvY5XWm7dFQ//XSXkB2X3rfIXbf@AQ)

This is essentially just `sum`, padded with extra characters to reach the sum of `2540`. Usage is `ࠂ(s)` where `s` is a byte string (which acts like both string and integer array). Feels kinda cheaty, but ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

The first character in source code is the Unicode character with codepoint `2050` ([Samaritan letter Gaman](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0802/index.htm)). This character might not be displayable depending on your browser.

---

The previous solution is longer but has nice Unicode characters:

**11 bytes**

```python
ϕ,ϴ=sum,9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY8xUsMwEEV7neKjNPKMSJOKzISaG1AAhZDX2IOj1UhrhhwkN@EePpIjywVpJO3@t3@/4kV6Dodlh@x@CNITMk/JEzy3BJeRJQ3hy0IYvif/vTHTGaMTSqpiJ2itl/lq579TkezTUur9OhlNoxT9kjcrWN47CGWpJt0UvAwcVMcJGUPA26d22qKcbrtfaBzZ4pXT2D7oj6MCYokjJlvox@fCzFeTm@r7n25dFblgNSd3919S27x@D3faJh2LXWmas4uGU2tr4qZZbg)

Comment: [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY8xUsQwDEV7n@LjbZwZQ0O3M0vNDbYACuMoJEPW8tgKAy0n4WjcJChOwTaW7f/09ZW/ZOR0vx5QwwdBRkLlpURC5J4QKqqUKb15CCOOFN93ZrlgDkLFNOwEa@36@/PtT6r4VV93W192nTH0SdFtmN4PEKrSLIYlRZk4mYELKqaEp1cbrIeeYa@PNM/sceYy9zf25WiArGHEVQ97@6CMjnS1a8b/4bZZmZVrMXm43sjsBvY5XWm7dFQ//XSXkB2X3rfIXbf@AQ)

Answer (score 12):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 25 bytes

```hs
b~zw=sum(fromEnum`map`zw)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P6muqty2uDRXI60oP9c1rzQ3ITexIKGqXPN/cVGyrRJOaSWu3MTMPNuCosy8EpUkBaDi//@S03IS04v/6yYXFAAA)

The `~` is not an infix operator, but a marker for a [lazy pattern match](https://wiki.haskell.org/Lazy_pattern_match) on argument `zw` of `b`, while conveniently being the largest-valued ASCII character at 126. The infix-ized `` `map` `` is also used because the backtick has a large ASCII value of 96. With both of these, we can avoid any spaces or other whitespace, which have low ASCII values.

The dense 24-byter

```hs
z~zz=sum$fromEnum`map`zz
```

comes just short in its sum of 2525, 15 too small. Its average ASCII value is 105.21, with the only values below 97 (for `a`) being `=` at 61, `$` at 36, and `E` at 69. An improvement would like involve finding an alternative for one of these.

(Non-ASCII characters can surely do better by having higher character values, but I'm not doing that because this is more interesting.)

Comment: [22-byte Haskell version with non-ascii](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1Hh@HLb4tJclbSi/FzXvNJcGxW748v/Fxcl2yphl1Piyk3MzLMtKMrMK1FJVACq/P8vOS0nMb34v25yQQEA) btw.

Answer (score 6):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), 32 bytes

```
<[[[{({}()<>)<>}<>({{}[()]})]]]>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v/fJjo6ulqjulZD08YOiGpt7DSqq2ujNTRjazVjY2Pt/v//r0RIjRIA)

### Explanation

First the observations I made my first time around (that solution and its explanation is below) continue to be important here. We need and even number of `()` pairs for a valid answer.

This time however we are going to use a starting program that already has an even number of `()`s.

```
{({}()<>)<>}<>({{}[()]})
```

This program first increments every element by 1 then calculates the sum of 1 less than every element.  If we look at all possible ways to delete from this without causing a bracket mismatch here are what they do:

```
{(()<>)<>}<>({{}[()]}) # Never halts
{({}<>)<>}<>({{}[()]}) # Sums 1 less than every element
{({}())<>}<>({{}[()]}) # One more than above
{({}()<>)}<>({{}[()]}) # Never halts
{({}()<>)<>}({{}[()]}) # No output
{({}()<>)<>}<>({[()]}) # Never halts
{({}()<>)<>}<>({{}[]}) # Complex output still incorrect
{(<>)<>}<>({{}[()]})   # Never halts
{({})<>}<>({{}[()]})   # Sums 1 less than every element
{({}()<>)<>}<>({{}})   # Sums 1 more than every element
{()<>}<>({{}[()]})     # Sums 1 less than every element
{({}()<>)<>}<>({})     # Adds 1 to every element
{<>}<>({{}[()]})       # Sums 1 less than every element
{({}()<>)<>}<>()       # Adds 1 to every element
{}<>({{}[()]})         # Outputs 0
{({}()<>)<>}<>         # Adds 1 to every element
<>({{}[()]})           # Outputs 0
{({}()<>)<>}           # Outputs nothing
({{}[()]})             # Sums 1 less than every element
```

So this is a good starting place.  To make it the correct sum I use the same method I outlined for the first attempt.

> Now we just need the proper combination of `[..]`s `<..>`s and `((..){}){}`s to hit 2540.  Unfortunately while `[..]`s would be ideal seeing as they have the highest codepoint average I can't seem to get it to work with any of them present.

This time we are luckier and the winning combination is `<[[[..]]]>`.

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), 34 bytes

```
<<<<<<<<(((({{}})){}){}){}>>>>>>>>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v/fBgo0gKC6urZWU7O6FoLsoOD///9KhFUpAQA)

### Explanation

The code that does the task is `({{}})`.  But we need to pad it to 2540.  The main issue is that apart from `()` every pair has an even total.  This means we need and even number of `()` pairs, and at the same time our starting code uses only 1 `()` pair.

On top of this unlike `[]` or `<>` `()` pairs are not so easy to add.  The one way we can do that is to wrap the entire program in `(..){}`, so to rectify our issue we alter the base program to

```
(({{}})){}
```

Now we just need the proper combination of `[..]`s `<..>`s and `((..){}){}`s to hit 2540.  Unfortunately while `[..]`s would be ideal seeing as they have the highest codepoint average I can't seem to get it to work with any of them present.  The one that works is the one used above.

Comment: Is there a way to make `{...{foo<>}...}<>` work as padding?

Comment: I started with `{({{}})(<>)}<>`  (with an extra `()` to make things even) and ran a program which determined that there was no way to add `{}`s, `<>`s and `[]`s which resulted in the correct amount

Comment: @Nitrodon I realized that I can also add `()`s in even amounts so I ran it again and got `<<[[[[{{({{}})(((<>)))}}]]]]>><>`, which is still 32 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Comρiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 13 bytes

I *had* to abuse the IO so that C# can be comρetitive once in its entire existence. Takes char codes as `int`s as inρut. To make this seem less terrible, this acceρts any `IEnumerable<int>` instead of only an array.

```cs
ρ=>ρ.Sum();
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpds4@maV5qbWpSYlJNqk5lXYqejACIV3BRsFf6fb7S1O9@oF1yaq6Fp/T@gCCij4aahhCKspBeS75yRWORYVJRYqaGpF5yak5pcolFha6cBVK5Zoampac0F1@qRmpOTr6MQnl@Uk6JIjNb/AA)

Alternatively, for less byte savings (30 bytes):
This includes the most descriptive variable name ever on this website.

```cs
strS=>strS.Select(p=>+p).Sum()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5yRWBQdq6OQmVdip@CmYPu/uKQo2NYOROoFp@akJpdoFNjaaRdo6gWX5mpo/rfmCigCqtVw01DySM3JyddRCM8vyklRVNILyXcGmuVYVJRYqaGpqYmkEL@RmDr/AwA)

Comment: Did you just mispell `Compiler` into `Comriler`? Also `comretitive`, `accerts` (`ρ` is rho in greek.)

Comment: Nope, the homoglyph attack is intentional.

Comment: If I remove the last `;`, I get a lambda that just works as well. But it shouldn't be working according to the rules.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 17 bytes

```
žĆs"þþþþþx"g6QôkO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L4jbcVKh/fBYIVSulng4S3Z/nikAA)

This was made by Kevin Cruijssen.

### Explanation

```
žĆ                # Push codepage
  s               # Swap
   "þþþþþx"       # Push a string of length 6
           g      # Get the length of the string (6)
            6Q    # And compare it with 6 (True -> 1)
              ô   # Split into chunks
               k  # Index into the codepage
                O # Sum
```

## Original idea, <s>63</s> <s>48</s> <s>36</s> 29 bytes

-15 bytes by using `1!` and replacing the `!`.

-12 bytes by dropping the factorial entirely, and using `≠` instead of `1`.

-7 bytes by using `тн` and replacing the `н`. I'm not sure if this is allowed though, because with no input, it just outputs 49.

```
тžĆ"ʒʒʒʒʒʒʒʒʒʒKþþþ"gè.VôžĆskO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//YtPRfUfalE5NwoTeh/eBoFL64RV6YYe3gNQVZ/uToQUA)

### Explanation

```
т                             # Push 100
 žĆ                           # Push the codepage
   "ʒʒʒʒʒʒʒʒʒʒKþþþ"           # Push a string of length 14
                   g          # Get the length of the string
                    è         # Index into the codepage (н)
                     .V       # Run н (first digit of 100)
                       ô      # Split into chunks of 1
                        žĆ    # Push codepage
                          s   # Swap with input
                           k  # Find each char in codepage
                            O # Sum
```

Comment: [17 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L4jbcVKh/fBYIVSulng4S3Z/nikAA)

Answer (score 3):

## brainfuck, <s>41</s> 39 bytes

<sup>(I haven't tested exhaustively)</sup>
Uses 3 strategies for wasting the codepoint sum: repeating all `<` and `>`, nesting the innermost `[` and `]` unneccessarily, and adding and later removing the same number to/from the output.

Runs in an interpreter with large cells and wrapping/bidirectional memory, which TIO isn't :(. Outputs by charcode.

```
++++++[[[[[[[<<<+>>>-]]]]]],]<<<------.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 25 bytes

```java
Ƌ->Ƌ.codePoints().sum()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY1NCsIwEIX3PcXgKhHMBbSCG1cKgu7ERewfqfmjMykU8QTeq9eKsboTV8Pje9@8VvZy0Za3qIx3HUGbsgiktKiDLUg5K@bL7AcidZU0b1RoiQh7qSzcMwAfrloVgCQpnd6pEkxi7Eidss35ArJrkE9VgJPbOdtsv0OrT2cNNeRxfC7W41MUrqwOTllCxgUGw3hcTqpOIhDkUAvpvR42@H7FZn@9Gf@IxwGpMsIFEj7NkbaMJvTIHvEF)

All alternatives I tried failed:

```java
s->s.chars().sum() // Function<String,Integer>
s->s.sum()         // Function<IntStream,Integer>
java.util.stream.IntStream::sum
...
```

Comment: I just came up with an identical answer only to scroll down and find yours here. :)

Comment: For the IntStream, [13 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZY5LCsIwEIb3PcXgKhXMBaqCG0FQEOpOXMS@SM2LzqRQxIN5Ca8UY3Ajrobh@/5/phejWPT1LUjt7EDQx517koq33lQkreHzIvuDSEMj9AdVSiDCQUgD9wzA@auSFSAJimO0sgYdGStpkKY7X0AMHeZJBTjZvTXd9ntouTNUpt41tLAKr@di/Xpy9JrlRUgBFXUgWEHLhXNq2uCngM1@1BmvbN0crTSELM@LlCwnpEZz64m7@AkpwyihR/YIbw)

Comment: @MariaMiller Thanks, but `l->l.sum()` (without the semi-colon) is *also* a valid lambda, so that answer is invalid because the rules say that there may not be a substring of the answer that also works.

Comment: Okay, here's [another one](https://tio.run/##ZY5JCsJAEEXX5hRFVh0hfQEHcCMICkLciYs2Ex17IlUdEMklcjGPFNvoRlwVxXv/VzWiE2lT3EapnW0JmrBzT1LxypucpDV8voj@IFJbCv1GuRKIcBDSwCMCcP6qZA5IgsLorCxAB8YyaqWpzxcQbY3JpAKc7N6aevs9tNwZyqbeNVSwGp9Dun4OHL1ms2RcTAkVfCBYQcWFc@q@wXcDi3/cmOe2KI9WGkKWJJ9kdkcqNbeeuAuvkDKMJtRH/fgC) that doesn't violate that rule

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 26 bytes

```python
lambda ŏ:sum(ŏ.encode())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUeFov1Vxaa7G0X691Lzk/JRUDU3N/wVFmXklGmkaSh6pOTn5Ogrh@UU5KYpKmppcXMoKQNUKaaV5ySWZ@XkKJRmJJQrJiXkKKamJOQrlmSUZCnn5ebqOwc6enlzptlA7isFW5CYWaOQXpegUA82B2JCOxQa4DFTv4R6w5sM9CPdhU4bFG0Bl/wE)

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 28 bytes

```python
lambda	eZ:sum(bytearray(eZ))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklkTM1yqq4NFcjqbIkNbGoKLFSIzVKU/N/QVFmXolCmoYSPlVKmv8B)

Comment: Hopefully it's fixed now :\

Comment: Looks like the sum of this code is 2450? The alternative seems to work out to the specified 2540.

Comment: I don't think your non-printable answer sums to 2540, since `Ì` has code point `204`. I replaced it the correct code point `335`. [TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUeFov1Vxaa7G0X691Lzk/JRUDU3N/wVFmXklGmkaSh6pOTn5Ogrh@UU5KYpKmppcXMoKQNUKaaV5ySWZ@XkKJRmJJQrJiXkKKamJOQrlmSUZCnn5ebqOwc6enlzptlA7isFW5CYWaOQXpegUA82B2JCOxQa4DFTv4R6w5sM9CPdhU4bFG0Bl/wE).

Comment: Thanks for that, @Surclose Sputum. IDK why I keep messing up my answer :(

Comment: That's because your function only works with ASCII characters. For UTF-8 encoding, an ASCII character is encoded into 1 byte that is the same as its codepoint. However, a non-ASCII character is encoded into multiple bytes. [Here](https://tio.run/##ZY5BDoIwEEX3nOIHNjRRg6AbExfGFWuXhEULYyDRlrQlhjt4Kw@GLaLGuJnMn/lv5neDbZTMxtFgj/BxDxFBKrk8nI55jqrhmleWdCDc2qxIVqqmmDnTq63RSqsgBksmCCLcCBWXMESwDbeu0PcIWvOLpTPYaSfjcBK7cAHB/kdFUi5EsS6Zf@PPmv4KdZ7ayQWuCVm2faN@/8GdiAWbWNHPsVwOdMp5fS4lLwPSZDPTStexYWwcnw) is a demonstration.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 28 bytes

```python
lambda	zva:sum(map(ord,zva))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfnJ@SaqukpPQ/JzE3KSWRs6os0aq4NFcjN7FAI78oRQfI19T8D1SgV1xSlFmgocmVZptalpijAdKoyVVQlJlXopAG4f0HAA)

Uses a tab after the `lambda`.

Comment: Your code contains 2 newlines, which could be removed. The actual sum without newlines is 2520. "The program must not work with any consecutive substring removed".

Comment: @GB Nice catch, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-nl`, <s>28</s> 26 bytes

-2 bytes from GB.

```ruby
p $_.chars.sum{|ay|ay.ord}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0BBJV4vOSOxqFivuDS3uiaxEoj08otSavHJ/csvKMnMzyv@r5uXAwA)

Comment: -2 bytes: use p instead of $> and name your variable 'ya'

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 29 bytes

```perl
for(split//,<>){$u+=ord}say$u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z8tv0ijuCAns0RfX8fGTrNapVTbNr8opbY4sVKllID0v/yCksz8vOL/ur6megaGBgA)

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 35 bytes

```php
FOR(;$zz=$argn[$u++];)$a+=ORD($zz);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk3fyDNKxVqqpsVRKL0vOiVUq1tWOtNVUStW39g1w0gBKa1v9dnT38VRKtoWqdYEqdIUodoUqdNK3BCh2t/@UXlGTm5xX/13UDAA)

OK I'm cheating a little bit here, but the shorter code I found for PHP having too much codepoints sum already (2549), I'll interpret the question in a litteral sense:

- "program or function that sums all codepoints of the input string" -> it is not said I have to display the result, above code actually sums it :D (yeah I know, implicit rules.. well!)
- "you can output any number, including 0" -> well I can, but if not forced to, I won't :P

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 28 bytes

```
A[J_]:=Tr@ToCharacterCode[J]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/98x2is@1so2pMghJN85I7EoMbkktcg5PyU12iv2f0BRZl5JtGO0UmJSckpqWrpSbCwXXAyfTqDC/wA) Defines a named function `A` that takes a string as input and returns the sum of its ASCII codepoints. `ToCharacterCode` converts a character to its codepoint (and outputs a list of codepoints when fed a string of characters) and `Tr` sums them.

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 28 bytes

```
'zzzzzzzzzzzh'+{}/]{+}*1446-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X70KATLUtatr9WOrtWu1DE1MzHTxywIA)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 15 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/78410)

```apl
üüd←⎕UCS⍞⋄+/üüd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97f/hPYf3pDxqm/Cob2qoc/Cj3nmPulu09cGiIAX/geKe/kB5Ay5tfSDbMexR72Z1PJrUFRQe9c5VCMnILFZISc3NzysuKUosSS1WKMlILAESqQrJ@SmpBfmZeSUKxaW5CuWZJRmZeWCJlNS0xNKcEoiCxPRUBaARRqYmBly6urpcaVyGRsZAMjEpGaguPSMzKzsnNy@/oLCouKS0rLyisgoA)

A full program that takes a single line from STDIN as input.

The ASCII characters are shuffled around within the default codepage (along with APL symbols and accented characters), and many useful characters appear at the high half (character value > 128). Accented characters are valid to use in an identifier, and `ü` has the highest character value among them.

This code achieves "The program must not work with any consecutive substring removed" by separating the Unicode conversion `⎕UCS` and sum `+/` into two statements.

The character `⎕` alone is *over nine thousand* (pun intended) in Unicode, so APL can't compete using Unicode scoring.

#### How it works

```apl
üüd←⎕UCS⍞⋄+/üüd
        ⍞        ⍝ Take a line of input from stdin
    ⎕UCS         ⍝ Convert to Unicode codepoints
üüd←             ⍝ Assign to variable
         ⋄       ⍝ Statement separator
          +/üüd  ⍝ Sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 30 bytes

Works in Python 2 and 3.

```python
lambda abZ:(sum(map(ord,abZ)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSExKcpKo7g0VyM3sUAjvyhFByigqan5v6AoM69EI01DHb86daBSAA)

Alternative 30-byter:

```python
lambda aN,b=ord:sum(map(b,aN))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHRTyfJNr8oxaq4NFcjN7FAI0kn0U9T839BUWZeiUaahjp@depApQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 28 bytes

```javascript
Ă=>eval(Buffer(Ă).join`+`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY27DoJAEEV7v2K6nQk4sTeQaGVpb0xYllkDWRmyPOz5Nv5rxc76nnNuZxc7utgO07HXRpKHIm1rUcpiA15n7yXithJ32vZVVlFy2o8ahIO@0KO5SQgKH42hMUTnw//8YGb0kIEx9OS3HdBBUYJjtz/d9@B0mZCIozSzE0SbQ00/wu5OncOJKH0B)

Submission only works on ASCII. Although it source code contains non-ASCII.

This one based on code by [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld).

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 31 bytes

```javascript
s=>Buffer(s).map(c=>w+=c,w=0)|w
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYu9DoMgEIB3n8LxiC1xJ@fQJ/FCwWDAI4eVpe@ODsb1@1npoGIl5P298de1LLwIpR77uRWcPj/vnUBROlEGi1Md0L4qjupf26x3CQmU6fzVu4Mi3PuFOstb4eh05AX8I5RpJw)

---

Another trivial one.

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 37 bytes

```
func[-][!: 0 forall -[!: ADD ! -/1]!]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhIdy5Vm9T@tNC85Wjc2WtFKwUAhLb8oMSdHQRfEc3RxUVBU0NU3jFWM/V9QlJlXopCmoESUciUuuHpDI2Ol/wA)

Nothing original. `-` is the input string, `!` is the sum. For each character in the input string I add its value to the sum. [Red](http://www.red-lang.org) is case insensitive, so I use `ADD` instead of `add` (and isntead of the `+` operator) in order to match 2540. `forall` iterates over the entire series (list) and at each iteration returns the remaining series - just like `cdr` in LISP or `rest` in Racket. That's why I use `/1` to obtain the first element in the series.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 15 bytes

```
ＩΣＥＳ⁺⊗⊗⊗⊗ＬPP⌕γι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEI7g0V8M3sUDDM6@gtCS4BCiRrqGpoxCQU1qs4ZJfmpSTmoKT9knNSy/J0FAKCFDSBAEdBbfMvBSNdB2FTDBf0/r//2JbO6fStLTUIo1iTb1coEXJtnbl2rbJOuW2Bpo15f91y3IA) Link is to verbose version of code. Only works on printable ASCII, so I can't feed it its own source code, even if I could create it in the right code page. Explanation:

```
   Ｓ            Input string
  Ｅ             Map over characters
              ι Current character
            ⌕   Find index in
             γ  Printable ASCII
    ⁺           Plus
          PP    Literal string `PP`
         Ｌ      Length
     ⊗⊗⊗⊗       Doubled four times
 Σ              Take the sum
Ｉ               Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

Hex dump in Charcoal's code page:

```
C9 91 C5 D3 AB 9E 9E 9E 9E CC 50 50 9B E7 E9
```

Answer (score 1):

### Common Lisp, 42 bytes

```
(LAMBDA(%)(APPLY'+(MAP'CONS'CHAR-CODE %)))
```

This was found by trial and error using the following test: basically the code is printed to string, with some spaces removed (but not all, otherwise it parses badly), then it is read back to lisp and evaluated with its own representation.

```
(let ((string (remove #\space
                      (princ-to-string
                       '(lambda(%)(apply'+(map'cons'char-code %))))
                      :count 6)))
  (values string
          (funcall (eval (read-from-string string)) string)))
```

This returns both the code as string, and its sum:

```
"(LAMBDA(%)(APPLY'+(MAP'CONS'CHAR-CODE %)))"
2540
```

Usually you call `map` as follows, `(map 'list function sequence)`, where `list` is the type of result you want to build with map. Any Lisp type can be given, but obviously it should be a sequence. Here I used `cons` (lists are made of cons cells) to change the count, but the consequence if that is that there will be an error if the input is an empty sequence, since it cannot be expressed as a cons cell.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>19</s> <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```ruby
->΃{΃.sum}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1@5cc/W5Zr3i0tza/wUK6sh8db3kjMSiYhBbQ80qvyhFk6tAIS1aPSM1JydfPRbIgTIx1P0vSS0u@ZdfUJKZn1f8XzcvBwA)

The weird char probably isn't displayed, so it's ASCII 899.

Comment: Oops, now I'm at the top of the ones that aren't cheaty.

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 22 bytes

```
"̛̜"-&57i:&+&1+?.&n;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X@nMnDOzlXTVTM0zrdS01Qy17fXU8qz//09JAQA)

Contains two two-byte unicode characters, which can't be removed since they are used to set the initial value of the accumulator. Relies on the official interpreter's quirk of normalizing jump coordinates back to 0 if they are outside the code box (for parity).