# Print the banned characters based on the most common characters

Tags: code-challenge, restricted-source, answer-chaining

This is an [answer-chaining](/questions/tagged/answer-chaining) post, so in this challenge every answer (except the first answer) depends on the previous answer.

The goal of this challenge is to output the restricted characters. The restricted characters are the most common `n - 1` characters of **all answers**, if happens to be a tie, then the characters with the lowest UTF-8 range is restricted.

The max bytes for every answer is:

\begin{align}2n+60\end{align}

where `n` is answer number.

### Rules

- The answers only output the restricted characters, no newlines, no other characters like that.

  - The code may output the restricted characters exactly once, in any order.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden by default.
- No answerer may answer twice in a row.
- No languages may be reused in the last 5 answers.
- Every answer takes empty or no input, and outputs to STDOUT.
- The wrong answers (that break rules or don't do that this challenge say) are completely ignored if this answer is 10 minutes old, and should be deleted.

The last answer after 5 days of the challenge not getting answers wins.

### Example

First answer

```
# 1: Python 3, 13 bytes

    print(end="")

Next charset: `"` [link]()
```

The second answer should output `"`. If the second answer's code is `ppaaa`, then the third answer should output either `pa` or `ap` (because these are the most common characters in all answers), and doesn't use these characters.

Note: The scoring formula is based on the byte count and the answer number. The goal is to output the restricted characters efficiently while adhering to the specified byte limits.

Have a great day!

#### Clarifications

- The banned character set is the N most common characters of the concatenation of all answers.

Comment: The intent is that each answer must print the most common character of each answer before it, right? The wording reads a bit like you wanted the banned character set to be the N most common characters of the concatenation of all answers.

Comment: @noodleman Yes, I mean the banned character set to be the N most common characters of the concatenation of all answers.... I'll try to change the wording before it goes too late.

Comment: The challenge repeatedly mentions "the restricted characters", but seems to nowhere mention what the restriction is.

Comment: "No languages may used in the last 5 answers" do you mean resued?

Comment: Does the output have to include each character in the set exactly once, or can there be duplicates?

Comment: @noodleman The output needs to include every character in the set exactly once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 9: [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 43 bytes (37 characters)

```
[32,43,9,92,114,99,101,10]~ạw
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/P9rYSMfEWMdSx9JIx9DQRMfSUsfQwBCIY@se7lpY/v8/AA)

Prints `<space>+<tab>\rce<newline>`. Next set: [`<space>+<tab><newline>1\r,c`](https://tio.run/##jVNtjtowEP2NTzFiVyURISJ8rVgt9EerHmDb/togZJLJYm2wU9spIETP0Cv0Gj1A79GTUNvhsxLbmuCMx@M3b148xVrPBe/udmxRCKlBrRXJpFhAIvIcE80EV7DfeydKrlEScgMfSu72QAsTadyQzKmkidkGkSSllMgTVLBkeg6a4UwifTF7s7UJlJ4PjIPErygVgpCpAU0xq5CmRyQ13Yd4Glfavydgxk1F4yKLyABpMj9xcJF2Na3IjQ7cKyS3vUf7aCs7pXQM3Zm/GQLlKeg5chvymbNEpAhuKgSr4hNqgzOgtmSHrww6pq4kZVhUS@/ELGQaF8rzA3jB9Sini1lKwfruwWvZ91M0CWx@zy3aE9@/YP@eqSKn6zP1Hexe@EyUElRBrUZUW/Iww2fGOePPR9FyxiuumZAOJzgJcE6/kt8Olrk4GI2gAY2T345CGi28rG7tB5d6DC3YOMRt3T/GYn6OEuvXYDSd/RcIfw2E49JW@g@g0OhpT9FZjp5/HW5jg7dXsBReHryBRywkKjSilvyIf37rSmU/CaqEFggKv5TuYl9NH8erjb0UFsG/b3dWl1SIzUhT8wWLUoNrZ6VTxolzTG0P2Mu4VqFzh6Y5U88nV9vvdMzf7ZZzZrh/kqWpsub6@tf3QgpD18GJUodLaW6rV4/73bjfj@968d2g7r8pslZ0C8HobfM4nlrj02LcfHiYjJuhdVqj2Qxv65uqxl53u7cGnYMVtaOD2RscrGFnaxWq1WpmIs6yC2INN7nOqbmnMgnZG@5HalAdJEAIrjCpF3E06BjpG3GvHWtXUzvuR9bbqD91O0GvGwyDYSeIol4wHAaGlvlPvv3@@WP5Bw)

Comment: A mistake on my part; the set you should print is `<space>+<tab><newline>\rce`

Comment: @UndoneStudios Ah, thanks for letting me know, I fixed my submission

Answer (score 4):

## 4: Uiua, 10 bytes

```
&pf-1$ ,=?
```

[Uiuapad](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=0_2_0__JnBmLTEkICw9Pwo=)

New banned characters: +-<>

Comment: Seems to be outputting an r and not Ɛ?

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood the question, that's the assignment, right? The 3 most common characters in all previous answers combined were r, e and '.

Comment: I interpreted it as this: When an answer is posted, the most common character of that answer is added to a running character set. The next answer must print the whole character set without using any of the characters from it. I posted a comment under the question to ask for clarification. (All I know is that this is how l4m2 seems to have interpreted it, so it's how I interpreted it in my submission; lyxal's answer would have been correct under either interpretation.)

Comment: OP has clarified that your interpretation was correct, I’m waiting to change my answer until @l4m2 updates theirs.

Comment: Whoops, but it is outputting a newline. Is it okay if I amend it (cause you're still waiting anyway)? (Just change &p into &pf)

Comment: I think you should wait for l4m2 to fix their answer first, because the banned characters might change.

Comment: Now you can change your answer, l4m2 fixed their answer.

Comment: Done. (Why is there a minimum length??)

Answer (score 3):

## 3: [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 42 bytes

```
++++++++++[->++++++++++>+<<]>+.[->+<]>+++.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGw6ide0QHDttG5tYO209kCCIoa2t9/8/AA)

Outputs `er`. Can't fit in js

Answer (score 3):

## 6: [C# (Shell)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/repl/), 54 bytes

```cs
$"{(char)43}{(char)62}{(char)101}{(char)46}{(char)92}"
```

Prints `+>e.\`.
Has to be in a shell rather than standalone, since there's no way to output in C# without `e` otherwise.

Next set is `+r()ac` ([link](https://tio.run/##jVNdjtowEH5uTjGCVTcREPG3rIqAPrTqAbbt0wYhk0wWa4Od2k4hQtyhp@q1qMcBApXY1g8wnvn8zTeTmbw0KykGhwNf51IZ0KX2UiXXEMssw9hwKTQcY59kIQwqz2vCl0K4GBhpkdYN8YopFtswyDgulEIRo4YNNyswHJcK2auNLUsLVH4AXIDCn6g0glSJJU0wrZgWZya9OEJ8g1sTjD2wp1nJuMoiU0AWr2oNDkm3RSVuetJeMbnwke0rVVandArdm78VAhMJmBUKgnwXPJYJgvvJJa/wMSNwCoxKdvzasmPiStJWRXX1a2UhN7jWftCGVyynGVsvEwbkG4Pfof/n3rxN@X136c6D4Er9Z67zjJUX3Xe0x8anslCgc0Y9YobEwxJfuBBcvJyblnFRaU2lcjztugGX8qv20@Gpw8F0CvdwX/vp5Mr2wk8bZE9c6hl0YOcY943gjMXskiUyb9EYtvwvEvEWicANVfoPotD2k16xZYZ@cJtuR@D9DS6N1w@b8IS5Qo22qYU4819OXaHpk6COWY6g8UfhBvtm@ija7mgoiCEYd/vbaykeZWSJ/YJ5YcCtszYJF55zLGgHaBhLHTp3aJcz8QPv5vrVz4LDYbPiVvs3Vdgq37m9/v0rV9LKdXSyMOFG2Wn1G9HDIHp4iB6H0eOoEbzP007vDtrTj63zee7M6susNZnMZ62QnGS0WuFdY1fVOBzsj9aof7J63d7JHI5O1of@vvEH))

[Try it online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/a0L3An)

Comment: The output includes quotes and a trailing newline, which is not a valid answer. Can you change the answer a bit?

Comment: Hm, so unfortunately the C# shell automatically formats variables (a string literal like this implicitly creates a variable) based on its datatype, which means adding `""` and a newline for strings. The underlying variable doesn't actually have these so I can't remove them from the output. So it's up to you whether this is acceptable; if not I will just delete this answer.

Comment: You can delete your answer, but you also can edit your answer to be correct.

Comment: I've updated the link, dotnetfiddle doesn't add the extra formatting so it's now correct.

Answer (score 2):

## 1: [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 18 bytes

```python
while True:
	break
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/vzwjMydVIaSoNNWKizOpKDUx@/9/AA)

```
e - 3 (Now banned)
r - 2
<tab> - 1
<newline> - 1
<space> - 1
: - 1
T - 1
a - 1
b - 1
h - 1
i - 1
k - 1
l - 1
u - 1
w - 1
```

This [code I stolen from ChatGPT](https://tio.run/##jVNNb9swDD3Pv4JoDrWANOi2W9DssmE/YN1OSxHIMl0LdSRNH02MoL89E@k0Tgqkmw62RT49Pj6Lro@tNZ/3e7121kcIfSgab9egbNehitqaAIfcV5tMRF8UE/ieDOcg2ozMYVCt9FLlNFilkvdoFAbY6NhC1Fh5lE85V/UZ6EsB2oDHZ/QBwfo6k9bYDEyrI1NYHSBlxG0U8wLymgwyzqrYBlCqdtTASNqtBnGLV@0DE6cPbPfU2ViSFfKZtwpBmhpii4Ygv4xWtkbgh7N6wCtJ4AYktcz8IbNjzS2FrGLYlqOymY64DqWYwhP2i06uq1oCxeZQ3tD798eHKdUveXP7IMSZ@m86uE72J@4z7cH4xiYPwUnySEYSDxU@amO0eTya1mkzaG2sZ57paMCp/MF@WrphHCwWcA3XY5yW89mLsrmi7zsu/QVuYMeML1fiiMXulGUZ36OJsvovEvMeicENdfoPoln2k07JqsNSXKbbEfjlAlfA84MT@IHOY8BsajJH/tNblwL9EgxKOoSAfxJf7Ivll8vtji4FMYj57aftuZSCKso6/0GXIvA4h1hrU3BgRTNAl7EPMw7P8nDWpSgujt94TOz3m1Zn7T99yl1@4Ln@Cw) makes easier to make the character list, but you have to combine answers manually.

Answer (score 2):

## 2: [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 2 bytes

```
Ɛ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N////2IT//wE)

Simply prints the letter `e` and exits.

Comment: I changed your byte count, because every answer should use UTF-8, not other char encodings.

Answer (score 2):

## 7: [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 73 bytes

<sup>The byte-count is 1 below the limit of \$2\times7+60\$. :)</sup>

```
[S S S T    T   T   S S T   N
_Push_57_c][S S S T T   S T T   T   N
_Push_55_a][S S T   T   N
_Push_-1_)][S S T   T   S N
_Push_-2_(][S S S T S S T   S S S N
_Push_72_r][S S S T N
_Push_1_+][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S S S T S T S T S N
_Push_42][T S S S _Add_top_two][T   N
S S _Print_as_char][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgZOTE0hwgVkgDheIASYUwIJgBGFycUEZYMjFqQDRyKXAxfX/PwA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Push the codepoint-integers minus 42 of string "ca)(r+"
Start LOOP:
  Add 42 to the top integer
  Print it as character to STDOUT
  Go to next iteration of LOOP
```

The constant `42` is generated [by this Java program](https://tio.run/##fVLda9swEH/vX3HoSUKpyWB7qB1RWujAsHRQp9uglCG7aqJOkT3pHAgjf7sr1x9xttEXSdzd70N39yJ38vzl6VfTFEZ6D0up7Z8zgKrOjS7Ao8Rw7Ur9BNuQohk6bdcPjyBZWwbQBcApXxsEAfJh/pi8ZbRF8FtpjPJtIrWo1spFy6sfP79dfbm/mUEqLpIpyVB9N5AR0uW/3q9u7uLn0tGWVIs00YsPn@aJ5ry3cTQiCJnhrBIDFqDF5XtUkMedzWit8DoEPGUjPPh9BpoLoRkUpUVta9XpJmMFiiC/Kr9vdMBWslDX2kq375Rpfq5ZMmGjGKnftTSeVlMZCBZd5FRlAsFn7TzSalZxkt1mZII/gDJewSkOuZtUjK9K4BAegkHeRUbZNW4og8XY2omRf7o94Z7M7UhzTKchrk8luzPbe1TbqKwxqkJT0FhKOrggfCDlJAkzJDzlBGIg/L2mpqyX/ZuZntp/qzqchaNf2X4d3uNud8n2DdlJF8ZLsoxwaoWYXxIS20W4ViQm42CGDSziYZuxPKFss2wpcRPJ3FPL2P9WDbkoFh8vLgNvHPiTSf@cwtrZUEFuSfejQ9M03FEmi1c), based on [this Whitespace tip of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158232/52210).

---

The next set is [`<space>+<tab><newline>r()`](https://tio.run/##jVNdjtowEH7GpxjBqpsIiJafZVW00IdWPUB/njYImWSyWBvs1HbKIsQdeqpei3ocIFCJbZ3ImRnPfPPNxFNs7FLJwX4vVoXSFszGsEyrFSQqzzGxQkkDh7OPqpQWNWMt@FxKfwZWOU9nhmTJNU/cMagkKbVGmaCBtbBLsAIXGvmLO1tsnKMOQhASNP5EbRCUTh1oilmFND8hmfnBJbD4asMxA7daFY2LLCoD5Mmy5uA9SZtX5CZH7hWSPz6gfaXK6pSeoY/5myFwmYJdoiSX71IkKkXwW6FE5Z9wcs6AU8ke3zh0TH1JxrGo1KBmFgmLKxOEHXjBzSTnq0XKgWxjCLr0ferNOpQ/8MrdLAwv2H8Spsj55qz7HvbQ@EyVGkzBqUfcEnlY4LOQUsjnU9NyISuumdIep1M34Jx@1X5aIvN@MJnALdzWdlqFdr0IsibJjz71FLqw9Yi7ZnjyxfwcJbZvwVi@@C8Q@RaIxDVV@g@gyPWTovgixyC8Drcl590VLIOXgS34goVGg66ppTzhn9@60tAvQZPwAsHgj9Jf7Kvp4/h1S5eCEMLxXf/1kgqjjDx1f7AoLfhxNjYVknnDnGaALuPGRN4cueFMg5BdHb86LNzv10vhuH/Tpauy4ef6969CK0fXw6nSRmvtbmvQjO8H8f19/DCMH0bN8F2RdXs30Jl8aJ/WU3daK9P24@Ns2o7ISEK7Hd00t1WNw8HuII36R6l31zuKw9FRet/fUYcajYbbmJdIYST4zU9Ow7@VyNhB8A9rQBXIgLE/).

Answer (score 2):

## 8: Python 2, 34 bytes

```py
exec"p\162int'\40\t\53\50\51\162'"
```

Explanation:

```py
exec                               # run (in Python 2, this is a statement)
   "p\162int'\40\t\53\50\51\162'"  # <space><tab>+()r (r is replaced twice)
                                   # and then a newline (which is implicit)
```

Prints `<space><tab>+()r<newline>`. Next set: [`<space>+<tab><newline>\rce`](https://tio.run/##jVPbjtowEH3GXzHKrkoiLgIWWHW10IdW/YBenjYrZJLJYm2wU9spIMQ/9Kv6W9TjAIFKbOtEzng8PnPmxFNs7ELJu/1eLAulLZiNYZlWS0hUnmNihZIGDnsfVSktasZu4HMp/R5Y5SKdG5IF1zxx26CSpNQaZYIGVsIuwAqca@Svbm@@cYE6jEBI0PgTtUFQOnWgKWYV0uyEZGaHkNDi2kYPDNy4qWhcZFEZIE8WNQcfSatZRW5y5F4h@e0D2leqrE7pGfozfzMELlOwC5QU8l2KRKUIfiqUqOITTsEZcCrZ4xuHjqkvyTgW1TKsmXWFxaUJoza84maS8@U85UC@Bwg79H3qP7cpf@gXvecoumD/SZgi55sz9T3sQfhMlRpMwUkjbok8zPFFSCnky0m0XMiKa6a0x2nXApzTr@SnITIfB5MJNKFZ@2kU2mkRZgHZjz71FDqw9Yi7IDrFYn6OEtu3YCyf/xeIfAtE4ooq/QdQ1@lJp/g8xzC6Drel4N0VLIOXB2/gCxYaDTpRS3nCP791paFfgibhBYLBH6W/2FfTx/F6S5eCEKKH3mB9SYVRRp66P1iUFnw7G5sKybxjRj1Al3Fjut7ddc2ZhhG72n71sWi/Xy2E4/5Nl67Khu/r378KrRxdD6dK211pd1vDIB7dxaNRfD@M78dB9K7IOv1baE8@tE7jqTOtF9PW4@PztNUlJxmtVvc22FY1Du92B2s8OFr9Xv9oDsdH6/1gRwo1Gg03MW/RgpHhJ985Df9WJmMHwz@sAdVBBozhGpOgiPvjgZO@GQ97sfU19eJRn7zN4A8)

Comment: Did you just include an extra char `.` in your set?

Comment: You're right; I saw what appeared to be a `.` in the Whitespace answer. Hope it won't change the sets much...

Answer (score 1):

## 5: [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 36 bytes

```javascript
process.stdout.write("\53\55\74\76")
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLz8ldcGCpaUlaboWN1UKivKTU4uL9YpLUvJLS_TKizJLUjWUYkyNY0xNY8xNYszNlDQhaqFaYFoB)

This prints `+-<>`. I previously had a more interesting GolfScript solution here, but I realized that it contained a `+` which made it invalid.

Next charset is `+>e.\` ([link](https://tio.run/##jZNdbtswDMef51MQybDacGK067ICQZI9bNgB9vFUB4Es07VQR/IkeYkR9A491a6ViXIWJwPSTQ@2RVE//kmTdWtLJW/3e7GulbZgWhMUWq2Bq6pCboWSBg5nH1UjLeogGMLnRvozsMp5OjPwkmnG3TEozhutUXI0sBG2BCsw08ge3VnWOkcdRiAkaPyJ2iAonTtojkVHWh1JZnVwCS1ubTQNwK1hJ@MsiioAGS97Dd6TdqtO3PyP9o7kjw@0r5RZH9Ir9Hf@VghM5mBLlOTyXQqucgT/qJXo/Dkj5wIYpez5xtEx9ykZp6Lbhr2yRFhcmzAawSO284qts5wB2aYQjul9f7McUfzQb66XUXSm/pMwdcXak@p77KHwhWo0mJpRjZgl8ZDhg5BSyIdj0SohO62F0p4z6gtwKr8rPy1ReD@Yz@EKrno7rVq7WoTFgL5nPvQCxrDzxKdBdPTF6pSS2pcwlmX/BZEvQSRuKNN/gBJXT7rFsgrD6DJuR85PF1gGzy8O4QvWGg26ojbyyD/tusbQL0HDWY1g8EfjG/ti@DTd7qgpiBBNr99uz6UEFJHl7g/WjQU/zsbmQgbesKIZoGZsTeLNiRvOPIyCi@PXX4v2@00pnPZvunFZvvJz/eu51srJ9TjV2GSjXbeGg3Rym04m6d279O79IHpTF@Ob1zCaf4iP63686DeLeDZbLuKEjPQRx8lv))

Comment: I've updated mine, you're good to go

Comment: Why are 6 characters banned, shouldnt there only be 5?

Comment: @regr4444 Done :)

Comment: @nextwayup Sorry, that was a typo

Comment: Apologies if I'm misunderstanding here, but wouldn't `+` be a banned character, which means it can't be used in this answer?

Comment: @Acer Wow I can’t believe I missed that, thanks for pointing it out. Unfortunately that makes this impossible in GolfScript so I’ve added a JavaScript solution instead.

Comment: You made a typo in the link of the charset. Also you forgot the `Ɛ` in the lyxal's answer.

Comment: @Fmbalbuena I didn’t bother adding it since it was definitely not going to be in the top 5, feel free to edit it in if you want